# Consideration for removing the downvote button from questions

Tags: discussion, flags, questions, edits, downvotes

I have noticed that a lot of legitimate questions get downvoted cause they don't use proper nomenclature or are unclear. That's a frustrating user experience for people who are trying to learn, but are being punished because of their ignorance.

Take my question here as one example: [Can I Allocate a Block of Memory with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793517/can-i-allocate-a-block-of-memory-with-new)

To me it seems that a `flag` should suffice for purging inappropriate questions, and an `edit` should suffice for scrubbing poorly-formed questions. I just can't think of a question that would earn a downvote which shouldn't already fall into one of these categories.

Some of my friends have been lost to Stack Overflow because of this issue. Their statement is: "There are no stupid questions -- except in the minds of Stack Overflow users."

Comment: How are these bad questions to be found, given that flags don't have any visibility in the different question listings? That is, how will there be enough eyeballs and close/delete votes on these, if they are not surfaced?

Comment: There may not be stupid questions, but there **are** low-quality questions that are of no use to anyone else. Stack Overflow is **not a support forum**, it aims to build a collection of good questions with even better answers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think your comment is an excellent grounds for an edit. The simple truth is that question-askers may not know enough to produce a high-quality question. I think an edit could be very valuable in this case.

Comment: Sure, and that's why we put questions on hold. While on hold the question can be edited and reopened.

Comment: @Obed are you suggesting that downvoting helps them surface? I guess I don't understand.

Comment: But take into account we get over 7300 questions *every day* and we cannot edit each and every one. Then there are all the duplicates, and questions that show no research done on behalf of the asker, the posts that lack enough detail to be answerable, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Who is the "we" you speak of? This site is supposed to be user run is it not? I am suggesting that removing the downvote button would create better user experience and better questions because of people editing rather than downvoting.

Comment: @JonathanMee: not everything is salvageable through editing. Downvoting is never personal, it is a signal to other people that a post has problems and/or is not helpful to future visitors. Taking away that signal will *not* magically make questions improve.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How about this then, there should at least be a requirement to comment on *why* the question was bad when downvoting. Just a downvote is discouraging and unhelpful.

Comment: @jon, that has been suggested to death and the community is heavily against it - [one example from MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224877/limiting-downvotes-to-those-with-an-accompanying-comment)

Comment: @JonathanMee: And this is why questions get downvoted: you didn't do your research. Requiring a comment when voting leads to revenge votes, to arguments instead of an incentive to improve the post, and to nonsense comments (including but not limited to '+1 great post, carry on!' while downvoting). As such the suggestion has been made *many, many, many, **too many*** times over, always with the same result: status-declined.

Comment: @JonathanMee: you also seem to expect that it is the community's job to improve low-quality questions. That expectation is misplaced. With over 7000 questions each and every day, it is the job of the question asker to make sure that the post is at least well researched and on-topic. Grammar and spelling mistakes we can easily fix, but we *cannot* fix lack of information. If you did not include the error message or code that lets us reproduce the problem, or show what we already tried, we cannot help and the question is not worth our time. We are not psychic!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I had not considered the repercussions of requiring the comment. I just wish there was some kind of middle ground. Alas perhaps the status-quo is as good as we can hope for.

Comment: If the goal is to make sure we have good information (answered questions) for the future, it isn't required to downvote.  If the question is wrong/stupid in someways, help fix it via comments.  That will be productive.  Only if the person asking the question is doing it on purpose, downvote it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, but the thing is that usually question is immediatly downvoted.  There is not even an effort to fix it.  You are not psychic but some people will understand the question better than you--give them a chance.

Comment: @YasserAsmi I disagree.  I find it quite usually for a question to attract a lot of downvotes with no comments explaining its problems at all.  In the majority of cases there is someone to point out at least some of the problems.  The majority of the questions I see with downvotes and no comments are also usually completely unsalvagible, regardless of what comments they might get.

Comment: @Servy I believed the [linked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793517/can-i-allocate-a-block-of-memory-with-new) provides an excellent example of YasserAsmi's point. Even now that I understand the answer, I still don't understand why the question was voted down, or what could have been done to improve it. I assume that there is some nomenclature that it is missing, but I don't know.

Comment: @JonathanMee Until today the question had only attracted 2 downvotes.  Two is not "a lot" of downvotes in my book.

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure whether the quantity or time of downvotes has any bearing on the issue at hand. My statement is simply that I don't want ignorance to be punished on a Q/A site. And that's what I feel is being done. I want to learn, but just giving myself or my fellow "newbs" downvotes doesn't assist in that process.

Comment: @JonathanMee It's relevant because I said that questions that attract a lot of downvotes usually get comments as well.  Your counter example doesn't actually demonstrate a question getting a lot of downvotes without a comment, but instead just a few downvotes without a comment.  You also need to recoginze that downvotes simply aren't there for you.  They're there to provide a signal to *every single other person in the world* about the quality of the question.  While it may help you as well, that is not the primary purpose of those votes.

Comment: @Servy I think you make a good point about a vote being a signal. When looked at from that perspective I can see the merit to your argument. But from the "newb" perspective, if I'm asking the wrong question it would be tremendous if I could be guided into asking the right question.

Comment: @JonathanMee And yet the shear volume of terrible questions and the comparatively small number of site regulars simply doesn't allow for every bad question to involve a personalized question tutoring service in which a considerable amount of time is spent teaching you how to ask a good question.  The resources to do that simply aren't available.  It happens sometimes, and that's great, but it can't be expected.  At the end of the day it is the author's responsibility to learn how to craft a quality question.  There is no other practical way.

Comment: @Servy I appreciate your explanation there I think that perspective makes helps your comments and MartijnPieters comments make more sense. However, from a personal perspective I still wish that something could be done about how demoralizing this can be.

Comment: @JonathanMee " But from the "newb" perspective, if I'm asking the wrong question it would be tremendous if I could be guided into asking the right question."  ----- I would say that's what the help link is for above. If one would like the help of the community the least they could do is research how to ask a question. This link for example guides a newb towards a well structured question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Craicerjack You make a fair point for some situations. In making my point I have ignored any number of poorly written unhelpful questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26118936/replace-map-to-vector

Comment: @JonathanMee Is downvoting objective? no. My knowledge of c++ is zero so from my point of view that question isn't in anyway helpful, but its also obvious that the authors first language is not english and that they have supplied enough code that those who have looked at it understand the question. It also has an upvote which means someone has found it helpful.

Comment: @JonathanMee the point is that if youre looking for guidelines to write a good question, they are there. All you have to do is look. This applies to all situations.

Comment: @Craicerjack My goal was less about dealing with those kind of questions, and more about finding a way for well meaning new users, who are the future of StackOverflow, to cope with the extreme negativity which can be expressed toward, what I perceive as a question that is useful, and well within the help guidelines, such as the question linked in the original post.

Comment: @JonathanMee "extreme negativity" - a little bit of extreme language there. 3 people downvoted you, out of a community of how many. Your example. Once again Im not familiar with c, but issues i would have with it is that you dont explain what you are asking - you link to another question. If that question disappears, your question is then redundant. You also ask a general question instead of a specific one. As with any community there is going to be some negativity, but I have found the helpfulness of the community far outweighs the negativity.

Comment: @Crackerjack I agree with you that the community overall is helpful. There is a lot of good here, that's the reason I want there to be a way for new people to survive negativity, so they can be part of something good. Initially I viewed downvoting questions to be the problem. But you can see from my answer that I've changed my tune. Basically voting is an imperfect system, but I can't think of anything better to suggest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some good comments from [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) and [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy) that helped me understand the goal of the down vote button on questions. And I wanted to summarize their comments here so it's not necessary for people to read through 23+ comments to get the gist.

There are two perspectives to be considered with respect to downvoting questions:

1. The perspective of Stack Overflow users who come after who are *looking* for help with a particular problem
2. The perspective of the Stack Overflow user *writing* the original question

**With respect to 1:** A downvoted question indicates that the question itself is poorly formulated or unclear. This is helpful to *looking* users because it helps them filter results. In this perspective the ability to downvote questions is essential.

**With respect to 2:** A downvoted question can be discouraging, and it can turn new users away from the site, particularly new users who don't understand the perspective 1. In this perspective downvoting questions is costing Stack Overflow new members.

**An idealist solution:** Would be that even new users questions could be crafted into a question that is well formulated and clear by helpful comments and edits from more senior Stack Overflow members, thereby providing benefit to both perspectives 1 and 2. This solution lacks the reality that if senior members to spend time working with each individual question they will be able to vet far fewer questions, and many poorly formulated, unclear questions will fall through the cracks, without being downvoted or edited.

**A realist solution:** The best solution I've come up with is an appeal to holders of both perspective 1 and 2.
*To those who subscribe to perspective 1:* If you are downvoting a question and it has no comments, you are simply driving away what could become a great question. Please take the time to just leave a quick comment on what's wrong with the question.
*To those who subscribe to perspective 2:* Please bear in mind that just because your question was downvoted doesn't mean it is not valuable. Take time to reread it and clarify it to the best of your ability.

Answer (score -4):

I answer here because I cannot add a comment yet. Some of the considerations made to support the need for downvoting are fair, but I think in some case it is better to put a comment asking to clarify some aspect of the question, or to add some detail, or just explaining why the question is bad. This way, you may be able to help the user and to transform a useless question in one valuable for the community. This should apply especially for new users, who are not expert and may not be able to express their problem in a proper way.

Otherwise you will push new people to get frustrated and leave, when your goal should be to attract as many people as you can. The argument "we get 7000 questions each and every day" sounds a bit cocky because gives me the idea that you feel accomplished and you don't need new people anymore. And I hope that is not the case.

My answer is freely inspired from my personal experience, so feel free to value it or ignore it completely.

Comment: So it's the community's responsibility to fix every terrible question that anyone posts?  They have no expectations as to fixing or improving their own question?  They have every right to demand a quality answer to every question no matter how bad it is?  Everything else aside, that's simply not physically *possible*, even if we wanted to do that.

Comment: I think you've massively misinterpreted Martijn's point about there being so many questions - he didn't say *anything* about "therefore we don't need new users"; it's all about "there's only so much that can be done to help users who appear not to care about putting effort into asking good questions."

Comment: And Serby misinterpreted my point when I said that you could make questions better. I wasn't suggesting that you all start going around fixing bad questions, but, if everyone start writing a quick comment explaining what's missing in a question (again, this is especially for new users) instead of downvoting straight away, maybe the user will fix a question and it will become something useful for someone else as well. And again, you say it isn't physically possible, but the concept of peer review is against you; see Wikipedia.

Comment: Your point is valid, yet you still get downvotes. This is not healthy, it is trolling. And the questioner, essentially pleading moderation of the downvoting, gets an avalanche of downvotes. That's bullying. My guess is the strict rules are attracting people of a certain mind-set that see the down vote as a psychological lash (which it is). Over time, they have formed a closed community that has fomented the idea that outsider intrusion, by way of ideas that reduce their "power", are a threat to their community. I've stopped contributing to SO until they get on top of this. I've complained.