# Suggest a Question for the 2015 Stack Overflow User Survey

Tags: discussion, survey

Conical trees. Symmetrically branched candelabras. Hats! It's "the most wonderful time of the year," and that means it's time to suggest new questions for the annual Stack Overflow user survey.

**What do you want to know about each other?**

What do you want to know about the Stack Overflow users who answer your questions (or ask your questions before you get the chance to do so yourself)? What do you want to know about the millions more readers you reach with your posts? This is your chance to ask.

Please suggest a question in **multiple-choice** format as an answer.

Need inspiration? Check out [last year's blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/), the full [survey results dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16C6ZeNSvd-qIg45J9E-vx2YCsD8w5oZaSTUtJ-52e-w/edit?usp=sharing), and [last year’s call for questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209790/suggest-a-question-for-the-2013-stack-overflow-user-survey).

Comment: "Tabs or Spaces?" in the SO user survey would surely settle it once and for all, I think.

Comment: You could use your diamond to migrate the question from MSE, you know.  (would have saved you couple of clicks ;))

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski It would be interesting to see the breakdown of responses to that by amount of programming experience.

Comment: How many people do you think we could catch if we asked, "Have you ever voted for yourself with a secondary account, or formed a group of co-workers to vote for each other?"

Comment: @animuson hmm, that brought me to an interesting realization..  That isn't an option for me because the majority of my co-workers don't have accounts. From my understanding, it is because they're intimidated. I wonder if that could be formed into a useful survey question (or if it is even common)?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Spaces. Definitely.

Comment: Most of them will be vamps, and if we ask them are you satisfied? all they will answer is no

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think the better question is how many spaces make up a tab/indentation. :)

Comment: @JoeW Quite obviously four, do we need survey for that? :P

Comment: I dont get along well with spaces people

Comment: @MightyPork ...but if you ask anyone tagged `Delphi` you'll find the answer quickly becomes two.

Comment: although personally, I use tabs - 4-space-sized tabs. Because, you know, it saves space. One byte instead of four!

Comment: @MightyPork pfff, `vi` defaults to 8 spaces, and I say that still isn't enough, let's make it 14!

Comment: @TTT but that's the beauty of tabs, everyone can set them to what they like. (Not in vi, maybe)

Comment: @MightyPork: `:set tabstop`. However, classical vi doesn't support `:set softtabstop` , `:set expandtab`, or `:retab`, which allow for easier interworking with lesser editors.

Comment: What is your favorite text editor, and why is it Vim?

Comment: @MightyPork I personally prefer 4 space-sized tabs to 4-space-sized tabs.

Comment: @MartinCapodici are you serious? With that, anyone else (with 4-space tabs) will see 16-chars-wide indentation!

Comment: @Doorknob vim is too posh with colors and stuff ... vi is the real deal :D

Comment: I am wondering why this is not a *community wiki* `:P`

Comment: Coming from "What is the reason for the survey": there is not much I want to know 'about each other'. I have however upvoted many answers that tell something about **how SO is perceived**. *That* will give useful info about actions that can be taken.

Comment: Can we get the survey results as raw data? (To enable us to visualize how one question's answers vary with respect to other questions' answers.)

Comment: If there's anything I can take away from the answers to this question, it's that writing skills and professionalism apply even to survey questions. Some of the worst answers here are bad simply because the proposed questions are so cheesy and poorly written.

Comment: If I were writing my own code, I'd use tabs (space saving, as MightyPork mentioned). However, when you have to collaborate with others, who may have different settings for how many spaces a tab represents, it's best to use spaces so the code looks the same regardless of who's editing it.

Comment: I am just curious, did I miss the actual survey and if not, when it's gonna happen?

Comment: @exebook didn't miss a thing! Survey will be released in the next week or two. Thanks for hanging in there.

Comment: So, is this question now for the 2015 Survey? Seems like an odd way of asking for more questions, when there are already two pages of them...

Comment: So do I have to vote again on the existing answers?  And I can't vote again for something I voted for last year?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan The 2015 survey came and went. This is an old (deprecated) post.

Comment: @ryanyuyu you're free to vote on whatever you like, but this is an old post for the last survey. There will be a new request for questions (probably next week) for the upcoming survey.

Answer (score 100):

How much time per week do you spend on programming, as a hobby (Not job related)?

- None
- 1-5 hours
- 6-10 hours
- 11-20 hours
- 20+ hours

If applicable, which proportion of that time was spent contributing on open-source projects?

- None
- Less than half
- More than half
- All of it

Both could also be easily converted to a simple yes/no format, like "Do you program in your free time" and "Do you contribute to open-source projects".

Comment: I'd add a bonus to that: If applicable, which proportion of that time was spent *using* open source projects? Or something to that order... Because, well, hacking a blog running WordPress, for instance, is basically using OSS and can lead to a contribution here or there in the form of a bug report -- even if your hobby plugin or theme remains closed source.

Comment: *Not job or school related

Comment: Does Stack Overflow count as a hobby?

Comment: @AHiggins Counts as a hobby, does not count as programming per se IMO.

Answer (score 92):

While this may not be a question to ask survey respondents, would it be possible to bring back public site analytics to go along with the survey? I believe the last time this was done was [the end of 2010](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-overflow-2010-analytics/).

Survey results are biased towards the people that take the time to respond. I'd like to see how they compare to actual analytics as far as geographic location, OS usage, and browser statistics go. That could give an interesting measure as to who is actively engaged with the site vs. who just visits.

It would also be useful to examine year-to-year trends in these stats.

Comment: Or we could ask the participants in the survey. For example, fill a box with captured information where they can check a box for sending it along with their answers.

Comment: @danijar That would again be biased towards the people that take the survey at all.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs How do you plan to overcome this? The same problem is stated in the request above and I think we have to live with it since there's no way around.

Comment: @danijar You can overcome it if you include analytics of everyone not any specific person (e.G. not the answerer of the survey). The proposal of this Answer is not survey based as far as I understood it.

Comment: @danijar - As Angelo states, I'm referring to the internal analytics for all visitors to the site that SE gathers, not volunteered information from survey respondents. Survey respondents in previous years were asked for this information, but before that the raw visitor stats were reported. I would like to see that information be made public once again, which I think would make for an interesting comparison between survey respondents (which we can assume to be active participants on the site) and overall visitors (including those who only read the site).

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.

Comment: If it is not an answer you are supposed to add a comment.

Comment: @exebook [Meta doesn't follow the same rules as main](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Furthermore, the question is tagged [tag:discussion]. This point by Brad is clearly a popular opinion regarding the discussion.

Answer (score 89):

Choose all that apply. Stack Overflow is

- a research assistant
- a debugging tool
- clairvoyant
- a source for service recommendations
- a place to have your homework done
- a social network
- a forum or discussion board
- attacking you personally
- all of the above
- none of the above

Comment: I'm not sure what we should do with those who answer incorrectly, but seeing the answers to this would be awesome.

Comment: +1 i would be genuinely interested in this if we get analytics.

Comment: On a side note, _all of these_ is a troll answer for any logical thinking person as it would imply selecting _none of these_ as well.

Comment: @CarrieKendall - Fixed ;)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a social discussion forum that's attacking me personally.

Comment: a place full of nazi users :P

Comment: I love this one.

Comment: Missing a "Jon Skeet" option.

Comment: I understood this reference.

Comment: Clairvoyant? Stackoverflow is not pseudoscience.

Comment: @simonzack People sure seem to think it is...

Comment: I think predict-the-future is perhaps more neutral.

Comment: @simonzack I think it was more along the lines of telepathy/reading the user's mind.

Comment: For me, it is a way of helping others and a source of interesting questions. Is that "none of the above"?

Comment: This question seems to lean heavily towards "askers". Can we add a couple answerer-centric options like "a way to give back to the community" and "where I document solutions I've found". Maybe "a place to find experts in a given field". Also, "my safe place" and "my first stop for magic internet points".

Comment: I'd love to see this implemented, as long as all users who answer "a social network" are automatically banned...

Comment: "A place to learn new programming languages". I really hope it is not. Many think it is.

Comment: "A dating platform" is missing :)

Comment: If I have to select all that apply, why is there an 'all' and 'none' option? This will generate some warped results, because of people choosing different ways to represent the same (i.e., selecting nothing vs selecting none, selecting everything vs selecting all, selecting every checkbox because troll etc.)

Comment: @Fabrizio: that must be what [this suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278968/2564301) is for then.

Comment: "provider of link to Stack Overflow chat"

Answer (score 89):

**Are you aware that all your published content is licensed under *Creative Commons BY-SA (3.0)*?**

- Yes.
- Yes, but I have no idea what that means.
- No, I was not aware.
- What are you talking about?

Comment: I think this is a fantastic question - I doubt most users even consider that they are licensing the content when they post it.

Comment: What about another option: _"Huh, I thought anything I'd post here became IP of the site owner anyways."

Comment: "Yes, and this is annoying since CC BY-SA 3.0 is not meant for software and isn't GPL compatible"

Comment: @psubsee2003 This is why copyright is so irrelevant to most of us. Nobody cares about it.

Comment: @simonzack [citation needed]

Answer (score 80):

#### Q: What amount of formal/professional training have you received in programming? (select all that apply)

- Extensive study in higher education/university
- Some school/university coursework
- Intensive industry certification programs
- Intensive code "boot camps"
- Short-term employer-provided training
- probably
- lots
- more
- No formal training

Comment: I fear for those who respond "probably" :) Where would a simple bachelors degree in software engineering fit in those options?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET recognizing software engineering isn't the same thing as programming, I'd still think it is unambiguously "Extensive study in higher education/university"

Comment: Works for me. I might include a few guidelines in the options, as I read the top option as likely graduate level course work.

Comment: I actually would think about further separating the college/university items further.  Getting a BS or MS in CompSci or Software Engineering is a lot different than taking a lot of electives related to programming.  Someone who has a different degree but a lot of electives is likely to be more of a seriously enthusiastic programmer than someone who got a degree in it

Comment: @psubsee2003 It takes an *awful* lot of dedication/enthusiasm to programming to get a degree, at least where I went to school. That said, I would like to see the "High end" of the spectrum defined better, if not split out more.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET in most schools, I would tend to agree, but I think there are a lot of "programmers" that got a degree related to programming who really only wanted to do it because that is what was supposed to be a quick path to a high salary.  My suggestion was a hope to try separate those people.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Fair enough, there were certainly some of those at my school as well (suffice it to say they didn't make it). So how would we separate the "degreed" but unenthusiastic and the enthusiastic *and* "degreed"? Perhaps it is unimportant, but I think your suggestion makes a presumption that could skew the data.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET that's a fair point.  I think you new [question suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278867/250725) may help with this idea.

Comment: What about an option like "Enrolled or finished degree but learned more from SO"?

Comment: Another option to include might be for people who have learned primarily through [MOOCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course), since they currently occupy a space somewhere in between formal and informal training or study.

Comment: Most of the suggested proxies for enthusiasm would classify me as unenthusiastic, which I don't think reflects reality. Maybe directly asking would be better.

Comment: Many CS degrees provide little or no training in _programming_ -- students are expected to figure it out on their own.

Comment: At the lest there should be a "bachelor's" and maybe "some masters/phd work" between "some coursework" and "I (should) have a Ph.D." A full bachelor's in CS is a great deal more training than CS 101.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Yes, respondents will need to keep that distinction clear. More practical programs *do* provide training in programming however.

Answer (score 80):

What mainly motivates you to write answers?

- Helping others
- Training myself
- Increasing my reputation
- Taking a break
- Being bored
- Other reason

For the last option, I think you could get quite interesting insights from a free text input if that is possible here.

Comment: Please add "boredom" to the list.

Comment: I would add "Take a break from work." cause answering is a nice to way to take a break while actually learning.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Good point, added.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's what I meant by "take a break from hard problems", but obviously it wasn't very accurate.

Comment: I would add "training myself". Most of the times I answer just to see how I could solve a problem as that problem was mine

Comment: "training myself" could be rephrased as "to improve my programmer and writer skills".

Comment: I like it. Other possible options: "Increase written communication skills", "Feedback from others", "Documenting solutions to my own problems" _(in the case of answering your own question)_

Comment: How about "feel the need to contribute to the community for having gained from it"?

Comment: Does "procrastination" fall under "being bored"? When there's nothing on Twitter or Google+, I just go and help some nuubs

Comment: @BitBank Where do you see the concrete distinction of "For the sake of helping others" and to "Give back to the community"?

Comment: @MightyPork Yes, I think that should be one category. Would you improve the wording of it?

Comment: @danijar - the difference is, one may have a general desire to help others, but in my case, I contribute to SO because I've gained so much from it and feel the need to pay it back in kind.

Comment: I'd add "Giving support to my software users". I often see people working on project X that help people using such software. For instance http://stackoverflow.com/users/18122/oliver-gierke for Spring Data.

Comment: I always wondered what are the reasons that push Jon Skeet and other great answerers to dedicate so much effort on StackOverflow. Maybe become recognized experts in the world? How could we express it?

Answer (score 69):

Q: What do you think about the level of **question** moderation of the Stack Overflow *community*?

A: (select all that apply)

- The community closes too many good questions
- The community is not fast enough to close off-topic<sup>1</sup> questions
- The community fails to reopen enough questions that have been sufficiently improved<sup>2</sup>
- The community downvotes too many good questions
- The community upvotes too many bad questions
- Too many of the close-worthy posts I encounter receive answers
- Too many likely/obvious duplicate questions are answered by high-reputation and/or long-term members instead of moderating them appropriately (flagging or voting to close as duplicate)<sup>3</sup>
- Most questions I encounter received an adequate level of community moderation

<sub>1 - this may be better written as non-conforming questions since not all closed questions are off-topic</sub>

<sub>2 - credit to [Ian Goldby](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278846/suggest-a-question-for-the-2014-stack-overflow-user-survey/278865?noredirect=1#comment126817_278865) for this idea</sub>

<sub>3 - credit to [LittleBobbyTables](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278846/suggest-a-question-for-the-2014-stack-overflow-user-survey/278914?noredirect=1#comment127138_278865) for this idea</sub>

Comment: • The community fails to reopen enough questions that have been improved

Comment: @IanGoldby good idea, added

Comment: Good addition of 'sufficiently'.

Comment: to 1: The word for this questions here on meta seems to be: crap - making it: [...] to close crappy questions.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs of course, but we have to be more *proper* in the survey :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 Okaaay, [...] to close properly crap questions.

Comment: You missed out "The community is too damn fast about condemning questions which are not yet up to the perceived standard of perfection required to be eligible for SO (or SE)".

Comment: Off-topic sounds like non-programming, the crap umbrella fits better: the do-my-homework-for-me-urgent!!!, google-this-for-me, and the never-heard-of-a-debugger questions.

Comment: "• The community *answers* too many off-topic questions" and/or "• The community doesn't sufficiently exercise its privileges to close off-topic questions"

Comment: • High-reputation and/or long-term members answer questions that in all likelihood have been asked before and are duplicate questions, instead of closing them

Comment: @psubsee2003: Yes somehow it must be addressed. Some questions get unfairly closed.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables for your first comment, is that different than my 2nd to last bullet? ("Too many of the close-worthy posts I encounter receive answers")?

Comment: @psubsee2003 - no, I somehow missed that one O:-)

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables for your 2nd comment, I agree.... added

Comment: such question can bring a lot of emotions, but I cannot see how SO could actually benefit from answers. It is already known that all those problems do exist, moderation lacks human force and moderators need better training and education.

Comment: @exebook - it may already be known by *some*, but I'd venture a guess that a large portion of Stack Overflow users never visit Meta, and in fact aren't aware of a large portion of the policies here.

Comment: @exebook it is known that a verbal set of people thinks so. It is by no means known that the majority (or even a significant minority) thinks so.

Answer (score 51):

How satisfied are you with the chat feature?

- Satisfied
- It needs improvement
- I hate it
- I know about it but I do not use it
- I didn't know there was a chat

Comment: You can leave out the first three options and the results will be the same.

Comment: Edited, good suggestion.

Comment: Should "Know about it, but don't use it anyway" be added to the list? At least that's what would apply to me

Comment: @SpaceTrucker I think the intention is to figure out why you don't use it. How about: "I don't care as I would not use it anyway"

Comment: I guess pretty much everyone who uses it would tick the second option :P

Comment: @AwalGarg I use it (sometimes) and I would tick the first option.

Comment: What about "I don't use it because when I need it most, the other person doesn't have enough rep to use it too (even though the system tries to suggest I  should use it!"?

Comment: By chat, you mean the chat rooms, right? I don't know if I'm alone in this, but to me "chat feature" sounded like you meant something else since I've always heard them referred to as "chat rooms".

Comment: @rightføld If half the people choose "I didn't know there was a chat," then despite the first 3 options being useless, that half will have learned something they didn't know, which one way or the other is cause to have such a question listed.

Comment: @Neil the first 3 options were different when rightfold said that. Check the history.

Comment: This isn't detailed enough. For example, chat is _great_ but the mobile version needs a lot of work. I cannot give an accurate answer to this question based on that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit it needs improvement gives a general sense that people use it but think it needs more work. I don't think this is the place to go into absolute specifics - if it is established that chat needs work in the survey that gives a lot of leverage in questions asking to improve it in certain ways.

Comment: For me chat is basically a thing where I'm told to continue comments conversation. The other part doesn't enter the convo there and so it is ended. Never used it for anything else.

Comment: "What is your impression of the chat feature?" Might be a better way to word the question. `I love it and use it daily`, `It meets my needs and I use it occasionally`, etc... ? Or perhaps this should be two separate questions. One on satisfaction, one on usage patterns.

Answer (score 46):

Q: Stack Exchange has been attempting to improve the quality of content you see. How do you feel they are doing? Has the quality improved in the past year?

A:

- Excellent improvement
- Noticeable improvement, but some ways to go
- No noticeable change
- It's actually gotten worse.

In the more general case (not so much about the SE Quality Project):

Q: What change, if any, have you noticed in the quality of content on Stack Overflow (or SE in general):

A.

- Large improvement
- Moderate improvement
- No change
- A little worse
- It's gone done the garbage chute.

Credit to @DavidGrinberg for the more general form.

Comment: I was going to go with something like this. I think it's a bit too soon though; so I think a timeframe is needed, the last year? Or, ask in a different way, say "how quickly do you find complete answers to your questions"?

Comment: @Ben Agreed that its a bit soon, but its hard to wait til next year :) I like the time frame idea and added it. I would do your other suggestion as a different question, as this is posed more towards answerers than askers (though it applies to both).

Comment: I like this question a lot, but I would reword it a bit. "SE has been doing alot" places the affirmative response in the respondents head before they even see the options. I'de word it more like "Have you noticed any increase or decrease in the quality of content you see at SE?"

Comment: @DavidGrinberg Still trying to see if I can word it better, but I took out the absolute affirmative on the quality getting better in the question, and added a more "general" option.

Comment: Would love to see this question

Answer (score 45):

**Did you hesitate to create an account on Stack Overflow? If so, why?**

- I don't remember
- No, I joined immediately or shortly after my first visit
- Yes, I wanted to learn more about the site before joining
- Yes, I was intimidated by the community
- Yes, I was intimidated by the complexity of the website
- Yes, I didn't think I had anything to contribute
- Yes, I didn't have the time to set up an account
- Yes, I didn't need an account for my needs

Comment: I like the one question format better.

Comment: Good question, but it probably needs an "I joined years ago, I don't remember" option. That's what would apply for me, at least.

Comment: I'm not sure if points one and two can even be answered truthfully. The complexity and (possible) hostility are probably only noticable *after* the account is created and the user tried to participate. Also, it is heavily biased based on the experience after the account creation.

Comment: Add : "I wanted to learn how SO worked before creating my account." or was I a strange one to do that?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist good call, added

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau how about "I wanted to learn more about the site before joining"?

Comment: As far as this question goes, I would add another whole question asking them *when* they did join the community. The time period when they joined is very relevant to some of the responses for why they hesitated. The atmosphere here is very different than it was back in 2008, and clumping all users who bother to reply into one statistic doesn't seem like it would make for very useful information to anybody.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Good point! And I'd even like to add a point here: Reading the one-question version I tried to put myself into one of the categories. But in case of two questions I think I would answer "No" to the first question. I think the first version is more accurate.

Comment: What about "my needs were met by browsing without an account"?

Answer (score 40):

How often you read the Hot Meta Posts?

- Daily (or more)
- Occasionally
- Seldom
- Never (or next-to)

Comment: It pops up in the sidebar, so you can't just "not read it".

Comment: @MightyPork so do ads and I don't read them either.

Comment: @MightyPork Only the title pops up in the sidebar.

Answer (score 38):

Two questions about the (perceived) employers perspective on SO.

**Do you think that disclosing your SO profile and your activity on the site during a job interview or in your CV will rather help or harm your chances of being hired?**

- help
- neutral
- harm

**Does your current employer encourage you to be an active SO user?**

- absolutely
- only to solve the problems currently assigned to
- there is a similar in-house tool that is supposed to be used instead
- only in spare time
- employer restricts overall internet usage
- don't know / employer doesn't care

Comment: second question needs a: Does not care.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs You are right. Maybe the second question is a bit pointless after all, when considering that most employers will probably not encourage/disencourage this in general.

Comment: They still may, but with a lot of provisions, such as "do not mention our clients; do not post our code; do not use our name as leverage; do not browse SO during work time" ... wait, summing it up like that it *does* sound disencouraging.

Answer (score 37):

What are your three "favourite" pet peeves on Stack Overflow?

- Asker doesn't fully describe the problem or take the time to make the question understandable
- Misused tags
- Asker does not properly indent code
- People's names are not capitalized ("I want to use the fourier transform...")
- People using answers to post comments
- People taking downvotes personally
- Answering in Stack Overflow is like a drug you can't get away from
- Asker completely changes question after answers have been posted ("the chameleon question", as wittily put in the comments below)
- Asker deletes question while you're typing the answer
- Code with a blank line after *each* actual line (a program doesn't  look more impressive just because it takes more vertical space)
- Being able to downvote without specifying a reason (by enforcing that the reason be specified, the downvoted asker/answerer could learn how to improve their contributions)
- (My pick): Asker writes, at the end of their question, "please help, *it's urgent*" (italics added)

If possible, it would be nice to include a free-text option:

- Other (*please specify*).

Comment: The "Too minor edit" option removal... then having to improve too many edits to make it worth reviewing.

Comment: Add an option "Rules bores"

Comment: How about "asker dumps entire life story, including, but no limited to, what programming class they're in, how close to failing they are/how close their project is to being overdue, how their professor screwed them over, and how bad their textbook is before getting to the actual question?"

Comment: When it takes about 10 comments from 4 different people until someone actually understands what the askers means, after which the problem is solved with 2 lines of code.

Comment: How can you have a "favourite" pet peeve?

Comment: Mine is *50k rep moderator copy/pastes standard text to 1 rep newbie that he should use comments to ask for clarification* (newbie does not have enough rep to comment, moderator must know this).

Comment: @starsplusplus Hence the quotes around "favourite". [Scare quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes), actually :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo I don't understand. You didn't use scare quotes; I did. So how does this answer my question about your answer?

Comment: @starsplusplus Sorry, I see now I didn't use qoutes. Edited. That pet peeve is my "favourite" because it's the one that annoys me the most; the one that really gets on my nerves

Comment: My biggest pet peeve: People asking a question and leaving. Comments asking for clarification (and there are always some) don't get answered. I so hate this.

Comment: @juergend That's quite mean indeed. I personally haven't seen that happen often, though

Comment: @LuisMendo: I see that practically on at least 70% of the questions I watch in the SQL area.

Comment: The chameleon question is one everyone hates... Please add - "The random sorting of Answers", "Losing points on answers when a user is booted", "People changing their username causing @user comments to be orphaned", "Hans Passant answering bounties as a comment", and "Jon Skeet beating me everytime".

Comment: people asking "is it possible?"

Answer (score 32):

Q: What is the shortest amount of time you've spent researching a question before posting it?

A:

- I've never asked a question.
- < 5 minutes
- 5 - 15 minutes
- 15 - 30 minutes
- 30 - 60 minutes
- > 60 minutes

Or "longest amount of time..."

Comment: I wonder how many lazy users will answer this honestly....

Comment: Just for comparison, What is the longest amount of time you've spent working on an answer (after the question was asked)?

Comment: Why? What would this information provide?

Comment: @DavidThomas I'm not sure where the question was directed, but for the question I added, I think that finding out how people answer this question would be indicative of the level of care is being taken in asking questions. Especially if we were to hide how other people have voted...

Comment: I feel like this needs an option for people who never asked a question.

Comment: @Spokey Good point. I was assuming there would be a way of skipping questions on the survey, but if there isn't, I'll add an option.

Comment: Another related question: _"How many of your problems did you solve yourself during the process of writing the question?"_

Comment: Interesting question, but I would probably increase the time intervals since I doubt that *gimme teh codez* users will bother responding to a survey. They are happy to get *their codez* returning as a brand new user. On the other hand I believe (and hope) that people who will respond this survey will never choose < 5 minutes option. In any case it would be interesting to see the results.

Comment: This question is not for meta, it should be asked each time you post a question on SO

Comment: "Less then 5 minutes" is OK if you already know a lot about the topic, or if it is a question that will benefit lots of other people.  E.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6453235/what-does-damp-not-dry-mean-when-talking-about-unit-tests

Answer (score 30):

The Stack Exchange team would need to devise sensible ranges for hours, but to ask users to self-report the amount of time they spend on typical SE activities...

#### Q: How many hours per week do you spend on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange *Questions* you have asked?

- 0-1 hours
- 2-5 hours
- 6+ hours

#### Q: How many hours per week do you spend on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange *Answering* the questions of others?

- 0-1 hours
- 2-5 hours
- 6+ hours

#### Q: How many hours per week do you spend reading Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange questions & answers without actively participating?

- 0-1 hours
- 2-5 hours
- 6+ hours

#### Q: How many hours per week do you spend on Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange moderation duties (review, flagging, editing, etc)?

- 0-1 hours
- 2-5 hours
- 6+ hours
- I lack sufficient reputation to participate in moderation tasks

Comment: Shouldn't the server logs already have this for logged in users and those with static IPs? I assume the purpose is to determine the proportion of lurkers vs. contributors?

Comment: What about an additional Question asking about active care taking?

Comment: @Ben It may be sort of quantifiable from logs, but individualized reporting on what users perceive to be their participation levels could be useful too

Comment: @bummi Originally I included it but removed it because of the minimum rep requirements.

Comment: You might just role all of these into one question: "When you are on SO, what do you spend most of your time doing?"  "A: 1) Asking questions. 2) Answering questions, 3) Browsing posts. 4) Moderation tasks."

Comment: Thanks, from what I see 6+ is a low upper range, will say 6+ up to 40+ will be one single  group.

Comment: @bummi I assume the team would come up with sane numbers. My own would all be way off the charts, as would be true of most power users.

Comment: "How many hours a week do you spend weeping into your keyboard in response to (some) questions?"

Comment: @DavidThomas Approximately all of them.

Comment: These are like marketing questions.. Which is fine, but the answers already exist server-side in a much more accurate way than answering this question can provide. Unless you're looking for the "how much time do you *perceive* yourself spending on SO/SE", which could bring an interesting psychological twist, maybe we will find out which users are more derealized than others? On top of that, 6+ is going to be a very popular answer and in reality aren't the >6 hour answers going to be the most beneficial? I would suggest asking "0-1", "2-6", "7-12", "12+" or at least leave room for real answers.

Answer (score 30):

How often do you *moderate* <sup>**1**</sup> questions/answers that you browse to? (e.g. Flagging, Close voting, etc.)

- Always (100% - 90%)
- Usually (90% - 75%)
- Often (75% - 50%)
- Sometimes (50% - 25%)
- Rarely (25% - > 0%)
- Not interested (0%)

<sup>**1** *Not review queue*</sup>

Comment: Does this mean reviewing posts using the tool or posts found in the wild? Also, can you indicate perhaps moderate posts that need it as opposed to moderation in general (sometimes I cherry pick only the good stuff).

Comment: @TravisJ posts found in the wild. _Review queue_ is another issue imho. The ones who _review_ and the ones who _moderate_ posts in the wild should be distinguished. speaking of myself, I rarely _review_ but I actively moderate posts on the tag I'm experienced with. Nonetheless, I flag/vc posts I encounter by coincidence.

Comment: In that case, perhaps the question could be, "How often do you *moderate* questions/answers that you browse to? (e.g. Flagging, Close voting, etc.)", or some version of that to make the distinction?

Comment: @TravisJ makes sense, I've edited my post.

Comment: I think "(Almost) Always" would be a better wording of option 1, otherwise just about no-one can honestly pick it.

Comment: @Jeroen I guess that depends on whether doing nothing because nothing is required counts/should count as moderation. I always assess the quality of posts I read, even if I don't necessarily take any action on it.

Comment: Should this include something to point out the concern is questions needing moderation? Or do we care about how often people moderate all questions, including the ones that may not need it?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I don't follow? What I meant was that I think *nobody* will "*Always*" moderate questions they browse to; everybody at least incidentally will browse to a question and do nothing (no time, nothing to moderate, rl emergency, etc, etc)

Comment: @Jeroen _always_ doesn't mean you do moderation 100% of your time; let's say 100% to 80%.

Comment: @Omar which is why I suggested to change the wording to "(Almost) Always", which better reflects the fact that it's a range from 80%-100%. Something like "Nearly always" would also work. Or perhaps even better: rewrite the question and answers so they include the percentages.

Comment: @thegrinner it's an indicator an of how many users are devoted to keep SO clean while browsing not reviewing already flagged posts.

Comment: @Jeroen valid point, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Omar I get that, I'm just wondering if we want to explicitly differentiate "what percentage of questions you view do you moderate" and "what percentage of questions do you view that need moderation that you moderate", if that makes sense?

Comment: @thegrinner that makes sense, this could be a follow up question (tricky) that validates previous question.

Comment: @Jeroen My point was that there are plenty of people who always moderate questions, if your definition of moderating includes just checking to see if there are issues with it (which mine would). If it's only moderating if there are problems that need to be acted upon and you act on them then I agree, there's probably nobody who *always* moderates questions they look at, because at least one of those questions won't need to have any actions taken.

Comment: Does editing count as moderation? (I think it does, but I can that being debatable and reliant on context)

Comment: @ouflak In my opinion editing counts as moderation.

Answer (score 25):

Q: What are (or have been recently) your primary level(s) of interaction with programming? (Select All that apply).

A:

- Professional
- Open source contributor
- Hobbyist
- Student
- Beginner

I'm *sure* there's a better way to word the question, so feel free to suggest! Note that I'm defining "professional" as it being your job.

Comment: I was trying to express the same idea, but also found the wording difficult. I came up with: "What are the primary reasons for which you do programming? (check all that apply): (a) Programming is (part of) my job (b) I use programming as a tool to solve problems (c) Recreation (d) Education / curiosity".

Comment: Methinks rephrase this somewhat so it's along the lines of "What's your level of interaction with programmer? (Select all that apply)" That way, someone can check each of Professional, Hobbyist, and Open Source Contributor if they all apply.

Comment: @Denis Checking all of them was *supposed* to be what the top option was for. I see your point, but the idea was that interaction is a relatively linear scale. I think I just need one more option...

Comment: Still seems to leave out cases imho. Script kiddie + student + hobbyist + OSS, pro + hobbyist + OSS, yada yada yada. Methinks it's really a type of question that requires checkboxes rather than radio buttons. :-)

Comment: @Denis I guess I see many options as mutually exclusive. OSS is like a "super-hobbyist". Professional means its your job (so those can be combined). Script kiddie and student are things you are *before* you become a hobbyist/professional. If someone said they were a script kiddie/professional, I would be very concerned...

Comment: Err... I'm afraid I have to disagree. SO is absolutely *full* of script kiddies (= someone who downloads and uses code they don't understand) who masquerade as professionals (= someone whose job is to produce software). It does raise the valid question of whether a script kiddie would identify as such, of course.

Comment: @Denis Fair enough (scary as it may be). I added the "select all that apply".

Comment: Maybe change Script kiddie to Beginner.

Comment: @Trilarion I suppose that would be better wording; even if they are related here on SO :(

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You need to clarify whether you are asking about everything the respondent has done, or their current status. I was a full time student for several years after I had been a professional for over 30 years. Now I'm retired. Which boxes should I check? Should I check "Professional" because I have been a professional programmer? Should I check "Student" because I have been a computer science student?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I would say "Professional", but I agree I need to clarify it. I think it comes down to what you would say if asked "What kind of programmer are you?" You would likely answer "Retired", but really thats "Professional" (just not currently working). I *almost* used that wording, but liked this one better.

Answer (score 20):

Has your opinion about SO changed during your experience on it?

- I have lost all confidence
- I lost a bit of enthusiasm
- My opinion is always the same
- I'm much more satisfied
- I've discovered paradise

Comment: Might be more interesting to ask this question about specific aspects of SO: the overall community, the moderation/StackExchange team, the quality of content, etc.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Yes it could be split in a table where rows are the specific aspects and columns are my options

Comment: @AnthonyGrist seems valuable as it is with follow up questions for each piece.
That way we get an overall opinion/impression as well as an opinion on specific parts...  thoughts?

Comment: @MER That sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 20):

This isn't an example question, but it's something that has been sorely missing from previous years' surveys. A lot of the questions assume that survey respondents are working programmers. These questions are impossible for college students like me to answer. As a result, every year so far, I personally haven't finished the survey, and other college students have made similar complaints on the surveys' blog posts.

So, for the questions that only apply to career programmers, can you please add "Not Applicable" responses? For example, these are some questions that I find very difficult to answer as a student.

> How many people work at your organization?
>
> - 1-50
> - 50-100
> - 100-500
> - 500-1000
> - 1000-10000
> - 10000+
> - Not applicable

.

> What is your salary?
>
> - $0 - $25000
> - $25000 - $50000
> - $50000 - $100000
> - $100000+
> - Not applicable

.

> How many years have you been with your current company?
>
> - 0-12 months
> - 1-2 years
> - 2-5 years
> - 5+ years
> - Not applicable

Comment: I think you can skip questions. I don't know what additional value this extra option would bring.

Comment: if Kevin brings that up and other people complained about it, I'd say this possibility of skipping questions could be more evident if already present

Comment: I was unaware I could skip questions. Making it more clear that we don't have to answer every question would also work for me.

Comment: For the salary ranges, I suggest changing "$100,000+" to "$100,000 - $150,000", and adding "$150,000 - $200,000" and "$200,000+" options. :-) (Many programmers in the Bay Area and New York earn 6 figures, even at entry level. It'd be useful to be able to stratify them a little further. Personally, I'd prefer even finer-grained steps, such as $25k steps.)

Comment: My suggestion isn't about what specific questions SO should use. It's that questions specific to career programmers should have "not applicable" answers for those who aren't yet working.

Answer (score 18):

Think of your all votes to the questions. What has been your strongest reason(s) to decide to cast a vote, if ever? (You can choose multiple choices)

- **Up Vote** : I had the same problem.
- knowing the answer was interesting to me.
- I thought its a very useful question however I knew the answer.
- I thought it is a well researched question.
- I liked the tone, format, style and structure of the question.
- I liked the asker (I knew him/her, my friend, my colleague, my countryman...).

---

- **Down Vote** : It was not well researched (repeated, trivial, obvious..).
- I disliked the style and structure of the question (poor English, poorly written).
- The question was ambiguous, unclear, not a question (or maybe off-topic).
- The question was not useful to future readers.
- I disliked the asker. (based on your feeling toward him (lazy, uneducated, imploite ..., his English, his origin, his tone... ))
- To retaliate his comments or his opinions toward me or my question or I felt he/she has down-voted me. (He didn't accept my answer to the question or my reasons!...)
- I never voted a question or I don't believe in voting to questions.

Sorry for my bad English, you may edit the sentences or offer more options, In fact I liked to know the reasons for both up and down votes, although asking them in separated question might be better.

Comment: I would find it difficult to pick, as I have picked all of those actions (except the "disliked the asker") at different times depending on the post. I couldn't even say I do one *most* of the time.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Then you could choose all of them (I just added a new option). its more a statistics question, finally some of them gain more weights

Comment: @Kendra Thank you, I merged some of your suggestions to the existing options and added the rest.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Also please note you don't need to say which you  do or may do usually, you should say which you have done.

Comment: `Because I disliked the asker. (A lazy, uneducated, imploite, with poor English... person)` needs adjusted.  I can't think of a better way to phrase it, but I think this needs split into 2 options.  Downvoting the user is different downvoting a lazy and poorly written question.

Comment: @psubsee2003, Thank you I made them distinct! I merged the poor English and bad written to weak structure and style and the described the option which was based on some feeling to the asker

Answer (score 16):

What is your favourite StackExchange site?

- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow
- Stack Overflow

Joking aside, maybe:

How often do you browse questions in languages/platforms you are not familiar with?

- Multiple times a day
- Once a week
- Only if I have to work with it on a project
- Rarely
- Never

Comment: This could be skewed. A novice programmer is *always* browsing in platforms they aren't familiar with. Combined with some of the other questions it could yield some very interesting data though!

Comment: Ahhh yeah, didn't really think about that part! If that wasn't an issue, I think it would be good as you can't really get that type of information from site analytics easily.

Comment: I think you are missing a "Rarely" option.  I know I do it occasionally, certainly more than never, but definitely less than once per week

Comment: Might be better to word it as "What is the StackExchange site with questions/answers that most interest you?" With a fill-in-the-blank option.

Comment: Good call @psubsee2003, added a "Rarely" option.

Comment: @TylerH while that would be a good way to word that first question, I was thinking more as a joke rather than taking it seriously. ;)

Comment: @Turnerj Aww bummer!

Answer (score 14):

I'd like to see questions about the actual and preferred working hours per week.

**How many (paid) hours per week do you work professionally?**

- < 15
- 15 - 25
- 25 - 35
- 35 - 45
- > 45

**How many hours per week would you like to spend working if you were able to decide freely?**

- same answers as above.

Comment: This question is tough to answer for freelancers who have no employer at all but may have so many customers that none of them is "main". How about: "How many hours per week do you work professionally?" without mentioning employers at all?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Absolutely. I tried to improve the question, please have a look.

Comment: Great question, though it might benefit from an extra "As many as I have projects to occupy" option. That would definitely be my personal response for the second question.

Answer (score 14):

We all know that Stack Overflow isn't a social network. It's all about questions and answers. So it would be quite interesting to know:

> **How many regularly active Stack Overflow users do you actually know in person?**

- None.
- 1
- 2
- 3 - 5
- 5 - 10
- 10 - 20
- 20 - 50
- > 50

Comment: This may need to be qualified with something like "how many _regularly active_ Stack Overflow users" or "_actively contributing_".  Otherwise, the question is nearly synonymous with "How many programmers do you know in person?"

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I guess you're right. I picked your first suggestion. If you still think my post can be improved, please feel free to edit.

Comment: We can't have this question, it would ruin the "What is Stack Overflow?" question! Jokes aside, I would suspect this is 0 for most users, unless your co-workers/friends are on it.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You might be right, but that's still an assumption. I would like to *know* rather than speculate;)

Comment: I think this would be like asking people "Are you in a voting ring?", "How many users do you collude with?"

Answer (score 13):

How fast do you expect to get an answer to your question on Stack Overflow?

- in minutes
- within the hour
- that day
- this week
- never

Comment: This is missing an option for more than a day.

Comment: The "never" option makes little sense. Why would you post a question if you expected it never to be answered?

Comment: Some users tend to have a bad experience and don't get much response. I guess there are users asking a question but be disappointed and don't expect really a answer.

Comment: This might be an interesting graph when plotted against reputation.

Comment: @Anko, might be for users who posts only definitive self-answered questions. Or pessimists :)

Comment: @Anko - some of my questions never get answered because they are either too obscure, or I already researched the O*&t out of them before posting. I fully expect that outcome for such questions.

Comment: Some people come here, ask their question and say "it's urgent". With a straight face. I find that hard to believe, even after all the times I've seen it myself

Answer (score 12):

**Question:** How many other Stack Exchange sites do you *actively* participate in? (Not counting per-site metas)

1. None -- Stack Overflow 4ever!
2. 1-2 -- I know some stuff...
3. 3-5 -- I know quite a bit, actually.
4. 6-9 -- I'm kind of a genius. :)
5. 10+ -- I am brilliant.

Comment: Surely this could be got from the database quite easily.

Comment: I'm upvoting because I think there is value in the question (although the recommended answers really suck - how does being brilliant line up with actively participating with 10+ sites).  The reason I like the question is it isn't based on raw analytics but is based on a users own perception of  whether they are active in a site.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, but it could also be interesting to see the difference between all users (from DB) to users answering the survey. Also "active" is subjective.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs you're both saying the same thing. I think the beginning of your comment should/could be "*Yes it could be interesting to [...]*"

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No we are not saying the same thing, at least not in the way I understood martins comment. He says: "DB Query solves this" I say: "DB Query is not enough (but could additionally be interesting as well)". Thats different.

Answer (score 11):

I don't know if this is possible (or qualified), but I'll suggest anyway.

---

For those of you who are already ~5 years using Stack Overflow, how do you like SO...

... <strike>before</strike> when you started?

- Like
- Somewhat like
- Neutral
- Somewhat hate
- Hate

... now?

- Like
- Somewhat like
- Neutral
- Somewhat hate
- Hate

Comment: By "before", do you mean "when you started"?

Answer (score 9):

Q: How would you describe the general attitude of users on Stack Overflow?

A: (these can be improved)

- Awesome, very helpful and kind
- The users don't seem to appreciate new users
- I haven't noticed anything either way, neither good nor bad
- ...

Comment: If recent meta discussions are anything to go by, all the high-rep users will respond: "Awesome!" and most of the low-rep users will be "We aren't appreciated!". Perhaps thats just the pessimist in me though. I like the idea, just not sure how to execute it...

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I would love to see this question graphed by reputation. I think it would shed light on the heavyweight/newbie disparity

Comment: Was going to post the same question if it weren't here already... :)

Comment: "unreasonably patient"

Comment: "Approaching ServerFault"

Answer (score 9):

Do you use Stack Overflow more often for exploring content (e.g. homepage, tags) or looking up facts (e.g. from search engines, incoming links)?

- Only exploring
- More exploring
- More looking up
- Only looking up

Comment: @BradleyDotNET You're right. What do you think about the phrasing now?

Comment: So If I just look at C# questions, does it count? I'm not on the home page.

Comment: Yes, my intention was to include this. Discovering content vs looking up facts.

Comment: Works for me. I know what you are getting at now.

Answer (score 9):

If you are afraid of participating, then why:?

- You do not expect an answer;
- You expect your question be closed;
- You expect down votes;
- You will be not correctly understood;
- Your English is not good;
- Your are not able to answer as fast as answer-hunters;
- You are afraid you cannot meet quality of top gurus;
- You just never tried;
- You feel in hostile environment;
- Your internet connection is slow;
- You cannot do things without a friend or an assistant;
- You do not have enough time on your hands
- You are afraid of comments directed towards you
- You are not sure where to click
- Website rules are too complicated

Comment: This is extremely similar to a previously added question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278846/suggest-a-question-for-the-2014-stack-overflow-user-survey/278875#278875.  While there are subtle differences, they are similar enough that the concepts should be merged.

Comment: Yes, I actually borrowed two last items from Carrie Kendall's question. But she talks about creating an account, while my concern is about actual participation. Probably they could easily merge.

Comment: This would be most relevant for myself. I have an account, on multiple SO sites. However, I am very hesitant to ask questions. For example if there is a bit of math involved, but it is about a library, I might have maybe a valid question, but I'm referred to one of the sister sites. Or, the question is not valid for subtle reasons that the non die-hards like me don't understand. I don't mind that there is etiquette, but it makes me more a consumer than a producer. Maybe rather than closing a question it might be an idea to move it to some "beginner's space" where still answers can be given.

Answer (score 7):

How much time do you spend on Meta (site specific or global) in comparison with the base site?

- Almost exclusively visiting Meta
- Mostly visiting Meta
- Equal split
- Mostly visiting Stack Overflow
- Almost exclusively visiting Stack Overflow

I'm not sure if purely exclusive ("Only visit Meta"/"Only visit Stack Overflow") options make sense.

Comment: This could be guessed from amount of questions on both sites

Comment: @exebook hardly - your statement is based on the idea that you need to ask or answer a question to use the site.  If you looked at my question & answer, you'd assume that I only visit Meta.  But maybe that is only because my usage of Stack Overflow does not involve asking questions or answering questions

Answer (score 4):

Q: How many people do you usually work with, on projects related to your Stack Overflow questions and answers?

A: I am usually:

- the only person working on a project
- working with one other person on a project
- working with a team of three to ten (?) people on a project
- working with a team of ten or more (?) people on a project
- (more/other buckets?)

Comment: I like the question. What do you think about choices like "Alone for hobby projects, more hobby, more work, team at my workplace"?

Comment: @danijar Hobby projects may include OSS with many contributors. Work projects may be solo. In fact, most of my programming-related work projects have been solo. I think it would be very difficult to mix these concepts into one question, which is why I limited this to team size only.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense to me. I think this should be two separate questions, too.

Comment: This is vague (what does "working with" mean?) and the data it would generate doesn't seem relevant to SO.

Answer (score 4):

What should StackOverflow's new years resolution be?

- Get more users to join
- Have more accurate answers
- Answer more questions
- Reach an all time high in site traffic
- reach an all time high in users gaining rep
- Other (Please specify)

Comment: Instead of new years resolution maybe say something like "future plans" or "would most benefit"...

Comment: Only two of these options are even remotely good ideas. Could you add some more?

Answer (score 4):

Is StackOverflow the primary site you participate in on the StackExchange network?

- Yes, by a long way
- Yes, but it's close
- It's one of 2-3 main ones (all roughly equal)
- No, there are others I participate a bit more in
- No, I participate in other sites a lot more
- What's the StackExchange network?

Comment: Surely if the team want this they can just data mine it? This has the dual advantage of not bothering users and increasing accuracy (100% sample size).

Answer (score 4):

Do you long for a section of StackExchange where "help me select the best technology" type questions are welcomed rather than being closed as not productive?

- Totally!  Those are often fun and informative.
- No way!  A correct answer can never be objectively chosen.
- Sure.  Objectivity is an illusion; overt subjectivity is more honest.  Just look at popular news these days.
- No!! Since when is the empty rhetoric of popular news any kind of role model?
- Yes.  SO is of the people.  Give em what they want.
- What's next?  Selecting the president by popular vote??

Answer (score 3):

Would you like to take part in a real life user meeting of stackoverflow users?

- Yes and I would travel across the world for it.
- Yes and I would travel within my nation for it.
- Maybe, if it would be in my city/next bigger city.
- Probably not.

Idea is to find out how much desire there is to meet offline with the guys you see here.

Comment: If we do this, our nametags should be an image of our "flair" right before the event. Or even better, a live rendering of it :)

Answer (score 3):

How would you rate the overall quality of typical StackOverflow questions?

- Great!
- Good
- Average
- Bad
- Terrible

And the same for answers.

Answer (score 2):

How satisfied or unsatisfied you are with the quality of the answers you get to your questions?

- Very much satisfied (Always get the perfect answer in before it is
  too late)
- Satisfied (Some times get the perfect answer before it is    too
  late)
- Neither satisfied nor unsatisfied (Sometimes get the    perfect
  answer other times not)
- Unsatisfied (Most of the time does    not get a good answer)
- Very much unsatisfied (Never get a good    answer)

Answer (score 2):

What is your age?

- below 20
- 20-29
- 30-39
- 40-50
- above 50

Comment: Needs refining, people celebrating a decade can belong in two groups

Comment: @Jerry: Oh, fair play, didn't even notice the edit.

Answer (score 2):

In case you find a great answer to a question somewhere else, do you come back to other discussions to let them know what you have found or do you just move on ?

Answer (score 2):

'Are you passionate about coding in and of itself or is it just a job to you ?'

Rationale:
In my opinion, there are people who are coders through-and-through and then those who simply do it as a job. It would be interesting to know the split between the two groups.

Comment: I hate this term "passionate" applied to stuff. It's an overloaded term destined to hit the bottom of my bin when I read it on CVs.

Comment: Fair comment, by all means change the wording but the question still stands. Is it just a job or is it more than that ?

Answer (score 2):

Do you believe it is important to increase diversity on engineering teams?

Comment: Oh not this nonsense again. The whole point of race and gender not mattering is that race and gender don't matter. So why does everybody keep insisting on talking about them? Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** *Which aspects of your live do you use the programming (that means both algorythmic approach, and the programming itself)?*

**A:**

- Don't program.
- Just for fun, trying to do something sometimes.
- I spend my programming time only for work.
- I'm in programming at work, and sometimes for hobby.
- Trying to fill all of my live with it, i.e. think algorythmically, deep in coding, create devices, robots, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** Does stack exchange reputation helped you in professional life(Job)?

1. Yes
2. No

If yes

**Question:** Does stack exchange reputation helped you in getting?

1. Job
2. Promotion

Comment: reduce it to one question: SO Rep helped you in getting: 1) Job 2) Promotion 3) Nothing

Comment: -1 Vague. What does "helped" mean? How direct does it need to be to count?

Comment: "No, but I would like to"

Answer (score 0):

Is software development your profession and if so, how big is the company you are working for?

Answer (score -1):

Do you use Stack Overflow more often for exploring content (e.g. homepage, tags) or looking up facts (e.g. from search engines, incoming links)?

- Only exploring
- More exploring
- More looking up
- Only looking up

Comment: Well this is a duplicated answer...

Answer (score -2):

What do you think about the down votes you received? How much of them were unfair and non-constructive (when you didn't learn anything)?

- All of them
- Most of them
- Half of them
- Some of them
- Few of them
- None of them (All were fair and constructive and I learned something)

Comment: [This is a duplicate of your other answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278955/2982225). Please propose different ideas instead of reposting the same idea again.

Comment: @Sunshine they are not the same, this question show s how people consider the vote they **receive to their question** (the receiver status),  and that question show how people vote to other questions (caster status). I may never vote to questions but have feeling toward the votes I receive. they could be complementary but not the same.

Answer (score -2):

How many other sites of the StackExchange network do you use regularly?

- None
- 1 other
- 2 others
- 3 - 5 others
- More than 5 others

Answer (score -2):

Q.

When do you mainly answer to SO questions?

A.

- During working time
- During free time

I'm not sure if there is a clear distinction between working and free time for everybody.

Answer (score -3):

What has Stack Overflow offered to the beginners in programming, choose all that apply:

- Develop interest in different programming languages
- Get answers of all the queries taking the minimum time
- bringing together all the programmers together and help each other
- provide good social network for the learners to learn and others to show what they got
- Discussion forum for discussing various topics
- getting jobs of your own type and need

Answer (score -3):

Are you addicted to StackOverflow

- No
- Little
- Yes

Answer (score -4):

What is your main aim for using Stack Exchange?

1. Helping Others.
2. Gaining Knowledge.
3. Earning Reputations.
4. Testing your skills.

Comment: This assumes that the only motivation to use Stack Overflow is to answer questions.  More users use it to get answers to questions

Comment: @psubsee2003 getting answers to questions is covered in gaining knowledge as asking question means having less knowledge on some particular thing and getting answers on that result in gaining knowledge about the particular thing

Comment: While that does make sense, I see "Getting Answers" and "Gaining Knowledge" as 2 separate items (although they can be related).  I could use it to gain knowledge through general browsing and reading through questions (as well as gaining knowledge by answering questions), whereas "Getting Answers" is a very distinct action where you have a problem and you come to the site to get that specific answer.

Answer (score -5):

What type of person frustrates you the most on StackOverlow:

- Driveby Downvoters
- Vampires
- Repwhores
- Apathetics

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/2642059

I'd like to know what the general populace really feels is a problem.

Comment: Complainers.​​​​​​​​

Comment: It's very interesting how you replaced "caretakers" with "driveby downvoters". Sums up your attitude, really.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, he did ask [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions).

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel: Ahahahahhaa. Hah. No wait that's not funny

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have my days.

Answer (score -10):

How Stack Overflow differs from other Q&A Sites?

1. Tons of Information
2. Knowledgeable Persons
3. Quick Response
4. Good noise to signal ratio
5. All the above

Comment: "specify" is not a good fit for multiple choice answers; also please add: - good noise to signal ratio;

Comment: I'd suggest removing "All of the Above" and replace it with a "Select all that apply".

Comment: I would ask first "Are you using another Q&A site", which should lead to a 100% "No", cause SE is all anyone would need really.

Comment: Also, this is highly biased towards a positive response (there aren't even any negative answers!). Its basically a "How are we awesome? (Pats self on back)" question.

Answer (score -16):

How Good profile on StackOverflow helped you apart from getting good knowledge?
I mean

1. Getting good job?
2. Any benefit after showing your stackoverflow
   flair on your website,blog,linkedin profile?
3. Any benefit after showing your stackoverflow profile on freelancer portal like Odesk,  freelance, elance etc.
4. Impressing your fellow developer :P

Share your story in brief.

Comment: "Share you story" is not a good fit for multiple choice answers.

Comment: We can provide free text box in which upto some character.

Comment: Have you looked at the old surveys? There are none of them. While SE could do it they most likely won't

Comment: In large part because freetext answers are not aggregable in general.

Answer (score -18):

If you would learn to create software and develop again, what would you recommend to yourself?

Comment: Questions were asked to be in multiple-choice format, not short answer.

Answer (score -24):

How do you compare Stack Overflow to Quora ?

1. What is Quora ?
2. Quora is far more open than Stack Overflow.
3. Both are complementary to each other (something should be done to tie them like sharing options).
4. If Stack Overflow is a boat than Quora is the rescue wheel.
5. Irrelevant question.

Comment: Irrelevant, as in Obviously No Comparison? That could work in both directions. I suggest "4. What is Quora, and why should I bother anyway?"

Comment: @Jongware without offend, your suggestion is not innocent.

Comment: 5. What is Quora ?

Comment: "Quora is far more open than Stack Overflow" [Is it, now?](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lhso3hmwvxqdjec/Screenshot%202014-12-12%2010.34.02.png?dl=0)

Comment: @DavidRobinson, yes indeed.

Comment: hope this get the worst downvote, for this kind of question, the more an answer get downvoted the more it will make sense.

Comment: @elsadek How is Quora more open? a) You need to sign in just to *read* questions and answers, b) they don't make their content available in a data dump, while Stack Overflow provides both regular data dumps and a [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/), c) Quora allows posters to mark their content "Not for Reproduction," while all content on StackOverflow is released under CC-BY-SA.

Comment: Quora is more *permissive* in terms of the questions they allow. That's very different from "open."

Comment: @DavidRobinson **for a)** that is not entirely correct you still able to read q/a without sign in if reach a post from SE or share. **for b)** I'm not even aware of this feature in SO. **for c)** reproducing a content is different from sharing it.

Comment: @elsadek a) But not if you reach the page in other ways. Stack Overflow never requires sign-in for reading questions. b) [Data dump is here](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange). c) I don't even know what this means. The fact is that all content on SO is CC-BY-SA and can therefore be shared with attribution, and that is not true of Quora.

Comment: @DavidRobinson the precipitation to lock or close a question or an answer is a _feature_ that undermines openness.

Comment: @DavidRobinson **a)** how does a user reach content on Internet ?!  **c)** means you can share content even it is _"Not for Reproduction"_

Answer (score -26):

Do you think new users should be allowed to post comments?

- Yes
- No

Comment: Might as well throw in a "Should you be forced to comment when downvoting?" question while we're at it.  Joking aside, I don't think this  survey was meant to reevaluate SO's core policies.  It is just a chance to discover the kind of people we work with everyday.

Comment: These discussions are what Meta is for, not a user survey.

Comment: A survey would find out the general opinion of the community.

Comment: New users *are* allowed to post comments.  Just not everywhere they please, it has to involve their own posts.  You might as well change the first bullet to "Yes, I ought to be able spam anywhere".

Comment: While the existing downvotes make it too tough to save this idea, I think to make this more in line with what the community would expect from a survey question, it would be better phrased as "Do you think the existing reputation level for the comment privilege is an obstacle for new users to start using Stack Overflow"

Comment: @psubsee2003 While I agree, its *still* basically asking to revote on a feature request thats duplicated all the time. We get this opportunity once a year, It seems like we should avoid standard Meta questions in the survey.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I get that much, but the idea behind the rephrasing is giving users who do feel that way an opportunity to at least voice that opinion without getting shouted down on meta.  I certainly would be disappointed if SE implemented something based on a survey, but if a significant number of respondents felt it was an issue (which I highly doubt), it might at least provide some idea on whether or not it is worth even looking at an alternative solution that does not eliminate the 50-rep limit.

Comment: All you can find out from meta posts is that a few users who are not afraid of being downvoted think refusing comments from people who are allowed to answer is counter-productive. That tells you nothing at all, in either direction, about the views of typical users.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I would argue that the votes themselves indicate the community does not want this feature. Granted, this is only users with the voting privilege (15+ rep) and the subset of those users who even *read* Meta. But it *does* say that the people who *really care* about the site don't want it, for what thats worth. Regardless, we will have to agree to disagree on this one I think :)