# Topic suggestions for the 2016 Stack Overflow Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

We're hoping to get an early start on the 2016 Stack Overflow Developer Survey, and we need your help coming up with questions.

What do you want to know about the users who ask and answer on Stack Overflow? Who are the teeming masses of programmers who pass through the site every day? Poll the programmers of the world. Ask them anything.

We will be recycling many of the questions we asked in 2015 to keep an eye on year-over-year trends, but we realize a few of last year's questions were clunkers, and others were pretty conclusive – this year we probably don't need to ask about [tabs vs. spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-tabsspaces). So we've got a few open slots. How should we fill them up?

Please suggest a question in **multiple-choice** format.

For inspiration, see [last year's suggest-a-question meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/278846/896802) or the [full 2015 survey results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015).

Comment: Which tag on SO is the most soul-crushing due to the appallingly low quality questions: vb6, vb6, vb6, or vb6?

Comment: @C-PoundGuru lol, must go there for a larf.  I won't be down/close voting however: I use all my downvotes up on the C  tag.

Comment: @C-PoundGuru Nope, because php. It's always php.

Comment: @apaul34208: Ok, we have 2 tag candidates.  A couple more and maybe we'll have a suggestion...

Comment: Could you post the current list of questions? (The two links don't really cover it)

Comment: @C-PoundGuru JavaScript. Always JavaScript.

Comment: "*We will send you a SO t-shirt, stickers, coffee cup and as many dollars as your reputation. What is your address?*" would be a great question. The answers should remain private, though.

Comment: @Oriol: I'm not picky, I'd even take my reputation in dimes. Pennies would be acceptable as well, I suppose.

Comment: when it closes?

Comment: Where will I go to participate. I wish I knew about last year's I would have participated :(

Comment: @Oriol If Jon Skeet responds, SE will be out of business

Comment: Can the survey stop pretending every one has, wants, or is looking for or has opinions about a career/job? Last time about **half the survey** was not applicable and asked career-related questions even after you say you're not interested in that stuff. As a result, I just had to make up answers.

Comment: At the bottom, it should probably say "Keep Stack Overflowing" instead of "Keep Stack Overflow flowing".

Comment: The equivalent meta question for the 2017 probably won't be put up before I forget, but it would be nice to ask what everyone's font of choice is for their editor.

Answer (score 257):

**How old is the product you are working on?** (aka how many of us work on legacy all the time)

- Not released yet
- Just released (sub 1 year)
- 1-2 years
- 3-5 years
- 5-10 years
- 10-25 years
- 25+

I realize that many people also work on a number of products at the same time, in that case we can just ask for an average or their primary product or something.

Comment: How about adding "Release? When did we say we were going to release?" for those instances when stuff never makes it to the public, or even to the company's majority workforce. Just a thought.

Comment: @CSS raises a good point.  Project age is an interesting question, but it isn't always defined in terms of "release"

Comment: @CSS Releases/release frequency is another good metric, but it should be another question

Comment: Maybe split that into “How old is the oldest product you are still working on?” and “How old is the newest product you are working on?”

Comment: 'How old is the oldest product you are still working on?'  Dunno, can't remember.  I guess I could look at the file dates if I had an 8" floppy drive.

Comment: What about projects that have undergone major refactoring/rewrites (like switching languages or serious technical debt reduction)?

Comment: This is arguably something though that would only apply to people who are actually working on something though, arguably in a workplace.

Comment: What about 2.5 years? The 5 years and 10 years cases seem to be covered well, but not 2… :p

Comment: "The" product? How many of us work with just one technology? One a given day I'll work with multiple different products and technologies.

Comment: @Zizouz212 Even those not in a workplace can be working on older products. With all the Open Source stuff out there (most recently for me was json-simple for JSP) that has been deprecated and almost lost to the rest of the world, there's got to be someone that's looking into making updates out there. Also, I tend to get more Java and Visual Basic from schooling than anything else, and those're getting old quick.

Comment: 10 to 25. That's quite a range. The product I'm working on (at least one of them) is in that age group.

Comment: This should include a choice for people who aren't currently working on anything intended for release, e.g. students, hobbyists, and out-of-work pros who aren't currently contributing to open source.

Comment: I work in an ERP product that was first released around 25 years back, and it has evolved to a totally new one. Think Windows for example. How would a Microsoft employee in Windows team answer that?

Comment: So is  4-week long scrum project that's already been released twice is older than a 4 year waterfall behemoth? We'll have to figure what the programming equivalent of "breaking ground" is, first commit? or do prototypes count?

Answer (score 199):

**How many times are you physically active during the week?**

- Once a day
- A couple times a week
- Once a week
- Once a month
- Never

**Note: This is referring to physical exertion (Getting off your chair doesn't count!)**

Comment: Unusual question for this site... It will be surprising if people on SO actually did physical exercise. UPVOTE

Comment: @shanmuga that's the reason I want to know!

Comment: What about 2 a days?

Comment: We play ping pong in office twice a day, and that apart from all the exercise I get while playing games at home.

Comment: Define (physical) exercise? I bike to work everyday (and with me many Dutch people), but don't consider it exercise. I see exercising as going to the gym and doing sports.

Comment: @Bono certainly depends on how far you bike! I think Health questionairres in the U.S generally specify "times you exercise per week"  to be when you spend >= 30 minutes on physical exertion.

Comment: What does "exercise" mean here? Running for the bus?

Comment: @davidkonrad Almost, I'll update the answer to include what I think should be classed as exercise.

Comment: Does playing FIFA get me in this list? If not, may be Need for Speed, I think it is _enough physical_.

Comment: I like *spend >= 30 minutes on physical exertion* as a definition because with "sport" the question just becomes, "Does X count as a sport?"

Comment: @BSMP Good point. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol Remove the "ping" and then maybe :D

Comment: What language is "Physically active"? Newly developed? Can't wait to get a reference book.

Answer (score 197):

**My best debugging ideas/realizations come when I'm:**

- in the shower.
- on the toilet.
- at my desk.
- commuting.
- in bed trying to sleep (not that we *really* sleep).
- waking from a dream/sleep.
- trying to explain my problem to a coworker/rubber duck.
- part-way through writing the question on SO.
- inebriated.
- smoking.
- ...wait, what is debugging?

I should have made this a CW. Feel free to edit with any other great options you might have.

Comment: you forgot "inebriated"

Comment: And *"part-way through writing the question on SO"*

Comment: @ryanyuyu HOW COULD I HAVE DONE THAT?!?

Comment: @jonrsharpe another good one! Feel free to edit, guys

Comment: _while doing something completely unrelated (e.g. sports, cleaning, etc.)_

Comment: @jonrsharpe That had **better** be one of the options. I can't even count how many times that's happened to me.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Relevent [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/323/)

Comment: ... just finished spending two hours devising a test sequence to implement my last, greatest debugging idea.

Comment: And "...while I'm in production changing other code"... I'm not going to edit that one in, in case my employer show up ;)

Comment: In my case, one of the best solutions came to me while looking at 3 SO questions with completely different syntax...Go figure, Jasmin/Karma/AngularJS =*) Seriously, though...Generally I arrive at a spark of intellect while working on something completely different - Angular issue solved while working in PHP, for instance...But that's my life, always between 5 or 6 projects in different languages...

Comment: While telling Arnold Schwarzenegger to shut up and feel my bicep.

Comment: No idea why, but I generally lose an idea if I get it before going to the bathroom and not writing/typing it first. My parents always joked with me that I had crap for brains, maybe this is actualization? Headed to the bathroom now, then I'll type out the other awesome thing I was just thinking of.

Comment: Exercising or other physical activity.  I do a lot of problem solving while walking the dog.

Comment: Also needed: Talking to a rubber duck

Comment: @jonrsharpe you're a genius. Writing a really good question on SO forces you to really think about the problem - the factor missing in your solution.

Comment: @CSS - clearly you need to install a typewriter (remember those..?) on a strategically located swinging shelf in your bathroom. Sit down, get a great idea, type it out. Extra points if you can figure out how to use the conveniently located continuous roll of paper. :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis most of the time, it's at work. I generally sit at my desk and pound out my assignments until I'm too tired to come up with creative ideas when I'm at home. Great idea, though. Maybe I'll recommend something like that at Intel next contract I get with them. =D

Comment: "Walking into someone else's cube/office to explain the... nevermind! fixed it!"

Comment: The best idea so far came up when i was sitting on can and taking huge dump. My brain is in `nirvana state` after doing that.

Comment: In the bathroom :D

Comment: Missing the mandatory: "I don't write bugs"  :)

Comment: Also related: Rubber Duck debugging. I ask someone a question, they understand my question, but I answer it myself

Comment: @ryanyuyu thanks, I was planning on doing some cleanup soon myself :)

Answer (score 188):

How frequently do you check-in/commit code at work?

- Multiple times a day
- Once a day
- A couple times a week
- Once a week
- A few times a month
- I do not use version control

Comment: Whenever I get something working, and right before the window of a deadline closes (homework assignments).

Comment: @CSS [Seven seconds after the deadline](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLWCs.png).  [Or up to an hour later.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rjaBA.png)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Usually within 5 minutes, unless I'm working with PHP, 'cause I don't want people seeing my explicit printouts... or if I'm working with ridiculously slow merging technologies like Jenkins (have to restart the deployment engine and then redeploy if idle for more than about 20 minutes, which takes about half that time).

Comment: Add: Just before the build request.

Comment: I think this is a good question to cover but the last option should be "I do not use version control."  Joke answer might be amusing, but would get too many votes for the sake of the joke answer - this survey is intended to be useful afterall...

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Where is that taken from? Looks interesting.

Comment: @poke [MIT 6.172 Performance Engineering, Fall 2010](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-172-performance-engineering-of-software-systems-fall-2010/video-lectures/lecture-9-cache-efficient-algorithms-ii/) (at the beginning).

Comment: How about adding: 4-6 weeks

Comment: Could also add _"When I get back from vacation"_ I've had plenty of supervisors and coworkers that did just that on critical updates. Awesome, right?

Comment: You lack "_When needed_" ...

Comment: @davidkonrad Or just (less subjectively) "It varies greatly."

Comment: How often should developers be committed? What?

Comment: I'm definitely less frequently than once a week, but I do use it. I'd say "a few times a month".

Comment: I miss something like “When it semantically makes sense to commit the changes” as I absolutely hate time-based committing.

Comment: I'm in agreement with @Poke, many devs don't commit on a 'timely' schedule, but moreso when that project's workflow demands it. Often I commit only once per lifetime and have a codereview / move to test.

Comment: It might be worth modifying the question slightly to make it explicit that you're talking about pushing code to a shared server. With git, it's possible to commit very frequently on your local machine without integrating with the rest of your team as often.

Answer (score 161):

> **How much of your working day do you spend programming?**
>
> - 100%
> - 75-99%
> - 50-74%
> - 25-49%
> - 1-24%
> - 0%

And by programming, I don't necessarily mean typing into an IDE — to me, sketching on a whiteboard is programming too — would just be interested to see how much of a person's time is spent on other admin-y tasks (interviews, meetings, timesheets).

Think it could be quite interesting especially when cross-compared vs. experience, job role, remote working, etc.

Comment: Followed by: "How much of your working day do you spend on Stack Overflow?"

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot A: "None, at all. Ever. I devote 100% of my available work time to my current project."

Comment: Is this predicated on being employed ("professional and...") as a programmer?  What about the "...enthusiast programmers"? How should students answer?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom, that's a good point! You could make it more general I suppose & just make it "How many hours a day do you spend programming?", but personally, I would put it into the "Work" section alright (alongside the salary, remote working, job title, etc. questions), as that's the angle I'd be interested in.

Comment: For me would be "How much of your working day spent on programming produce the desired results?", my A: >1% :/

Comment: This question hurts.

Comment: *to me, sketching on a whiteboard is programming too* - That should be clarified in the question. You say this wouldn't include meetings but what if the meeting is to get requirements from the client?

Comment: @BSMP Maybe change 'programming' to a wider term (open to suggestions), but to me I'd still draw a distinction between development related activities (coding / sketching / pair programming) and other things that take up your time — for me, I wouldn't consider requirements gathering as part of development itself (which isn't to say that it doesn't bring value or that developers shouldn't be involved in it.)

Comment: OK, I've thought about it...and can't actually come up with a better term. :/ If most other people think the meaning is clear, I withdraw my earlier comment.

Comment: Related: How much of your workday (for professional programmers) is spent on documentation? . . . though in my case I would have to give an answer in perctentage of work year.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot 100% of my day is on StackOverflow, with 100% of my day on programming.

Comment: @MacroMan Do you never run into situations where StackOverflow would (or might) be helpful?

Answer (score 155):

***#WomenInTech***

Gender diversity is an important issue in our industry. Let's see how we're doing.

Last year, we surveyed the gender diversity of respondents: https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-gender

I think we should take this a step further this year and survey the gender diversity of the teams in which respondents code. Something like:

**How many developers in your team are women?**

- 0
- 1-2
- 3-4
- More than 4

People work in teams of varying sizes, so we could add an accompanying question, asking how many developers are in the respondent's team. (This may be interesting anyway.) Another option is to ask for a percentage:

**What percentage of the developers in your team are women?**

- 0%
- 1-10%
- 11-25%
- 26-50%
- 51-75%
- 76-100%

Comment: I like this angle - I think there's a massive diversity/bullying problem in "tech" in general. I would however, suggest that broadening it a bit - percentage of female devs is interesting, but I'd also be quite interested in the general 'techy' case. (I have no female devs in my team, but I also have no devs in my team). And perhaps LGBT representation and ethnic diversity.

Comment: Percentage may not reflect best, what do you think? 50% of my team being female isn't as impressive when we say the team only consists of 2 people.  I agree with your point, to ask for how many females & then follow up with dev team size. 

And which choice do I select if 50% is the answer? 25-50 or 50-75? :)

Comment: @Trobbins I also prefer the first option. Will edit %s to fix the overlap. Thanks!

Comment: @Trobbins Generally speaking, these ranges are of  the form `(a, b]`. So, the lower limit is not included in an interval.

Comment: @hj I understand, but it was a question just waiting to be asked :)

Why not make it absolutely clear?

Comment: I think a _combination_ of team size and percentage / amount of women in the team is required.

Comment: it is important to still (rather the question asks for percentages or number) ask about the *size* of the team. I'm one on my team. It amounts to 0% female, or 0 female, which while real, doesn't really reflect diversity at my work.

Comment: Doesn't labelling people as male/female run foul of modern diversity?

Comment: Great question but has the potential for skewed results. Consider a number of large teams with many SO users - it could give heavier weighting to some values. (Although I suppose you'd have to interpret results as 'percentage of people working on teams with X% women', rather than 'percentage of teams with X% women'.)

Comment: It might be interesting to compare against the percentage of applicants, if people know.

Comment: Times have definitely changed. First programming job had more than 60 devs on the same team, only 10 were women. Now, more than half the company I work for are women, about the same size for the office, and more of them are tech; very close to even, if not tipped in their favor.

Comment: Do you expect these results to be significantly different from the overall gender stats? I'd assume the results here would largely mirror the overall gender ones - unless the girls code either all by themselves or in girls-only teams. Is that the hypothesis? I don't necessarily want to pre-judge the conclusion, just trying to understand the hypothesis or question being asked.

Comment: Maybe just ask team size and gender percentages. Based on that, you can do all kinds of calculations (for instance, check if the percentage is lower or higher if the teams get larger.

Comment: Why is it (apparently) acceptable to ask about a team's sex composition, but not race, ethnicity, or religious beliefs?

Comment: @FuriousFolder because it is easier to generalize support for #WomenInTech than it is #X-ReligionInTech or #Y-EthnicityInTech :)

Comment: What if I work in a team of one? Should I put 0%?

Comment: @Lego why so binary?

Comment: "_Gender diversity is an important issue in our industry_" - **No** it is not.

Comment: Perhaps does your current project pass the Bechdel Test for software (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bechdel_test#Bechdel_test_for_software)
*"Source code passes this test if it contains a function written by a woman developer which calls a function written by a different woman developer"*

Comment: @Mr.Boy I've updated the wording to be a bit more inclusive

Comment: Says Mister @Boy...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I identify as a boy so it's OK. My comment _was_ slightly tongue in cheek but these days LGBTX groups _would_ say a simple binary choice isn't adequate. I don't even know what the right wording _should_ be... "identify as female"?

Comment: hmm, my troll comment got me farther than I tought, but I'll have to ask then, how does your avatar name not run foul of modern diversity? @Mr.Boy *oh well, maybe it's poetry*

Comment: Because the focus is on what the individual identifies/expresses their gender as, not what you think they are. But we digress ;)

Comment: *I don't even know what the right wording should be.* - Depends on what you're trying to ask. If really want just women you could say "how many are women (cis or trans)?" but if you want to include agender, genderfluid, etc. then it'd be easiest to ask "how many are not men?".

Comment: Does it really matter who programs, as long as they are good?

Comment: *Why is it (apparently) acceptable to ask about a team's sex composition, but not race, ethnicity, or religious beliefs?* @FuriousFolder - Has someone actually said we can't ask that? If it wouldn't be a complete nightmare to come up with an appropriate list of races and ethnic groups for each country with an SO present, I'd be interested in seeing that data.

Comment: @davidkonrad - What makes you say that? As I see it, we have half as many programmers in the world as we could have for no better reason than rampant sexism in the industry. The world has a shortage of programmers, and a large part of why is because we aren't including them well enough.

Comment: "The world has a shortage of programmers" [citation needed].

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare Have you considered the possibility that men tend to be more likely to enjoy programming than women?  An unequal proportion of males to females in a given industry does not automatically imply rampant sexism in said industry.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare By your logic there is rampant sexism in the world of ballet as well. Here's an alternative (and empirically backed up) theory: there is limited sexism in our industry and there are just not that many female compsci graduates to choose from. Now the reasons for that are vast and varied, but its not because our industry has "rampant sexism." I would add that claiming that I work in a "rampantly sexist" environment offends me.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg - Ballet may or may not have a lot of sexism in it. I don't know. I'm not in any sort of performing profession. I don't care to investigate and I don't really have any way of persuading them to change if it is a problem. It doesn't really matter, because the world doesn't need more professional performers. Performers don't fix world problems. The world needs more programmers - they are one (of many) professionals which can fix problems that exist in the world.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare So now we went from accusations of rampant sexism to saying people of type A are better and/or more important than people of type B? And somehow that makes it "not really matter" if they have rampant sexism?

Comment: Why is it so important to fill up the tech industry with women? Are we also going to recruit more males to become ballerinas or nurses?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare It's a very low-brow perspective to believe that art doesn't solve human problems in the world.

Comment: I don't see why the hashtag is necessary. Can you help me understand, @rouan?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, because it not is a problem for the industry.  When companies as SO have focus on this issue it is pure branding, nothing else, it has nothing to do with "shortage of programmers". We have shortage of **good** programmers, not shortage of programmers as a whole.  People tends to seek to the branch they like, in some branches there is overweight of a specific gender - like in the coal industry or among child care and nursering.  Is that a problem for the "industries" themselves? I think not.

Comment: Not interested in the argument here, but I will comment on the question. As @m01 points out, **I don't see what this adds to the last years gender diversity data**. In fact it feels like a less transparent and intuitive metric that ultimately shows the same thing.

Comment: @davidkonrad Your arguments are contradicting. If there is a shortage of good programmers, and the amount of people with _the potential_ to become good programmers are reduced by half just because all women are excluded, how can it not be a problem? Especially since there is this overwhelming number of _bad_ programmers in the industry, who (instead of becoming coal miners) are taking the jobs that those potentially good programmers didn't take.

Comment: @Lundin, but women are **not** excluded, that is the whole point. There is no evidence that supports the theory that good female programmers are excluded from the industry.  But there is overwhelmingly evidence that explains why there is fewer women than men working as programmers - just take a look at the sex ratio on the educations.

Comment: Down vote. I think it is important to say whether _you_, the survey-taker, is a woman or not. However, number of women in the workplace is not the best thing. If I were to answer this, I would say I am the only woman out of 9 people (including myself). **Diversity is important in the overall field**, not just the company... Unless you are Google or Apple or something.

Comment: @davidkonrad David, there's no point debating this stuff - if someone sees gender inequality nothing you say will convince them otherwise. In fact your attempts at explaining it are seen as proof of the gender bias, it's very much a damned-if-you-do-damned-if-you-dont situation.

Comment: @BSMP This question was downvoted to "meta-hell": http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310438/2014857

Comment: @FuriousFolder - I saw that after I left the comment but even then, only one person said they down voted because it wasn't "appropriate". Another commentor said it just isn't *relevant*, which implies they just don't think the numbers would mean anything, not that they'd find it offensive. There's no way to know whether most down voters are actually offended by the question or not.

Comment: @FuriousFolder - In fact, way more comments from people offended by this question than the religion one.

Comment: @BSMP I think its just way more obvious that the religion question is bad. That and religion doesn't enjoy the same PC-protected status as gender diversity currently does.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg are you saying a question about #WomenInTech is bad!? SEXIST! BIGOT! MISOGYNIST! (end sarcasm)

Comment: Wouldn't be better just to ask how many males are on the team and with simple math calculate how many females there are? Or is that too sexist?

Comment: *That and religion doesn't enjoy the same PC-protected status* @DavidGrinberg - I don't know if you're in the US or not but race, color, religion, national origin, age, sex, pregnancy, citizenship, familial status, disability, and veteran status are all protected classes in the United States.

Comment: @BSMP PC-protected status is not a legal term. I'm not saying that religion is not protected by the US Constitution - it absolutely is. I'm saying that in the current cultural environment the reality is that gender diversity is more center-stage than religion.

Answer (score 143):

Because more and more I'm seeing job adverts that want someone with knowledge in a *collection* of associated languages rather than a single language.

---

**In how many programming languages would you consider yourself to be an "experienced user"?**

- None
- 1 - 2
- 3 - 4
- 5+

Comment: I'd be interested in "How many programming languages have you 'learned' and then forgotten?" Or something of that nature. There has been at least one instance I've studied a language for a project and have since left it at the curb.

Comment: @Trobbins Pascal, Clipper, Basic and the little bit of Perl I learned vanished.

Comment: Isn't this technically covered already as there's [already a question](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-lang) asking which languages are used?

Comment: @Trobbins Not only forgotten; many languages (/platforms) moved on extensively in time, so experience becomes too outdated.

Comment: Everybody thinks they are well experienced in many languages. but they will realise truly when a new project is assigned to them.

Comment: @TRobbins - perhaps the question should be "How many programming languages have you learned that you haven't used at all for the past three years?". I'd have quite a list - COBOL, SPL, APL, PL/I, PL/C, Fortran, Wang 3300 BASIC, EDP-18 assembler, IBM mainframe assembler, 80x86 assembler, that funky accounting package's built-in language that was billed as a 4GL but looked like assembler, GPSS, VBx, SAS, Perl...

Comment: @DavidG - there's a question about which ones are used, but there's no question about which ones are no longer used, which I think would provide an interesting metric.

Comment: @Trobbins I think others may be interested too - post it as a suggestion!

Comment: @BobJarvis That may be a better twist on the question, but some of it could be inferred from the languages that are no longer on the list after being there in previous years :)

Comment: @MacroMan Sure, I went ahead and submitted mine and Bob's comments as an answer http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310458/4771017

Comment: @BobJarvis I tried to make such a question about older languages and it got downvoted until it was removed. Nobody wants to know what older languages you work with or have recently worked with except us 2. 6 months ago, I was on a contract utilizing Natural and ADABAS. Gotta love state agencies where it's obvious state government is out of control.

Comment: You lack the option "_Any_" ...

Comment: I feel like this is a very poor question to ask. Many languages change enough over the course of their life that their initial version may more strongly resemble another language entirely rather than the current version. They're always changing, and the differences between different languages can be minuscule or vast. I don't feel like there's any value in asking for the quantity that you know.

Comment: @CubeJockey "How many programming languages have you 'learned' and then forgotten?" - can't remember. (PLO? CAP/Dacapo? Occam… the one with the green manual (ah! PEARL), XSLT, what's its name (hey, funny nobody put _forth_ WIN))

Answer (score 109):

> How long do you *typically* spend employed at a job?
>
> - Less than a month
> - One to six months
> - Six months to a year
> - One to two years
> - Two to five years
> - Five years or more
> - I'm a student!

I'm curious; I know that it's pretty common to move from position to position in our industry, but I wonder what most people consider typical.

Comment: Errrm, I freelance.

Comment: Seeing that the [majority of users](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#profile-age) is younger than 30, maybe this should be reworded so it doesn’t require past experience. E.g. “How long to you *expect* to typically spend employed at a job?”

Comment: @poke At first I thought people (especially students) guessing would mess up the data, but if another question asks for an age range we can find interesting trends by association.  I approve of the rewording.

Comment: "I'm a student" option needed.

Comment: You need an option for "I'm still in my first job", so, uh "typically" it's 11+ years...?

Comment: Being on my second job for a short time, what should I answer? This may also come with cultural aspects, countries where you can be fired any day or countries where you are protected for 3 months.

Comment: @Thomas You'd answered whatever you think your typical length of employment is. I don't see a problem with having worked one job or ten jobs. The cultural stuff is what would make this interesting.

Comment: Should probably have an option for those that work for themselves like "Until I sell my business". There are also contract companies that keep people paid between contracts so something like "Until I leave this company" would work for them and (permanent) state employed workers.

Comment: Last year we sort of covered this with: "Did you start a new job within the past 12 months?" (35% yes, 51% no, 14% No, I'm a student) But maybe this is a better way of capturing liquidity in the job market + typical dev employment behavior. Maybe.

Comment: "5 years or more" is too small a cut-off. Some people might spend an entire 40 year career in the same job.

Comment: While I see the benefit of the question, like others have said -- most users are so young they are in their first or second programming jobs. I am in my first prog job, and have stayed a little over a year now. However, I was at my last job (retail) for 4 months. Freelance and contract work is also a good thing to note, as there is either no set or a cutoff of employment time.

Comment: @IanGoldby sounds a _position_.

Comment: @greybeard How do you see the difference between a job and a position? Would you call "Technical Consultant" a position or a job?

Comment: I see _job_ on the transient, hire-and-fire side of employment, possibly without amenities such as holiday (US: vacation?) entitlement - thinking _jobbers_. A position is conceivably more permanent than the employment of the person filling it - fall guy impersonator, QA group head, office manager, you name it, I think _employee benefits_. _Technical Consultant_ is a role to play in an organisation the person is no regular employee of - she might be with a consultants bureau.

Answer (score 107):

If you have a dress code policy, which best describes it?

1. Suit
2. Dress/Skirt + Blouse, Khakis + Dress shirt, dress shoes
3. No-hole Jeans, No-logo t-shirt
4. Any and everything
5. More formal than Suit
6. No official policy

How often do you intentionally violate the policy?

1. Rarely or never
2. Every few months
3. Every few weeks
4. Every few days

How much do you care about the policy?

1. A great deal
2. Somewhat
3. I don't care either way
4. It's annoying, but I live with it
5. I detest it with the fire of a thousand suns

If you could change the policy (and wanted to) how would you?

1. Doesn't need to change
2. Make it much more formal
3. Make it a bit more formal
4. Relax things a bit
5. Allow employees to come to work in cosplay attire (relax a great deal)

If your employer has a "Casual Friday" or similar relaxation of dress code, what is permitted during that time?

1. No Casual Friday/Similar
2. Suit
3. Dress/Skirt + Blouse, Khakis + Dress shirt, dress shoes
4. No-hole Jeans, No-logo t-shirt
5. Any and everything

Is participation mandatory?

1. Yes
2. No
3. Don't know

How often do you participate?

1. Every chance I get! (~100%)
2. I miss once in awhile, but I'm pretty regular (~75%)
3. About as often as not (~50%)
4. Sometimes (~25%)
5. Never! (0%)

How relaxed do you get?

1. No change
2. Suit
3. Dress/Skirt + Blouse, Khakis + Dress shirt, dress shoes
4. No-hole Jeans, No-logo t-shirt
5. Any and everything

---

Comparing to age/legacy code work would be interesting. If the participant answers, "No" to a question that asks if their employer meets some condition (has policy, has casual Friday) it'd be nice if they didn't have to answer the rest of the associated questions.

Comment: **What is your preferred style/code of dress?** might make a good add-on question. And on a personal note, seriously, when did business casual stop being a slacks and button-down thing? Business formal used to add a tie with an option for vest. Am I the only one discouraged by the downward slide on dress requirements?

Comment: CSS I was under the impression these needed to be multiple choice; your suggested rephrasing would make it open ended. Perhaps I misunderstood the prompt?

@Trobbins Very likely. My company's pretty unconventional from what I've heard from coworkers; when they built the new office ~4 yrs ago, great pains were taken to make the environment feel like a home.

Comment: What about "uniform"? I'm in an office of programmers (in Japan, I must add) and about 80% wear the corporate jacket thing.

Comment: "Uniform" may apply to some students as well, though as phrased this question presumes employment.

Comment: I think a description of clothes is better than the labels, because: a) people might dress smarter than they have to because of social norms b) they might live in a place where "business casual" means something different. It might also be worth asking if they think this is "too formal" or "not formal enough", as that combined with the previous question can tell you more about norms in each country.

Comment: Depending on your answer to the first, the others may not be applicable.

Comment: What's the difference between "any and all" and "no policy"? (I love this question by the way)

Comment: @TylerH He should replace "any and all" with "Don't Be Naked".  No policy means 'undefined'.

Comment: @KevinB, Does the text at end, "If the participant answers, "No Policy" at the beginning, it'd be nice if they didn't have to answer the rest of the questions." not cover that?

Comment: @L_7337 The two are very different. "Any and all" means that the policy expressly grants the right to wear whatever the employee desires. "No policy" means the company doesn't have a stance.

Comment: As it is the question is kind of badly phrased: a) if they have no policy at all (which is common), there is no question to capture that response b)  by "If you have a dress code policy", do we mean "your employer has a policy" c) what if there is no written policy (as is also very common), and you just infer it based on what coworkers typically do, and/or what managers complain about d) what about policies which allow for casual Fridays, or no-meeting Wednesdays or whatever: what does "violate" the policy mean? That makes it sound like coming in in beach shorts of superhero costume

Comment: I like the premise of the question, but I think it should be defined as business (-formal?), business-casual, neat casual (no logos but jeans are allowed), casual (logos are allowed), anything/no policy (rips are fine). Other than that, great set of questions!

Comment: @HunterStevens, Sean's comments above made a compelling argument to the contrary, hence the current state. If you check the edit history, you'll see you and I were of like mind, initially :)

Comment: @smci Violating the policy means exactly that; you dress in a manner proscribed by the policy. So, wearing jeans when you know full well that only khakis are allowed. To curtail thoughts: Asking "do you violate on purpose" isn't as useful (IMO) as inquiring about personal interest in maintaining  proper attire since it moves the focus from "Do you care about how you dress" to "How forgetful are you"

Comment: @FuriousFolder thank you. I just wanted to get my comments out before threads reached the point of no return. I understand the purpose now. However, most women do not wear a "suit". Rather, a dress or slacks with a blazer are equivalent. Maybe we should just use photos as comparison? Or be like "Do you dress like they do on the show Suits?"

Comment: @HunterStevens My intent was for a person who wears suits frequently to see "suit" and ascribe the appropriate meaning. Someone who infrequently wears them will see "suit" and immediately continue to the next option. Saying "most women do not wear a suit" is incorrect: Many women wear pantsuits and skirtsuits.

Comment: @FuriousFolder I apologize. I do not wear suits of any kind. Also, I work in a casual environment. I _assumed_ most women do not wear suits because I do not see them often when shopping. It mostly leans towards fancier blouses, skirts, etc

Comment: @FuriousFolder: most (tech) places **don't** have a written policy, and certainly not one which includes a written list of allowed and prohibited clothes (unless you're in legal or finance). So the concept of "violating" is utterly a gray area: often they simply say "business casual" (or nothing), so if you wear a polo tshirt, is that ok? or work shorts? (does it depend on whether it's 110F and you bike to work?) Since managers will never waste their time complaining in writing about dress code, so how do you know you've "violated", if (say) one coworker suggests your attire is too casual?

Comment: @smci "most (tech) places don't have a written policy, and certainly not one which includes a written list of allowed and prohibited clothes (unless you're in legal or finance). "  I edited the question, several hours ago, to include "No Official Policy". How does this not address the concern you stated previously? Also, please note: "*If the participant answers, "No Policy" at the beginning, it'd be nice if they didn't have to answer the rest of the questions.*"

Answer (score 105):

Describe your current working environment. Select all that apply:

- I have my own office
- I share an office
- I have my own cubicle
- I share a cubicle
- I have dreams of cubicles with walls big enough to share
- Open workspace
- I work from home in my kitchen/lounge/dining room
- I work from home in a dedicated office/spare room

Comment: Perhaps this is pedantry, but some people work from home X days a week and report to the office the other Y days. There woud be 2 or more correct choices in that scenario (And maybe some crazy folks have cubicles at home...).

Comment: Select all that apply then?

Comment: If each scrum team has a glass room with plenty of windows, does that count as 'cubicle', or should there be an extra option?

Comment: I share an office. Still better than cubes.

Comment: Also, nothing to differentiate between a massive bull-pen coding sweatshop and small open offices with a handful of developers

Comment: Aren't cubicles mainly an American thing? I've seen quite a few office buildings in Europe, but in none of them I've encountered cubicles...

Comment: Office has a window or not.  Window is to the outdoors vs. hallway/internior.  Amazingly, I have 2 windows to beautiful mountains and greenery of Upper East Tennessee!

Comment: This is a great question. @McVenco: many European tech companies have cubicles too. Some even fads like opendesking. As you say, there are also offices for managers or senior people as a trapping of prestige.

Comment: @McVenco: Lucent tried to introduce them to their European offices, but the company imploded within a year after doing so. Not entirely a coincidence: both were caused by incompetent management.

Comment: I think the open workspace option should be expanded. I know some companies have OW, but employees share desks, or even computers (pair program).

Answer (score 102):

Most productive hours of the day

A slider bar for range over the 24 hours of day

The same could also be extended to most productive day of week...

Comment: Make sure that slider can be split up because people may have multiple (smaller) ranges.

Comment: This isn't a multiple choice question...maybe checkboxes and hours 0-23 and Sunday through Saturday?

Comment: Make it an option to just put in a github (etc) username and a timezone.

Comment: If you just want to see stats like this, they're available on Github. Unless you think there's something particularly different and interseting about the StackOverflow community compared to the GitHub community.

Comment: @SteveBennett The stats on GH are specific to one user or one project. The surveys' results would be more generalised.

Comment: @SteveBennett GitHub stats are specifically targetted to the GitHub community which is very open source focused. On SO, there are a lot enterprise users which simply don’t contribute to open source (for varying reasons) and as such wouldn’t appear there. Also, I think that a lot people mixing job and open source work (during free time) will shift the statistrics to evening times when they are not at work.

Comment: So my most productive is when no one else is about to interrupt me. That's rarely a timeclock specific time.

Comment: I'm better at creative thinking in the morning, and more routine churning out code in the afternoon. Both are productive. Maybe two questions: which hours are you best at creative thinking, at producing code.

Comment: @SteveBennett Also, considering GitHub only records push and pull times, that doesn't really cover periods of productivity. Sometimes I forget to push something for days at a time and others I push repeatedly trying to get one feature acting properly (for apps with remote databases) and am too lazy to properly set up the necessary resources locally.

Comment: @paulmorriss No idea how you could segregate those like that. My process (between creativity and code production) make a roller coaster ride look like a mild change. I can pound out basic functionality and UI code consistently, but I randomly get hit with sparks of ingenuity and abstract process, which generally only derails me long enough to comment it into existing code. That is, unless I'm feeling particularly "spot on" at the time of inception.

Comment: Many people have none typical sleep patterns. A better slider bar range would be       `[awake ..... sleep]` without certain hours on the day bound to the bar.

Comment: @davidkonrad but that's an implicit assumption that you have no children/family or other obligations, and that you're only either sleeping or coding.

Comment: @smci - and this implicit pattern is worse than to assume you have family and children?

Comment: @davidkonrad: no need for false dichotomies. The question should be constructed to avoid implicit assumptions. Hence, **since the intent was to ask about work hours and productivity, ask directly about those**, don't ask about sleep hours. If you want to ask a question directly about sleep hours (or about non-sleep/non-working hours), you can raise that as a separate question.

Comment: @Bergi I would disagree. My github profile shows very few contributions, because 99% of my work is closed-source private for my job.

Comment: Pity that some of us work in a place which firewall blocks github

Answer (score 97):

What do you normally do during downtime at work e.g. while compiling, uploading, downloading, etc?

- Stack Exchange
- Caffeine
- Social Media
- Daydream
- Read/Write Documentation
- ?

[image]
https://xkcd.com/303/

Comment: “Talk to people/socializing in real-life”?

Comment: @poke Perhaps it is implicitly assumed that programmers wouldn't even consider that option :)

Comment: play online games?

Comment: @poke haha, funny, I get it.

Comment: Have to agree with @Mr_Green...most devs I know have at least 1 WoW account, among myriads of others.

Comment: Swordfighting, obviously. Or (for those in employment) employer-supplied facilities - pool, etc.

Comment: I like this question, but I wonder if it works as a multiple choice question as there are literally infinite things someone can do while their code compiles. Also, do devs have one single thing that they typically do while their code compiles? I suspect lots of us don't have a single typical behavior.

Comment: @samthebrand I was thinking of it as one of the fun questions, much like last year's "How many M&M's are in the jar?"

Comment: There are too many possible answers to that question. I learn physics at kahnacademy or do math for my space tram project. There are just too many options to cover us all.

Comment: I am seriously frightened/weirded out that "chat to coworkers" wasn't even in the option list. Or "go for a walk". Unless "caffeine" is the Dilbert option that comes closest.

Comment: Would online chat rooms or IRC count as social media? I think it can be its own category. This can also be "select all that apply"

Comment: What is this downtime you speak of? When something is taking time I do something else, maybe multiple other things...

Answer (score 86):

**What is your code editor of choice?**

- [Atom](https://atom.io/) (and Atom-based: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/))
- Brackets
- Eclipse (or MyEclipse)
- Emacs (or Spacemacs, etc.)
- IntelliJ IDEA (also: AppCode, PyCharm, WebStorm, Android Studio, PhpStorm, CLion)
- jEdit
- NetBeans
- Notepad++
- Qt Creator
- RAD Studio
- RubyMine
- Sublime Text
- Vim (or Vi, NeoVim, etc.)
- Visual Studio
- Xcode
- Zend Studio
- Other...

*Feel free to edit and add more, guys*

Comment: I added a few, and grouped Vim and Emacs together to maximise antagonism of both groups.

Comment: what about netbeans and zend studio?

Comment: and android studio.

Comment: Damn, i knew someone would have already asked this.

Comment: @mega6382 Wouldn't Zend Studio not only be an addition to Eclipse, like "Eclipse (also: Zend Studio and others)"?

Comment: Would IDLE qualify for this list? I am sure there are some people that use it for python.

Comment: needs more `cat + sed` what's this new fangled interactive text editing thing.

Comment: Sticky notes on Windows vista ftw

Comment: What if I have two favorites? I use Xcode for iOS development, and Atom for web development.

Comment: @insertusernamehere True that.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/378/

Comment: Wait, wait, wait! Vim _slash_ Emacs? Did you just prefix Emacs with Vim? :)

Comment: How about [Brackets](http://brackets.io/)?

Comment: what about Windows Notepad?

Comment: vscode <minimum>

Comment: @Jack - Good god, somebody uses IDLE? I see its value for getting starting/learning/teaching, but once you're comfortable with a command line, I would recommend throwing out the IDE entirely and just using Sublime + a Command Line.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I didn't say I use it. I use Sublime text. I just expect it gets some use.

Comment: I would personally love to see vim and emacs statistics separately on this list!

Comment: Lispworks should be added.

Comment: Code Composer!!

Comment: Add Geany perhaps?

Comment: Let's add "Coda 2" to the list (Mac only)

Comment: frontpage? *evil grin*

Comment: If 2% of C# programmers used Visual Studios, that would tell me interesting (and surprising). If 2% of developers use Visual Studios, not knowing how many C# developers there are and (even if I did) lacking a calculator to hand, I'm not sure what that tells me. **It's too language/environment based to really be interesting in isolation**. The generalists will win (Vim etc), but I'm not sure what we will have learnt.

Comment: EditPlus could be added, a bit old school, but still in use by some.

Comment: @NathanCooper there's bound to be other questions on primary languages used, so if SO wanted to, they could aggregate these two data sets and produce some fancy information, like they did on other sets in previous years.

Comment: @dthree Yeah, okay. In that case this sounds fine.

Comment: I find this one hard to answer because I prefer different editors for different tasks. E.g. Android Studio / IntelliJ for Java / Android work, Atom for web development and Vim for quick scripts.

Comment: No one else written an entire site it notepad?

Comment: Shouldn't be RubyMine grouped with other JetBrains' IDEs under IntelliJ?

Comment: BTW, Wikipedia says vscode is not based on atom, but that's nitpicking I suppose.

Comment: Xcode 7 is not a choice unfortunately

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not based on Atom. They both use Electron.

Comment: No one would write an entire site or application in notepad. They'd use notepad++

Comment: @Underverse you'd be surprised

Comment: No, I wouldn't :-) Not at this stage anyway. Nothing can truly surprise me now. I think. Anyway, I'd call that the 'sadistic' option, however someone has already mentioned Frontpage :P  Now, just for that extra level of pain, imagine writing Windows - as in Windows 10 - in Notepad.

Answer (score 81):

**What was the first programming language you learned?**

And

**What was the first IDE / editor you used for programming?**

Both of these should probably be open fields (Or maybe a list of all available SO tags).
I suspect that the second one will get a lot of "Notepad" votes...

In addition:

**What year did you start programming?**

Comment: Would be interesting to combine with the year they started programming, so that one could see trends. It would mainly be interesting to hear this from new programmers who started programming during the past 5 years or so.

Comment: Great idea! Added :-)

Comment: Notepad/Command Line (DOS prompt), Java, and 2003. Next semester, jumped into Eclipse. Since then, I've been mostly a fan of NotePad++ (since release) and more recently, NetBeans since it does everything Visual Studio does, but equally for all languages.

Comment: `ed` and `WordStar` were my first editors at work.

Comment: What? No love for [ISPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISPF)? Was I the only one?

Comment: Guys, this is just a suggested question, no need to answer them.

Comment: Related to "what year", but how old were you when you started programming (and be sure to differentiate PROGRAMMING a computer vs. USING a computer).

Comment: Would you consider basic html as _programming_? I feel like many younger folks today use that as their first exposure. Also IDK if people would initially consider Notepad as an IDE or tool. I just hope people don't say "MS Word".

Comment: @HunterStevens: While it may not technically "Programming", I'd accept it as an answer. I started with some basic HTML work in notepad.

Comment: I started in 1976, my answers don't have tags.

Comment: @Willeke: Eh? Care to elaborate?

Comment: In 1976 we were taught programming at school. The programming language was ECOL and we used pen & paper and mark sense cards. The cards were sent to another city and the next week we recieved the output on a big piece of paper.

Comment: I can't remember. The first 24 years of programming were at school/university, every 5 years or so. For me to answer you'd need to add "professionally", but that hurts those still at school. What is "starting"?

Comment: Whatever you'd consider "starting". I'd say: Just writing a "Hello world", then forgetting about the language, doesn't count...

Comment: Thanks Willeke. I was going to comment "Don't make it a text field or we'll get into a pissing contest past mainframe cards down to encoding bits onto the disk platter with a magnet"

Answer (score 81):

Do you talk to yourself while programming?

- Yes, and it helps.
- Yes, but it doesn't help.
- I would, but I'm in an environment where I can't.
- No, it just isn't something I do.

Comment: Option required: "only in expletives".

Comment: *"No, I don't. Yes we do! You might, but I stay quiet. Will all of you please shut up?!"*

Comment: _"I used to be schizophrenic, but we're OK now."_ Also _"You're not jealous because the voices talk to me. You're jealous because they listen when I talk to them."_

Comment: Could go Dr. House on this => _"I talk to people who have no idea what I'm talking about. They're like most of the voices inside my head."_

Comment: In all seriousness, though. Yes. All the time. I bounce ideas off the dual (or triple/quad when available) monitors; figuratively and literally.

Comment: Am I weird to think this is weird?

Comment: Does talking to [my rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) count as well?

Comment: Put me down for "Yes, and it helps".

Comment: I think to myself. Does that count? Otherwise I use Stack Overflow chat :D

Comment: wow. This is a relief. I was thinking I've gone crazy programming all these years.

Comment: only to drown out my office mate

Comment: @jmcg, you are going crazy

Comment: @Kirby I guess all the best people are ;)

Comment: I don't talk to myself, but I talk to others, which in turn helps me. #RubberDuckDebugging

Comment: I talk to my computer.

Comment: No, but I listen to music ?

Answer (score 67):

**How willing is your team / company to take on junior or entry-level developers?**

- Unwilling
- For the right candidate, maybe.
- We occasionally take on junior or entry-level devs.
- We regularly take on junior or entry-level devs.
- We are extremely entry-level friendly.

Comment: _"No portfolio, no go. Final answer."_

Comment: People should get at least 5 years of programming experience before seeking a job.

Comment: @GolezTrol If you start in high school and get a four-year degree, that's five years, right?

Comment: I'd be curious to know why the company is/isn't willing to take on entry level developers too.

Comment: Ratio of junior to senior could also be interesting.

Comment: What's the difference between "regularly take on" and "extremely friendly"?

Comment: I do not see this as a great question. It depends on the company and the job market around. Also, some companies differentiate junior from entry-level.

Answer (score 62):

Somewhat related to this [suggested question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278851/2499035)

**What web browser do you most commonly use**

- Chrome
- Edge
- Firefox
- Internet Explorer
- Opera
- Safari
- Yandex
- Other
- Multiple

Comment: I'd like to see this split between what you use in your personal time vs what your employer allows / supports.

Comment: I imagine there are better ways to measure this than a self-reporting survey.

Comment: There is no cutting *Edge* technology here!

Comment: @BhargavRao added it now.

Comment: Mobile (android)/Mobile (iOS)?

Comment: What web browser do you most commonly uninstall in disgust?  (chrome)

Comment: I dont think this is a particularly great question to ask on the SO Dev survey because this information is collected by other sources.

Comment: @DavidGrinberg It's not horrible, considering the myriad JS, PHP, and other web specific language questions posted frequently on SO. It could be forked for 3 questions over a single, however: "use for viewing", "use for development/debugging", and "use for research (SO)". This is because we all favor at least one of these for viewing live code in, generally have to check multiples for consistent formatting, and may even have one that we prefer to research in more than the others. I'm a fan of Chrome in all cases, though.

Comment: What, no [Lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_(web_browser))?

Comment: I made it CW, so please feel free to add any browsers you think would be somewhat common.

Comment: This can already be answered using actual data from server logs.

Comment: @CSS Hard to believe, but not everyone is a web dev… :P

Comment: assert('edge' == 'IE')

Comment: What? No _Sleipnir_?

Comment: You can just measure this while people take the survey. But then again, why would you want to know? I don't think this is a very interesting question. Web developers should use more than one (at least for testing), and for other developers, the browser is relatively unimportant. One might as well ask about favorite text editors, diff tools, paint programs, games and many more, but it's too much detail on what is not core programming software.

Comment: @GolezTrol Tabs vs spaces isn't very interesting either but that gets asked every year.

Comment: That's no reason to add more. Besides, tabs vs spaces at least is related to programming.

Comment: I can't answer this because my strategy is to use multiple desktop browsers, and two mobile ones. I really can't do without three desktop browsers, not just for testing browser specific stuff, but for the concurrent use scenarios of code/test, research/reference, interact, need a fresh browser clear history, firefox for some devtools, chrome for other, Safari for tethered iOS debug. Leaning too much toward any one browser just gets me in trouble. IE is the one that is relegated to test only. For me the better question would be which do you NOT use regularly, or which has the best dev tools.

Comment: s/Firefox/Palemoon/g   - due to Firefox 41 being the last final version before the browser died for the last time.

Comment: While the current browser being used can be collected, assuming that the user agent isn't faked, it does not reflect the web browser most used.

Answer (score 60):

Sometimes, I find that all the technology gets in the way of productivity; and the most basic things (ie, least distractions) provide the most boost.

This question can also be used as a way to find out what things that people think that increase productivity (like standup meetings, open plan offices, etc.) actually work or not.

> Which of these tools do you use to increase your productivity the most? (Maximum of 3 choices)
>
> 1. Multiple monitors
> 2. Ergonomic peripherals (keyboard, mouse)
> 3. Paper and pen/pencil
> 4. Whiteboard
> 5. Furnishings to suit my need (desk, chair, lighting)
> 6. ...

Comment: my gaming mouse helps me a lot, combined with a mouse pad and its all heaven.

Comment: You have to phrase this question more carefully if you only want to know what improves productivity, rather than just what people use.  There's really three questions here: What do you use?  Of what you use, which things increase your productivity?  Of what you don't use, what do you expect would increase your productivity if you used them?

Comment: ...and if you ask all three, you can see if people's "I should do that" expectations match what people actually doing it think.

Comment: ... specifications by the product responsible, ... project plans by the project responsible, ... an IDE instead of Notepad, ... continuous integration, etc.

Comment: Smart furniture. Check out Steel Case's new lines. They do a whole bunch of stuff from mobile desks and chairs that gauge your working height from posture to conference room indicators that let people inside and out know when time is up, to mood lighting within cube walls depending on the pressure you put on them or your connected smart desk (headdesk causes good things, now). It's like you can buy Bill Gates' house for your employees, and it might even make them more productive!

Comment: Do ritalin and caffeine count as tools?

Comment: How about: "how many monitors do you use?"

Comment: I really like this one. I use pen/paper myself. I think calendars/agendas would be a good addition.

Comment: Furniture that fits my size and big headphones.

Answer (score 52):

I think it would be interesting to see what aspects of a job/company culture other developers value most, so...

When looking for a new job, which of the 12 aspects of [the Joel Test](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000043.html) would you consider to be **mandatory** to apply for/accept a position? (Pick all that apply)

- Do you use source control?
- Can you make a build in one step?
- Do you make daily builds?
- Do you have a bug database?
- Do you fix bugs before writing new code?
- Do you have an up-to-date schedule?
- Do you have a spec?
- Do programmers have quiet working conditions?
- Do you use the best tools money can buy?
- Do you have testers?
- Do new candidates write code during their interview?
- Do you do hallway usability testing?

Comment: These answers need to be multiple choice. You can't just use binary/True-False logic. I suggest senary logic. If you've never heard of senary logic it's really quite simple - there are six states, which together successfully model the world on many different levels. These six states are "True", "False", "Maybe", "Sometimes", "I Dunno", and "Screw It, Dude, Let's Go Bowling". Kinda says it all, really...

Comment: @BobJarvis So you're suggesting 12 questions with the same answer set. How are you at marketing? That kind of idea could be a gold mine. =D

Comment: These should definitely be a Likert-scale-style question.

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom Non-negotiability of each of those aspects is binary, and I think that's a lot more useful than knowing that having the best tools money can buy is "somewhat important" to you when considering a job. Plus this is just one question rather than twelve, which I'd probably skip when answering the survey because that scale is literally the worst.

Comment: Just to be tedious, lately most of the best software tools I encounter are free. The Joel list is a list of practices, but it doesn't really cover culture. Culture includes really important stuff like "no lying to clients or employees", "no death march projects", "no caustic and abusive personalities", "no clueless managers". I suspect that if you ask developers you'll find that these are all common problems and more important than Joel's list, though I like Joel's list. I think I even like Joel, based on reading his stuff.

Comment: @joshp I would expect "tools" to also include hardware, and I can't imagine the best hardware you've used lately was free. Obviously culture includes a lot of other things, but I think you can get a rough idea of their attitude towards developers - and therefore how you're likely to be treated as an employee - based on the answers to some of the things covered in the Joel Test. Obviously you'd also need to look at those things in more detail if you did decide to apply and interview with them.

Comment: As a follow-up, which (if any) of the 12 traits does your company follow? (Of course, a student option too)

Comment: @HunterStevens Now we just need to come up with a good question to figure out why there's a difference between the two, in the cases where there is.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sometimes people take a job because it is the only one around. Also, remember that job offers are advertisements. Of course, an employer will leave out the negatives... You will only find out the company doesn't follow your personal whatevers until you've worked there long enough.

Comment: @HunterStevens Right, there's probably too many potential reasons to actually create a question that's worthwhile, and I can't imagine it would be particularly useful data.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Don't get me wrong -- I think this is a good question. But now that I think of it, wouldn't everyone want to follow the 12 points? Maybe, an alternative could be "which _one_ of the 12 are you willing to sacrifice?"

Comment: @HunterStevens They'd *want* to, but for most people I doubt all 12 are going to be non-negotiable deal breakers. Personally, I wouldn't work anywhere that doesn't have testers, that doesn't use source control, that doesn't have a bug database. On the other hand, I can live without having the very best tools money can buy; it would be nice, might even sway me if I was choosing between two jobs, but I'm not going to outright dismiss a job because that's not on the table.

Comment: I'd also have a hard time just picking *one* of the 12 to sacrifice, since there are a couple I could live without. Since most people are probably going to pick more than half with the way the question is currently worded, I guess you could probably flip the polarity of the initial question to reduce the number of options they have to select.

Comment: I think what you can live without is more telling.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Of course hardware is not free, but with free tools, cheaper hardware, virtualization, aws, the decision facing managers today is dramatically easier financially than the time when Joel made the list. The list feels dated in a few places. So just not my preference for where to spend the time. And it's really not about what's important in culture. It's about infrastructure and methods, which reflect indirectly on culture. All a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 48):

What point in time of product development do you write test cases.

1. Right from the beginning
2. Somewhere in the middle of Start-Date and Beta Release
3. When the program appears to be working fine.
4. After product release
5. Never at all, for they are for the weak.
6. What are test cases?

Comment: When the program appears to be working fine.

Comment: Any time you have some process working (producing a result of some kind).

Comment: After someone asks to see your tests

Comment: Sometimes it's right from the beginning, but not necessarily TDD.

Comment: _I don't always test my code, but when I do, it's in production._

Comment: *"What are test cases?"* option is missing

Answer (score 47):

**Are you aware that all content you contribute to Stack Overflow (which includes code) is licensed under Creative Commons BY-SA (3.0)?**

- Yes.
- Yes, but I have no idea what that means.
- No, I was not aware.
- What are you talking about?

(Suggested it [in 2014](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278914/1591669) and [in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209869/193139).)

Comment: Wait, who is the author? Is it me or SO?

Comment: @DanielCheung: I don’t understand … what do you mean?  -- If you post content on SO, you (as you are the author) license it under CC BY-SA 3.0.

Answer (score 44):

#### How often do you reach the [flow state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) while programming?

- I'm always in the zone!
- Multiple times a day
- Once a day
- Multiple times a week
- Once a week
- Multiple times a month
- Once a month
- Few times a year
- Even more rarely
- I've never reached it

Comment: Might want to expand to "Multiple times a week", "multiple times a month", and "Once a year" to include those that might not find a consistent flow state. Could also include "I'm *always* in the zone!" for those that...well don't ever stop while awake.

Comment: *never enough*...

Comment: @CSS: Thank you for your feedback. I added the options you mentioned as well as extra _Even more rarely_ to cover all the possible answers.

Answer (score 43):

What recently new language would you learn more about and play with, if you had a couple extra hours every day?

- Rust
- Go
- Dart
- Scala
- Groovy
- Kotlin
- [CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript)
- [TypeScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TypeScript)
- None. Dahm kids and your languages, get off my lawn!

Comment: What recently new language would you wish to hear less about? a) Haskell, b) Haskell, c) Haskell, d) All the above.

Comment: @BhargavRao 'A Sieve of Eratosthenes benchmark, computing all prime numbers less than 65536, was tested on a Sun SPARCstation 1. In C, it took less than half a second; the same program in INTERCAL took over seventeen hours'. So, faster than Ruby, then :)

Comment: @Martin No wonder we have to say, *PLEASE GIVE UP* :D

Comment: Can I say you might want to add PolymerJS to the list? New HTML elements, you gotta be kiddin' me! Also, loving CoffeeScript.

Comment: What are the criteria for including a language in the list?

Comment: @CSS, isn't polymer a library?

Comment: @CSS Polymer is a web framework more than it is a language

Comment: @kdbanman It is, but it's so great it should be its own language. Nah, I'm just kidding, but it **is** pretty sweet.

Comment: Instead of listing the languages, how about the question is an open-ended text field? For example, I'm not very interested right now in any of the languages you listed, but I would like to learn more about how to use the Unity gamedev engine, which is close enough to a programming language that I'd submit it if I could.

Comment: @Kevin that would be fine I guess. It said put it in multiple choice format, so that's what I did, but your suggestion works as well.

Comment: This could easily become indefinite. There'd be options like node, elixir, erlang, swift and what not...

Comment: @MartinJames: Haskell might be recent, but it's not new.

Comment: What would I do about that languages that I already *did* learn in those extra hours?

Comment: Haskell is probably one the most commonly mentioned language in job ads (eg. Bonus points if you dabble in Haskell, Scala, or other FP language).  Good luck finding a job that is actually hiring someone to write code in those languages.

Comment: Y U no mention Elixir???

Comment: If you are a web/desktop developer, which of the following branches of programming are you aware of? a) Web/desktop development b) Web/desktop development c) Web/desktop development

Comment: @MartinJames - I thought they said "recent". Haskell's been around for 25 years now. Gosh and golly - where *does* the time go..?

Comment: Keep meaning to get around to this `python` thing but it's a bit too new-fangled.

Comment: Is Groovy a new language?  Between Scala and Clojure I thought it had seen its better days.

Comment: I think we should only mention new languages, less than 5 years. And nodejs isnt a language. Kotlin, Dart, GoLang should get some attention here. Which is good!

Comment: Swift is new. I can code in it but not as smoothly or naturally as I do in Objective-C. So yup I'd like to spare a few hours and learn it properly.

Answer (score 41):

Which new feature of Stack Overflow were you impressed the most with:

- Teams
- New Nav
- Docs
- New profile looks
- None
- ***What!!! There were new features?***

---

<sub><sub>Or the fact that [Stack Exchange became Stack Overflow again](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)</sub></sub>

Comment: Hehe @canon That means the SO Devs will start to feel sad :D

Comment: Well, if I had any actual experience of the new features, I guess I could have a go at voting.

Comment: Has the new area (Stack Documentation?) been released yet? that might be something worth throwing on the list.

Comment: @CSS Though it isn't released, we've almost got a clear picture of how it might be like through the many different posts by the SO devs.  (Therefore I've added it in the list, please feel free to edit it.)

Comment: You forgot the 'What new features?' option :)

Comment: Now @anotherdave That is a good addition!

Comment: @canon: Yup. You should start taking bets.

Comment: As much as I want to put SO's recent ventures (as in "venture capital") to a referendum, I think the Developer Survey is intended to have a wider audience than the people reading meta posts and participating in private betas.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom True. Perhaps we can add another option like they did last time. *I don't use SO, I just participate in surveys*. :-).

Comment: Teams and Docs are not released yet, so how can I be impressed by something I've never seen?

Comment: @Thomas Teams are [released](http://stackoverflow.com/teams). Please refer to my previous [comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey/310338?noredirect=1#comment271438_310338) to answer your other question. Thanks.

Comment: Can you answer [this question then](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310460/how-do-i-create-a-team)?

Comment: I never heard of any of the features. And when I look, Teams is in Beta (@BhargavRao, that's not "released", unless SO treats Beta as different), it's *barely* being used (only 132 "teams", many of which only contain one member(!!)), and no person or company I know is using it. So, obscure and hardly-used.

Comment: @smci Sure. The SO teams will usually check all these before making the survey. Cheers :)

Answer (score 38):

How many times do you get interrupted during work day while working on something, being forced to switch to something else.

- Barely
- Couple of times a day
- Its mostly like that

Comment: _"Does it count if I ignore it?"_

Comment: This is the question I was looking for, as I'm plagued by constant interruptions and it really affects my productivity (nobody else seems to have picked up on it but I know it's happening).

Answer (score 38):

**What time do you usually wake up on workdays?**

(24-hour selector)

Comment: Probably should add another slider for when you go to sleep. There have been days when I didn't sleep, though, and those are the longest weeks (weekends) of your life.

Comment: Somewhere between 06:00 and 8:30. *Too broad. ;)

Comment: and a follow up question, what time are you supposed to be at work?

Comment: In our house, it's more a case of "What time do you get woken up, every day".  Kids, eh....

Answer (score 34):

**How many Hours a week do you spend programming (paid & unpaid)?**

<20

20-29

30-40

>40

**How many StackExchange sites do you use?**

1

2-10

11-29

30-69

70-99

100-125

>125

Or you can make the list a little shorter

Comment: Site usage stats could be collected automatically for participants willing to have their responses associated with their profile.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It wouldn't accurately reflect the true disposition of the survey's participants, though. I spend all week on SQL (though rarely on SO) and my nights are almost equally divided between JavaScript, PHP, and various forms of Java, C#, and Visual Basic. I probably do about 80 hours of coding and thinking about coding, but I've only got 4 questions and 26 answers on SO. I'm only 4 months old here, but I've been this consistent for about 5 years.

Comment: @CSS I think it would accurately answer "How many sites do you use?", as well as giving a breakdown of _which_ sites specifically.  I wouldn't expect it to answer the first question ("How many hours...").

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Ahh, that would be my disconnect. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'd rephrase "do you use" to "do you participate in" personally. I read around 2 or 3 other sites in the SE network, however I don't participate in them and therefore have never logged in.

Comment: Also, would a site plus its meta count as one or two?

Answer (score 30):

**How did you discover your current job?**

- Applied via a Job Board
- Email or In app message from a recruiter
- Personal Introduction
- Job Fair, Meetup, or Hackathon

Comment: I would add posted resume (Or similar) online to a site like SO careers, Monster, etc.

Answer (score 29):

How do you commute to work/school?  If you use multiple modes of transport (either together or on different days), choose all that apply.

- by foot/walking
- by bicycle
- by car
- by motorcycle
- by mass transit (bus, subway, train)
- by boat/ferry
- by airplane
- I work from home

Comment: Programmers have a reputation for liking to commute by bike more than most; let's see how many do.  (If you include both this question and the physical exercise question, you might note that walking or bicycling may count as exercise.)

Comment: Of course. It's all about efficiency. If I cycle to work in an hour, while public transport would take 40 minutes, I basically get an hour of exercise, while wasting just 20 minutes.

Comment: You're forgetting motorcycles.

Comment: *by airplane* - There was a woman with one of my prior employers who did commute by plane. Is this more common than I think? Because I assumed that was an edge case.

Comment: @BSMP I was thinking of airline employees. Outside of them I wouldn't expect it to be common.

Comment: biclycle include roller skates?

Comment: @jasilva I think roller skates are closer to walking than bicycling, even though they involve wheels. But I've never used them.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I really not sure, but my friend ever used it

Comment: Do we also need [pedelecs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pedelec)?

Comment: Uni wheel electric scooter? Hoverboard? Teleport? Work? Wheelchair / Crutches?

Answer (score 26):

**If you develop software professionally and you aren't you own employer, are you satisfied with your salary?**

- Yes, it's awesome!!
- Yes, it's not bad at all, certainly better than average
- It's ok
- No, it could certainly be better
- No, it's ridiculously low and I am seriously considering changing jobs

Perhaps the wording is not the most appropriate but you get the idea.

Comment: Who is ever satisfied with their salary? ;-)

Comment: This question will give us the answer! :-)

Comment: If my mortgage was paid off and I had a Tesla, I'd probably be satisfied with my current salary for the rest of my life (adjusting for inflation). As is, I wish it were higher so I could get closer to accomplishing both of those things sooner.

Answer (score 24):

**I've made this answer Community Wiki, with the intent of capturing issues with the old surveys in one "answer". Please comment or edit. I'll help to maintain this answer as the "improvement suggestion" answer.**

This isn't so much a new question, but suggestions for improving old questions, should they be reused this year. Thinking back to last year and reviewing the old survey results, I found three sections that had significant issues and should be reworked.

## Educational Information

The level education question is somewhat unclear. First, it neglected an explicit inclusion for people who have a [Bachelor of Arts in Computer Science](http://www.soic.indiana.edu/undergraduate/degrees-certificates/ba-computer-science/) or [Master of Arts in Computer Science](http://www.brandeis.edu/programs/computerscience/masters/9-course-ma.html). I've also noticed that there is an increase in free courseware and free "boot camp" style courses.

My recommendations for an education question would be about the highest level of education obtained:

- Self-taught, including free online educational programs
- On-the-job training
- Industry certification program
- Boot-camp program
- Some college or university coursework, but did not complete a degree program
- Completed a degree program (at any level) in an unrelated field
- Completed undergraduate degree in computer science or related field
- Completed graduate degree in computer science or related field
- Completed doctoral studies in computer science or related field
- Other

## Technologies

The technologies questions should be broken out by languages, frameworks, and tools. For example, in last year's survey, the most dreaded contained "Visual Basic", "Wordpress", and "Matlab". But it doesn't give that much information. Was it Sharepoint development that was terrible, or just the fact that your company used Sharepoint and you hate it? The correct answer is that Sharepoint is just plain bad, but that's beside the point.

I don't know if the prework is feasible, but from a data perspective, if lots of people love working with Ruby but hate Rails, that can give useful information to people that maybe if they want to keep Ruby developers happy, they'll use a framework other than Rails. I don't mean to pick on Ruby and Rails here, but it was the best concrete example I could come up with.

I'd also generally like to see more inclusive tool questions. For example, the text editor question didn't include IDEs. I think it would be more useful to ask about what tools you use to write code in.

## Occupation and Industry

This is a big hole in the survey. I didn't know how to answer it.

First, there needs to be a differentiation between "role" and "occupation". For example, my occupation is software engineer. But I have many roles - I'm a software developer, I'm a software tester, I'm a software process engineer, I'm a project lead.

Second, it's missing an entire level of management. You have "student" roles, "developer / administrator" technical roles, and "executive" roles. This is totally missing engineering management / front-line management style roles.

I just generally think that all of the occupation / roles questions need to be reworked to address who developers are and what they do.

The industry section is also extremely lacking. For example, my company's parent company is a conglomerate. My company (business unit) is aerospace. My segment is aerospace and defense. None of these were valid choices in 2015. Automotive was another industry that was clearly lacking. The fact that "Other" was 20% of the survey seems to be an issue - what were those others and how should they be broken down?

Comment: this is very helpful. Thanks for your sharp memory.

Comment: @samthebrand Also, just as an aside, "other" for a lot of questions makes sense, but only if you provide a text field. Then, for the next year, look at what people wrote for other and adjust your values. For time based ranges, it doesn't make sense. But for any selection values (including multiple selection), it does as other could possibly feed what default values you provide. Not sure if the other data is available for 2014 and 2015's questions that had it as an option.

Comment: Yeah we're looking at this Thomas. There are some pretty obvious fixits from last year (ie. $10k was lowest salary category when there are lots of devs who make less than that), but some aren't so easy. The tech vs. lang vs. framework question, for instance, is particularly tough given all the options and categories. I thought it turned out pretty well last year all things considered, but open to suggestions.

Comment: @samthebrand I'm going to be thinking about it. Not sure if I'll have any answers. Maybe someone out there will, though. Thanks.

Comment: Did the survey have any way of noting non computing/IT degrees? (ie. my degree is animation but now I work as a developer). Given the multiple approaches to training I think this could be interesting info.

Comment: **EDUCATION**: (1) Should we include "associates in computer science or related?" (2) What if work on the job (or self-training) taught me more than formal education? (3) Would on-the-job then be considered "highest level?" Same goes with some college, but with bootcamp. **TECHNOLOGIES**: Great points. **OCCUPATION**: (1) I would say "title vs role" instead. (2) I agree that "other" fields should be expanded upon. Maybe There can be other1, which is a dropdown list of other fields (taken from Glassdoor or something), and other2 which is something that was not provided.

Comment: @HunterStevens re:Education. I'm not sure how wide spread the equivalent of an Associates degree is. I would just perhaps group that into "undergraduate education", perhaps? As far as highest level, I would consider a degree to be "more than" on the job training. But that's something that would be debatable. Perhaps this should be "check the boxes for what you have"?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I think it should be "check all that apply," for that reason. I have some college, self-training, and on-the-job training. I would rank the latter two as higher, because I did not learn Ruby in college. As far as an associates, I guess that can go under "some undergrad", because AA/AS programs are 2 years of a 4yr program.

Answer (score 22):

In 2015, there were many questions about remote work.

## **How do you share your progress with your teammates?**

- Public git/svn cloud repo (like free github repo)
- Private git/svn cloud repo (like private bitbucket repo)
- Own git/svn repo server (like gitblit)
- Email Zip/Rar files
- Cloud files manager (like box, dropbox, etc)
- IM app (like skype)
- Private app focus in project management
- Flash drive

Comment: GitHub offers private repos and Bitbucket offers public repos, so I'm not sure why they're listed as examples in the first two bullet points.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom yes of course, but they are known to be more open and commercial respectively, may not be necessary to add the examples in the final survey, but thank you for your comment

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for edit, I imagined a remote environment, but perhaps the question could be divided into two questions, remotely and locally

Answer (score 20):

**How do you receive your requirements?**
*(Select all that apply)*

1. Verbal Only (discussed functionality)
2. Visual (some screenshots / power points / pdfs)
3. Written (list of requirements, functional / business)
4. Functional (a working mockup)
5. Extensive (requirements captured more extensively than the options provided)
6. Other

The **purpose** behind this question is to find out the depth of requirements developers are receiving.

I am open to changing the answerable options as long as they adhere to the purpose.

Comment: Maybe "How do you **prefer** to receive your requirements?", which is similar to "How do you learn best when confronted with a new concept?"

Comment: The purpose of the question is to see what kind of requirements other developers are receiving not to find out how they learn best. So making that change would conceptually change the purpose of the question.

Comment: I would add some sort of requirement database (IE, Doors).

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto, I am not familiar with that product. Would this be the same as putting requirements in Confluence? To me if they are putting written requirements into the product it would still be covered by #3. I have never used a requirements specific piece of software, is there something unique about its functionality that I should capture. To me someone could select that as an option if they are using Confluence or Sharepoint but still could only be receiving visual or written requirements. I am trying to find the depth of the requirements received.

Comment: I assume Confluence is the same kind of thing. Sharepoint is somewhat different, that's a version management system for an entire file, as opposed to a database.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto, I have updated the answers to better reflect the purpose. Do you still feel it would be a valid option? If you provide a valid relevant option I do not mind adding it.

Comment: If you are using a database to keep track of requirements, it implies a fairly extensive set of requirements. So yes, I would still include it.

Comment: I think this question would be better formatted as a "select all that apply" multi-checkbox.  Then you don't have to enumerate all the possible combinations.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto, I have updated the answers to include an "Extensive" option which should cover the database driven options and I would assume requirements tightly tied to programmers unit tests and QA's tests. Ideally I would assume they have some type of system integration but I have not worked with any such system personally. Is this an acceptable addition that covers the need?

Comment: @ryanyuyu, I am not sure if they support the "select all that apply" but I modified the question to assume so. I originally wanted to do this but wasn't sure if it was supported. i honestly do not remember last years survey. Thanks for the nudge :)

Answer (score 20):

Does your employer invest in your professional development? Please check all that apply:

- **Yes - my employer will pay/reimburse**:

  1. tuition, regardless of course of study
  2. tuition for coursework **related to my current position**
  3. cost of workshops/conferences
  4. cost of learning materials (online courses, MOOCs, books, etc.)
  5. cost of certification
  6. cost of membership in professional organizations
- **Yes - inhouse**: my employer provides training materials and courses
- **Partially**: my employer has some of these benefits but not for employees in my position
- **No**: my employer does not do any of the above
- **Not applicable**: I am unemployed, self-employed, retired, etc.
- **Don't know**

Comment: Maybe add an option for don't know / doesn't apply / positions where it is not really defined?

Comment: Interesting question, but a bit too much text to be effective.

Comment: @Jeroen - My intent was to give enough information so it was clear what I meant by each option, but I agree that it's too text heavy. I've cut it down to something I would expect to see in the actual survey.

Comment: @Jeroen, I edited it down further and summarize each option in bold

Comment: BSMP: both for *"1. tuition, regardless of course of study 2. related to my current position"*, there is almost always a cap on tuition reimbursement annual and/or per-course, I've seen between US$3,000-30,000/yr. This prevents people funding their MBAs and PhDs. Also, larger expenditure like that is typically subject to manager/"business case" approval, and often comes with golden handcuffs (a pro-rated or full clawback clause if you leave within say 24 months)

Comment: and for *"3. cost of workshops/conferences"*, it's often restricted by "you must be presenting"

Comment: @smci - True, but I don't think making separate options for capped/uncapped tuition makes sense since it's almost always capped. I put in the two different options for whether or not the coursework had to be related to your current job because I thought it'd be interesting to see how many employers are willing to invest in employees who want to change fields.

Comment: I'm of two minds on adding separate options for conferences in general vs conferences where you're presenting. The latter feels like to doesn't really count as the employer investing in the employee as much as them acknowledging that their employees presenting at conferences helps the company. That makes it more of a marketing/business expense for them rather that purely professional development. On the other hand, maybe that's why there should be two choices.

Answer (score 19):

**Has your Stack Overflow profile/reputation helped you in your job search/career?**

- It's helped my career
- It's hurt my career
- It's had no impact on my career

Comment: How would you know if the reputation/profile helped your prospective employer make a decision?

Comment: I guess you really wouldn't, but some employers do ask for your Stack Overflow profile during the interview/hiring process (or so I've heard).

Comment: @KevinB I got my current job through SO, so I’d guess I could give a clear answer to that ;)

Comment: Then maybe better as a companion question: ***"If you use SO to assess a candidate, what do you consider to be positive and negative things to look for in a candidate's SO behavior/usage?"***

Answer (score 18):

(Based on [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310358/4771017) and feedback to [my comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey/310358#comment271633_310358))

How many programming languages do you think you have you 'learned' for the sake of a project / hobby and then forgotten / never used again?

Alternate phrasing per [@BobJarvis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey#comment271873_310358):

"How many programming languages have you learned that you haven't used at all for the past three years?"

Comment: Does this include college projects?

Comment: @Ryan, that's a good question and I'll leave it up to discussion. I believe adding college projects definitely inflates the numbers. In that regard I think it would be better to lean towards BobJarvis 's "for the past X years" though that would still include recent college grads.

Comment: I'd include all the languages you had to learn in order to pass a class and then hope you never, ever see again.

Comment: I've worked with more than 20, but the few I don't ever want to see again are mainframe and compiler languages. I've even decided that VB/VBA isn't so bad after swimming in Natural code for a year and a half. I'm just as competent with all of them now as I was when I left the position I was introduced to them in, and I'm a lot better with some of them, now, even though I don't use them in the project I'm on. Hooray for going back to school!

Comment: a) Is this question asking for a number, not a list, which seems meaningless: "7!" vs "23!"?

Comment: b) For the sake of focus and excluding laundry lists of stuff taught in colleges, clones like Octave, and complaints about Haskell, I'd cut this down to ***"In the last three years, which specific programming languages have you learned for work/projects and then forgotten / never used again?"***

Comment: great feedback @smci, I agree with your rephrasing. I honestly haven't put much thought into the question myself, so I'm happy to see criticism. 

This question may not fare well as a multiple choice question without becoming too verbose.

Answer (score 17):

Which of the following statements is true about your most active (Highest Scored) tag within Stack Overflow? (Multiple choice)

- I professionally teach this skill.
- I use this skill professionally every day.
- I previously used this skill professionally every day.
- I occasionally use this skill professionally, but have not used it on a daily basis.
- I am self-taught with this skill.
- I am not yet proficient, and want to learn more.
- I am studying it in school.
- I am using it to making personal projects.
- I want to make a career transition using the skill.

Comment: The idea behind this is that I know personally my highest tag is a language I've never used in a professional setting, and I'm curious to see what brings people to a particular tag.

Comment: My most active tag is php, but I haven't used it very frequently in the past year(s). Perhaps there should be a 'i used to' option in there or something.

Comment: @Bono Added a few more options, does that look better?

Comment: I still program professionally every day, just not PHP which is my most active tag. So I still can't pick a correct option! :p

Comment: @Bono: Good point. I avoided adding "Using this language" to everything, but I think there's a case for something. How's the latest iteration?

Comment: Yeah that's a lot better! :)

Comment: Most active, or highest scored.

Answer (score 16):

Do you use a standing desk?

- Yes, I stand all of the time.
- Yes, I stand most of the time, but sometimes sit.
- Yes, I stand some of the time, but mostly sit.
- No, but I would use one if my employer/school would buy one for me.
- No, I'm fine with always sitting.

Comment: At my office a lot of people have split desks. Half of it is sitting, the other half is raised to standing. Both are mounted to the wall and don't easily move. Instead, when people want to switch, they move all of their I/O devices from one half of the desk to the other. Seems to be a rather cost effective solution.

Answer (score 15):

**How Knowledgeable In Software Development / Programming Are The People You Report To In Your Organization ?**

1. Excellent
2. Good
3. Average
4. Poor
5. Clueless

Comment: I feel like it'd be a good idea to cross this question with another one, such as "How pleasant are the people you report to in your organization?"... Something like that. So we could see if there's any sort of correlation between liking your boss and how well your boss can program.

Comment: This means nothing really  unless we know what level you're at and who you report to. "The People You Report To In Your Organization" could be an intermediate devpr, a mgr, director, VP, CXO, chief software architect... so really this is just indirectly asking where you are on whatever passes for a technical ladder at your employer. Equivalently stated "Are you the most senior technical person in your chain of command?"

Comment: Think before you speak.

Answer (score 14):

How many minutes per day do you spend searching for answers to coding problems encountered on the job, whether online or in text books?

- Less than 15 minutes
- 16-30 minutes
- 31-60 minutes
- more than 60 minutes
- **Most of the Day!**

Comment: On my own problems or SO problems?

Comment: @Matt, He said *...on the job...* so that would depend if you are really working for SO or not. Because then SO problems will also count. :D

Comment: What about answering other’s SO questions while on the job?

Answer (score 14):

**Which is your dominant hand?**

- Left
- Right
- I'm ambidextrous

This would be interesting in and of itself (to me), but especially so when combined with job title data (e.g. do more left-handed people tend to be designers/right-handed people tend to be in data-oriented jobs), and just to see, in general, if a disproportionate number of people are left-handed compared to the general world estimates.

Comment: You missed an answer: "I don't have hands, I'm a unicorn." (In all seriousness, I've met a programmer without hands... He used text-to-speech, and amazingly well.)

Comment: @Kendra I seriously considered adding that but thought I'd avoid levity since I'm sure there are plenty of answers already that include joke options.

Comment: Left handed and I hate design work :P

Answer (score 14):

How social would you consider yourself?

- **Extremely extroverted**: Life of the party. I love attention.
- **Fairly extrovert**: Parties are fun. I like attention.
- **Slightly extroverted**: Parties are fine. I don't mind attention.
- **Slightly introverted**: Parties are fine. I'm not a fan of attention.
- **Fairly introverted**: Parties are forgettable. I do not like attention.
- **Extremely introverted**: Parties are agonizing. I hate attention.

Answer (score 13):

How many programming languages you actively use?

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4+

Note: Here actively means you code at least something or the other every day or at least every alternate day.

Comment: Do javascript frameworks (like [tag:angular-js]) count?  And why such a strict definition of "active"?  I'm a not-quite-full-stack web developer, so sometimes I write server-side code for a week, and then go right back to client-side code.

Comment: I don't think  angular-js can be counted as a language because if we include that then it would mean counting some similar frameworks like node.js, backbone and many other as separate language which would be wrong. And as far as "activeness" is concerned what I mean to say is you have hands-on experience of it and know it well. Not like something you have learned in high school and don't remember how to use it now.  @ryanyuyu

Comment: By this definition of "actively", my answer would be zero.

Answer (score 11):

## **Which other Q&A sites do you use besides the StackExchange network?**

**Options**

> - [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)
> - [Yahoo Answers](https://answers.yahoo.com/)
> - [Ask.fm](http://ask.fm/)
> - [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/)
> - [ExpertExchange](http://www.experts-exchange.com/)
> - [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) (some subreddits)
> - Other
> - None

Fell free to edit and include more sites. I based my options in [this Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Q%26A_sites) and just chose some of most famous sites, IMHO.

**Why This question?**

Basically, for curiosity.
However, as pointed by @smci in the comments, getting this information annually it's possible see trends and then the own Stack Exchange could incorporate great features based in this trends.

Comment: There are other Q&A sites?

Comment: There are definitely more. ExpertExchange, obviously, since that's the nemesis of StackExchange. There's some other small ones I've heard of but I can't think of them off the top of my head right now...

Comment: @James: if you compile this annually, you can see trends.

Comment: Would Reddit be an acceptable answer? I've found some of their subreddits to be very helpful.

Comment: Personally, I don't consider reddit as a Q&A site (it's more like a forum to me), but it's added like suggested.

Answer (score 11):

### How many cups of Coffee do you drink on a normal workday?

- I don't regularly drink coffee.
- One cup
- Two cups
- Three cups
- Four cups
- Five or more cups

Comment: Is this different from the ["caffeinated beverages" question last year](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-caffeine)?

Comment: Actually, I think so. Because not everyone drinks coffee, it would be interesting to know what portion of the SO community does so. In the places I have worked, coffee seems likes a staple to the developer's diet.

Answer (score 10):

> Assuming you are a professional (gets paid for programming) developer, do you use any kind of *agile* process or methods at work?
>
> - Yes
> - No
> - N/A

Maybe this can be broken down into SCRUM and KANBAN or Waterfall, V-Model etc... but I think a general yes/no might be a good first start.

Comment: *Thinks waterfall is an agile process

Comment: -1. self taught (often seen as not professional) and student can also use processes and methods, be them agile or else, while working!

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier "Professional" is someone who receives money for their programming. Which means he should pick the method that *works*, not the one he *likes*. There's a big difference between how I work at work and at home.

Comment: Instead of the word "professional", I would say program with a team. And instead of just using agile, I would include a list of similar methodologies, or perhaps methodologies related to agile.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto I appreciate your input, but personally, I'm not interested in teams that don't have any financial pressure to perform.

Comment: Should there be a N/A option for SO users who aren't professional developers or should they skip the question altogether?

Comment: @BSMP I guess.. I will edit that.

Comment: You forgot Scrumerfall

Answer (score 10):

I think it would be interesting to talk a bit about overtime work this time. We all know how it works in companies we or our friends work at, but I wonder what's the global situation.

**1. How often do you work overtime?**

- Always (Every month, multiple times)
- Usually (Several times in a few months)
- Sometimes (Once or twice in few months)
- Rarely (Few times a year)
- Never
- I don't work (I'm a student, unemployed, etc.)

**2. How often is overtime work paid?**

- Always
- Usually
- Sometimes
- Rarely
- Never
- I don't know*

*(this option can be used by those who never worked overtime, so that they don't pick something at random and change the resulting statistics that way)

Answer (score 9):

Which is your preferred method of reading documentation or other technical references?

1. On my laptop/desktop/tablet/e-reader
2. As a book/printed paper
3. As an online wiki (with user comments)

The goal here is to find out what people actually use for reading documentation; so that if there is a need to develop documentation, should developers concentrate on printing regular books or electronic formats are preferred.

Comment: I'd love to try out Warlords of Documentation.

Comment: 4. I don't read documentation

Comment: @KevinB 5. I am the documentation.

Answer (score 9):

**What aspects of a company's culture are most important to you when looking for a job?** [Choose 3]

- Flexible working hours
- Perks
- Benefits
- Low turnover
- Great leadership
- Etc.

Comment: Any example....

Answer (score 9):

**How would you classify your employer?**

- A company whose main products are software tools, applications,
  or websites
- A company whose main products are NOT software tools, applications and websites
- A consulting agency
- I am a freelancer
- I own my own business
- A non-tech company
- Academia
- I work in education (K-12, training and vocational schools, etc.)
- I am a student
- I am unemployed or don't work in IT

Here's what I'm shooting for:

I'd like to see this data cross referenced with salary, job satisfaction, etc. You always hear how great it is to work for Facebook and Google. I'm trying to find a way to categorize these employers or, perhaps, the type of work. This might be another way to look at it:

**What do you work on?**

- I work on THE product(s) that generate revenue (e.g. Google, LinkedIn, McAfee etc.)
- I work on a system IN a product (e.g. embedded system in cars, smart appliances, etc.)
- I work on internal systems (e.g. Intranet Web App, Internal DB Admin)
- I AM the product (consulting agency, freelancer)
- I teach/research

Comment: a tech company unrelated to software tools applications and websites?

Comment: @KevinB I think that makes sense. Got an example?

Comment: An electronics manufacturer. While they may have web developers/IT staff that handle their network and corporate website, the company's main products aren't software tools applications or websites (even though they may occasionally release one.)

Comment: @KevinB I like it. I can see a lot of gray area still so if others want to help refine, that would be helpfult.

Comment: I freelance?????

Comment: @James_Parsons I was thinking I should add that to consulting agency because you effectively own your own business. However, I think I'd like to see the salary breakdowns against this data so I added it separately. Thoughts?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Does it make sense to combine freelancer and business owner?

Comment: By "higher education", do you specifically mean teaching, or are you including research institutions?  I'm a PhD student at MIT, so under the question's current phrasing I'd pick "company whose products are not software..."; MIT's main products are research papers and the occasional startup.  Change "higher education" to "academia" and I'd pick that, though.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Not sure as I didn't add that. I've updated per your suggestions.

Answer (score 8):

### What time do you usually go to sleep on workdays?

(24-hours selector)

### What is your average time of sleep on workdays?

### What is your average time of sleep during weekends?

### Do you take naps during workday?

Answer (score 8):

Who tests your code, and how? (Select more than one)

- Quality Assurance (or another team) writes the integration tests.
- Quality Assurance (or another team) writes the unit tests.
- Quality Assurance (or another team) performs manual tests.
- Development writes the integration tests.
- Development writes the unit tests.
- Development performs manual tests.
- There is no formal testing requirement, but we manually test our code.
- There is no formal testing requirement and we do not manually test our work.

If it's another team that tests your code besides Quality Assurance, who are they? (Write-in)

Comment: What about "There is no formal testing requirement, but we write integration and unit tests and use automated fuzz testing"?  At least, whether there is a formal testing requirement seems orthogonal to the other questions.

Answer (score 8):

**Do you use any coding competition sites? If yes, select which one.**

- HackerRank
- CodeChef
- TopCoder
- Dev Wars
- Project Euler
- USACO
- uVa
- Other (please suggest)
- No

Wanting to find out if these websites are only used for younger people to help them secure jobs or is it used by developers of all ages. I'm not sure if the age brackets I included are the best, so if you want to suggest better age brackets, feel free to do so.

Comment: The age question should just be a separate question. The other 2 can be combined into one question.

Comment: @Cerbrus altered the question, hope it's better now?

Comment: The age question should still be unrelated to the coding competitions one, but yes, better.

Comment: @Cerbrus I'm keen to find out what age people are who use the coding competition websites, that's why I included it. Mainly because I'm wondering if people go on them as a hobby or if they do it to prepare themselves for interviews for jobs.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean the age question is related to these competition sites. It should just be a completely separate question in the survey.

Comment: I'll take it out, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Is Project Euler a "coding competition site"?  I do occasionally get recruiters contacting me based on it.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom added it to the list thanks!

Comment: I would add USACO, uVa and many others that are in the Internet for more than 10 years.

Comment: @NikolayKostov added! Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

**Do you have a link to your SO profile on your LinkedIn / CV?**

- Yes
- No
- Not applicable

I'm mostly curious whether people advertise their profiles when job hunting, and would also be interesting in seeing how that correlates with a user's reputation. Are high-rep users more or less likely to advertise themselves?

I'm not sure how to word this question for people who are not looking for work though.

Answer (score 7):

**How often/thorough do you test and/or document your code?**

(could perhaps be split in two separate questions)

- Testing? My code doesn't need testing/documentation...
- I just write the code. Testing/documenting is other people's work.
- I only do some simple on the fly debugging / leave a few comments in the code here and there.
- I write/run extended tests / make full documentation of my code
- Other

Maybe it can use some more steps in between?

Comment: Maybe make it clear whether *Testing/documenting is other people's work* is something formally set up by the company (there are actual QA people) or whether getting user testing done is something the quiz taker has to handle themselves.

Comment: Another possible option: "Sporadic. I do thorough tests/documentation on some projects but less or none on others." Current answers assume the quiz taker generally does the same amount regardless of what they're working on.

Answer (score 7):

How frequently your code is reviewed by your senior.

1. Everyday.
2. After each task.
3. Weekly.
4. Never.
5. I don't have senior.

Comment: Why not just a coworker?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare you are right

Answer (score 7):

**Recent graduates from software engineering related courses (past 3 years)**

How well prepared did your course make you for working in the industry?

- Well prepared
- Some what prepared
- Neither prepared or not prepared
- Some what not prepared
- Not well prepared

**Employers who have employed recent graduates from software engineering related courses (past 3 years)**

How well prepared was your graduate for working in the industry?

- Well prepared
- Some what prepared
- Neither prepared or not prepared
- Some what not prepared
- Not well prepared

I think it'd be good hearing from a graduate perspective and an employer perspective on how well prepared courses related to software engineering make you for working in the industry.

Answer (score 6):

How current are the tools you are using?

- Latest & greatest
- One version behind
- Two versions behind
- Too far behind

If not using the latest tools, why?

Comment: My tools have versions?

Comment: Is a beta version the latest & greatest?

Comment: @Willeke: Latest - Definitely, Greatest - Possibly, Buggiest - Undoubtedly!

Answer (score 5):

How many alcoholic beverages do you consume per day? (note: per week would also be acceptable, I suppose)

---

What kinds of alcoholic beverages do you typically drink?

- Beer
- Wine
- Cider
- Mead
- Distilled beverages / liquors
- None / Don't drink

Comment: Kombucha, which has such a low alcohol content I can drink the stuff (considering I am only 14).

Comment: Why does alcohol have to be integrated into every aspect of life...

Comment: @CSS Why not? There's a question about caffeine consumption in the 2015 survey. Why does caffeine need to be associated with software development - soda, coffee, etc?

Comment: @ThomasOwens I don't really agree with that either. I drink water all day and generally avoid anything except hot chocolate and soda, but those are generally only reserved for when I'm bored or need a mental break to overcome my mental block. The cost and distance I travel to retrieve such varies from job to job, but is usually not more than a couple of bucks and a 10 minute walk.

Comment: @CSS That's nice. Then you'd answer both questions with "0". If you dont' think this is a good question for the survey, you should down vote it. I think it's a good question, though, which is why I posted it. 10 other people agree with me, and 6 don't.

Comment: Changed to 12 like it vs. 7 don't. @CSS, I have heard it put that a programmer is a organism that changes caffeine into code., found that one funny XD. I would say it is a pretty good question.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I haven't found the question about caffeine yet, but I'm sure I'll downvote it too. I'm just so sick of not being able to go anywhere without seeing beer, wine, or hard liquor commercials, billboards, and spreads. I don't drink by choice, not as a result of religion or whatever the other usual reasons, and I'm sick of being bombarded with it everywhere I go.

Comment: I also choose not to drink alcohol, but I'm not offended by the question.

Comment: I'm interested in the answer to the question: what dev types, where in the world consume the most & least alcohol. I wonder how we can ask this question in a way that doesn't offend anyone.

Comment: @CodeCaster I generally agree. This doesn't seem like it should offend anyone, but the comments here & votes suggest it might. It's not up to me to decide what's offensive; we can only acknowledge that and try to address it, in this case by finding language for this survey question & answers that plays nice.

Comment: It should include an option for `None`; for those of us that don't drink.

Comment: @samthebrand: Just because one user seems to take offence, we suddenly have to take care when mentioning caffeine or alcohol? Why should we acknowledge that? What's the harm in telling your users to get a thicker skin every once in a while? This question as it stands right now is in no way offensive. It's just asking _if_ one drinks, and offers a _"none"_ option... It can't possibly be more harmless.

Comment: @samthebrand I wouldn't take the votes to mean that people are offended, but rather that they don't see the question as being valuable. I only see one person indicating that they would be offended. I'm not a moderator here, but unless there are flags on this post, I don't think this meets the bar for an offensive question. I totally agree with Cerbrus on this one.

Comment: Don't care much for the first form of the question, but I do like the second one!

Comment: @TylerH They really aren't two forms of the question. It's two questions. The first form is a rewording of [the caffeine question from the 2015 survey](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-caffeine) while the second is a follow-up. If a caffeine question is asked again this year, I would expect a follow up question to include choices such as "coffee", "tea", "soda", "other", and "none".

Answer (score 5):

In a programming language you are comfortable using, how long are you typically able to program before hitting a roadblock and resorting to online help?

This could be looking in the documentation (to see what's available or reference correct usage), looking up libraries, asking assistance in a help forum; anything that takes you away from either coding, debugging, or testing.

- 0-1 hour
- 1-2 hours
- 3-5 hours
- 5-8 hours
- 8-12 hours
- Never

Comment: There was a pattern emerging until 8-__12__.  Also, why not 0-1?

Comment: My IDE automatically displays documentation along with code completions.  I read it often, without disrupting my flow.  Should I answer 0-1 here, or only for when I need to switch to a Web browser?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That was something I was unsure about. Does referencing the javadocs in eclipse count? What about code complete in Visual Studio? I'd have to say no. Usually, if you're doing that quick referencing in the IDE you have a handle on what you're doing and just might be checking input parameters or what methods are available. It's slightly grey . =\

Comment: I know quite a lot about PHP, but I have to look up just about every function signature, but that's just because PHP is designed to be impossible to remember.

Comment: I use Sublime and Python. Whenever I need to look up input to something I do `!py whatever` in my browser on another screen... It's not disruptive at all. DuckDuckGo for the win.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if that will work for a survey also I don't have suggested answers but that's just one i always wanted to ask:

What type of chair do you use ?

Comment: Not multiple choice.'

Comment: Suggestion: Use the same chair categories Amazon does for office chairs. "Task chair", "Desk chair", "Executive Chair", "Stool", "Other"

Comment: How about an exercise/stability ball? Generally I use a chair, but I find sitting on such a ball a welcome change at times.

Answer (score 4):

Name one skill/language/technology that you don't specialize in but would love to master given the opportunity:

- Javascript
- SQL
- Java
- C#
- PHP
- Python
- C++
- C
- Node.js
- AngularJS
- Ruby
- Objective-C
- HTML5
- CSS3
- Responsive Desgining
- Swift
- Other

Comment: Should Swift be in there?

Comment: You could add it in there if you feel so :)

Comment: There's a pretty standard set of programming languages that are used in most questions, I'm sure they would just put the same list in that is used in other questions. I think this is a standard question already anyways...

Comment: Sadly I can't, The edit button is grayed out and when I hover over it I get a pop-up that says "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites", so I can't because I don't have 2000+ reps.

Answer (score 4):

This is really a three part question:-

- **How useful/relevant was your degree to the job you ended up doing?**
- **Did it adequately prepare you?**
- **If you are a student, how relevant do you think your studies will be?**

I find that most developers say what they learned in uni was out of date, irrelevant and/or didn't prepare them for life as a developer.  As a result many developers say they learned way more in their first 6 months than all the years of university combined.

Comment: It might be interesting to ask "If you're a student, how useful do you think your studies will be?", and contrast this with people who are employed.  Note that _degrees_ are often essential for getting a job even if the _studies_ required to obtain them are not -- you'll have to phrase the question carefully.

Comment: Good point, I've added that.  It just feels sometimes like a degree is 4 years just to receive a piece of paper with very little valuable information.

Answer (score 4):

**How confident are you in the programming languages you use most at work?**

E.g. if you are mainly programming C++ at work, how experienced and confident are you in C++? Do you get your job done, mainly with the knowledge you already have, or do you need to lookup everything everytime. Not sure about the wording, since I'm not a native speaker. Please modify the question, if you find something that fits better.

- I decide what's right and what's wrong. / I refactor every checkin of my co-workers.
- I know every detail of the language I am using. / I checkin without compiling.
- I always know what I am doing. / I checkin without running the unit tests.
- I am always certain that I did everything properly. / I checkin without a code review.
- My co-workers often ask for my help. / I review the most code.
- I am pretty confident, but double check most stuff to be on the safe side. / I let all my code review by an experienced co-worker.
- I often ask my co-workers for their help. / I have to rewrite my code sometimes after reviews.
- I need Stackoverflow for every line I write. / I always have to rewrite my code after each review.

Please add or modify answers, if you have better ideas.

Sometimes, I have the impression that a lot of people on SO, don't even have a clue about what they are asking. But with the right answers, they seem to get their stuff working. Same applies to me... ;)

Comment: Only at work? I see a lot of questions by people who can't program yet.

Comment: Yes, only at work. If you are still in school or studying, you are most probably not confident in the language you are still learning and that's ok. But if you are earning money with it you should be confident in it, right? I have the feeling that this is not the case for a lot of people in software development...

Comment: People who check code in without running the unit tests don't know what they're doing, whether they know the language or not.  Also, many college students are already capable programmers who simply need a degree (which is good for them, because most CS programs teach CS, not programming).  Finally, confidence is subject to Dunning-Kruger.

Answer (score 3):

**What is the normal quality level your product has when your company releases it to its customers?**

- very good (almost not bugs, good usability)
- good (few not critical
  bugs)
- average
- poor ("It should not have been released like this...")
- very poor ("Don't ask me, It wasn't my call...")

I am aware that the release date is decided by the bosses and not by the developers, but I am interested in this anyway, because it tells something about the pressure on the developers and the quality awareness in the company.

Comment: **And what company do you work for (so we can avoid as appropriate)?** Release those text results...please!

Comment: I'm not sure why people are downvoting this.....it seem like a really useful question. In particular it's a question that would only get a useful answer from survey that is done anonymously.

Comment: Perhaps there are some sales guys around here which want to avoid scaring customers :)

Answer (score 3):

Does the consumption of psychotropic substances positively affects your coding experience, and results?

---

I think this is a touchy subject. However, since the survey is anonymous I think one can express themselves without fear of recognition.

The point here is, what if software on earth is mostly written by high people? I'd like to know the *facts*.

Reword as you see fit.

Comment: Americans consuming kinder surprise eggs could answer this with a _"yes"_.

Comment: I don't isEven..?

Comment: Those chocolates aren't legal in the US. --> consuming illicit materials.

Comment: This seems like a flawed question... You're asking people to self-diagnose, which they're generally bad at, when they're high, which means they're worse than usual at it.

Comment: I thought about this, a bit. That's the reason for the *and results* part. I'd imagine to evaluate results, one have to evaluate code that's already written and shipped.. (That being said, you're quite right)

Comment: After I smoke I tend to code "better", but quickly that turns into just eating junk food and watching cat videos.

Answer (score 3):

What is your primary purpose in programming?

1. Professional setting
2. Personal projects at home
3. Traditional School
4. Online/ one time courses

In general, I program mostly personal projects at home. I'm sure I'm not the only one. It would be nice if there was more questions that recognized that not everyone on SO is a professional programmer!

Answer (score 3):

With the rise in popularity of cloud services (i.e. Amazon AWS, MS Azure, etc) for more than just hosting, how much work do you do with clouds?

- We work exclusively with cloud services
- We do most of our work with cloud services, but still have some dedicated resources
- We do most of our work with dedicated resources but have begun to use some cloud services
- We do not use any cloud services at all
- We cannot use cloud services due to the nature of our work and/or contractual obligations

Answer (score 3):

Something which I'm a little bit concerned about and I think results from this question might help convince me to buy items to help prevent RSI. Also might help identify what age to expect RSI.

**Have you experienced some form of repetitive strain injury (RSI) throughout your career?**

- Yes
- No

**What age were you when you first experienced a repetitive strain injury?**

- 0-17
- 18-25
- 26-35
- 36-50
- 51-64
- 65+

Answer (score 2):

On average how many hours of sleep do you get?

Answer (score 1):

What do you think of Stack Overflow?

- A  Programming School.
- Code Shop.
- Chat Room.
- Rep. League.
- A voting room.
- Place to share and gain programming knowledge.
- My Homework/Project Buddy.
- Overflow caused in a stack.
- None Of the above.

Suggestions about more/better options are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

For the software you work on which parts of the lifecycle are you responsible for?

Slider from:

Development of the software only <-> Development and operation of the software <-> Operation of the software only

Answer (score 1):

I feel podcasts are growing in popularity and I'd be interested in seeing how many people listen to tech related podcasts and which tech related podcasts they listen to.

**Do you listen to any tech related podcasts?**

- Yes
- No

**What tech related podcasts do you listen to?**

- Material
- This Week In Tech
- XDA
- Android central
- Fragmented
- Wired.co.uk
- Startup
- Founder's Journey
- Hanselminutes
- DotNetRocks
- ReplyAll
- RadioLab

These are some of the podcasts I know about and listen to, feel free to suggest more to add to the list.

Comment: I think listing podcasts is going to be difficult. I listen to Hanselminutes and DotNetRocks for example. It's not on your list. You could end up with a massive list.

Comment: @JamieR I only listed the ones I had heard of, by gathering a list of popular podcasts it might help some of us discover great tech related podcasts which we never knew existed. I've added the two podcasts you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, Upvoted for you sir.

Comment: ReplyAll? RadioLab?

Comment: @inquisitiveIdiot added, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Which of the following AI-related areas are you interested in?** *(multiple choice question, select all that apply)*

- Machine Learning
- Natural Language Processing
- Big Data
- Computer Vision
- Robotics
- Reasoning
- Automated Planning and Scheduling
- Knowledge Representation
- General Intelligence (Strong AI)

If the system doesn't allow choosing more than one answer then the question should be *Which of the following AI-related areas are you most interested in?* and a new option should be added:

- None

Comment: "None"? (I'm interested in at least some of these, but there's someone in the world whose answer is "None")

Comment: This is `many of many` question so he may not select any

Comment: And what if the validation of the survey doesn't allow that? (I wouldn't know for sure.) Either way, if there's a chance someone would say "None" there really should be a "None" option.

Comment: Ooook, edited :)

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm super-late with this one, but I'm writing it now in the hopes that I don't forget it for next year.

The last few years have asked which desktop OS developers use. I'd love if the survey also asked about **target/deploy operating systems** — perhaps both "pick one preferred" and "pick all that you write for".

<sub>N.B. I admit to being somewhat biased in this, as I work on an project which makes an operating system. But I think it's an interesting question for everyone.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What legacy systems are you putting up with?

- mainframe
- Cobol
- magnetic tape recorder
- Windows 3.x
- Windows CE
- Java ME

  ...please come up with many more, there is such a heterogenic world out there to discover!

Comment: We shouldn't ask a legacy-specific question; just list old technologies in the "What do you work with?" question instead.

Comment: Windows Vista...not necessarily legacy, but gawrsh, it's awful. I'd rather have Windows XP on that laptop, if only I could get a free/cheap license for it.

Comment: Cobol... *shudders

Comment: You know, I work with TPL which gets translated to XPL which gets translated to Cobol for execution.

Comment: How about FORTRAN?

Comment: IE7 of course...

Comment: How about everyone commenting this, upvotes the question? Otherwise it won't get asked.

Answer (score 0):

**How often do you backup your work/data?**
(as not all stuff that we want to backup is work related)

- Daily
- Weekly
- Monthly
- Yearly
- I rely on a tool to do it in the background automatically
- I rely on a tool to remind me to do it
- Never

Comment: I check in regularly. Multiple times per day. Technically, that's also a backup.

Comment: I do it manually multiple times a day when doing coding (Using Git), and automatically whenever I'm working on document related work (DropBox).

Answer (score 0):

Which Buzzword / Ad Lingo are you most tired of hearing / seeing:

- Agile
- DevOps
- Cloud
- Enterprise
- IoT
- All of the above
- Other

Comment: Don't forget "cyber"

Answer (score 0):

I do have a couple of questions. Here goes...

1. What will motivate you to  invest time (within and outside work hours) to build your competency in a new technology ?

   - Inclusion of Competency Development as a mandatory Performance Review criterion
   - Rewards, Monetary benefits and Recognition for top learners
   - Hackathons and regular training (where I get a chance to present a new topic)
   - Other options (Please specify)
2. How much time do you reserve for leaning new technologies/concepts other than what you are currently working on?

   - 30 mins to  1 hour
   - 1-2 hours
   - 2-3 hours
   - I don't as I still have a lot of catching up to do in my current technology

Intention : To understand the motivation and eagerness of software developers to up-skill themselves and what drives them to do so?

Answer (score 0):

A question I am always interested in is:

> **How are your development changes deployed to production?**
>
> - FTP / SFTP
> - Pull latest release from source control
> - rsync
> - Deployment tool (e.g. Capistrano)
> - Several individual steps

If there are any options I've failed to consider or suggested edits then they are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

- How many books regarding code/development/it do you read every year?
- Do you follow blogs/websites related to code/development/it with frequency? If yes how much time do you spend in this activity and what is the frequency?
- What are your favorite online resources apart stack overflow [list few]? :)

Comment: What about blogs or other articles?

Comment: @Cerbrus good point, I have added to my list :) thanks

Comment: Suggestions on number ranges?  It's supposed to be multiple choice.

Answer (score 0):

**If you work as a Developer at a permanent office** (perhaps already a previous question) **what facilities are provided for relaxation/getting your mind off things?**

- Free tea/coffee
- Quiet area
- Table tennis
- Gym
- Soft Play
- Gaming (PC / Console / Arcade)
- Holodeck
- None of these

Answer (score -1):

**How often do you change/switch technologies?**

- Once in 2 years
- Once in a year
- Once in 6 months
- Very frequently
- Never

Answer (score -2):

Which is your most effective code hour?

- 8am-11am
- 11am-1pm
- 1pm-4pm
- 4pm-7pm
- 7pm-10pm
- 10pm-1am
- 1am-4am
- 4am-8am

Answer (score -2):

**What language do you think all developers should have to learn as part of their tution/self-study?**

- C
- C++
- Python
- Javascript
- Java
- C#
- Go
- Ruby
- etc.
- I do not think any language is mandatory.

Answer (score -2):

***Relative to your activity on Stack Overflow*, how often do you engage in asking or answering technical questions in another medium (e.g. web forums, email, chat, in person, etc.)?**

- Much more often than Stack Overflow
- Slightly more often than Stack Overflow
- About the same than Stack Overflow
- Slightly less often than Stack Overflow
- Much less often than Stack Overflow

**Other than Stack Overflow, where do you *most commonly* ask or answer technical questions?**

- In person with teammates/coworkers/others
- Asking (or answering questions from) individuals you know personally via email/IRC/other
- Asking (or answering questions from) teammates/coworkers as a group (team chat, team mailing list, etc.)
- Asking (or answering questions from) people you don't know on the Internet (public mailing lists, forums, etc.)
- Other

Answer (score -3):

Do you share (through mail or something else) your ideas/important articles with your colleague fellows? if yes, how do they react? (on a scale, per se, 1 to 10)

- Says awesome and reads it.
- Approach you and tell to explain the idea/article (*without reading it*).
- Says busy and never reads it.
- Simply ignores it.
- Argues with you that it is wrong.
- Warns you not to send such mails again.
- Others

(*Users can rate mentioned all above reactions*)

Answer (score -3):

Three simple binary questions, with each revealed as you answer Yes.

1. **Do you own your own domain?**
2. If Yes: **Do you have it resolving to the IP of a machine in your household?**
3. If Yes Again: **Does your current plan with your ISP allow that?**

Comment: I'd appreciate knowing what people don't like about this :-/.

Comment: What relevance does this have to the SO survey?

Comment: @KevinB - A survey is a collection of questions, no? This is a collection of questions. Past surveys have asked about which embedded systems you've developed for, or which OS you've developed on, or what IDE you use. Owning your own domain and web server to develop on is about as common as owning an Ardurino to develop on, I imagine. #3 is something I'm curious about. I personally ignore the fact that my ISP clearly says not to do it on my plan, and I'm curious whether other people actually comply with what their ISP tells you to do, or if they just ignore it like me.

Comment: If it only asked about #1, i'd be fine with it.

Answer (score -3):

**What is your big dream?**

I want to be a:

- company owner
- high level developer in a universal company.
- developer of a product which is used by millions of people.
- millionaire by sold my product to a big company.
- stackoverflow moderator.
- open source developer who is known by all other developers in the world.
- cafe owner at a seaside province.
- hacker reached by nobody.
- anybody who do not need stackoverflow.
- None of the above.

Comment: None of the above ?

Comment: @blackbird57 "None of the above"  added.

Comment: Why can't I just [dream to be happy](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/282517-when-i-was-5-years-old-my-mother-always-told)?  Or [insert some other dream]?  I don't think such an open-ended question is a good fit for multiple choice.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Imagine all the people :)

Comment: Free beer tomorrow

Answer (score -4):

Which Mobile platforms do you develop for?

- iOS
- Android
- Windows Phone 8 / 8.1
- Windows UWP
- Firefox OS
- Other
- None

Comment: What about "All the above"?

Comment: No love for cross platform? (Extjs, Phonegap etc..)

Answer (score -4):

**What browser extensions do you use the most for development?**

- Selenium
- Live HTTP Headers
- Firebug / Debuggers
- etc...

**What browser extensions can't you live without?**

- Ublock Origin / Ad blocking
- Ghostery
- HTTPS Everywhere
- etc...

Answer (score -4):

What is your dominant programming paradigm?

- Functional
- Object-Oriented
- Imperative
- Other

Comment: Most modern languages are so mixed, that it doesn’t really make sense to ask this. And I’d also guess that a lot simply wouldn’t know the difference between some of these paradigms.

Comment: It's a question of style not of language, you can do functional programming on any language, and as the saying goes you can write Fortran in any language. And I think you're underestimating the community. If anything it will start a conversation.

Comment: Starting a conversation isn't the point behind a survey.

Comment: What's the point then? To provide insights isn't it? It's a more interesting question than Scala vs Ruby vs whatever. I want to know how many of us are doing what kind of programming, not what platform they're using.

Comment: A survey asks one set of questions and gets one set of answers.  There's no chance for a back-and-forth conversation to clarify what the answers mean.  I think the responses to this question aren't clearly-defined enough for the results to be meaningful.  (For example, I don't know the difference between the _imperative_ and _procedural_ paradigms, and I write a fair amount of functional code in the object-oriented imperative Java.  What am I supposed to answer?)

Comment: By conversation I don't mean feedback to the survey, I mean it in the way that the news generate social conversation inside communities.But I  think you have a point, I removed Procedural, Logic and Symbolic and placed an Other clause. Initially I just copied the paradigms from wikipedia. As for what you would answer I'd say functional, you said so yourself the language is based on OO but you'd rather write code in a FP way. There is a clear divide between the FP and OO and I want to know how many of us are in which category. It would also be nice to know how many are doing esoteric stuff.

Answer (score -4):

Do you use or plan to use hybrid mobile development frameworks along with Cordova/Phonegap to build applications? Which ones?

- Ionic Framework
- React Native
- jQuery Mobile
- Appcelerator Titanium
- Meteor
- Famous
- Sencha Touch

Are you confident about the relevance of hybrid mobile apps in the future?

- Very Confident
- There may be a niche
- I will do both just in case
- I think it is on the decline
- Native will obliterate hybrid

Answer (score -4):

What programming language do you think will be most popular 10, 20, 50 years from now?

Feel free to add a language that you think is possible.

Comment: Turbo Google Visual COBOLTRAN Scalakell++# .NET 6.0.

Comment: Oh, I guess by "a language that you think is possible" you're asking us to fill in the choices for you, not to predict future languages that might be invented in the future?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Essentially what language that is in vogue now will grow most in the next 20 years.

Answer (score -5):

2 Parter...

**1st part...**
How many employees are in the organization you are affiliated?

- 000-010
- 011-050
- 051-100
- 100-999
- 1000-5000
- 5000-10,000
- More than 10,001
- I'm an independent freelance programmer; it varies.
- I'd prefer not to say.

**2nd part...** What duties do you perform along with programming (Check all that apply)
 (if Possible track %'s along with multiple choice; but may not be so multi select)

```
 - Business Analyst (BA)        10 % - Requirements? We don't need no stinking requirements
 - Technical Analyst (TA)       10 % - Who needs technical documentation?
 - Systems Analyst (SA)         40 % - Programmer!
 - Test Analyst Technical (TAT) 10 % - Hey, I met the requirements prove that I didn't!
 - Project Manager (PM)         10 % - Can't anyone plan ahead?!
 - Other Duties As Assigned     05 % - Someone had to make the coffee. (Specific to Programming Job)
 - Read Trade Rags              03 % - Haskell ?!
 - Answer SO questions          07 % - Altruistic activities
 - Admin Overhead               05 % - TimeSheets, non-project Meetings
 - Non-Business Activities beyond those listed above. (down time)
 - Business Activities beyond those listed above. (business activities not really related to programming, but you do becuase the boss said so)
```

**HUMOR:**

- And people wonder why I'm only code productive 40% of the time...
- %'s would be a nice addition I think but understand the need for multiple-choice.
- [Requirements?](http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/images/steverumsby/2006/01/30/dilbert20060121046729.jpg?maxWidth=800&maxHeight=600)

Comment: This doesn't seem like it'd even _work_ well in a multiple choice format...

Comment: It would be interesting to see it in a workable format, but I think you forgot to list the time you spend skipping/adding music to your Pandora/IHeartRadio or choosing music/vids on YouTube, and the potential for office gaming (which is becoming more and more acceptable these days). Unless your "altruistic activities" is mean to cover all of that as well.

Comment: For the duties side, check boxes for the roles with radials for percentage ranges would work for this. Thinking huge matrix, though, since we could add a lot of other roles to it. Admin (calls, scheduling, coffee, etc.), Technical Lead, Technology Evangelist (trying and promoting new tech), Bus Boy (cleaning common areas, kitchen, break room, etc.), and the list goes on. All of which I've done as a contract-developer, by the way.

Comment: Yeah I cheated and covered the things I believe a programmer typically does and have 3 categories to cover the rest (other duties as assigned) non-business activities, and business activities.

Comment: @Kendra thanks for the feedback, I've tried to update to be more of a multiple choice.

Comment: How many people or how many developers? In a non-IT organisation there is quite a difference.

Comment: @GolezTrol that's tough.  If I'm a web development company that's one thing.  If I'm a car dealership with 2 IT one admin one developer. or if I'm a Large Insurance company with 10's of thousands... I think I"m after employees in total though, knowing Industry would help better understand results...

Answer (score -5):

**What do you prefer while travelling to/from office?**

- Email
- Quora, Linkedin
- Social Media
- Podcasts
- Make tasks list of today
- Read blogs, book, news paper
- Play games
- Sleep
- listen music
- just sit and wait

Comment: Maybe a good option could be: Podcasts!

Comment: If you drive you could still listen to podcasts or music on the radio.

Comment: Why aren't _"Sleep & listen music"_ 2 separate options?

Comment: Can, "The radio in my car while driving" be an option? I think this question is heavily skewed towards those that only "sit and wait" as their commute to work.

Comment: that the other drivers aren't doing any of these things

Answer (score -5):

Who is the best resource to have:

1. The Person who knows multiple programming languages .

or

2. The Person who is expert of one language.

Answer (score -7):

How many crushes do you have in your team ?

- 3 or more
- 2
- 1
- Not even one :(

Answer (score -10):

How technically astute is your leadership?

- Dilbert Pointy-head boss clueless
- Knows a few tricks here and there
- Used to sling code back in the day
- Active technical contributor
- Makes the Stack Overflow 100K club look like n00bs
- N/A (self-employed or other)

Comment: This would be hurt by the [Dunning–Kruger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Comment: @resueman which reminds me, _that_ might be an interesting thing to test for

Comment: ......Jon Skeet.

Comment: See my response to @haris 's question above - **How good are your social skills?**

Answer (score -12):

Would a stackoverflow meeting be intresting to you?

- yes
- no

Comment: I think _"if it was close by"_ is a requirement for everyone. I doubt anyone's going to fly to a meeting just to see some SO people. (SO employees aside)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, ill edit my post.

Answer (score -13):

**How many lines of code you write per day ?**

```
0-100
100-500
500-1000
1000+
```

Comment: Some days, that number goes below 0. Quality over quantity. Other days, it's over 1000.

Comment: I think this could vary a lot. Some days I don't write a whole lot. Some days I do a lot of prototyping, which means a lot of code, but most of which won't ever be used.

Answer (score -13):

**How many mugs of coffee you drink at work ?**

```
0-5
5-10
10+
```

Comment: This is probably downvoted because a similar question was already asked last year: http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-caffeine

Answer (score -16):

**Besides online communities, How many people can help you without cost when cannot resolve a programming problem?**

- `>=100`
- `>=50`
- `>=10`
- `>=5`
- `>=1`
- `===0`

Comment: I like the `===0` touch - just sayin'

Comment: There are devs in many countries that are lost when there is not internet connection and even the nearest hospital is 3 hours walking in the jungle. Not always developers work in a first world environment; surrounded by dev teams, skilled co-workers, smartphones, etc.

Comment: theoretically help, or practically help? Because just because there are a 100 developers around me, doesn’t mean that they could help me with the problems I have :P

Comment: @poke Any help, and the question wasn't "How many developers work around you that can/want help you...?" Even if there are dozens and only one can/wants counts as 1

Answer (score -23):

#### What is you favorite operating system?

- OS X
- Windows
- Linux
- Chrome OS
- Unix
- The hack I did to make Android work on desktop
- Multiple Operating Systems at once.
- Other...

---

Possibly have a dropdown or text field after each on to specify the version i.e. windows 8, OS X 10.10 and so on.

Comment: Apparently, there are some people who are really productive with stuff on a Chromebook Pixel…

Comment: Might want to split out versions. Win7 vs Win8 vs Win10 (or Vista; hate it but when that's what you use...) or RedHat vs Fedora, etc. Also, you forgot Unix.

Comment: Vista was a bug that wanted to be an OS.

Comment: @CSS, I added Unix, but having multiple versions of the same operating system might be over kill.

Comment: Win8/8.1 also wanted to a viable OS...Same with Win95, WinDE, and a handful of others. I think following the answer with a text field for users to enter the version manually could cover it. Could produce a sub-results set by whatever OS at a time. Could be pretty sweet.

Comment: 'What operating system you are forced to use by your customers?'

Comment: 'What operating system sucks the least for you?'

Comment: Maybe reword as what would be your operating system of *choice* stuck on an island? I would do it but it changes a lot the meaning of that, I'd let op do.

Comment: windows for workgroups 3.11

Answer (score -41):

**Do you consider yourself religious? If so, which religion do you most identify with?**

- Christian Catholic
- Christian Protestant
- Muslim
- Buddhist
- Judaist
- Hinduist
- Mormon
- Satanist
- Scientologist
- None (Agnostic)
- None (Atheist)
- Other
- Don't know
- Prefer not to answer

Comment: I don't think "atheist" fits here as "atheism" is not, by definition, a religion. If this has to be asked (and I think it's a bad question) I'd strongly recommend replacing "atheist" with "None".

Comment: For me knowing the gender/age of users is as interesting as knowing their religion. The curious part is that I don't know why there is lots of people afraid/ashamed to share their religion even if anonymously.

Comment: Downvoted. Not afraid. It's just not really relevant at all to the profession. Age matters for career planning, and there are known gender biases and discrimination that impact how you can advance as a developer.

Comment: I agree with @DavidVogel. Are you trying to start an internet war or something?

Comment: This question might be better phrased: do you consider yourself religious? If so, which religion do you identify strongly with? The results would be interesting.

Comment: If asking someone their beliefs is 'starting a war' I see why there is so much problem in some countries regarding this matter...  Anyway, regarding 'interesting results',  there is [this study](http://www.nydailynews.com/news/national/atheists-generous-religious-helping-study-article-1.1072386) about generosity of non or religious people. We could verify if it has some true or if it has some BS.

Comment: Downvoted. Religion or lack of isn't appropriate.

Comment: :( I'm pastafarian

Comment: Thinking about the religions of people I work with versus everyone else in my life, I think this question would yield very fascinating results. I know 3 Jews, 2 Mormons, a Hindu, a Muslim, and an atheist (there are many coworkers where this has simply never come up so I don't know). I don't think I know a single non-Mormon Christian via work. Outside of work, I know 2 Jews and a butt-ton of Christians and Mormons. I didn't realize it until now - but the people I work with are far more religiously diverse than the people that I know through other means. Also, Agnostic needs to be a choice.

Comment: I've added a few more options. (I didn't put pastafarian because, correct me if I'm wrong, some people would chose it just for the fun of it).

Comment: @DavidVogel for the sake of argument, discrimination in the form of religious bias can impact how one can advance as a developer as well.

Comment: What about [Raelians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra%C3%ABlism)? Probably goes under Atheist.

Comment: Also there is no: Judeo-Christian