# Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2016

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

> **Update: This survey is now closed. Stay tuned for release of the full results.**

The annual developer survey is now open:

https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016

It should take about 10 minutes to complete. We know you have bugs to squash and things to build and taking surveys isn't in your job description, so we appreciate your attention.

Just like [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015), we'll be compiling the results over the next month, and will present them to you so you can see for yourself who works remote, who likes working at night, and who considers themselves a rockstar, ninja, guru, etc.

Do you? [Let us know.](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016)

Comment: "Do you believe in aliens?" best question ever. :)

Comment: You should add "Are *you* an alien?", since most of us are.

Comment: First time I ever did the survey- I like it. I think I'll do it again next year. :)

Comment: I haven't written a cover letter in years, and that question still got me irrationally frustrated.

Comment: Is it too late to make question 37. "Star Wars or Star Trek?" a radio button selection? I'm sure it's intended to be a single selection.

Comment: Well @CubeJockey, I checked both - why not? And on the OS selector, I tried to check both Windows 10 and Mac OSX, but apparently that was deemed to be *too* bizarre.

Comment: for `19. How did you discover your current job?`, why there's no option for a in-campus recruitment? I believe a `Career fair` is just not the appropriate _alternative_ in that case.

Comment: I wish I knew what I said last year. I wonder if "what I consider myself to be" has changed!

Comment: @SouravGhosh - It probably didn't come up on the thread asking for questions and answers for the survey.

Comment: I feel like the survey last year was longer. That, or because I answered similar to most of the questions

Comment: @Jongware yeah, I guess we have to be an Apple Fanboy, Windows Casual, or Linux hacker and not all three at once

Comment: @CubeJockey I didn't see any questions about cover letters.

Comment: Why do you let your survey company advertise themselves at the end of the survey ("take more surveys to get stuff")?  Are you not paying them already?  It comes off as mildly slimy.

Comment: Is it possible to make localized surveys for localized SO sites (Ru, Pt and others)?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom That's not something Stack Overflow has control of. SurveyMonkey does that on its own, and it is a separate company from Stack Overflow.

Comment: taking these surveys always makes me feel so negative :(

Comment: @TylerH They are not forced to use SM, they can choose another platform if they want. But I guess everyone uses SM since everyone uses SM.

Comment: *" If you applied to a job at Google, what do you think is the likelihood you would get an interview?"* How should I know? I'd never apply and have no idea about their processes or requirements. Why isn't there an option "I don't care" or "How should I know?"

Comment: 38. Star Wars or Star Trek? Aliens!

Comment: Just like last year, **there are countries missing**. Please add them (using the countries from last year, because that list was complete). Cannot currently participate because my country isn't listed.

Comment: What is your gender? Female , Male , Other <- made me laugh so hard

Comment: Is it possible to leave fields empty? Because I have the feeling that I missed an entire page now I took a second look at the survey this morning :p

Comment: @dew1 it's not a joke:  https://www.genderspectrum.org/quick-links/understanding-gender/

Comment: @cybermonkey: explain how the country list from last year is more complete than this year's because this year's list is missing some **and so it did last year**: "Just like last year ..."

Comment: Should **If you applied to a job at Google, what do you think is the likelihood you would get an interview?** be **If you applied *for* a job at Google, what do you think is the likelihood you would get an interview?**

Comment: @Jongware They added most of the missing countries last year, but those same countries are missing again this year. Using the same country list would eliminate most of the country problems.

Comment: This survey would be a lot faster to take if there weren't so many irrelevant bulls*** questions...

Comment: @KФ Educational answer for piggy bank pennies count?

Comment: @TylerH "_I didn't see any questions about cover letters._" There was a question about most annoying part(s) of the job application/search process. (paraphrasing, I have no access to the questions anymore)

Comment: I still haven't got my "swag" *(I hate this word)* for the 10m event, the thought of having a chance to get a tshirt really isn't much of an encouraging factor.

Comment: Just some feedback...I think I got to page like 3 and gave up.  Way too many questions.

Comment: DjDavid98 I've been promised plenty of times.  @TimPost why can't you fix this?

Comment: @DJDavid98 I made a mistake with the last half of the 10M swag that had to be manually corrected (due to how easy it is to send responses to the wrong place in Google docs when you've got multiple forms going). The rest of it is going out shortly (Your's too Jon) - it's completely my fault and I'm sorry for the awful delay, I didn't realize what I'd done until it became quite hard to fix (or ask people to enter their information all over again, which thankfully I didn't have to do).

Comment: tl;dr; I'm not allowed to touch swag anymore, so things should be running optimally in no time :D

Comment: Why is SQL Server the only RDMBS available in the languages and technologies questions? :(

Comment: 10 minutes? I'm pretty sure that was closer to 40 minutes.

Comment: Is it "I believe that aliens exist somewhere in the universe" or "I believe aliens are regularly visiting the earth and probing hill-jack Americans"?

Comment: 'I want to go to Mars right now...' Coding at −63 °C and 96% carbon dioxide atmosphere? What about finding a reliable ISP or a secure backup server there?

Comment: I wish I can select all for why I hate for my company, not just three!

Comment: I did feel a little misrepresented by the Mars question... I'd of course *love* to go for a short time, but the way it phrased it made it sound like "even if it were a one-way trip" rather than "even though, like in reality, there would be some risk of something happening on a multi-month trip to another planet". I don't want to go to Mars and never come back.

Comment: The "how many years" question could have some more choices. There's a huge range covered by the 11+ years category. Maybe next year we can have {11-15, 16-20, 21+}, or {11-20, 21-30, 30+}.

Comment: "What are the biggest challenges at your workplace?" "Other: half the company getting laid off to save on payroll." - "What could you improve about the interview process?" "Reply to my application and offer me an interview, please, anybody." Why do some questions understand that not everyone is employed, and then there's an entire page about where you work?

Comment: I'd rather write the software for the spaceship than actually go to Mars.

Comment: @samthebrand If I am selected for penny challenge, will T-Shirt delivered in India? By the way there are 1450 pennies.

Comment: WordPress should have the P capitalised.

Comment: Result of survey?

Comment: Hey, where is my "I Voted 2016" profile image hat?  :-)

Comment: I spent at least 10 minutes staring at the pig full of pennies figuring out if I could reliably count the wrappers

Comment: Believe in me people, believe...

Comment: Question 12: On a scale of 0-9, how would you rate your programming ability?

Comment: Star Wars or Star Trek? No we love Game of Thrones. :)

Comment: Best survey every thanks for all the great work

Comment: Star Trek or Star Wars... NaNaNah, BATMAN!
By the way, it was a great survey :-)

Comment: Is it just me, or did they add questions since the survey launched? I do not recall the Google Interview question, for one.

Comment: USA visa application says "Are you an alien allowed to work in United Stated?" Now I believe I'm an Alien .. and so I believe in Aliens :)

Comment: @vendettamit As a US non-resident alien, I also interpreted the question that way (deliberately!)

Comment: Some questions are quite funny :) I hope we can get copies of our answers. via email or a summary at the end to copy/paste

Comment: Do you love your boss.. hehehe what we supposed to do with that -_-

Comment: what is dogs or cats in question ?

Comment: My answer for city: "no" :)

Comment: I'm just curious, does someone actually review what we type in the "Other" box?

Comment: @Rachel Yes. A real human (or near enough, anyway) will read the responses.

Comment: `It should take about 10 minutes to complete.` 10 minutes to complete the survey, 2 hours of calculation to determine piggy bank and pennies volumes/amount.

Comment: How does it feel to be a single person from Tajikistan doing the survey last year?

Comment: I just did another form in http://www.typeform.com/ and IT WAS WAY MORE AWESOME THAN SURVEYMONKEY's.  Can this be considered for next year's survey?  Keyboard only entry is very programmer friendly.

Comment: 40. "I occasionally drink alcohol while coding."

Comment: @Bhushan 1450 pennies ? No way

Comment: Is ny aliens ment any biological organisms? Or any developed species with origin not from earth?

Comment: Star Trek or Star Wars? Firefly! Vive la Browncoats!

Comment: I have an idea to write a software to help people can write the idea from their brain.

Comment: Where's the all-important question on the morality of Windows???

Comment: One question I found ambiguous was "What's important to you at work? -> Working from home". For a job in the city where I live, I don't care about this; I'd rather work in the office anyway. But for a job far away geographically, it's critical - I don't want to relocate, but I would be glad to telecommute for the right position.

Comment: Question about "what annoys you most when search a job" should have option "Being interviewed for IT company by people who know nothing about IT". Most annoying part is HR who does not know relevant topics, feels like this is just an unnecessary obstacle you need to overcome before real interview starts.

Comment: Piggy bank: "Too many for me to care"

Comment: New question: "On a scale of question to question How much question do you think this question is?"

Comment: Notepad++ but not BBEdit? WTF??

Comment: Q44: If we could add one thing to Stack Overflow just for you, what would it be?    
A: "Year-round hats"

Comment: The minute I read _"How involved are you in purchasing the products or services..."_ I stopped, feeling betrayed because I expected a fun and interesting survey with no ulterior motives. For me, this question is a clear sign that I will be targeted for marketing campaigns in the future. So sad...

Comment: *Aao.. Hum Sab Pyaar Kare*

Comment: come on!! who does not loves his/her boss ;)

Comment: Are we get free T-Shirts?? Free delivery ?? :)

Comment: Any planned survey for ServerFault people?

Comment: they should not have asked about salary mine is too low..lol

Comment: Piggy bank? Pennies? All I could see was a black square, which, when I highlighted it became a transparent square.. intentional? It would be hilarious if my guess wins me a shirt despite that.

Comment: Great, opening the survey in chrome shows me the piggy bank.. I might've overshot my "estimate" by 700 pennies.. Is there a way to edit my answer now that I've already submitted the survey responses? I wants me a shirt!

Comment: Comment/Request: Could we get a "follow user" feature on here? Every now and then you come across a truly brilliant contributor that seems to pop up providing answers to almost every question you posed in a Google search that ultimately brought you here, and after awhile you realize it'd be nice to just read the question/answer interactions they have each week on the given subject to become more knowledgeable, like educational blurbs you read in the morning from an e-zine, but there doesn't appear to be a way to do that.

Comment: 36. If we could add one thing to Stack Overflow just for you, what would it be? Stop depending on ajax.googleapis.com, use a local fallback for jQuery!
And I forgot to remind you that Stack Overflow careers resumes are not working without JavaScript, use progressive enhancement in 2016 please: https://twitter.com/baptx/status/657876550545756160

Comment: When is the survey closing? I need to know the number of pennies!

Comment: @enrico.bacis, i think there were 650 pennies as one role containing 50 pennies and there were 13 opened role so total is 13*50 = 650.. hope so

Comment: Pennies in the Piggy... it's all about wrappers and HTTP codes ;-)

Comment: @Anil: damn... then I've won :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios 8 wraps x 50 coins = 400 coins. 9th was opened but just few coins taken from it, so I thought it could be one of the HTTP codes and chose 402 (Payment Required) as the mostly related one. Let's see :)

Comment: What is the date of result of the piggies ?

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues [it was announced!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315181/developer-survey-how-many-pennies-were-there)

Comment: I took this survey first time. It's the best one I ever had...Waiting for results..

Comment: @samthebrand I hope in next survey CSS and HTML will be added as technologies. You know there are many UI developers.

Comment: How long will the survey be open? I just can't seem to find the time and keep postponing it.

Answer (score 432):

As a sixty-year-old programmer, I get stuck on the *third* question of the survey:

[image]

Comment: Clearly the option should be `>60.0`, so that you can choose that option if it's past your birthdatetime.

Comment: Great catch. Apologies for not catching it myself. Will be fixed next year.

Comment: haha, this should be an interview question to see if people catch it.

Comment: @samthebrand next year it'll be fine seeing that he'll be 61 :P. Have to admit this made me laugh.

Comment: I'm curious: Are you really sixty years old?

Comment: It still should be `>= 60` for those participating in this survey at their birthday.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Or.. ya'know.. > 59..

Comment: For those who don't fit into your age construct: `i² = −1.`

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't account for that considering there was a meta topic on [Age distribution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9822/age-distribution-of-stack-overflow-users) about this.

Comment: @Harbinger : lolz, I am agree with you

Comment: Well spotted! It should be >= 60

Comment: @CubeJockey but then what would you do if you were 59.5??

Comment: Next time that question may be updated like " > 61" - smiles...

Comment: I'm surprised they put `> 60` at all, and didn't just skip to `Prefer not to disclose` ;)

Comment: Should just be 60+ ...

Comment: I think they assume you don't want to disclose your age which you eventually be ok with one year after.

Comment: Seems like this should be defined in terms of a half-open range. 20-25, 25-30, etc. Then you don't miss anyone. If I am 25 years old, I select 25-30.

Answer (score 393):

[I've said it once and I'll say it again:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285193/1223693) **stop asking questions that assume that I have a career/job.**

The survey this time around seems to have eased up on the endless career questions, but there's still stuff like

> What annoys you most when searching for a new job?

I have never held nor searched for a job.

> I love the technologies I use at work.

You gave "Student" etc. as an option for the "occupation" question, yet you assume I program professionally here!

> I love my boss.

What boss?

> What's important to you at work? (10 sub-questions follow)

*sigh*

---

Anyway, all complaints aside, thanks for continuing to do this every year! The results are always really interesting to look through. (Also, as per "tradition," [here are my responses made public again](https://gist.github.com/KeyboardFire/a36c11dd8bb080390171) like last year.)

Comment: Why do you want to ignore the best feature of Stack Overflow?

Comment: @TylerH Ignore the best feature?

Comment: @TylerH, that's sarcasm, right?

Comment: Why should they not collect information about people who *do* have a job simply because you don't like having to read the question? (You know you can skip it, right?).

Comment: @Rob I'm not saying the questions shouldn't be there. I'm saying that questions that don't have an "I'm unemployed" option force me to speculate. (Is it possible to just skip a question? If so, that wasn't made clear enough, then.)

Comment: But also, it kind of gives me the impression that it's unorganized, and that they don't know their user base. There were multiple pages in that survey, so why can't they redirect me to different pages based on whether or not I have a job? If I'm 16, I probably don't have a job, I'm not looking for one, and when I tell you this at the beginning, stop asking me questions that assume I have one - I don't, and stop assuming I do.

Comment: @ZAD-Man His public response requests that the [chat] tag be made a synonym of [tag:status-ignored].

Comment: @CaptJak No it's not.

Comment: @TylerH No, it requests the exact opposite...

Comment: @Doorknob Oh wow, not sure how I missed that "not". Probably because I had to scroll horizontally to read so I didn't put much enthusiasm into it.

Comment: @TylerH, Oh, I thought you were referring to Jobs as the best feature...

Comment: @CaptJak oh, no... although from a business POV, Jobs is the best feature of Stack Overflow, Inc.

Comment: Just to be a bit of an ass here: I am an student! But, I have a boss and all the job questions apply to me, as I am a PhD student. Do not assume that because you are a student the rest of the question immediately do not apply to the rest of the students!

Comment: @Doorknob all questions are optional

Comment: 256 pennies? Why?!

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, okay, that makes much more sense. I don't think that was ever mentioned in the survey, though, so I assumed otherwise.

Comment: @dotctor I guessed 253 pennies. I hope I'm closer.

Comment: @Rob: That questions can skipped does not help; the actual issue is that, e.g., when you're a student, you might interpret many questions in a "sort-of the same" way. To stay with that example, a question asking about one's workplace might be discarded by some students on the grounds that they do not have a workplace, others might answer it, thinking "university is like a workplace for me", yet others might answer it only with respect to a single part of university at which they have a student part-time job ... like this, answers will not be comparable and could just as well be free-text.

Comment: I like the answer to question 34. c:

Comment: *I love my boss.* - Shog by default, of course.  Say you love him or risk having your survey invalidated.

Comment: Seriously though, I too still don't have a job, but I tried to answer some of the job-related questions in the perspective of a former student (I probably could've just skipped them, but oh well).

Comment: @Sklivvz Don't get me wrong when I say this, but that's somewhat of a lousy excuse. If you're saying *oh, you only have to fill out the survey if you want to* almost defeats the purpose of the survey, and kinda shows lack of thought.

Comment: I can assure you it is deliberate and actually quite a common choice.

Comment: I agree with you. I'm 16 and I have no idea what to answer all those job related questions. I wonder why your opinion was not considered when you posted the same thing last year.

Comment: I'm a Product Manager, so a lot of the questions weren't a perfect fit, but I didn't find it too difficult to adapt or skip. I'm also self-employed. "I love my boss." *Agree strongly*

Comment: It's a "Developer Survey."  If you're a non-developer (like me) then you might not be the target audience.

Comment: Ha, I'm seeing all your guesses about the piggy bank, and I guessed `$("#piggybank").attr("pennies")`. It's probably wrong though, as the universe is [made with Perl](http://xkcd.com/224/).

Comment: `What boss?` SWAMBO

Comment: 10. Which of the following (...) technologies do you WANT to work with this year? ... Other: Julia

Comment: If you look at the response data from previous years most users *do* have jobs. So it makes perfect sense to ask about it. 
I know someone always has to be the one to fuss over nothing but there's really no need here.

Comment: If you don't have a job how can you be placed in the correct box?  If we don't know what box you go in, how do we know what to feed you?

Comment: Same. I'm a student and really my only job is to go to school so..... :(

Comment: I love my boss. "Yes" or "Multiple times a day"

Comment: `What's important to you at work? (10 sub-questions follow)` I'm not sure why not *currently* working would disqualify one from having an opinion about what factors they consider important in a work environment.

Answer (score 191):

All of the "how do you classify yourself" options assume that if you're not some sort of programmer that you must be management.  There are no options at all for designers (many of us who participate in the HTML/CSS tags would classify as one), testers, or UX specialists.

Comment: sysadmins of the world represent!

Comment: And I'm not a back-end **web** developer nor a **desktop** developer, but everything in between. I guess that'd be "Enterprise level services developer"...

Comment: Yeah, I also had to put in an "other", as I am neither a "full stack web developer" nor any other non-full-stack developer; I am totally a "I will do whatever you need" full-stack (which could include web and/or thick client and/or backend) consultant type.

Comment: Also missing would be "non-developer but create my own tools".  Various sorts of non software engineers/accountants/research scientists/etc would fall in that bucket.

Comment: The way the world is shaping anything other than a full-stack is out of date.

Comment: @Nelson that says more about your world view than anything else. Not everyone is writing Single-Page Applications for startups, hosted on an .io domain.

Comment: @CodeCaster its called sarcasm.

Comment: @Nelson sarcasm doesn't work well with text alone. You'd be surprised at the number of people who genuinely believe what you said. ;-)

Comment: @CodeCaster Capitalism, single-tasking has become a romantic way of being unemployed.

Comment: The notion that true fullstack developers are something that every company/startup needs says a lot about the industry in general.  I'd rather have 2 developers with complementary specializations than 2 fullstack developers.

Comment: What is a "full stack" developer anyway? I _think_ it's a web programmer who can write for both server and client, but I'm not sure. From context, I'm pretty sure it's not someone who understands the _full_ stack, from hardware, thru firmware, compiler, OS kernel, libraries, system daemons etc. thru whatever application is relevant.

Comment: @ArlieStephens your description SHOULD be what is meant by "full stack" :) But indeed generally it revolves around front-end + back-end + communication between the two + datastorage

Comment: Scientists and artists are also not represented. Very disappointing.

Comment: Clearly a millenial! ;)

Comment: and what if I'm Senior Googler? :P (I write all my code by googling up the parts and stitching them together)

Comment: These strange choices from the "classify yourself" question are esp. weird given the industry choices from question 14. Industries like Aerospace or Goverment don't really seem to go together with "full-stack web developer" or the like. And where do code monkeys from Healthcare companies fit it with q. 6? What I mean to say is that q. 6 appears very narrow-minded to me, while q. 14 doesn't follow the same pattern.

Comment: @ArlieStephens It's kind of funny you mention that, I was at first impressed to find out that there was a lot of work out there for "full stack devs", I was pretty disappointed to find out that it was actually web related which doesn't really interest me as much. I'd enjoy being a "full stack dev" by your definition of the term.

Answer (score 128):

What confused me is out of the top 10 up voted answers from [Suggest a question for the 2016 Stack Overflow Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey/310422#310422). Only 2 answers was chosen for the actual survey.

Now I understand that we were just suggesting some questions, but I think if you included more of the answers from that question, the survey and results would have been a lot more interesting for the community (Since we **are** interested in seeing the results).

Just my thoughts.

Comment: I was particularly interested in [this suggestion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310422/2476755). Sort of bummed they didn't add it.

Comment: @royhowie I was intrested in a few. I just feel like they are doing this for their own personal benifit. Which is fine, its optional for anyone to fill in. But I wouldn't have thought it would have been difficult to even make the survey 2 minutes longer and add some community questions that are on that thread. I am disappointed.

Comment: Actually, if you go down in the list, there are more answer chosen, for example: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310396/319875 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310451/319875 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310341/319875 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310509/319875

Comment: @FlorinGhita In my answer I stated my stats are from the top 10 upvoted results. We have a voting system, us the customers have voted on what we wanted to see and most of the top voted answers did not make it. If they are in the top 10, in my opinion its a good indication to what we the customer want to see in this survey.

Comment: It looks like they mostly stuck with questions whose answers say something about you as a programmer.

Comment: Oh, did you think the survey was for *this community*?  Don't fret, the community of market researchers that comb through the data will find something that interests them.

Comment: How about making a survey out of all the unaccepted suggested questions. Just for the community.

Answer (score 102):

It's very hard for me to decide whether I "love my job" or "somewhat satisfied." There is a lot in between. I do enjoy my job a lot, but "love" is something that doesn't go with work.

Also, I'm a full-time employee, student and an entrepreneur but I can only select one in that question. You don't want to know about people having more than one hat?

Comment: "I do enjoy my job a lot, but "love" is something that doesn't go with work." Then that sounds like "somewhat satisfied" to me.

Comment: I think the implication is that one can be more than "somewhat satisfied" but not "love" their job -- I could be "completely satisfied" but not "love my job".

Comment: +1. I don't think anyone actually *loves* working for money.

Comment: @Zenadix I know people who do. Teachers often do, or they'd be doing something that pays more. Musicians/artists/etc. generally do. Programmers *occasionally* do. But I absolutely agree with this person: I like my job significantly more than "somewhat", but less than "love".

Comment: To avoid ambiguity like this, most of the professional surveys I've seen use a grammar like: I am satisfied with my job: Strongly Disagree, Disagree, Neutral, Agree, Strongly Agree

Comment: @neminem Teachers may love teaching and artists may love singing, but that doesn't mean they love doing it for money. Similarly, many people love driving, but if they are offered money to drive someone else somewhere, it becomes a chore and they will refuse.

Answer (score 65):

I couldn't click fast enough on "writing cover letters" as the most annoying thing about finding work.

In fact, thinking about it now, I'm still annoyed at the **thought** of writing a cover letter.

Those were some curiously large pennies.

Looking forward to the responses, and hopefully this year - a t-shirt as well.

Comment: Or a curiously small piggy bank...

Comment: I would have clicked "writing cover letters", except it annoys me to the point that I never actually do it.

Comment: @Bobson I've only ever written cover letters for classes which required them for some sort of grade. To be honest, I'm not sure how many great job opportunities I've missed that have required cover letters, I've skipped them all. So of course I still selected "writing cover letters" :)

Comment: Re: the piggy bank - If you google image search "pink transparent piggy bank", the one the SO team used is literally the first result. That takes you to the seller page which tells you its dimensions, roughly 6"x4"x4". It's a kid's piggy bank. If you put coins of other denominations in it and paper money, you can easily get like $60+ dollars by the time it's full.

Comment: Who the heck writes cover letters these days anyway. HR don't want to read them, we don't want to write them. Optimal solution seems fairly obvious to me.

Comment: My only other major gripe is that so many companies cast the interview result to Boolean before returning, with no API for extended error information.

Comment: @TylerH [I searched for "pink piggy bank pennies" on DDG](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pink+piggy+bank+pennies&t=ffab&iax=1&ia=images)

Comment: @AnderBiguri what if there are some out-of-circulation historical pennies in there?

Comment: @Agostino something like this: http://cl.jroo.me/z3/u/f/C/d/a.aaa-HUGE-Penny.jpg?

Answer (score 60):

> How would you best describe the industry you currently work in?
>
> - Aerospace
> - Automotive
> - Consulting
> - Consumer Products
> - Defense
> - Education
> - Finance / Banking
> - Foundation / Non-Profit
> - Gaming
> - Government
> - Healthcare
> - Internet
> - Manufacturing
> - Media / Advertising
> - Retail
> - Software Products
> - Telecommunications
> - Web Services
> - I'm a student
> - Not Currently Employed

A bit sad to see that Agriculture is woefully missing.  Everybody eats, and you might not realize just how much technology is used in food production.

It will be interesting to see how this compares to [last year](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#work-industry), where over half the responses fell into unlisted or potentially ambiguous categories - 20% other, 25% software products, 17% web services/Internet.  Specificity will be interesting, especially since this survey is still missing a few cornerstone economic sectors.

Comment: let's also not count out Architecture & Construction...

Comment: Do you write the Cow AI  that allows cows to choose a more efficient path to get to the milking shed?

Comment: Nope, I write the farm AI that allows tractors to choose a more efficient rate to apply seeds and inputs to get to the maximum yield using our exhaustive archive of environmental data sets.

Comment: Also I don't see foodservice here! OR LASERS (I see "defense" but not "offense")

Comment: There's also no Transportation or Non-Profit. (There's Automotive but that sounds more like a specific type of manufacturing than, say, about building systems that manage traffic.)

Comment: Sorry, yes they have non-profit. It's right next to "Foundation" and I was looking for it in alphabetical order.

Comment: Tourism, the industry of my current job, is also an important one missing.

Comment: I also was a bit disconcerted to not find Agriculture listed. Ag is a quickly growing field as far as programming goes.

Comment: Intelectual Property?

Comment: I would have expected Ecommerce to be listed.

Comment: @pydsigner "Quickly growing field." +1

Comment: @MattGibson Completely fortuitous, I promise :]

Comment: Plus Natural Resources. (Separate from Energy).

Answer (score 46):

"I just like taking surveys" was rather cute. Although I am a Stack Overflow user, it's fun to see stuff like that sprinkled in.

Comment: Fits in well for people that may share this survey to other devs in their workplace.

Comment: I didn't even think of that. It appeared to me as some weird person trawling surveys online.

Comment: That one was probably meant for Jon Skeet.  His bot does all his postings, and he just takes surveys himself.

Answer (score 34):

Just a nitpick: as a user of Atom and Vim as my two primary general-purpose text editors, calling Atom “atom.io” felt a little weird. So much so, that it took me a few moments to find it! I think that might have made a little more sense two years ago, when it was new, but the editor is called “Atom”.

But y’know, just my two cents. I don’t actually use Stack Overflow. I just take surveys.

Comment: For a moment I questioned whether or not Atom was rebranded when I saw this, and then I checked to confirm that [it was listed properly in the Meta answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310396/359284). Looks like someone copied it over wrong when making the survey.

Comment: Edited. Thanks for noticing this!

Comment: I introduced someone to Atom in chat once. That person, while taking the survey, asked in chat whether Atom was actually called atom.io, assuming he had been lied to. :P

Answer (score 33):

I don't know whether it could be achieved this year, but please could you pay attention to how social media sites scrape the survey page? The document metadata is completely misrepresenting the survey and looks wholly uninteresting.

How am I to grab the attention of my peer developers?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd like to do a survey for *ack* **OVER**

Comment: Is that something Survey Monkey even lets you change?

Answer (score 29):

For question

> 31. What amount of formal or professional programming training have you received? (select all that apply)

you actually don't have any option for a class targeted at kids/teens/them youngins. I did a course when I was 10 that was my first time learning programming. It is the only somewhat official training I've received but none of the categories seemed to match. It seems like this will only become more common with initiatives like Coder Dojo, so I think it makes sense to have as an option.

Comment: Is that particularly common? My impression is that it's a relatively recent, but then you do have things like after-school clubs and the like.

Comment: @MattMcCabe The one I went to was a decade and a half ago, and they're becoming even more common now so it's surely going to be happening more. Plus there may be people currently attending them that use SO. I feel like it would be useful to add to try and discern how common it is.

Comment: I took several programming classes in high school.

Answer (score 24):

I missed the option on many question to select more than one answer.

For example "What sector your company is in?"
My company is in the financial government sector - ouch? What to choose? Finanical? Government? Other?

(I decided government but that's only the half truth)

Comment: Hmm, Financial Government sector? If you work for a government organization, I'd say that takes precedence over *what* you do (AKA if I worked for the IRS, I'd say government). If you work in the financial sector and the government is just one of your clients/a major client/your exclusive client, I'd say financial. (AKA if I work in a department of Ernst & Young that caters exclusively to government agencies, I'd still say financial)

Comment: *If you work for a government organization, I'd say that takes precedence over what you do* - @TylerH I would think that public schools would be an exception to that, right? If you work at the Department of Education you'd say Government but if you work for a public University, you'd say Education even though the government owns that too.

Comment: @BSMP I was referring to the federal government. State governments are different; I'd refer to myself as a *state* employee at that point rather than a more general *government* employee. For faculty at a state university, I'd say a "professor/lecturer/faculty a state university". Typically the best way to describe your position is not what sector in which you work, but to say your job role/title followed by "private" or "public" sector.

Comment: *State governments are different* @TylerH - Eh, I don't see how they're different enough that you wouldn't answer the industry question with "Government" if you worked for the state's department of health, finance, etc. (again, with schools being an exception).

Comment: @BSMP Because "government" without an additional qualifier usually means the highest form of sovereign government, in the case of the US, that's the federal government. More local offices are referred to specifically (state employee, local magistrate, county police officer, etc.) when you want to make it clear you're not talking about the federal government.

Comment: @TylerH Everyone I've told that I work for "Government" assumes I work at the state level. Might be more of a regional thing. (And I didn't even hesitate to select "Government" as a state employee.)

Answer (score 20):

It would be great to give some badge/bonus reputation for those who participated at survey.

Comment: T-shirts for everyone!

Comment: What site would it apply to? Not everyone on the Stack Exchange network has a Stack Overflow account, but the survey is advertised on every site. So for example if a user is active on Graphic Design and Astronomy and nowhere else, on which site would they receive a badge and/or reputation for completing the survey?

Comment: @Jongware I would die happy

Comment: Isn't it enough knowing that your answers will become part of the market research helping to make tech recruiters successful in the new year?

Answer (score 15):

I was going to mention it last year but forgot ;¬

So, let's say you live in the UK and earn money in pounds £. Since you've selected UK on page 1 going into page 2 should ask you for salary range in £ rather than US $s? It would save you the hussle of going to google to convert your salary from £ to US $. What do you think?

Comment: I imagine having all the currencies would be a pain to implement. But I would like if there was some way to avoid having to go to google to convert my salary.

Comment: Why would it be a pain to implement? There are tons of exchange rate APIs available on the web.

Comment: Another problem is that in many European countries they use salary to refer to how much they make per month, and job listings reflect that as well. AKA a "2300 salary" would be 27,600 per year, not 2,300 per year.

Comment: But does SurveyMonkey have builtin support for this? OK, time for stack exchange folks to spin their own survey machine…

Answer (score 15):

I know what `Full-stack developer` means, but never heard of `Full Stack Overflow developer`. Does it mean something like those developers have their stack overflowing or something?[image]

Anyway, this one below was good, and I sort of liked it, though I did not understand what it has to do with SO. Same goes to the one about aliens :-)
[image]

Comment: I think those are all jokes/lighthearted miscellanies.

Comment: I think "Full Stack Overflow developer" is just there to confuse nonnative speakers who don't immediately see the pun.

Comment: I think that "Full Stack Overflow developer" is a developer that *only* uses code from SO.

Comment: First result on Google for ["Full Stack Overflow Developer"](https://www.christianheilmann.com/2015/07/17/the-full-stackoverflow-developer/) explains it pretty well.

Comment: I'm personally interested in the percentage of ninjas that are dog or cat people.

Answer (score 14):

> Same as age I am stuck on the 7th Question, I have 5.8 years of experience but with which options I can move [image]

Comment: Nice catch:) :)

Comment: Same thing will happen with 10.X experience persons :)

Comment: But they are considering 2.X and 1.X. :)

Comment: 5 in “2 - 5 years” is to be understood as “2 ≤ years < 6”.

Answer (score 11):

You forgot to put QtCreator in the IDE selection.

Comment: I just work with qtcreator and I was happy to not see it there. It means not so many poor people are forced to work with that abomination.

Comment: @TomášZato by that logic, Windoze could also be removed from OS list :)

Comment: @SargeBorsch What I said was no logic, it was my personal feeling about the thing. I did **not** say it does not belong in the list.

Comment: @TomášZato I have to work with it, as its part of the Ubuntu SDK, and it is frankly an awesome IDE. Writing Plugins for it is well standardized, the documentation is excellent, and the #Qt and #Qt-Creator IRC channels are very friendly and helpful channels. Then again; I havn't used much else. What do you prefer?

Comment: @Akiva Are we even using the same IDE? QtCreator's standard features are flawed (eg. every other editor has Ctrl+H shortcut, this could be a long list of UI issues), it used to crash on me (fixed), ask me to select target device every time (fixed) it takes very long to build (won't fix they say) it commonly creates problematic builds (.obj file problems). Every IDE has it's flaws, I usually use Visual Studio, NetBeans and code::blocks. One good thing about QtCreator is rather good code inspector, but not that Netbeans or Visual Studio had any worse.

Comment: @TomášZato There is a huge difference between the versions we use: http://imgur.com/IUdHneE -- What you see in the image, is HUD integration (An Ubuntu Feature)  which allows me to execute menu commands via search. I'm also using the well integrated Fakevim, which as it happens allows me to map `/` to that search window if I want. (I usually just use `:` for that) -- And because this is the UbuntuSDK, it is very stable, and WAY EASIER TO INSTALL considering that Canonical is wholly dependent on it for its developers, and its in the repos. I've had trouble with qtcreator on windows too, so...

Answer (score 11):

Question 13:

[image]

In my case I am both a student and employed full-time. It's entirely likely that many people would have some sort of combination between any number of the options provided, and it's not very clear which one should be selected over the other as it currently stands.

I suggest changing the options to be checkboxes, or having a combination between checkboxes and radio buttons.

Comment: Agreed - it's not unrealistic to expect a retired person to have a part-time job, and I have known a few people who are mainly self-employed but also work part-time. In fact, I used to know someone who was employed full-time, worked as a freelancer in the evenings, and did voluntary work on weekends - in addition to his hobbies! (I'm convinced that he simply didn't sleep, ever.)

Answer (score 9):

Maybe next year you can ask about ReSharper as I am quite wondering about statistics on that.

Answer (score 9):

Whenever I'm asked to provide an estimate, I always double it and add a bit.

Probably won't be a T-shirt coming my way.

[image: Piggy Bank Question]

Comment: It's a joke. Why down vote?

Answer (score 7):

Can I get a list of my answers somehow? I'd like to look back at these questions in a few months and see if my attitude has changed.

Answer (score 5):

I think that it would be nice to make clear how you will use the data. I would really appreciate to make public the raw data, as there are more awesome hackers that could discover amazing things from it. You know...

> With great power, comes great responsibility

Answer (score 5):

Regarding

> 7. How many years of IT / programming experience do you have?

It's hard to know whether to answer this counting non-professional experience (like, learning to code at home on my family's computer, or any unpaid development work).

I'm going to go with **including** non-professional experience. But both are valuable things to measure, IMO, and are on the footsteps of important questions about how developers get good at development/self-taught vs/in conjunction with formal training, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I feel like "QA" implies that I'm a manual tester.  I do QA automation, using Selenium; I'm a developer, but in QA.  It'd be nice if there were a job option for this.

Answer (score -7):

Few suggestions as I'm confused by the listed technologies (think of categories, not the names), therefore I had problem deciding which checkboxes to check, fairly I could select anything relevant, so it discouraged me to continue the form:

[image: Which of the following languages or technologies have you done extensive development with in the last year? - survey]

- *Which of the following languages or technologies have you done extensive development with in the last year?*
- There is *Redis*, but what about *Memcached*? They both in-memory key/value pair cache servers. Since there are plenty of NoSQL databases, I think this should be combined into single: [`NoSQL`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) option.
- Salesforce? What about Microsoft Dynamics CRM and other [CRMs‎](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Customer_relationship_management)? Some CRM‎ Analytics/Specialists can be disrespected.
- SQL/SQL Server - what's the difference? You mean SQL client and server? It's the same thing/technology. SQL Server sounds for me like sysadmin/DevOps section and instead, I think we should have: SQL and NoSQL.
- Wordpress? What about [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/) (which is far bigger), TYPO3, Joomla and other [CMSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)? I think this should be: *CMS (Drupal, Wordpress, etc.)*
- Sharepoint? This is very small part of *Microsoft Office server suite*.
- Cloud (AWS, GAE, Azure, etc.), what about OpenStack, Mesos, etc.
- LAMP? What about WAMP/UAMP/SAMP/FAMP? E.g. I'm actually using MMP (Mac+MariaDB+[PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php), no Apache), so this should be more generic, like: Web Development, or stick with the languages.
- *`C`, `C++`* - this is the same family of the languages, so it doesn't make sense separate them, but to make one checkbox *C-family* or *C, C++* - so that checkbox space can be used for other trending district programming languages (similar to *Arduino/Raspberry Pi* checkbox, they're different, but it's the same family).

  Further clarification: I'm aware of the differences, however C and C++ are closely related and C++ grew out of C and it was designed to be compatible with C (See: [Compatibility of C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)), otherwise they wouldn't call it *C*-like. When you write apps for OS X, XCode accepts both C and Objective-C. So basically it's the same family of languages. E.g. when you develop apps for both Android and iOS, you write in C, not Objective-C, but basically you're writing the same app (for sure you won't use other language such as Java or PHP). The same we can say that Python 2 and 3 are languages with different syntax as you can't run P2 syntax on P3 and opposite. Or you can't run PHP7 in PHP4 and opposite, but you would expect one checkbox for for it. Secondly, this is just a checkbox to have more space for other interesting distinct languages in place. So for me it's not a big deal.
- *AngularJS* should go under Web Front-end category (or similar) along with jQuery, SASS/LESS, etc., since person programming in jQuery would be split between selecting AngularJS and JavaScript.

Proposed missing checkboxes for technologies:

- [Continuous Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) (Jenkins/Hudson/TeamCity/Bamboo).
- QA/Testing (Selenium/Cucumber/unit testing).
- DevOps: Puppet/Ansible/Saltstack/Chef/Phing/Maven, CI, Load Balancing
- AWS: EC2, RDS, R53, SNS, SQS, SES, ElastiCache, Cloudformation
- Enterprise search servers: Apache Solr/Lucene, Elasticsearch, CloudSearch, etc.
- SCM: Git/Svn/Mercurial, etc.
- Infrastructure monitoring: Nagios, Opsview, New Relic, Cacti, Smokeping, Zabbix, Icinga, etc.
- CDN: Fastly, Amazon CloudFront, CloudFlare, etc.
- SaaS
- NoSQL: Hadoop, PIG, HIVE, MongoDB, Flume, Neo4j, Cassandra, Kafka
- Big data: Apache Mesos, Apache Spark, Hadoop, ElasticSearch
- Message queueing: RabbitMQ, Celery
- Quantitative development: NumPy/SciPy/Pandas, Pyramid, PyXLL, PyRo
- Multi-model DBMS (graph databases): TitanDB, Neo4j, OrientDB, Titan

Comment: I disagree about *`C`, `C++`, `C#` - this is the same family of the languages* -- as far as I know, `C#` has nothing in common with `C` and `C++`, except name and syntax. And `C` and `C++` are distinct languages -- sure, you can compile some `C` code with `C++` compiler, but in real world, you don't write `C++` that looks like `C`, because it's harder, slower and more error-prone.

Comment: I'm aware of that, however C and C++ are closely related and C++ grew out of C and it was designed to be compatible with C (See: [Compatibility of C and C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compatibility_of_C_and_C%2B%2B)). E.g. when you write apps for OS X, XCode accepts both C and Objective-C. So basically it's the same family of languages. When you develop apps for both Android and iOS, you write in C, not Objective-C, but you're writing the same thing (for sure you won't use PHP). Secondly, this is just a checkbox to have more space for other distinct languages in place.

Comment: I think "SQL Server" means the specific product (or family of products) from Microsoft, while SQL means a family of query languages (one of which is the one to query SQL server). I guess they could have written "Microsoft SQL Server" to make that clearer.

Comment: C and C++ are languages of different paradigms; SharePoint is actually used more than anyone would like to think; SQL and SQL Server are not the same thing even though they "do" the same things (vendors matter). In general your post is a bit confusing. On some accounts you'd like to narrow the options down for some categories but also suggest to add more for others.

Comment: If this question suppose to list all popular software and programming languages in some circles, it would be fine. But I think the whole point of survey is about IT job market to promote StackOverflow. Therefore narrowing down some and adding more categories, it can be more focused on IT jobs, otherwise people working on some exceptionally complex systems, they actually won't be able to tick a single checkbox (and they would feel dump), since this question looks like it's written from student/junior job perspective. And I believe SO wants to go big instead.

Comment: C++ isn't really designed to be compatible with C, even according to the wiki link you've posted.

Comment: I disagree with merging C and C++, personally I'd be curious to see how many devs on SO are using only C, only C++, or both C and C++.

Answer (score -32):

The survey is too long...  Why couldn't you break it up into some differenet sections, different surveys instead of having this thing that takes a whole lunch break to fill out.

Comment: It took me 10 minutes and I'm not that fast of a reader. The only question on there that could take more time is the piggy bank one - if you make a serious attempt at guessing the number of coins, it might take some time. Myself, I just gave a WAG.