# How do I choose If I don't understand a question in survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

I am filling the [survey SO-2016](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016). I could not understand the following two questions:

1. Do you believe in aliens?
2. Dogs or cats?

How should I interpret them and what does they signify?

I hope I am not spoiling any suspense or anything by asking about these.

Comment: Why unicorns are not proposed along dogs and cats is beyond me.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Because we want it to be a fair fight.  We wouldn't learn anything new about the community if unicorns was an option.

Comment: @Servy but the presence of an open text input...

Comment: @ryanyuyu Means you'll know who the *true* SE users are ;)

Comment: I thought the *Dog vs Cats* question was asking about **dining options**.

Comment: @Paulie_D In that case, you definitely better not put Unicorn in the box. That would be a crime against all of nature. Nay, against all the universe(s)!

Comment: @Kendra Not to worry...I went for a couple of slices of Black Labrador, Golden Retriever & Poodle each from the tasting menu.

Comment: I find it hilarious that you had no problem with "Star Wars or Star Trek?"

Comment: @TinyGiant Why would any sensible person have an issue with *Trek vs Wars*? It's not like it's even a real question...'cos the answer is always **Trek**.

Comment: @Paulie_D `Uncaught type error: invalid argument "Trek", the only accepted argument is "Wars"`

Comment: See...that's what I mean...your program is defective. Might I suggest you try asking for help on PsychiatryExchange.

Comment: @Paulie_D your program is defective. `(•_•) | ( •_•)>⌐■-■ | (⌐■_■)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those questions are just for the fun of it. There's nothing super important statistics wise about them, but they'll sure be fun to know when the results come out. As for understanding them:

> Do you believe in aliens?

This one is just as it says on the tin- Do you believe in aliens? Yes? No? Got a different answer, such as you are one? Your answer specifically won't be revealed to the public, so if you're concerned about someone finding out and using your answer against you, don't be. Those results stay right with Stack Overflow. (The only real question is if they mean space type aliens, or immigrant from a different country type aliens. Interpret it as you wish.)

> Dogs or cats?

This is a "Which do you prefer" question. Do you like dogs better? Cat person at heart? Or do you like a different pet/animal/unicorn more? Fill in the box with your choice if so.

These questions don't "signify" anything, really- They're just extra/fun stats for when the results come back.

Comment: And they're much more approachable than "Tabs or Spaces"

Comment: @ryanyuyu I don't know, I'd start a flame war over the existence of aliens faster than I would the tabs/spaces issue. :)

Comment: I couldn't resist intentionally misinterpreting "believe in aliens" though.  The text box was too tempting.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That's alright, for the "Motivation for learning new technology" question, I very very nearly just put "I want to be the very best, like no one ever was." But I decided that was too much for me to be asked to type for a short survey. (And "curious" pretty well covered my motivations.)

Comment: The flame war over *Trek vs Wars* is likely to rage longer than any other.

Comment: What survey? i don't see any mention of a survey.

Comment: @KevinB You weren't invited...we don't care what you think... *I joke, I joke*!

Comment: @KevinB here you go: https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016

Comment: @KevinB Here is the Meta thread: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016

Comment: @KevinB Here you go: [meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314186](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: Can anyone provide a direct link to it or a link to the meta post? I'm lost.

Comment: @KevinB Your comment is a possible duplicate of [What survey?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314193/how-do-i-choose-if-i-dont-understand-a-question-in-survey#comment291594_314194)

Comment: @CubeJockey If we get five dupe comment votes for that, what happens to the duplicate comment?

Comment: @Kendra well the comment becomes closed to future responses of course. We already had three FGITW responses (one of which was late, and not a real response) before a duplicate was suggested so we better get on that. Unfortunately I'm all out of votes for the next 15 minutes, otherwise I would help close it.