# There are two different survey links - is it a bug?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Today I noticed this: On my right sidebar there are two survey links, as shown in the following image:

[image]

When I click on the first link it will open [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016?so&cb=1) question in which there is a survey link.

When I open that [link](https://www.surveymonkey.com/survey-taken/?sm=71pY8MPLq_2BxzeoRLdSCIFvtgQJ8nehN8igSwNqTH3DwlOxaKlKt3ZmuOFBlMpFWyBjBtBVaXaTrVrw7D01BIzQ_3D_3D), it shows:

> You have already taken this survey.

[image]

And now when I click on the image as shown in the first image above, then it will open [this link](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-survey-2016-house). And it will start the survey. This will allow me to take the survey again even if I have already completed it.

[image]

Are there two survey links, **or** this is bug, **or** am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: Well they are definitely different links. The one in the question goes to `...so-2016` and the one in the ad goes to `so-survey-2016-house`. They also behave the same way for me as they do for you (the one in the ad can't tell I've already taken it). The different links could be on purpose (they want to know whether the ad is more/less effective than the Meta post) and they're hoping people will remember not to take it twice or it's a bug. It doesn't look like it's somehow your fault though.

Comment: And what's the "Upcoming Event" element of this? It's finishing counts as "upcoming"?

Comment: Worth noticing that I also see the first link as the completed survey, but I haven't taken the survey at all.

Comment: Perhaps A/B testing, or which link gets clicked most?

Comment: @BSMP Not all people. Many people will participate multiple times in the survey.

Comment: @ketan - Why would someone need to take the survey more than once?

Comment: @BillWoodger I guess the "Upcoming" part, is the upcoming deadline. As opposed to the start of the event.

Comment: @Knossos That would be an "interesting" use of upcoming. It's an upcoming event, then it's an event, then it's over.

Comment: @BSMP to get more chances at the guessing question perhaps..

Comment: @nicael the link is generated on the fly with an id for the user... I think.

Comment: @Veve - But you have to include your userid for your guess to count. Why would they let someone's userid have multiple guesses?

Comment: @Braiam huh, seems that you're right.