# Developer survey: how many pennies were there?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2016

Now that the survey is over can we please know how many pennies were in the piggy bank?

[image]

Comment: Zero. The piggy bank is a lie.

Comment: It's O(1), I'm sure.

Comment: None. The piggy bank didn't have a back side, so the pennies weren't technically "in" the bank.

Comment: Just wait until they publish the results of the survey, 6 to 8 weeks.

Comment: I think 50 Pennies were their. Hint were written on paper which were there they were torn. So I took this idea from their.

Comment: @RaviKantHudda it's probably closer to 500

Comment: My bet was around 800... Let's see :)

Comment: You are all wrong, there were 642 pennies there :)

Comment: 9001, the answer to everything :)

Comment: My bet was 217. I tried to interpolate - I counted the visible coins and tried to guesstimate the overall volume of the piggy bank

Comment: 42 is the answer.

Comment: I guesed 700-something, though it was a multiple of 42, sure.

Comment: None, they're all 1 euro-cents.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar really? I guessed 625

Comment: I counted the wrappers, and assumed there were some not included in the image.  Fifty per roll.  Don't remember how many rolls I could identify in the image, but I think it was a minimum of eight.  Assumed the image wasn't stock and that they didn't open rolls that were not used in the image (partial rolls being a possibility, of course).

Comment: I bet 321. I'm that lazy.

Comment: oh and we know what 6 to 8 weeks mean @HansPassant :^)

Comment: My guess was 260, simply because I thought there could be 20 coins per "roll", and around 13 rolls.

Comment: There certainly were a lot of pennies. At least 6. Possibly more.

Comment: My bet was 9,223,372,036,854,775,808: Long.MAX_VALUE + 1

Comment: The ends of the paper roll had a specific design, so i counted the times i saw that, got 18, implying 9 rolls ripped up, then there was the one standing there with a couple pennies removed... so i guessed 452 (since 50 per roll is standard for pennies).  Thought about trying to confirm it by calculating the volume of the jar, but was lazy.

Comment: My guess is about 500, based on paper wraps each of one contains 50 coins.

Comment: @Thymine "...since 50 per roll is standard for pennies" - Well, that explains why my guess was about twice those here. I'm not from the US and assumed they'd be a full dollar!

Comment: My guess was between 500 and 600, so I said 2^9-1.

Comment: Don't know why, but I approximated the pennies count to be 160. Let's see if others also voted for the nearby figures...

Comment: Should do this with a graph showing the distribution of guesses, and an indicator where the actual value is (perhaps outlined with a freehand red circle for clarity). Not sure about the best way to aggregate non-numeric answers though.

Comment: @FabioTurati You thought there were 20 pennies a roll?  Why? You can clearly read "50 cents" on the side of an unopened roll...As to the graph of the distribution, I'd like to know what the average guess was.  Ignoring Chis's maximum long value entry, due to calculation limits. ;)

Comment: @Draco18s I think Fabio is Mr. Money Bags and deals with rolls of nickels instead

Comment: @CubeJockey 50 cents in nickles would be 10! :X

Comment: @Draco18s ah, but we're assuming Fabio didn't read the wrapper! So your math is irrelevant!

Comment: @CubeJockey Touche ;)

Comment: @Draco18s - haha, I haven't been called "Chis" in years; have to go back to first year university for that memory :)

Comment: @Draco18s I saw that 50, but I didn't trust it. See the only roll that is standing vertically? It looks like it's full, or almost (you can see both ends, with the red pattern), and you can see the thickness of a single coin. More or less, I'd say you need 20 coins that thick to reach the height of that roll. They'd have to be thinner for 50 of them to be in a roll that high. But now that I have a better look, I think what I took for a single coin are actually 2. Then it makes sense that there are 50. Well, no problem, my estimate that there are 13 rolls is also inaccurate, so who cares! :-P

Comment: @CubeJockey Me, Mr. Money Bags? Well, yes, I admit it. I actually even had to get rid of all the coins at home, as I find it already hard enough to stash away all my 100-euro banknotes. I'd happily switch to 200- or 500- ones, but I don't like their colour.

Comment: 6 and 1/2 pennies to be exact.

Comment: @Thymine I did exactly the same thing... and also guessed 452. Assuming all the wrappers are in the picture we could be on the money. Oink.

Comment: I didn't bother to count the rolls or visible pennis or calculate the volume of jar n all... since it's 2015 survey... For some reason I answered 2016 n moved on :3

Comment: @Thymine and CasparHarmer I almost did the same thing but assumed that only 1 had been taken from the open roll and guessed 451.

Comment: 250 or 256, I searched google images for a pile of pennies

Comment: I found http://www.containerstore.com/s/collections/banks-safes/piggy-bank/12d?productId=10005788, calculated the volume based on that, saw that Google said there are about 50000 pennies per gallon, divided accordingly, and got 1100. I assumed the wrappers were a red herring.

Comment: @SomethingDark: did you consider that the pig is not square?

Comment: I said 486, because these are the best CPUs ever made...

Comment: Why is everyone talking about pennies in rolls? That pic has nothing to do with it!

Comment: My guess was 454 because there were 9 rolls from what I counted and one of them is opened with few missing.

Comment: I hate to be the one to break it to people, but the roll says 50 cent not 50 number.. there are 20 coins per roll...  If you look at the roll that's open with coins you can see that there wouldn't be 50 in that stack.

Comment: @tom_redox you'll have to run that one by me. 20 coins value 50 cents means they are 2 1/2 cent coins? Or am I still having trouble with simple maths? I thought one penny was one cent. I remember pre-decimal UK currency, as an aside. Fortunately, too young to have needed to do maths in it.

Comment: @tom_redox, I'm confused, 20 coins to make 50 cents would surely make each coin worth 2.5 cents? I'm not saying that's not a real denomination somewhere, but it seems odd...

Comment: @tom_redox I was wondering how to check, then noticed a big picture at the top of the page. 50 cents indeed, pennies.

Comment: They label the rolls as "pennies" generically I think, so the 50 cent is the value of each coin not the total value of the roll http://coins.about.com/od/uscoins/f/roll_of_coins_f.htm

Comment: @tom_redox `you can see that there wouldn't be 50 in that stack.`  Can you?  By what logic?  Defective [conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_%28psychology%29), perhaps?

Comment: @tom_redox your own link shows that 50c coins would be labelled in a roll as $10 (20 x 0.50).

Comment: According to [how many coins in a roll](http://coinauctionshelp.com/How_Many_Coins_In_A_Roll.html#.VqIP-3VStBc) there are 50 coins. Too bad as my bet was 25

Comment: Question is too broad to answer. :D

Comment: @ketan actually the question is quite specific: "...can we know...?" and apparently the answer is "no"

Comment: I don't have flagged the question. I just say i can't count So, it is too broad for me to answer.  :D :)

Comment: @ketan actually my comment was (a failed) attempt to joke

Comment: I stand (well) corrected! @J... that's an interesting article, yes I think I'm definitely guilty of that

Comment: Should we migrate this chat to the [chat]?

Comment: It's the **2016 annual** survey. Of course there are 366 pennies. The rolls merely give an upper bound.

Comment: I calculated 432... I did the math

Comment: lots-lots-lots-many-many-2

Comment: My spider _cents_ told me 499.

Comment: @Milad Really, you're no fun.

Comment: @Milad according to my research, yes, pennies do consist of matter.

Comment: Galton would be disappointed. http://www.npr.org/sections/money/2015/08/07/430372183/episode-644-how-much-does-this-cow-weigh

Comment: @BiscuitBaker This is a great example of programmers overthinking everything: The rolls clearly say 50 pennies, and here we have people guessing 20, 25, or 100 per roll. That said, I didn't even think to count the rolls...

Answer (score 125, accepted):

753 pennies.

Doesn't look like it, huh? The median guess was 423.

[image: pennies histogram]

56,032 people took the survey (wow). 42,035 respondents made a penny guess. 54 of you guessed correct. 37 correct guessers will be getting swag in the mail (they included a user link with their survey responses). 118 more of you will also be getting swag.

[image: winning guesses & guesses by top 10 countries]

<sup>N.B. The two sides of this sheet are two different tables; the countries bear no relation to the guesses on the left.</sup>

That’s because we said we’d be giving out swag to 100 people, but only 97 of you guessed within 1 penny, and 98 guessed within 1.06 pennies, so we expanded swag eligibility to all respondents who guessed within 2 pennies (and also included a user link at the end of the survey). If you’re one of 155 eligible winners, keep an eye on your inbox – we’ll be asking for your mailing address shortly.

Thanks for taking the survey. We’ll be publishing full results and releasing a dump of all responses (cleaned of personally identifiable information) within the next several weeks.

Comment: I could *swear* that 751.94 was me. Guess I'll be watching the inbox.

Comment: *...within the next several weeks.* Come on, say 6 to 8. We won't mind.

Comment: makes me sad that people were guessing less than 10.

Comment: @DanielA.White People guessing 0 also :D

Comment: Was the number of paper coin rolls a red herring or an accurate proxy? That’s what I used to guess the number (but I don’t remember my estimate, or whether it was close to the correct number).

Comment: arr, I think I answered 950ish, that was way off...

Comment: I think I guessed 803... so close-ish but no swag :-(  I can haz URL for to buy some swag consolation prize?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I did the same, counted the number of complete paper rolls, which contain 50 pennies each. I submitted 450 I think (making me guess that it was a red herring).

Comment: Amazingly interesting country-level data.

Comment: I got the right answer! I counted the number of empty paper rolls in the table, I counted 15 so that was 750 pennies. Then I estimated that there were 3 coins missing from the full penny roll in the picture. Therefore 753 pennies was my guess :)

Comment: @gabriellanata same here. Received my swag email already :)

Comment: @gabriellanata same method here. And I got the email also. Waiting for the swag now :)

Comment: Is the list of winners going to be released, similarly to the twitter/profile campaign winners list?

Comment: I recieved the mail, but I can't remember what was my answer...how can I check it?

Comment: What is the frequency or common factor of the spikes in the distribution? Hard to read from the axis, and I thought you might already have investigated that.

Comment: @JonasWielicki Round guesses: 200, 250, 300, 350 and so on (225, 275, 325 has minor spikes too)

Comment: Huh, who would have thought my start in classics would have paid off. I "guessed" correctly: [753 BC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_urbe_condita)

Comment: Is there any country restriction to deliver my swag? I am in Brazil and my guess was right (or almost, I don't remember). :D

Comment: @emartinelli nope! if you received an email asking for your address, then you'll receive a T-shirt... or at least your local mail person will.

Comment: @MattN. awesome coincidence =)

Comment: Neat data.  The shape of the container and the misleading wrappers around it probably threw off the mean guess (I know I guessed based on the wrappers!).  Is that giant spike right around 500 actually *512?*

Comment: @BhargavRao Maybe they believed it to be a trick question and that they were dimes.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I just looked at the histogram. There is really 751.94. Is that you?

Comment: swag for winners & wrapper for rest of us :( :(

Comment: Man, I was way off. At least I'm not the only person who guessed around 1000. I was always crap at estimating the size/amount of things.

Comment: @Draco18s The wrappers assisted in the solution.  There are 16 wrappers pictured (including the roll that is mostly full).  They are arranged in a way that makes it a bit difficult to add them up visually.  I recounted several times to make sure I got the same number of rolls a few times.  That gives the 750 coins for the 15 empty rolls.  From there I looked at the open roll and figured the thickness of the coins another 3 missing from that roll.  I was a bit surprised hearing from others how many people apparently miscounted the open rolls and ended up with roughly half the number of coins.

Comment: @bigtunacan I recall trying to count "ends" of wrappers and coming up with 20, ignoring the non-empty roll (each roll has 2 ends, 20 / 2 = 10, 10 * 50 = ~500).  In retrospect I see how I messed up my count.

Comment: Counting wrappers got me nowhere. There was no way to know if all the wrappers were being shown in the picture or if they weren't added just for aesthetics.  So I compared the approximative occupied volume of the piggy bank with the volume of 50 pennies. (I approximated the "disorder" volume factor to `.3`). Came out with "around" 15 times = 750 coins. Then I thought 750 might be too common an answer so I asked myself: *What would you pick? Below or above?* They looked like more to me, so I went with `752`. I'm surprised I got so close to the right answer.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Agreed on the aesthetics part.  The bank is partially transparent and I noticed that there did not appear to be any wrappers behind the bank.  I considered if the wrappers in the picture were only staged likely they would have had wrappers behind it that were either partially or not at all visible.

Given the proportions in the picture of the bank compared to the rolls the volume seemed a reasonable match to how many pennies were in the bank; so I then made the assumption that the rolls were placed to assist in the answer rather than to deceive.

Comment: @bigtunacan that was also my approach, and I also got it right :) glad the counting, recounting, and recouning, marking the ends, and recounting again paid off :)

Comment: If still possible, I'd like to change my ordered size from S to M. Some M's are large on me and some S's small. I feel more comfortable in a slightly smaller one, but look better in a slightly larger one. Heavily influenced by my wife's opinion, I would like to take my chances on a slightly larger one than I might need, rather than on a smaller one (which was my personal, initial choice). **Only if it's still an option and if it's not too much trouble.** Already submitted this via email form but thought I might increase my chances of getting this late change by posting it here, too. Thank you.

Comment: @samthebrand: Just wondering if these T-shirts have been dispatched yet? What's the typical delivery time (I'm in the UK)? I've not seen a postman walking round in one yet...!

Comment: @Ian you can only hope that it will be delivered faster than the 10M question swag. We were told back in August 2015 that we would get it "within 6-8 weeks"... We're still waiting.. More information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272623/314542

Comment: @Jordumus thanks for at least pointing me there!

Comment: @Ian hasn't gone out yet. Probably will be a couple weeks until swag arrives. Hopefully will happen a lot more swiftly than the 10M question swag.

Comment: You got it @AndreiGheorghiu

Comment: Any way to know what my guess was? I somehow don't remember :P

Comment: @HappyCoder did you find out? I'm curious about my guess too.

Comment: No clues! @Math

Comment: @samthebrand Any idea if the swag has gone out? I received an email asking for my address through a form, though haven't received anything from SO in the mail.

Comment: @Zack You can see the updates [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272627/293824) (spoiler: there are not updates, yet).

Comment: @samthebrand Many are not sure how much they guessed. How to find that?

Comment: @Jordumus I recieved my 10M swag a couple of weeks ago (I'm not in the U.S btw), I'd email Tim if I were you to check up.

Comment: I guessed 420, oh well.

Comment: Haha, the previous year, by the time the answer came round I'd forgotten what my guess had been. So *this* year I carefully noted it somewhere. But I can't remember where :)

Comment: Can we have that image of pennies please. Hope it won't be a big deal and thanx :)

Answer (score 31):

Ooooo yea, got my swag today! Thank you Stack Exchange!

[image: stack exchange swag]

Comment: <3.
Critical appreciation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317996/replace-kiddie-text-speak-with-proper-english-words

Comment: me too....  waiting...

Comment: Hi Phillip! What is this orange thing? =)

Comment: @zarkone: It [looks like](http://g03.s.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1SZQwIFXXXXXkXpXXq6xXFXXX1/202319262/HTB1SZQwIFXXXXXkXpXXq6xXFXXX1.jpg) it folds out to be a can cooler/coozie/stubbie-holder.

Comment: @Oddthinking, yes it is: it has small label, and i googled the company and get what is it.. I just never seen this things and was wonder what is it when I've got the parcel

Comment: any other surveys? we really want to have a shirt like this.

Comment: It's called a [Koozie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koozie), among many other names.

Answer (score 19):

Thanks from Spain StackExchange! :)

[image]

The orange thing is like a neoprene cylinder. Perfect for a small bottle ;)

[image]

Comment: whats in the little orange pack

Comment: It's called a [Koozie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koozie), among many other names.

Comment: Didn't notice any swag winners from Spain in the [results](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315438/692942)?

Comment: @Lankymart See: "N.B. The two sides of this sheet are two different tables; the countries bear no relation to the guesses on the left." Right below the image. The winners on the left and the country aggregates on the right are separate data.