# Forgot my guess for "Developer survey: how many pennies were there?". Can I find out?

Tags: discussion, support, survey-2016

I forgot how much I guessed for the "how many pennies are there in this piggy bank" question on the 2016 Stack Overflow survey, and I would really like to find out how close I was to getting a shirt... Is there a way to find out what my guess was?

[Everyone's guesses seem to have been synthesized...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315181/developer-survey-how-many-pennies-were-there)

Comment: I completely missed this and am somewhat sure that I answered ironically with a decimal value, so I would be very interested to know if the 751.94 was mine and my mail provider kept the swag for itself… :D

Comment: How do you propose this is implemented? Answering individual requests doesn't scale but publicising everyone's results would violate privacy expectations.

Comment: @MartinSmith How about, if you provided a user link, you can see your responses if you log in?

Comment: @OrangeDog yes that would work. Personally I'm not sure it would be worth the dev time just to satisfy this kind of idle curiosity though.

Comment: One way I tried but failed was checking to see if my response was cached in my browser, but (probably for the best) it was not there.

Comment: I guess we can wait for them to release the data dump of all the answers, and browse that.

Comment: It would have been nice to receive an email with my response to each question after I completed the survey. Doing this for each user would have solved this and any other curiosities.

Comment: I tend to forget stuff, so I just ask myself: how would you do it? And that usually is the answer. BTW I counted the envelopes and added 3.

Comment: @Braiam Did you get swag?

Comment: I got the mail... not the swag yet, but I expect my country mail deliver system be kind of crappy.

Comment: @Braiam I want swag........................................................................... :<

Comment: This question makes no cents.

Comment: @ruchir you're just passing the buck

Comment: @Bohemian If I had a penny every time I heard that!

Comment: A "sheet" with userid / guess would so much violate privacy??? I'm pretty confident no one cares if someone knows what they did guess

Comment: @Lankymart:  If we wanted to hear from you, we would have offered a penny for your thoughts.