# Take the 2023 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2023

> **Update on June 13, 2023:** Thanks to everyone who took the survey! The 2023 Developer Survey results are available [here](https://survey.stackoverflow.co/2023/?utm_source=banner&utm_medium=display&utm_campaign=dev-survey-results-2023&utm_content=survey-results). (Also see the announcement on the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/06/13/developer-survey-results-are-in/).)

The annual Developer Survey is now live! We want to hear from anyone who codes, is learning to code, is code-adjacent, or is in the developer community. The survey will remain open until **May 19, 2023**.

**[Don't delay, take the 2023 Developer Survey today](https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_czLVsbnGnF4Q04e?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2023&utm_content=meta)**.

Thank you in advance for your participation and for making your voice heard. A sincere thank you to everyone who [provided feedback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424290/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2023-developer-survey) on our listed technologies for the 2023 survey.

This year, you may notice some changes to the survey as we've worked to simplify the 2023 Developer Survey. For example, we have removed all demographic questions except age and country of residence.

In addition, we're unfortunately no longer able to award the Census badge for those who complete the entire survey. [You can learn more about this update here.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/removal-of-the-census-badge)

Survey results will be available publicly under the Open Database License. You'll be able to download and analyze the dataset later this year and we'll update this post once they're available.

If you use security or ad-blocking plugins, you may see error messages. Our third-party software provider, Qualtrics, does not work well with certain ad blockers and security software. To avoid error messages that prevent you from taking the survey, please try specifically unblocking Qualtrics in your plugin or pausing the plugin while you take the survey. Additionally, as a reminder, Qualtrics blocks certain countries from accessing their site and data: Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Syria, and the Crimea region of Ukraine (including Sevastopol). In addition, some users in China may have issues due to restrictions imposed by local internet service providers.

If you discover any bugs in the survey or have any questions or concerns, please feel free to add them below this post as answers.

Comment: Visual Studio (not VS Code) is missing from the development environments section

Comment: The mention of the change(s) about the 'Census' Badge is a bit vague, could mention the change directly (between brackets maybe) without having to read a long separate Thread...: => "*Beginning with the 2023 Developer Survey, we will no longer give the Census badge to those who complete the entire Developer Survey.*"

Comment: Web frameworks, presumably "Spring" and "Boot" are supposed to be one option "Spring Boot"

Comment: It would be good to be able to review the questions/answers after having submitted the survey. I had some feedback to give regarding some of the questions but now I have no way to go back to them

Comment: "*Which of the following best describes the code you write outside of work?*" => How is option "*Freelance/contract work*" *outside* of work...? // + Could mention "SO + Tech Forums", many of us write Code on SO when answering Questions.

Comment: IMHO, this post is asking for two things in one: a) as the title says "please do the survey" and b) at the very end "if you discover any bugs[...] post as answers.". I would have preferred two separate posts: a highlighted post for doing the survey and a different one for the bugs. This post is currently hard to find when looking for 2023 developer survey bugs.

Comment: My attitude towards the title is the same as ever: **Why should I?**

Comment: what's the internal review process for the survey like? [the community review post](/q/424290) uncovered a great many basic mistakes with casing the should have been fixed by basic googling, and the published survey contains several problems which people have pointed out here. I imagine this does not look good on the company. What are you going to do to avoid these kinds of mistakes happening in the future?

Comment: I edited the wording of the Census badge "change" sentence; the original phrasing felt actively misleading to me. My impression is that the intent of it was certainly to "soften the blow" rather than "mislead", but it danced around the actual effect too much, and just ended up being confusing. Folks deserve to know that "change" means "went away" without having to click through or [find out at the end of the survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424600).

Comment: Why was the "Race and ethnicity" section removed this year?

Comment: @Paolo Presumably because that information is irrelevant, and none of their business to ask about?

Comment: @DanMašek Why was it asked last year then?

Comment: @user every year they have these endless basic mistakes. Presumably the people designing and writing it are marketing people with no understanding of software development whatsoever.

Comment: @Paolo Beats me... I just remember that people were (IMHO rightfully) irritated by it, and let them know.

Comment: @Paolo Because this survey always had a heavy focus towards what upper management at SO considers the latest buzzword. Some years back it was "diversity". Now it is "AI". Buzzword-driven development...

Comment: There were a few how often type questions where the allowable answers included never and 1-2 times a week, but not less than weekly, though that would have been my answer.

Comment: Maybe one year they'll actually show the survey to at least one developer before releasing it.

Comment: What makes Sevastopol special to the point of deserving an explicit mention? Isn't it obviously part of Crimea?

Comment: Why doesn't the "How did you learn to code?" question not seem to include "Reading the documentation"?

Comment: Given that in the survey you ask for country and salary information, will you be sharing the collected data with us, perhaps broken down by country?

Comment: I wonder why this is downvoted. Maybe because we're not getting a Census badge.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica Officially, Sevastopol is not part of the [Autonomous Republic of Crimea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_Republic_of_Crimea), but is a [city with special status](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_with_special_status).

Comment: How many questions are there in the survey and how long does it approximately to finish it? Many other surveys kind of indicate that information at the beginning. Or am I simply not seeing it?

Comment: I used to complete them, but this is nothing but a money making scheme for SO to sell the data we give them. This site is going down the pan since people have flocked to AI. A sinking ship. And why? Because you pissed all over your users. I'm not completing this and I've urged others not to.

Answer (score 103):

> This year, you may notice some changes to the survey as we've worked to simplify the 2023 Developer Survey. For example, we have removed all demographic questions except age and country of residence.

I've stayed out of this discussion thus far, but... This is getting stupid. Please stop patronizing us.

You removed a bunch of questions [*and* a badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424491/updated-5-8-23-changes-to-the-census-badge) because someone got spooked and realized you were probably skirting the edges of one or more country's privacy laws, and... possibly skirting them from the wrong side of the border, so to speak.

**But you absolutely did *not* remove all but two demographic questions.**

The primary purpose of this survey from its inception has been market research on behalf of potential customers. You can't do market research without... Identifying the markets you're targeting. If you removed *all* demographic questions, all you'd be able to say is "we got folks who use Stack Overflow". With age, you can tell potential customers which age ranges we fall into. With country, you can additionally tell them how we break down by region. That's a lot more specific! But... It's not enough. Clearly, since you also ask...

- My profession
- My employment status
- Whether I work remotely
- My education level
- My field of employment

...and a whooooole bunch of other stuff. Heck, you even ask whether I've ever heard of Stack Overflow, have a SO account, which sites I visit, how often, etc. - the "demographics" that I suggested were almost a gimme.

**The survey is chock full of demographics!** You just removed the *handful* of demographics most likely to get you in trouble, while leaving the ones most useful when trying to sell stuff.

Look, I get it. Whatever's going on behind the scenes with the survey this year, I'm sure it's stressful and nobody's sure what they can or should say about it. **I've been there.** Heck, arguably I made the wrong calls when I was in that position, at least from a self-preservation standpoint, so... I can't really even be that mad about this charade.

But it is a charade, and a transparent one at that, so if anyone's wondering why this post is getting a grumpy response... Well, none of us like being treated as though you think we're rubes.

So if you can't tell the truth, at least stop lying.

Comment: Perhaps they labour under the misapprehension that "demographic" means "something that is readily identity-politicked over in the USA".

Comment: Naw, I don't buy that @Karl - Hanlon's razor not withstanding, that'd be akin to assuming a geologist doesn't know that "rock" is a broad term. More likely, the folks involved here are so accustomed to using more specific terms for various types of demographics that the term ends up as shorthand for a subset. Or, if we wanna be less generous... A less charged term for what under various laws and policies is properly termed Personally Identifiable Information. Given the persistent caginess surrounding all this, my bet is on the latter.

Comment: This made me feel something approaching the same as at the end of 8mile. Please oh please won't you start posting again :)

Comment: Think of all the trouble we would have saved ourselves if we had simply not been curious about the gender gap.

Comment: That was fine, @JonEricson - in fact, I think it was generally beneficial... What was lost somewhere along the way was the purpose. Collecting demographics is always a tradeoff - you're asking someone to give up pieces of their privacy in exchange for... What? Originally, we could answer that question, and *did* answer that question. When it can't be answered anymore, that's a good sign that you're collecting things you shouldn't. That goes for all the demographics *still in* the survey too.

Answer (score 55):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Visual Studio was [listed as a development environment for 2023](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424290/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2023-developer-survey) but isn't present in the actual survey.

[image: Visual Studio not listed]

IMHO, that's a major oversight which could lead to incorrect statistics.

Comment: Given that Visual Studio has been one of the most used IDEs last year, it's really a major flaw of the survey when it's not included.

Comment: Visual Studio added.

Answer (score 49):

This year's survey felt more like it was market research for Stack Overflow AI products moreso than a "dev survey."

I feel like in the past, the survey has felt more like "Developer Survey" where overwhelmingly the inputs would be interesting to me as an engineer.

Not this year's - it felt like almost all the questions I was answering were purely relevant to SO the company (though I stopped midway through as a result of this).

Answer (score 31):

Perhaps this is meta commentary, but I know I enjoyed participating in all previous questionnaires (and I'm a person who's known to voluntarily subscribe to such things).

However: I really couldn't get myself to finish the survey.

Is it me or is it repetitive and boring, more than previous years? It feels so soulless, as if I'm entering what's on my resume after uploading my resume.

Comment: any specific / concrete differences you noticed that might contribute to the feeling?

Comment: I mainly couldn't get through the long lists of "which technologies/frameworks/tools do you use".

Comment: @CodeCaster tbf, they did [make note of](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424290/review-our-technical-responses-for-the-2023-developer-survey) that problem when curating the list, though that doesn't mean the mistake won't occur in a different way, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @KevinB lol who started editing that post and putting it in tables, some with multiple columns and some with multiple terms per cell (based on first letter)? The fact that someone thought it needed that kind of edit tells enough, I think. Who's "they" though?

Comment: They being SO, the company. They're well aware of the feedback around adding emotional spin to our responses being negatively received, ;) The table formatting? the edit history has all that info. Probably came from the community if i had to guess? someone right out of the gate complained scrolling was hard.

Comment: I miss the 'fake' question that gave the survey a personality... Star Wars or Star Trek... Tabs or Spaces... or "is Hungarian Notation still the worst idea ever? [yes] / [of course] / [yes, but the concept it was trying to do was good, but the documented implementation is what is wrong]"

Comment: @scunliffe I think that's it, it's just a soulless questionnaire as if I'm entering what's on my resume after uploading my resume.

Comment: I miss the [opportunities for swag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315181/developer-survey-how-many-pennies-were-there/)

Answer (score 30):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Spring Boot (in *web frameworks and web technologies*) should be one option, not two, no?

[image]

Comment: Or *[Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework)* ***and*** *[Spring Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Spring_Boot)*? (If it makes sense.)

Comment: This! Also “Play” and (right below it) “Framework”, which is probably supposed to be “Play Framework”.

Comment: Ruby on Rails is also three entries https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWkW6.png

Comment: @gunr2171 My favourite framework is "on".

Comment: Spring Boot and Ruby on Rails fixed

Answer (score 28):

### What's in it for me?

This post is clearly a call to action, but I don't see any reason to act. Other answers have mentioned the removal of the Census badge; I don't care about badges, and if I did, it **wouldn't be enough**. We're talking here about the kind of thing that people sometimes offer significant amounts of real money for (and those offers sometimes get declined).

**You want me to disclose information about myself and get nothing in return**, so that you can market your products better by using the information. Then there's the **privacy risk**. I note here that you also expect me to **trust Qualtrics, not just you**; whatever your policies are, [data breaches are a reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2017_Equifax_data_breach). You expect me to assume this risk without compensation.

I will give slight credit for removing some questions that were asked in previous years (ones that you call "demographic" questions - although as Shog9 rightly points out, a lot of what you're asking is still clearly demographic in nature) for which I cynically see only culture-warring, identity-political purposes (i.e., asserting that XYZ policy has made the site more "[welcoming and inclusive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22welcoming+and+inclusive%22)" or else arguing that more XYZ needs to be done, without providing any empirical reason to *expect* a specific demographic breakdown of users beyond the [most](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blank_Slate) naive [blank slatism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa) imaginable). However, it appears that this is only [incidental](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424491), and not motivated by any actual ideological shift. Meanwhile, you are apparently now also asking a bunch of **questions about AI that seem intended to prime the audience** for new AI "integrations" and [get people used to the idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manufacturing_Consent), despite the [overwhelming rejection it has already received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388401).

I see no reason to take the survey, just as I have not in the past; and for those of you about to do so, I would like to strongly urge you to reconsider.

Comment: on your AI point's "_despite the overwhelming rejection it has already received._", well, the masses seem to have turned around (at least- those that kept their ears open) a _little bit_ once SE actually gave some concrete examples. [The title example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388492/997587) is well received.

Comment: Re *"get nothing in return"*: You do get to influence the result. The survey is [widely cited](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuHDQhDhvPE&t=5s), including trends. By not participating you are amplifying the voices of others who do participate (however slightly, but collectively it matters). And the ***free form text*** at the very end is also an opportunity to influence (the impact is unknown, but it is usually ***huge*** if it is actually read as very few people (presumably) bother). It could be the very thing that sways a higher-up to take the right decision instead of the wrong one.

Answer (score 22):

How is there not a *"I search on a search engine like Google"* option here?

I mean, even AI is an option, but the **one thing** people probably use most, good old fashioned google, isn't an option?

> [image]

Comment: Other -> and then let's enter late 90's sites. AltaVista anyone?

Comment: @rene ask  ̶C̶h̶a̶t̶G̶P̶T̶ Jeeves

Comment: This is beyond absurd

Answer (score 21):

I don't know how to interpret the "(more often)" part in this option:

[image]

Can one really have continuous delivery more often than continuous integration? I can only think of cases where continuous delivery happens less often than continuous integration. IMHO, we CI first and if that succeeds, we CD.

In my company, we don't have continuous delivery at all. So, should I check that checkbox, because we have CI, or should I not check that checkbox because we have less CD than CI?

Comment: I'd think it means "more often known as CI/CD, instead of CI only", which is basically "CI or CI/CD"

Answer (score 21):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Under web frameworks: it's "ASP.NET Core", not "ASP.NET CORE". Also, what is "Framework"?

[image: Framework]

Was that supposed to be "Play Framework"?

And thanks for applying 66% of [my answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424302/266143) to "other frameworks and libraries", but now there are ".NET (5+)" and ".NET Framework (1.0 - 4.8)", but .NET Core is missing.

.NET Core was [released and supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET#History) from June 2016 until December 2022. Any reason for not including it?

Comment: Play Framework fixed.

Comment: But the .NET Core one?

Answer (score 20):

Age question is missing a * even though it is a required question. Trying to move on without checking anything shows an error.

[image: img]

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

I'm asked about my **annual** compensation.

Below that, I'm asked whether that compensation is **weekly**, **monthly**, or **yearly**.

How is this to be understood? It feels confusing and redundant.

i.e., if I enter "24000" and "monthly", does it mean that I receive 24,000 each month, earning 24,000 × 12 = 288,000 in one year, or that I receive 24,000 / 12 = 2,000 each month, earning 24,000 in one year?

Comment: I don't remember seeing this. "Annual monthly compensation" is gibberish, obviously. Annual compensation is annual... Unless the survey wished to know if it is custom in your country to pay out salary once per week or once per month (no idea what that has to do with software development specifically though).

Comment: We have fixed this.

Comment: Why haven't I been asked about my annual compensation?

Comment: I would assume it's recursive, so if you enter that you receive infinite money monthly

Comment: @Joy Should this be marked [tag:status-fixed] like the fixes in previous years?

Comment: @Joy The fix seems to be removing the "weekly/monthly/yearly" switch. In my country the salarly is normally measured per month, so the switch would be convenient. :(

Answer (score 19):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

In the "Which programming, scripting, and markup languages have you done extensive development work..." question, there's an extraneous apostrophe in the Bash/Shell option:

[image]

It reads "*Bash/Shell (all shell's)*" (good grief, it hurts me just to type it). It should read "*Bash/Shell (all shells)*". Apostrophes are **not** used in plurals.

Answer (score 16):

#### Thank you so much for [listening](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/424293/11107541) and adding some C and C++ ecosystem tools to the survey!

Note that I'm pretty sure it's redundant to say "GNU" in "GNU GCC", since GCC stands for GNU Compiler Collection. But I might be wrong.

Note: It's a little :/ to see that in the "developer tools for compiling, building and testing" section, system package managers like Homebrew (that's a system package manager, right?) are there (and thanks for adding others as suggested like APT, Chocolatey, PacMan), and language-ecosystem package-management-related technologies are also there, such as npm, pnpm, Yarn, NuGet, Maven, Gradle, but not other language-ecosystem-related ones like suggested, such as vcpkg, Conan, Spack, Hunter, and build2 (for C++). I.e., I still feel like there are imbalances in representation for various language ecosystems' tooling. Also, when you've got all those package-management technologies listed, I think the heading for that section should really also include "package-management".

---

I tried looking for the Git option in the technology sections (in an attempt to see if other SCM/VCS technologies got added as requested) and... is it just me or is it not there any more? If it isn't,... why?

---

Now, I did make a point about Bash/Sh and other shells (Zsh, Dash, Fish, etc.), but calling the option "Bash/Shell (all Shells)" is also problematic, since you put PowerShell as a separate option, and PowerShell is also a shell / shell scripting option.

---

"*Worked with in PAST year*" is a *little* bit ambiguous. Does it mean strictly just the past one year? Or any past year? I assume any, but maybe not everyone will. How about "Worked with in any PAST year"? Also, why specifically "next year"? Why not a more general "in the future" and "in the past"?

---

What's up with the "shopping question"s like "*When buying a new tool or software, how do you discover and research available solutions?*". A lot of sites in the Stack Exchange network don't allow shopping questions (see also [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/))... so is this just a Teams advertising related thing? I assume we'll find out in a future blog post :P

Comment: It’s the past year, as in the previous 12 months. Also next year, as in the next 12 months. They’re looking at what is hot now, not what was hot 20 years ago.

Comment: GNU can literally mean anything, a whole bunch of tools mostly of the Linux variety, including gcc. Or is it GNU's not GCC?

Answer (score 16):

**What is AI?**

The survey immediately starts asking about "AI tools" without giving any definition for what it's talking about. Most computer assistant technologies from the last 30-40 years are "AI tools". From spellchecks and autocomplete to search and TTS and STT systems.

I assume from context you mean GPT and only GPT. But perhaps you were also thinking of GitHub Copilot?

If that's what you're asking about, then be specific. Almost everyone uses "AI tools" all the time, but most don't use either of those two.

Comment: *I assume from context you mean GPT and only GPT. But perhaps you were also thinking of GitHub Copilot?* Github Copilot is built on GPT.

Comment: @vandench yet another reason it should explain what it's talking about

Comment: What are [TTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TTS) and [STT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STT)? [Text-to-speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-to-speech) and [speech-to-text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen correct.

Answer (score 16):

I've received an email at my work email titled "The 2023 Developer Survey is now open!". It says:

> You're receiving this email because you are a valued customer.

It includes an "Unsubscribe" link but it takes me to Stack Overflow login page (with a redirect to `https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current`). I cannot login with my work email because there is no user associated with it. Instead, it asks me to create a new user. I apparently have a Teams subscription which is scheduled to be cancelled in 2 days but that doesn't have any settings to stop these emails. Please fix it.

Comment: I see you're in Germany. You can get them in big trouble for sending marketing emails with no way to unsub.

Answer (score 15):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Why is there a checkbox for the "none" option? Other questions (e.g. about databases) didn't have such an option. Suddenly I am required to check something where I already got used to the fact that there is nothing to check. That's inconsistent.

[image: None option for AI powered search tools]

It's also some kind of oxymoron: I worked with an AI-powered search tool and the tool I worked with is called "I haven't used any".

Comment: I interpreted this as "I don't want to use any AI-powered search tools next year" (a more extreme statement than "I don't want to use any of the below listed tools").

Comment: "I haven't used any AI-powered search tools but I worked with them in the past year. Next year I want to work with AI-powered search tools that I haven't used."  :)

Comment: columns adjusted

Answer (score 14):

For the Professional Developer Series, there's an asterisk in the text but it's never explained what the asterisk means. It can hardly be the asterisk explained at the very beginning of the survey, which means that the question is mandatory. If so, I expected that asterisk right after the question mark and not after an accompanying sentence.

[image: Asterisk]

Answer (score 13):

This problem is still exactly the same as when it was reported last year, so I'm just going to quote [Clonkex's answer from last year's survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418057/208273):

> What's with these intervals? From 1-2 times a week to never? What about 1-2 times a month? None of the options fit my case. I don't interact outside my team very often (maybe once or twice a month) but when I do it's usually because of knowledge silos.
>
> [image: A question asking "How frequently do you experience each of the following?" with options of "Never", "1-2 times a week", "3-5 times a week", "6-10 times a week", and "10+ times a week"]

Answer (score 12):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The list under
"Which **developer tools for compiling, building and testing** have you done extensive development work in over the past year"
shows a row for "GNU". What is that? The complete set of programs that replaces the classical UNIX programs (e.g. `ls` and `pwd`)? If so, why is there no row for the alternatives to the GNU tools?) Or is this somehow broken off of the "GCC" row? (GCC stands for "GNU Compiler Collection", so you shouldn't call it "GNU GCC").

Comment: Related: [The recursive joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU#Name)

Comment: A guess: *[GNU Autotools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Autotools)* AKA *GNU Build System*. Or the even more vaguely named *[GNU toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_toolchain#Components)*

Comment: Removed GCC and added to GNU so the selection is GNU GCC in Dev Tools

Answer (score 12):

In the top message about "The new survey is open", you should write with BIG letters that "WE DO NOT AWARD THE BADGE FOR PASSING THE SURVEY ANYMORE". You removed the main motivation to do the survey and it can only be discovered after filling in the survey and not getting a reward :(

Comment: see revision 5 that zcoop made. Not exactly what you're looking for, but an improvement.

Comment: Similar: ChatGPT asking for your telephone number at ***the very end*** of the sign up process (without any indication up until that point).

Answer (score 10):

For the questions that are 2 checkboxes of "do you do/use this now", and "do you want to do/use this later" it feels like there should be more explicit options available to get a better picture. Maybe a use this later (at work) and an (on personal/experimental projects) split?

Do I use AI code generation tools currently? **No**.

Do I plan to use AI code generation tools at work in the near future? also **No**.

Do I plan to (and do) tinker with AI code generation tools outside of work (where it isn't critical well regulated industries) where it can help me whip up some quick skeleton code to get me up and running faster with boilerplate stuff? **You bet!**, works great for this, then I can massage it to something usable and/or integrate it with other code... but it *always* needs to be reviewed, and requires a knowledgeable developer to be able to read through it and ensure it is doing what you wanted it to etc.

Comment: Yeah the "which have you done extensive development work with" (or however it's phrased) is something that some people won't read, and others like you and I will take too literally.

Answer (score 9):

It's impossible to remove the answer in the question "How favorable is your stance on using AI tools as part of the development workflow?"

As often, my real answer is "it depends". I see some use cases for AI where I'm very favorable (like building helper tools) and other use cases where I'm absolutely uncomfortable (e.g. in automotive or medical).

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

The "Play Framework" option is mistakenly split into two options as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The education question needs more 'declared' flexibility in the answers. Some countries (e.g. Canada) differentiate between College and University (although this difference is starting to really blend now)... and as such someone can successfully finish College, and get a Diploma/certificate for completion, but not specifically a degree.

The answers for "Bachelor" should include " `or College Diploma`" type wording, or there should be a separate answer for this, as the only other answer that mentions College is the "some College" answer that indicates the person dropped out... ***which is very different***.

Comment: Also, what kind of college? The American 18-21 college, the UK 16-18 college, or something else?

Comment: Most countries around the world don't have "colleges" at all. The vast majority of all countries around the world have universities.

Comment: Yeah, it just feels weird answering survey questions like this about education... I want to be honest, but I can't, so I have to choose a fake answer for associate or bachelor degree depending on my mood that day. For the data scientists in the room (e.g. presumably the folks that crunch this data afterwards)... just beware you're getting false answers because there isn't a complete set of valid options... and dirty data **just feels bad**... like its going to curve your spine, and/or keep you awake at night

Comment: Re *"differentiate between College and University"*: They would call it "[the Canadian system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_system)" (true story), but it is not just Canada.

Answer (score 7):

Sad to see that, [once again](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/418012/3889449), not a single interesting question was asked in the survey. This is the fourth year in a row that it happens and the first ever year that I do not submit the survey. Nothing exciting, nothing interesting, nothing funny, just the usual boring questions... I have pretty much zero interest in completing such a survey or knowing its results. Please bring back interesting questions!

Comment: Maybe they should have asked ChatGPT to come up with a funny question about programming.

Answer (score 6):

The banner on top appeared yesterday and I did the survey. Today I see the banner again.

> Calling all who code. Take the 2023 Developer Survey.

It's a small thing, but I don't recall it was in the past. New bug?

Also I don't recall that after completing the survey there is an affiliated service ad (which provide survey, right?) with invitation to register. Of course I didn't register. I wonder if someone did.

Answer (score 6):

Some of the questions provide no clear way to differentiate between "decline to answer" and "none of the above".

For example, I haven't done any database development work this year, nor plan to next year, so I left all the options blank on that question.  But that's indistinguishable from someone who did (or is planning) database work but preferred not to say.

Answer (score 6):

I felt this survey had repetitive questions like they do in psychological tests. Some questions started to ask about interactions outside of your team, but it wasn't clear that the questions after were technical or functional. So you end up asking yourself, "Should I answer yes or no to this question?". Did they mean I'm asking technical information to a colleague or that I was asking a business process information question to a colleague?

Does coding for one month in your spare time with some language counts as "extensive" or should I talk only about what I do daily or almost daily? I'm a [full-stack developer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_stack), I work with [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript), [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets), [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Go](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_%28programming_language%29), [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL); [Django](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29), [DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) (Django [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) Framework), [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), [Vue.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vue.js); [Redis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redis_%28data_store%29), [Typesense](https://github.com/typesense/typesense); [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) at my current work (yes, the codebase is split between legacy code and new code). I'm using [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs), but also [Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) (when I commit XD) and [Vim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29) on the servers. Obviously, I cannot use everything daily, but the problem is that the questions do not help us to know what we should list.

For example, Django abstracts most of the SQL part. I only write SQL queries for some extractions or production debug from time to time. Should I list PostgreSQL and SQL that I know very well, but rarely directly code right now? I'm using the shell all day, but modify Bash scripts monthly or less than monthly. Should I list [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29)?

Answer (score 5):

This question shouldn't have an text input field.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Is the deadline really May 19, 2023?  I thought for sure the 2022 survey was open for a number of weeks, but my memory may be faulty!

Comment: Yes, we are closing the survey on May 19 this year, and last year it was open for longer.

Answer (score 3):

I had quite a bit of difficulty actually filling in the survey. Several of the questions don't seem to capture inputs in a regular browser view and required me to move it into a mobile layout for my clicks to register.

Comment: What browser, including edition (e.g., [Firefox ESR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox#Experimental_builds_and_ESR)) and version? In what configuration? On what platform (e.g, OS, including edition (e.g., [MX Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_Linux)) and version)?

Comment: Barring automatic updates between friday and now, I was using Chrome version 113.0.5672.93, switching between the regular desktop view or emulated iphone 12 view when questions didn't work. Running on a Windows 10 enterprise, version 22H2. Configuration is standard as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

For me the survey was "laborious", in an unpleasant way.

I work mostly with Java, sometimes C++, and some other languages that I marked in the earlier questions.
And then I got into lists of tools / frameworks / libraries, where I had to scroll for my language libs across multiple things like JavaScript's Angular or Python's numpy.

Couldn't it have been done that the latter questions at least somehow base on the former ones, with the other libs (we don't want to exclude that possibility) presented in, say, another section?

Answer (score 1):

Another note is that other than the Play Framework, Scala's frameworks and tools/libraries are completely missing.

For example, you could have included [Akka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akka_(toolkit)) as a framework, [SBT](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/simple-build-tool-scala.html) and [Mill](https://com-lihaoyi.github.io/mill/mill/Intro_to_Mill.html) as build tools, etc.

Comment: But the technology space ***[is vast](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#SBT)*** and the space in the survey is (practically) limited. I hadn't encountered Akka and Mill until today. Though theoretically the questions could be context-dependent.

Comment: Just thinking out loud, but I wonder, in the future, if they could make the "which technologies do you use" section context sensitive? Like, show all the popular Scala libraries only if you selected "Scala" as a language you use. Only show Rails if you picked Ruby, etc., etc. It would give a lot more space to collect data on libraries in that awkward category of "very popular in language X but relatively unknown outside of it", which is a very large category.

Answer (score 1):

The free text fields appears (at least to me) as single line fields, but they ask pretty complex questions like the ones with AI. I wrote there quick and short answers (since I imagined that was the purpose when I saw those single line fields), but without any doubt we could put huge texts with suggestions on how to use AI in Stack Overflow for instance (I'm not saying you should accept any suggestions, but since you asked...).

Comment: Yes, that is slightly inconvenient. But a huge wall of text is not *verboten*. They can probably cope (if they are really interested). A workaround may be to insert a number of (literal) `PARAGRAPH_BREAK` (or similar).

Comment: They could either make simpler questions (be more objective), or leave space for a complete answer, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things missing from the survey. First, I noticed there's three build tools missing from the list on the "Compiling, Building, and Testing tools" question:

- `vcpkg` on the "Build and test tools" question. MSVC package manager for C++. NuGet was on the list though
- GNU `autotools`. I don't think this is used much outside of GNU projects
- `bazel` build system

Second, the answer choices were missing a few options I would've picked if they were there. The list of primary operating systems on "What is your primary operating system in which you work?" was missing my favorite one openSUSE. Manpages weren't an option on the "How did you learn to code?" question. There was no option for "I don't handle technology purchases in my company" on the Technology purchases question; the only options were "Investigate on my own" or "Given a list".

Finally, the country list used in the survey should probably be updated; Swaziland was in the list, but is now called Eswatini.