# Do you think my comment was offensive?

Tags: discussion

I'm curious why my comment relating to the [Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314186/stack-overflow-annual-survey-2016) might have been deleted. There was some snarky comments about the aliens question. Such as this one highly upvoted:

> "Do you believe in aliens?" best question ever

I too thought the question was somewhat funny and facetious. An OK question that actually might say something about what kind of person I am. Another person said:

> USA visa application says "Are you an alien allowed to work in United Stated?" Now I believe I'm an Alien .. and so I believe in Aliens :)

So in the spirit of a joke I asked rhetorically:

> Is God or Satan an alien? Angels? Devils?

[Google](https://www.google.co.id/search?q=define%20aliens&oq=define%20aliens&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i10l9.4069.4069.0.4652.1.1.0.0.0.0.122.122.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.1.122.lDguJGshws0) says that an alien is defined as "a hypothetical or fictional being from another world". But it's probably fair to say if I believe in an alien being I probably don't think its "hypothetical or fictional".

So my question is this: Do you think my comment was offensive? To whom might it be offensive and why? I really want to learn here. I'm not trying to be snarky. I guess I didn't think either believers or atheists would be offended.

Comment: The mere mention of Satan is offensive to some people. The mere mention of God is offensive to others. Such waters should not be treaded lightly, especially on the Internets.

Comment: I think you can only appreciate that *joke* if you're an atheist...

Comment: Maybe it just wasn't funny?

Comment: They'd have to be real to qualify as "Alien", in the first place. A question like that would only result in a endless debate about whether or not they are.

Comment: Hmm.. I may have said something unfriendly abut the PHP room:(

Comment: How do you know that the issue is offensiveness? Maybe someone *quite irrespective whether anyone would find it offensive* just did not see the joke there. (I don't find it particularly funny, and I'm not offended by it.) If a reader finds no humor in the comment, then what function does the comment perform? Banter? It seems to me that a moderator could also come to this conclusion even if the flag was originally for offensiveness: not actually *offensive* but worthy of deletion nonetheless, because it provides no value. (Whoever handled the flag would have to confirm though.)

Comment: Your assumption that it got deleted because of a "rude" flag is not that likely to be accurate.  It is just noise, fits a "not constructive" or "too chatty" flag.  Being funny is not that easy.  Those silly survey questions are not facetious, they are check questions to judge the value of the returned survey.

Comment: I guess I didn't realize that simple noise got deleted so quickly. Looking again I see that most zero-vote comments in the first week got deleted. Especially since that post got so much attention and comments. Must have been several hundred comments. There's still about a hundred left.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whenever a Meta question is featured in the sidebar, everyone crowds in and feels that they have to leave some kind of comment on it. That question has 96 comments on it, and 25 others that have been deleted (and 8 deleted answers, along with a bunch of other deleted comments on other answers). When things get to be that big of a mess, we occasionally try to prune the noisiest comments in an attempt to somehow bring out the signal.

That's what happened with your comment. A few other comments on that post that mocked certain questions in the survey were flagged as being rude, and we got multiple system-generated flags about the sheer number of comments there. In the process of handling those flags, I went through and removed several comments that I did not think added anything to the discussion, including yours.

I don't know that your comment was particularly offensive, it just didn't provide useful feedback on the survey and I removed it to cut down on the noise.

Answer (score 6):

[Brad Larson deleted your comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315203/2057919), for reasons explained in [his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315203/2057919). I would have deleted that comment, as well, and I had basically written this before Brad posted, so I will go ahead and offer my own thoughts.

Your comment was this:

> Is God or Satan an alien? Angels? Devils?

Unlike the other comments you mentioned in your question, yours brought God, Satan, and other supernatural beings into the discussion. This wasn't particularly helpful. After all, the post was simply an announcement of the annual survey, which your comment didn't address. The comment also should be deleted for a number of reasons:

1. It adds nothing to the conversation. While comments—especially comments on Meta—don't *have* to move the conversation forward, the post in question has received (as of right now) well over 100 comments. That's, frankly, an absurd number. So, extremely unhelpful or irrelevant comments are going to face a little more scrutiny than usual.
2. It's not even clear whether it was intended as a joke, as opposed to religious or political commentary of some kind.
3. **This is the big one:** it seems to be mocking or at least making light of God and the other beings mentioned. This site has literally millions of users, including Christians, Jews, Muslims, other monotheists, polytheists, atheists, religious agnostics... you name it. Any apparent mockery of religious beliefs is *totally irrelevant* to this site and extremely likely to deeply offend some substantial number of people. This is not an instance of people finding offense under every rock; it's a question of apparent mockery of people's most deeply-held beliefs. I'm not saying you *tried* to mock anyone's beliefs. I'm saying it's inevitable that your comment will be seen by some large number of people as mockery when it has so many potential readers.
4. Probably others that I can't think of until I've had more coffee.

The question to ask here is whether a comment is helpful to anyone without being unnecessarily offensive. The comment in question wasn't helpful—at best, it was a joke, as you intended—but it *was* unnecessarily offensive. You wrote in your post above:

> I guess I didn't think either believers or atheists would be offended.

Pretty much anything that you can say about God, Satan, angels, demons, or anything else supernatural is going to offend lots of people unless it's a sincere comment. You don't have to go tiptoeing around lest you offend someone with really unusual religious beliefs, but you may want to be more careful about religious humor in the future. That's especially true on SO and MSO, which are focused (more or less seriously) on programming, not religious topics or humor.

Thanks for teeing up the question; it's helpful to have people ask what is and isn't in-bounds.

Comment: I certainly don't want to mock or belittle God. I too am a Christian. I have to admit I was somewhat offended by the question about aliens. Of course that's taking it too seriously... I think people instinctively look for higher beings or a higher power. So they joke about aliens.

Comment: That's fair. Like I said, I believe you that it was intended as a harmless joke. It's just really, *really* hard to make religious jokes that don't offend people. Anyway, no harm done, and thanks for bringing it up on Meta.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I know _one_ that shouldn't be a problem:
- A priest, a rabbi, a monk and an imam walk into a bar. Barman: _"What is this? Some kind of joke?"_

Comment: So asking me if I am an alien is not offensive, but asking if God is an alien is?

Comment: Nobody said that. If somebody posted a comment saying, "Hey, @alianos-, are you an alien?", I can't think of a situation in which that would be constructive, whether or not anyone found it offensive. If it got flagged, it would be deleted.

Comment: Oh don't get me wrong, I totally agree it is not constructive, it's not even funny, at the same time though I don't see how it can be offensive for people that "are not finding offense under every rock". But we digress, the post had a good reason to be removed and thats that.