# Topic suggestions: What else should we ask developers?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017, survey-2016

Every year [we ask the community](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310323/suggest-a-question-for-the-2016-stack-overflow-developer-survey) to come up with questions for the [Stack Overflow Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016). We consider every single idea, but you always come up with a lot more questions than we can ever squeeze in. This year, we want to start collecting ideas now because the best ideas always arise when reading results (at least for me).

So check out [this year's full results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016). And check out [the question list from 2016](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Pp8ha5La6MlfbigDB3RRkbkzcpH26ti_TVZuLcNBYcA/edit?usp=sharing). (We'll be releasing a full data dump of all results in the coming weeks so you'll be able to do your own analysis.)

What did we miss this year? A couple things I'm particularly interested in:

- What question or series of questions can we ask to gauge a dev's
  programming skill? (I guess this is the dev hiring holy grail, but um, can we    find it?)
- What else can we ask about diversity to help
  surface data that might help companies hire and retain people that
  don't fit the mold of your typical colleague?

What else should we ask in 2017?

Please try to keep your suggestions in multiple-choice form.

Comment: Slightly related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319224/disparity-between-os-measurements-in-the-2016-developer-survey in that I'd like you to ask more specific details about Mac OS X versions.

Comment: (Freeform answer) List the three items that you consider essential for programming while on a boat.

Comment: @JoshCaswell IRTA 'on a goat'

Comment: *What else can we ask about diversity* - You mean other than age & gender but not race or religion? IIRC, someone suggested religion for the last one but it wasn't received well.

Comment: @BSMP I'd like to ask about these things. But I want to do it in a way that isn't biased, doesn't make respondents uncomfortable, and in a way such that releasing the full data doesn't invite dangerous misinterpretation. So yeah, we have to be really careful. But I'm interested in ideas how we might be careful.

Comment: Is the question about diversity missing from the spreadsheet? Can't seem to find anything with the word diversity in it. I also don't recall seeing the 'google interview' question

Comment: @Rob Good eye. The diversity question was actually one of several bundled into question 40: "How much do you agree or disagree with the following statements".

Comment: Is it appropriate to ask about ageisim in the context of diversity?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Docker, you know, just in case a whale appears from nowhere.

Comment: Don't you think a [Harpoon](https://github.com/cscott/Harpoon) would be more appropriate, @MarounMaroun?

Comment: Don't you think it would be better to open a new question for 2017? The top answers are all going to be dominated by posts from last year, which may have been added to the survey already

Answer (score 83):

**Impostor Syndrome**

Inspired by Sayse's answer, I think it would be interesting to measure confidence in self vs confidence in others:

- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate your programming ability?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would you rate the programming ability of your peers?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how would your peers rate your programming ability?

This would not just measure the [Dunning-Kruger Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect); it would also measure [impostor syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome), which is an issue that affects women, minorities, and other under-represented groups in computer science. (**Note:** I know that impostor syndrome also affects the rest of us. But it's a big issue when talking about diversity, so I'd be curious to see the results.)

With all of the other questions about diversity on the survey, I'm surprised this one's not already on there.

With this data we could do interesting things like compare impostor-syndrome-ness across groups- maybe we're all more alike than we thought? Or maybe certain groups are more self-conscious or critical than others? Then if somebody smarter than me comes up with a good question to accurately determine the survey-taker's actual skill level, there are a ton of interesting comparisons we could make.

**Reach Out**

I'd also like to see the survey taken by a more diverse group of people. Right now it is mostly focused on pretty active users of Stack Overflow. That makes for a good amount of self-selection- which is great if we're trying to survey users of Stack Overflow, but not so great if we're trying to survey the real world.

Anecdotally, I work at a place that does software prototyping for the government. We do very little web development. Most of my coworkers are over the age of 40, and they would never think to take a Stack Overflow survey. So most of the people and technologies I work with are not reflected in this data, and I would bet that most of the rest of the real world is not reflected either. And that's okay, but then I think it's a bit dishonest (and maybe even dangerous) to declare that JavaScript is the most popular language. The real world contains a lot more diversity, and not everybody is a web developer. It's not surprising that web technologies come out on top of an internet survey on a site that a lot of web developers visit. I'm not sure how much we can really extrapolate from that though.

I don't know what the solution to this problem is- maybe "brand" the survey a bit differently and "advertise" it on other sites a bit more? Maybe reach out to groups that might not normally take the survey? Saying something like "we're measuring tech trends across the entire computer science world, so get your voice heard" might be a bit more encouraging to non-SO-users than "take a Stack Overflow survey"?

**Computer Science isn't just Ones and Zeroes**

This might just be my daydream of the day, but I'd also like to see questions that fight (or at least measure) the stigma of computer science as being "boring ones and zeroes". Maybe a couple questions like this:

- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is math?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is science?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is art?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is a craft?
- On a scale of 1 to 10, how much of your job is fixing computers?

The results to this might be interesting, and might help dispel some of the misconceptions about what programming is? We could go a level deeper and ask "on a scale of 1 to 10, how much do **other people** think your job is ___?", but that might be a bridge too far.

**Edit:** *(Gall's comment refers to the above. Below was added afterwards.)*

**Computer Science Education**

With organizations like [Code.org](https://code.org/) pushing to get computer science taught in K-12 schools, I'd also be curious to hear what people think about this hot-button topic. Maybe questions like:

- Should computer science be **offered** in schools?
- Should computer science be **mandatory** in schools?
- Should computer science courses count towards graduation?
- At what age should computer science start being taught?
- At what age did you start learning computer science?

This is complicated, because as soon as you say "teaching computer science", people picture 3rd graders being forced to learn C++. In reality, "teaching computer science" usually means having them play games like [Light Bot](https://lightbot.com/hocflash.html) or working with 
[Scratch](https://scratch.mit.edu/). So the wording would have to be pretty carefully chosen. But this is a highly-debated topic right now, so I'd be curious to see the results.

Comment: I like the last ones. I would also add "How many people still think you fix computers?" though.

Comment: @Gall I love that. Added it to the list.

Comment: _"On a scale of 1 to 10, how would your peers rate your programming ability?"_ I can picture the question immediately following (or some other question down the list after) this one being, _"On Question `#`, did you ask your peers?"_ But I suppose that comes from being used to strange little surveys/questionnaires that do that kind of thing.

Comment: I've edited the part about the Dunning-Kruger effect out of my answer as you have described it a lot better than I had :)

Comment: This is the most important suggestion on here, imo.

Comment: This should really be multiple posts, so that we may vote on your suggestions separately.

Comment: @200_success I don't disagree with that, but nowhere in the question was that stated, and none of the other answers seem to be following that rule. And now it seems too late to fix. I guess feel free to comment on the ones you agree or disagree with.

Comment: Possibly a bit late here but in the third question "Should computer science courses count towards graduation?"? I don't understand this question? Maybe this is a cultural thing as all topics count in UK schools and there is no such thing as graduating from school. You just get marks in each topic (A-F). So I would have no way to answer this question at all as it's not relevant to my experience.

Comment: @Liam Fair enough. I'm from the US, and a common problem is that many school don't offer programming courses, and those that do offer them only as extracurriculars, so doing them doesn't "count" towards your regular school requirements. Maybe it could be reworded to be applicable everywhere, but really it was just an example of the type of question that we could ask.

Answer (score 81):

### I'd really want to know about their screens :P

[image: Graphic of flatscreen computer monitor]

**Here are a few suggestions:**

---

How big is your screen resolution on your main monitor (around)?

- 2560x1440 or above
- 1920x1080
- 1600x900
- 1366x768
- 1280x720
- Under 1280x720
- I don't use a monitor

*This question might be better if the question 1. just asks about the width, but the disadvantage is people might have super wide monitors and this might not be fair; 2. Asks about how many pixels in total are on their screens though it implies calculations and I know answering a survey with calculations might be slightly annoying.*

---

How many monitors do you use at your work station? (the number of monitors you are actually frequently utilizing, so if you only use 1 monitor out of the multiple ones you have, choose 1)

- 4+
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0

*I would love to see if experienced programmers love to use multiple screens.*

---

> Jeffrey Bosboom:
>    Your question is more likely to tell you how many programmers' employers give them multiple monitors.

*Well, for that, I'll add this question too.*

How many monitors do you **want to** use at your work station?

- 4+
- 3
- 2
- 1
- 0

---

Which monitor aspects do you prefer?

- 16:9
- 16:10
- 5:4
- 5:3
- 4:3
- 1:1
- A very lengthened monitor (ultra-wide or very tall)
- Others
- I have monitors with different aspects for different purposes on my workstation.
- I don't care.

---

> Jean-François Corbett:
>   Monitor aspects: Some like it vertical! Seriously! Add this question:

My main monitor is oriented such that its long side is...?

- Horizontal
- Vertical
- At some other angle. Please specify: ___(deg)
- Umm... My monitor is square? / My monitor isn't a rectangle.

---

Which display technology is on your monitor?

- CRT
- LCD
- Plasma
- OLED
- Others

---

Arm mounted or sitting on the desk?

- Arm mounted always.
- Sitting on the desk always.
- Bottom row sitting on desk, top arm mounted.

---

**I'm improving and adding questions according to the comments :)**

Comment: "I would love to see if experienced programmers love to use multiple screens."  Your question is more likely to tell you how many programmers' employers give them multiple monitors.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Then I'll ask about how many they'd like to use as well, and change the first one.

Comment: Monitor aspects: Some like it vertical! Seriously! Add question: "My main monitor is orientated such that its long side is... a) Horizontal (0°)   b) Vertical (90°)" ... and why not throw in: "c) At some other angle (specify:___°)"

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett OK, you're the boss. I bet no one's using it at a strange angle though :D

Comment: Worth noting that some of this data (resolution, aspect ratio) could be collected fairly accurately through analytics on the site. In fact, I'm pretty sure SE already has this data for visitors, so I'm not entirely sure this is needed in survey form.

Comment: Oriented at an angle ? Seriously ?

Comment: The "orientation" question could use an "other" option. At university, I used to have my main monitor horizontally (for coding), and the secondary one vertically (for reading papers).

Comment: "1290x1980" umm.... - have you managed a rather impressive typo of "1920 x 1080"? :p

Comment: @JonClements Wow... How did I manage to type that? :D

Comment: Sort that aspect ratio list because there's a million possibilities.  If you offer a list of ratios in order of ascending value, then people can pick one even if it's not exact.  (e.g., 1:3, 1:2, 9:16, 3:4, 4:5, 1:1, 4:3, 16:9, 2:1)

Comment: Yes please on the aspect ration question. Screw 16:9 so much. I've put off buying a new personal laptop way longer than I probably otherwise would, I hate 16:9 that much.

Comment: Arm mounted or sitting on the desk?

Comment: I'd also like to know how many screens are retina/HiDPI, especially desktop monitors.

Comment: +1 for "How many monitors do you want to use at your work station?"

Comment: `How big is your screen resolution` - of which of my 3 monitors (including one in the laptop)?

Comment: And maybe more precisely about monitor's screen technology, like IPS.

Comment: `Which monitor aspects do you prefer?` Add: `I don't care.` as option. Now you're forced to pick something.

Comment: For the last two I would like to have that `I don't care.` option as well.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom I am actual the sort of person who prefers a *single* screen, and when provided with two screens I typically use only a single one... Perhaps I'm an exception though ... :-/

Comment: I use a projector. Where does that fit into this model?

Comment: I don't want to be too much of a curmudgeon, but can I ask what the purpose of the image is? It's the only answer (that I can see) that contains an image, and it doesn't seem to convey any information. I could sort-of understand if this was a "hey look at me" type anchor (although, that seems a bit shady), but this is already the top answer, so I don't know what the purpose of it is? I am lazy and this page is already too long for me, even without huge images!

Comment: I can rotate my monitor, so it can be vertical, horizontal or custom angle depending on the situation.

Answer (score 65):

Maybe its just me, but quite often I hear programmers/developers/code-monkeys having the stigma that we sit behind a desk and do not partake in any exercise/physical activities. I'd love to see what (if any) other developers do in terms of do they play any sports? Go to a gym? Go running? etc.

Comment: I second the sport question. Most of the people in my team practice one sport or another; so much for the sport averse stigma :)

Comment: Wouldn't that just measure Dunning-Kruger effect?

Comment: @Barry - Yes you're correct I'd never heard of that before, I think Kevin Workman described it a *lot* more eloquently than I have so I've edited it out of my answer

Comment: I'd be offended if someone referred to me as a "code-monkey".  Perhaps a question regarding that is in order...

Comment: Would you include bike commuting under this question?

Answer (score 48):

Also regarding diversity, I would like to know how flexible work scheduling is to accommodate folks with obligations (children, elderly parents, etc.)

How about something like:

**How flexible is your employer in scheduling around your other daily life commitments?**

- I can independently schedule my work to meet my needs
- I have to ask for permission, but it is usually granted
- I commonly have firm work commitments at inopportune hours for me
- Flexibility? You mean sick days?
- Sick days? You mean vacation days?

Comment: Vacation days? You mean regional power blackouts?

Comment: Regional power blackouts? You mean _"Bring your candle to work -days"_?

Comment: Regional power blackouts? You mean you haven't already fully migrated to the cloud?

Comment: @CubeJockey Internet failure is far more common than power failure.  Migrating fully to the cloud would be a small disaster, I mean a lot more leisure time.

Answer (score 40):

Apart from introducing new questions, consider rewriting some commonly asked question to further specify the demography of the respondents.

The top <strike>complaint</strike> comment on Reddit:

> Seems like only web devs filled it in.

So some kind of question (multiple-choice and free input) that asks:

### What do you deliver?

- Web applications
- Web services
- Desktop applications
- Server applications / daemons / background jobs
- Mobile / tablet / handheld / wearable applications
- Queries / ETL jobs / ...
- Documentation
- Machines
- Environments
- Pizza
- Whatever I forgot to think of

This gives way more insight than titles like "rockstar", "growth-hacker" or "full-stack blah".

Related:

### How do you deliver (assuming a developer)?

- I edit the code or configuration on the live server.
- I [hit F5](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process/) on my machine and if it doesn't complain, copy the source or binary directory to the server.
- I hit F5, zip the source directory and send it to ops.
- I run a build script and if it doesn't complain, copy the source or binary directory to the server.
- I run a build script, zip the source directory and send it to ops.
- I commit my code, some server builds it, and somehow, sometimes, it ends up in production.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment here, but I think the problem is more in who took the survey than it is what questions were asked. It's not really surprising that mostly web developers took an online survey on a website that a lot of web developers visit. So the solution would be to somehow get more people (more non-SO users) to take the survey. I don't know how you do that, but we're losing out on a lot of "older" developers, as well as a lot of developers that use "older" languages, since they visit SO less than younger developers, or developers using younger languages. That skews the results.

Comment: @Kevin I do understand that, it's just that I as well would find it interesting what the respondents deliver and how that can be correlated with their other answers. I don't care what a "rockstar" earns, but it would be nice to read what someone earns who delivers the same kind of application as I do, for example. Just as well as how mature the environment is (see second question) for various kinds of deliverables. In no way am I suggesting that these questions will broaden the audience of the respondents. :)

Comment: Yeah I gotcha, and I mostly like your suggestion. I just wanted to comment on the top complaint from reddit. I would maybe expand the options in your second question: a lot of what I deliver is internal, so I send it directly to a target machine and run it. No server really involved, no ops team. This internal stuff if what I think a lot of this survey misses, since it assumes a product / customer relationship that isn't always valid for many developers.

Comment: Doesn't have to be "F5" because that assumes the use of an IDE. Can also be "make".

Comment: @Tanz it was a hint towards [The F5 Key Is Not a Build Process](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-f5-key-is-not-a-build-process/).

Comment: @Tanz I've extended my answer, thanks for the suggestion anyway. :)

Comment: @CodeCaster heh, everytime I hear about people struggling with building stuff and writing make scripts I'm just happy I work in .NET land where the IDE writes your build scripts and the source control server compiles your stuff and setting up a newcomer takes five minutes.

Comment: + operating systems, +drivers, +embedded systems - otherwise I and my peers are forced to miscategorize our work as "sever applications" etc.

Answer (score 31):

How many meetings do you attend in a week?

*NOTE: Including daily stand-up(s)*

- 16+ - My company *loves* meetings.
- 11 to 15
- 6 to 10
- 5 or fewer - My company knows they should just leave me the hell alone.

At what point do you consider meetings-per-week to be a hinderance to your productivity?

- No limit - I belong in project management!
- 11 to 15
- 6 to 10
- 5 or fewer - A single daily stand-up only, please.
- 0 - Please just leave me the hell alone.

When does your team conduct daily stand-ups?

- Early in the AM.
- Middle of the day.
- Closer to EOD.
- We don't conduct daily stand-ups.

What time do/would you *prefer* to conduct daily stand-ups?

*(same options as previous question)*

Comment: It may be dangerous to schedule meetings close to [EOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosive_Ordnance_Disposal).

Comment: I would change it to 2 or fewer. 5 already is a lot.

Comment: It is usually called COB _Close Of Business_ rather than the ominous sounding EOD.

Answer (score 23):

**What style of desk do you use?**

- I have an awesome adjustable standing desk
- My desk is only standing
- My desk is a plain old '*sitting desk*'
- Desk? I don't use a desk
- Other method to adjust desk or monitors?

**If it is an adjustable desk:**
How much time per day do you typically use it in standing mode?
Thanks @GalacticCowboy

**Also, What style of desk do you wish you had?**

Comment: If it is an adjustable desk, how much time per day do you typically use it in `standing` mode?

Comment: I use a desk with a box on it.  I can stand or sit as I choose.

Answer (score 22):

#### What have been the most helpful resources in building your skills as a developer?

- Degree Program
- Certification Program
- Dev Bootcamp
- Books
- Online Courses ( Video )
- Online Courses ( Interactive / Mixed Media )
- Web Communities ( StackOverflow, forums, etc. )
- On The Job Experience
- Internship
- Pair Programming
- Working On Personal Projects
- Apprenticeship
- Tutor
- ETC... ( any others? )

---

---

#### Ranked results would be most helpful.

#### EG:

- Arrange from highest to lowest helpfulness
- Rate each from 1-10

*+ option to omit answers not relevant to answerer*

Answer (score 21):

**On a scale of 1-10 how cluttered/messy is your desk?**

Or alternatively give options like

- Very clean
- Clean
- Somewhat Clean
- Somewhat Messy
- Messy
- Very Messy.

You could be creative with the options if you wanted.

I'd be interested in what kind of personal environment developers prefer outside of the technology or office vs. cubicle aspect

Comment: Examples of creative options I could imagine: "Covered in figures/collectibles/other personal momentos", "Covered in papers I really need to sort", "Decorated lightly with family photos"

Comment: @Kendra those are pretty good! I personally like to clear off my desk completely at the end of each day but that is definitely not the norm I have observed at my work

Comment: I literally just pulled the three most common things I see around here, with the first option being my own desk. :) A write-in other option could probably cover those, however.

Comment: Yeah those were great options, they cover most options I see at work as well. I was merely pointing out my preference rather than pointing out your options weren't all inclusive. A write-in is a good option but they probably would want cover most bases before that since to me it would seem hard to analyze the write-in, but I don't know their process so that's merely conjecture

Comment: One of the creative options could be, "A clean desk is a sign of a sick mind."

Comment: On a scale of 1-10... you're going to need a bigger scale.

Comment: "Very clean, if someone leaves a fingerprint on my monitor, I stab them in the face". Too much?

Comment: I've not found the skills/level of the programmer to be assessed by the the style of the workspace/desk.

Comment: add the option "not being able to type properly"

Answer (score 19):

Regarding diversity, there could be a couple of questions on disability. I don't think trying to include every possible disability is feasible so I tried looking up a list of categories.

---

Do you consider yourself to have a disability?

- Yes
- No
- I prefer not to say

Are you considered to have disability based on the laws in your country?*

- Yes
- No
- I don't know
- I prefer not to say

<sup>*For example, if you're in the United States, you would be covered by the Americans with Disabilities Act</sup>

If so, how? Please check all that apply:

- Chronic Illness
- Developmental Disorder
- Hearing Loss and Deafness
- Intellectual Disability
- Learning Disability
- Memory Loss
- Mental Illness or Disorder
- Physical Disability
- Speech and Language Disorders
- Vision Loss and Blindness
- Other Sensory Loss
- I prefer not to disclose the nature of my disability

Did you choose disclose your disability to your employer before being hired?

- Yes
- No
- Unemployed or Self-employed

How well does your employer or school accommodate your disability?

- Perfectly
- Very Well
- Somewhat well
- Somewhat poorly
- Very poorly
- Not at all
- Unsure
- I have not sought accommodations for my disability
- I do not need accommodations for my disability
- Unemployed or Self-employed and not in school

Are your co-workers and/or classmates aware of your disability?

- Yes, I am visibly disabled
- Yes, I told my co-workers
- Yes, but they don't know about every disability I have
- No, I've kept my disability to myself
- No, my disability is visible but I've been able to mask it
- I have no co-workers or classmates

Have you had issues with your co-workers and/or classmates that are related to your disability?

- Constantly
- A lot
- Some
- Not Sure
- A few
- Rarely
- None
- Not applicable

Comment: "To what extent does your employer exacerbate your disability?" "a) They make me work with Sharepoint  b) Oracle  c) PHP  [...]"

Comment: "Did you choose disclose your disability to your employer before being hired? a) Yes b) No c) Unemployed or Self-employed" I know at least in the United States you are not required to do so.

Comment: If you're asking this, it's *got* to have an option for "prefer not to say".

Comment: @ArtOfCode - Generally the survey just allows the user to skip the question rather than include a "I don't want to answer this" option on every question but in the off chance they change that this year, I'll add it.

Comment: If you look at some of the sensitive questions on this year's survey, such as gender, it's got that option on it.

Comment: @ArtOfCode - Should I break out whether a person's disability is recognized by law separately from whether they have one? Maybe the first question should just be "Are you disabled?" and then ask if their disability is covered by labor laws.

Comment: Perhaps something like "do you consider yourself to have a disability"?

Comment: `Do you consider yourself to have a disability?` is terribly biased; as it allowes the pseudo-hypochondriac to bypass the doctor's diagnosis and jump straight to the "I'm disabled" seat. In the real world, you need medical papers (proof) to qualify as disabled. Your opinion, no offense to anyone, really matters the **least** here.

Comment: @Shark - The "proof" of disability is already covered by the second question.

Comment: @BSMP fair enough, then perhaps it'd be better to just ask the person to say whats wrong than asking this `Intellectual Disability, Learning Disability, Memory Loss, Mental Illness or Disorder` as Epilepsy, Schizophrenia, Autism and Dyslexia cover 4/5 each. (ok, perhaps it's 3+/5)

Comment: @Shark If we were to try to ask what *specific* disabilities the user has, that list would go on for forever. The question currently allows the user to select multiple options if that applies to them.

Comment: Another option for the question `Are you considered to have disability based on the laws in your country?` could be: `I'm unsure about those laws`? I mean, There are not so much available info about medical conditions legally stablished in some countries...For example: Personally I don't like be in a place where there're many people..._(I forgot the name of the condition; it appears in The Workplace in some questions)_, but in my country that `condition` is not legally/medically? recongnized.

Comment: @Mauricio - Makes sense. Added it.

Comment: I really like this question as I notice problems with a few places I have worked. I would add a question of the style: *"Do you feel your disability has caused you issues among your peers?"* with range answers (A lot to almost none) and a N/A answer of course....Could add a separate question along this line about boss but I would think this is covered by the general work accommodation question you already have.

Comment: @JGreenwell - I've added that along with a question about whether their co-workers/classmates are actually aware they're disabled.

Answer (score 19):

Do you play games during your break-time?  If so, what do you play?

*(check all that apply)*

- Foosball
- Pool
- Air Hockey
- Ping Pong
- XBox
- Playstation
- MAME Cabinet
- Games on my phone
- Games on my laptop
- Board games
- My company doesn't have or allow games at work

I'd be curious to see an intersection of this along with job satisfaction.

Comment: *Steam on my laptop* - Why Steam in particular? It's possible to play games on a laptop without it. Are you trying to see if an employer provides Steam accounts?

Comment: @BSMP it could probably just say "games on my laptop."  I picked Steam because at my last job pretty much everybody had Steam on their work laptops.  But you're right, it doesn't have to be Steam.

Comment: I miss the board games option. And the "yes but only after work" option.

Comment: @Matty  Good call!  Board games added.

Comment: How about the "My company has all of the above but I / we never use them" option?

Comment: @GalacticCowboy Well, that just makes me sad.

Comment: Not *my* company, of course.  :)

Comment: include chess alone (outside of the <board games> category since I think it is a game played by a different category of people  than the ones playing "regular" board games, arguably requiring some different mental skills and not usually being played for the social nature of it)

Comment: My team plays bridge at lunch time. (A card game, for those who don't recognize it.) Better add card games. And possibly distinguish solitaire from other card games. (Though I'm guessing most solitaire players play on cell phones or other computers.)

Comment: Arguably Go and chess are in the same category. And family board games (parcheesi etc al.) are in a different category from wargames (Axis and Allies et al.). (And FWIW, it turns out that we have multiple war gamers here - none playing at work however.)

Answer (score 18):

Why did you decide to take/start/change to your career?

- It's all about the money!
- Someone needed to do it in the office and I was nominated
- My parent/mentor/friend said it would be a good fit for me.
- Are there other jobs in the world!?
- I've always done things like this growing up.
- I read a study that said this was a high demand field.
- My college counselor choose my major/career field due to an aptitude test.

  ---

A related question would be:

Do you want to transition out of your current field?

- Never
- I'd consider it.
- I hate what I do and want out now!

If people are interested in transferring then you could let them choose from a list of career fields so they can choose what area they want their next career to be in.

Comment: I would like to see this question, +1 for that, but the `options` for choose are too... informal?, maybe a little more elaborated answer could help to bring more upvotes and maybe, be considered in the next survey.

Comment: @Mauricio I just wiki'd the answer. Feel free to edit as is appropriate. I felt that the informal/somewhat silly options conveyed the concept and added a light hearted touch. IMO the concept is the important piece here and I'd fully expect SO to adapt the options to whatever they feel is most appropriate.

Comment: I enjoy coding.  Luckily I found work doing something that is pretty meaningful, but I'm already bored with it a pursuing a totally different field.  it would be nice to know more about the others who feel the same way I do.  Especially when I try to talk about it on Workplace.SE and it often gets closed as off-topic.  Then again, most of those questions do.

Answer (score 16):

**How do they sit?**

---

Since our job is in front of a computer (when we are not around with robots), it is critical to sit correctly. However that would be hard to ask.

Comment: Expanding on this, how about collecting information on who's sitting or standing whilst programming?

Comment: [Like that](http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/10/30/11/2DF0B33A00000578-3296650-image-a-15_1446205258503.jpg)

Comment: @Jonathan EXACTLY!!! There was a guy while I was in Switzerland who did this, but he hadn't the leg stamina to tolerate this so I do not know if he actually made it a habit. However, I was a footballer, I would be interested in this too! Maroon² is she at the dentist? huhuh :)

Comment: You can use the categories of chairs Amazon uses. "Do you sit in a: 
1) Desk Chair 2) Managerial/Executive Chair 3) Guest/Reception Chair 4) Task Chair 5) Stacking Chair 6) Wheelchair 7) Not Applicable - Standing 8) Not applicable - Other"

Comment: Or wait, was this question meant to ask about posture?

Comment: @BSMP posture!!

Comment: Maybe options like: "I keep a good posture out of habit", "I mostly keep a good posture but I have to be deliberate about it", "I have OK posture but have a few bad habits", "I don't know/unsure", "I have somewhat bad posture", "I have very bad posture", "I have posture problems related to an injury/medical condition", "Not applicable - I don't sit at work".

Comment: That would be a choice @BSMP, but not the optimal one..hmmm...thanks!

Answer (score 15):

I think if would be interesting to see what internet browser developers use, and how the choice of browser differs between web-developers and non-web-developers.

> What desktop internet browser do you prefer to use to browse the web?

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera
- Safari
- Edge
- Internet Explorer
- Other

> What internet browser do you use for web development? (If you are a web developer.)

- Firefox
- Chrome
- Opera
- Safari
- Edge
- Internet Explorer
- Other
- I don't do web development.

Comment: It might also be interesting to know, how the time is distributed between browsers for specific problem solving/optimization.

Answer (score 10):

For me it would be interesting to know, how much time developers can spend on actual programming and what other time-eaters occur. So:

How much worktime in an usual week do you spend (in %)

- Programming
- Meetings
- (Customer)-Support
- (Network)-Administation
- Talking to your co-workers (not work related)
- Learning/Looking for new techs
- Stackoverflow
- Other work-related tasks
- Other not work-related things
- I'm not working/not working as a software developer

I'm pretty sure this list is far from complete - it's just what came to my mind first

Comment: Can add time working in open-source or personal project. Can also relate this time track with the developer experience.

Answer (score 10):

It would be interesting to know how many extra hours people put in to their day job - whether they just work their contracted hours or whether they are regularly putting in lots of extra time/death marches.  It would be interesting to compare how it varies by country, etc.

**How much overtime do you do on a regular basis?**

0 hours - I only work my contracted hours

1-2 hours

2-3 hours

etc

Comment: What if you're a salaried employee and don't get overtime?

Comment: It would still be interesting to know (perhaps moreso?) - plenty of people have to do lots of unpaid overtime.  I'm a salaried employee and have to put in extra hours...

Comment: I'd make it "How many hours over 8 do you do on a regular basis" (or 40 for a week, etc.)," so that there's a clear baseline. I've worked at places that expect 50 hours a week *minimum* from salaried employees.

Answer (score 9):

Rank (or omit) these in the order of which you would use them to solve a programming related problem:

`__` ask a question on Stack Overflow
`__` ask a question of an expert in the field
`__` consult your equivalent of a ninja duck
`__` ask a question of a friend
`__` use a search engine or the search feature here
`__` ask a question of a coworker
`__` attempt to solve the problem on your own
`__` look in a book

Comment: Wouldn't this greatly depend on the kind of problem? Maybe the question should narrow this down a bit.

Comment: @5gon12eder - Narrowed. I had thought this was implied but I see your point as well.

Comment: I would want it to be possible to skip ranking an option if you never do it, so that the results aren't skewed by people randomly ranking the options that they don't use

Comment: @KeithHall - Edited to include that as an option, I think it makes sense also.

Comment: Missing: "*give up and mark it by design*", "*remove feature causing the problem*" and "*I don't solve programming problems, I just like taking surveys.*"

Comment: It could be narrowed more. If I'm trying to implement a new feature, the first thing I might do is check API documentation to look for functions or methods that would be useful, whereas if there's a bug then I would look at the relevant code and try to figure out what's going on. If I'm getting an error  message, I'll copy and paste it into a Google search. And these are all "programming problems".

Answer (score 9):

<sub>It's hard to say whether this was already asked in a previous survey or in a similar form, but I did not remember or find anything in this regard</sub>

### What are your preferred working hours?

This does not directly refer to the **number** of hours, but to the **schedule**.

One could also ask

### What [Chronotype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronotype) are you?

but this would not cover the schedule of the work. Particularly, I guess that many developer jobs are not the classical nine-to-five-jobs with a perfectly fixed schedule. There are certainly some degrees of freedom of how this question could be structured. One example might be

**What is the preferred time for you to start working?**

- earlier than 6am
- 6-8am
- 8-10am
- 10-12am
- 12am-2pm
- 2pm-4pm
- 4pm-6pm
- later than 6pm

and the same for the preferred time to *end* working, shifted by 6 hours or so.

(Note that this includes the possibility of someone preferring to start at 9am and to end at 12pm, which could mean that he's a workaholic, or simply that he would like to distribute his work over the day, maybe with several 1-hour breaks in between)

I think this could be generally interesting. Particularly, seeing a distribution of the preferred start- and end times could give an impression of how much to 9-to-5-pattern deviates from what people actually *want*.

---

<sub>The reason why I'm personally interested in this is that I'm an extreme "owl chronotype": Starting to work at ~3pm and ending at ~3am (with breaks) would be perfect for me. But I'm afraid that stating this would end any job interview quite abruptly. I just want to make sure that I'm not alone ;-)</sub>

Comment: Narrow jobs to timezones that would match

Comment: @random Assuming that this referred to my final remark: On the one hand, this is true. A 9-to-5-**remote**-job in the US would fit perfectly into my schedule due to the ~7 hours time shift. But globally, I think that the **vast** majority of people (and developers in particular) would **strongly** prefer to start working later than 9am. I think more flexibility here could be beneficial in many regards: Better work, done more efficiently, with fewer bugs, no "rush hour" (having economic and ecologic benefits!), and many more.

Comment: BTW: I even considered an RFE for an "Option to specify preferred working hours" in the "careers" section. I think the importance of being able to live according to your chronotype is severely underestimated.

Comment: Nice to see that this was included in the 2017 survey. I'm **so** curious to see the result. I *expect the surprise* (!) to see the peak at 8:00 am (too many years of "early-bird"-brainwashing), *imagine* to see the peak at 12:00am, and *wish* to see that I'm not the only nucturnal here.

Comment: Just to have the forward reference here: The results have been published, and the resulting diagram is shown in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350847/3182664

Answer (score 8):

I think that more questions about social interaction and learning within the company could be really neat. Developers love learning. And there is a stereotype that developers are introverted or lack social skills. It would be interesting to see how true that stereotype is when developers are together in a work environment.

> How often do your coworkers take time to teach you something new?

- Several times a day.
- Daily
- Weekly
- Rarely
- Never

> How often do you take time to teach your coworkers something new?

- Several times a day.
- Daily
- Weekly
- Rarely
- Never

> Which, if any, of the following does your team practice on a regular basis:

- Pair Programming
- Code Reviews
- Continuous Integration
- Agile standups/Code planning meetings

> Which of the following is your preferred way to communicate with coworkers about technical issues?

- Face to face conversation
- Video Conferencing
- Voice chat (phone or VoIP)
- Instant Messaging
- Email
- Issue tracking software

> How often do you spend time with coworkers socially outside of work?

- Daily
- Weekly
- Rarely
- Never

> Does your employer offer to pay for developers to learn their craft in any of the following ways?

- Online training (Pluralsight, etc.)
- Professional Certifications
- Coding bootcamps
- Conference attendance
- College/University

Answer (score 7):

I would like to know when and how people access SO! ie a matrix of:

- In the morning before work
- At work
- In transit
- At home - evening
- In my sleep

---

Using:

- Phone
- Tablet
- Home computer
- Home laptop
- Work computer
- Work laptop

SO could then overlay this date against when people actually engage in SO activity based on day of the week, local time and answers to other questions. Does the perception match reality?

Are people using SO at work disproportionately and are they supported in doing so by their work place?

Comment: SO specifically or any site on the SE network?

Comment: @mast good point, we should extend this to the whole network

Answer (score 7):

#### What OS does your phone run?

- Android
- iOS
- Windows
- [BlackBerry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry)
- Some other OS I left out
- Other __________
- I don't have a smartphone

Can then possibly add a second question asking what version the operating system is, but people might only care about the base OS.

This question is more about personal preference that work space, so I'm curious to see what programmers prefer.

Comment: The survey has finished [quite some time ago](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319228/raw-data-for-2016-survey). What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Cerbrus The 2017 survey already finished? The question says *What else should we ask in 2017?*, so I thought this was for the next survey. I'm confused...

Comment: Ooh, I think you may be correct, actually. It seems odd to ask that so early...

Comment: @Cerbrus It is strange. I also only noticed it now, because I usually only look for these posts this time of year. That is why I added the comment on top of the post that you just removed. I wrote that my suggestion is a bit late because it is 8 months since the question was posted.

Comment: @Cerbrus Looks like they wanted to ask while people were still looking at the results of the last survey.

Answer (score 6):

I would find it interesting to learn more about the political activities of the responders and what kind of projects / organizations / goals they support.

> **Are you trying to make a difference for our society in your spare time? Please select all of the following statements that describe activities you put in more than one hour a week on average.**
>
> - I'm actively supporting a political party (one you can vote for).
> - I'm actively supporting another political movement.
> - I'm active for a religious organization.
> - I'm a volunteer paramedic, fire fighter, social worker, …
> - I'm active in some non-profit organization like coaching in a local sports club, servicing hiking paths, nursing needy animals, maintaining a companionship's water supply, …
> - I'm passing on my knowledge by teaching voluntarily (apart from answering questions on *Stack Overflow*).
> - I'm actively contributing to free software projects or a standardization process apart from my work duties.
> - I'm actively contributing to *Wikipedia*, *Open Street Map* or other collectively edited knowledge repository (apart from *Stack Overflow*).
> - I don't do any of these, but I would like to if I had more time.
> - I don't do any of these and I'm not interested in doing so either.

> **Which of the following projects or organizations do you regularly donate money to?**
>
> - Classical charity organizations (helping untended children, offering medical treatment, helping homeless people, sponsoring education in underdeveloped countries, helping refugees, …)
> - Environmental groups
> - Computer user freedom / cryptography / hacker organizations
> - Free software projects
> - Free knowledge projects (eg *Wikipedia*, *Open Street Map*, …)
> - General political parties
> - Other political organizations
> - Religious organizations
> - Others, please specify: ____________________

> **How important are the following political goals to you?**
>
> [*Responders should be able to select between “very important”, “somewhat important”, “not very important”, “not important” and “I'm actually against this” for each goal individually.*]
>
> - promoting human and civil rights
> - improving social justice
> - protecting the environment
> - fostering economical growth and sustaining wealth
> - working towards equality
> - furthering peace and understanding among nations
> - putting an end to poverty and diseases
> - fighting oppressive regimes
> - preventing censorship and mass surveillance
> - preserving cultural traditions
> - spreading religious values

Please suggest other options if you feel that the provided options don't accurately reflect what people usually care about in your community.

Comment: On your last questions, last option: which god? (I could see this being a problem particularity as it is worded in a Christian way)...maybe just "spreading religious values or beliefs"?

Comment: @JGreenwell agreed & edited

Answer (score 6):

Do you consider your work:

- important
- somewhat important
- barely important
- non-important

How much of code you write goes into production and stays there:

- 100-80%
- 80-60%
- 60-40%
- 40-20%
- 20-0%

(If selected that is actively looking for job or passively)
Are you happy with career opportunities on market:

- yes
- somewhat
- no

Considering period since you started to write code - up to now - are you more or less happy with being involved with programming:

- happier
- sadder
- my feelings did not change
- difficult to asses but quite happy now
- difficult to asses but quite sad now

Comment: `How much of code you write goes into production and stays there` That's not how it works. Production code should evolve. If it sticks there for 15+ years you've written legacy code.

Comment: @Mast ok, so rephrasing - how much of your code never gets into production.

Answer (score 3):

What database management system do you use most frequently, if any?

- PostgreSQL
- Microsoft SQL
- MySQL/MariaDB
- Oracle
- DB2
- Other relational DBMS
- Other non-relational or document-based DBMS

I've found that many usage surveys rely on what I would call poor data, such as total number of questions related to the database online, questions per developer, and similar.
These tell me more about how intuitive (or not) a system is to use, the quality of the libraries, error messages, documentation, etc. but little about popularity (which is being measured) without further data. For example, Oracle is likely to get more questions per user considering the above metrics than, say, MySQL or Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 3):

This is a serious question.

I'm interested in the perception we IT people (devs, etc.) have about the "stupidity" of people we interact with in our work, whether they are management, product owners, customers, providers, support lines, people in general, and so on. Every one of us complain about this matter more or less the same, specially those in support or requirements gathering roles.

So I'd like to see the correlation between our role (Front-End, Back-End, Data Scientists, etc) and those we have to interact with, based on industry, pay grade, involvement in project (i.e. role), final user, and such.

The way I'd see the question would be like this:

What's your perception of the suitability for the job for the following roles you have to interact with on a daily basis (1: suitable - 5: completely inept/idiot)

1. Top Management, Investors
2. Project Management
3. QA
4. Systems Engineers
5. Design and UX
6. Development
7. End user
8. Documentation
9. Functional and requirement gathering
10. Recruiting and Human Resources
11. Customer Support
12. Suppliers
13. Other? ________________

Additionally to this one, It'd be interesting to see the emotional behaviour and perception of "grumpiness" in our field. Even if we consider ourselves rational and logic oriented to some extent, the truth is that we are not and we judge many times based on our emotions. [I got the idea from this](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24830513).

So the question would be like:

From 1 to 5 (1: always - 5: kind of never), how easily people in these roles break your nerves, drives you nutts, push your buttons, makes you want to destroy the world?

1. Top Management, Investors
2. Project Management
3. QA
4. Systems Engineers
5. Design and UX
6. Development
7. End user
8. Documentation
9. Functional and requirement gathering
10. Recruiting and Human Resources
11. Customer Support
12. Suppliers
13. Other? ________________

Answer (score 1):

What is the criteria for being self-taught? 
Because self-taught usually means using lots of internet resources and books and such to learn. So it's not really self-taught maybe as there are lots of teachers on youtube and other online platforms. Also, since programming technologies change so fast, it's hard to imagine any programmer who isn't at least partially self-taught.

I think that should be broken down more and possibly reworded. Maybe changing 'self-taught' to 'following a self-designed curriculum to learn'.

You list 'self-taught' and also 'took an online course'. Are they mutually exclusive or does the online course option only include thorough longer-term ones?

Just some thoughts. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I understand "self-taught" as anything that's not "formal education". I think it would be interesting to find out where all these self-taught developers learn to code (see [my answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/339679/2314737))

Answer (score 1):

The last few years have asked which desktop OS developers use. I'd love if the survey also asked about **target/deploy operating systems** — perhaps both "pick one preferred" and "pick all that you write for".

- Windows Server
- Linux Server
- Unix Server
- Windows Desktop
- OS X Desktop
- Linux Desktop
- Android
- iOS
- Embedded

(With further breakdown into versions if possible. Maybe include PaaS separately, too.)

<sub>N.B. I admit to being somewhat biased in this, as I work on an project which makes an operating system. But I think it's an interesting question for everyone.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In the technology section there is a question about development environments and another one on desktop operating systems but what I think would be interesting is something about development platforms (all the cloud services that developers use daily). I would include the following choices (these include team collaboration platforms & cloud services/platforms)

- Github
- Bitbucket
- Slack
- Atlassian Jira
- Parse
- Heroku
- Azure
- AWS
- ?

Another interesting question to ask since there are [69% self-taught developers](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#developer-profile-education) would be what are the preferred places for learning to code or personal learning networks:

- Stackoverflow
- Reddit
- Coursera
- Udemy
- Khan Academy
- EdX
- Hackerrank
- YouTube
- ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a stab at a possible question on race/ethnicity that will work regardless of location.

I think the fact that this survey is about IT gives us a better way of wording this. How about this instead of the first version:

---

Do you belong to a racial or ethnic group that is underrepresented in the IT industry in the country you live in? (Ex: A group you belong to makes up 20% of the population but only 5% of the IT population.)

- Yes
- No
- I don't know
- I prefer not to say

**If yes to the first question and you are a student:**

Are any of your fellow students in your racial/ethnic group(s)? Please consider only the students you have had classes with.

- Yes
- No
- I don't know/I'm not sure
- Not Applicable - I'm in online only classes
- Not Applicable - I'm not a student

Does your school have any initiatives related to increasing or retaining a diverse student body?

- Yes
- No
- I don't know/I'm not sure

If yes, did any of these initiatives positively influence your decision to apply to or attend your school?

- Yes, my decision was a direct result of one or more of their initiatives (For example: You attended a diversity related event and it made you want to apply there.)
- Yes, my decision was strongly influenced by one or more of their programs
- Yes, my decision was strongly influenced by the fact that they have diversity initiatives, but I was not involved with any of them.
- Yes, my decision was somewhat influenced by their initiatives.
- No, my decision was not influenced by their initiatives.
- No, I was not aware of their diversity initiatives at the time.
- No, I found their initiatives somewhat off-putting but attended in spite of that.
- No, I found their initiatives very off-putting but attended in spite of that.

**If yes to the first question and you are employed:**

Are any of your co-workers in your racial/ethnic group(s)? If your employer has offices in multiple locations, only consider the employees who work in the same office/location as you.

- Yes
- No
- I don't know
- Not applicable - Remote Employee
- Not Applicable - Unemployed or Self-employed

Does your employer have any initiatives related to increasing or retaining a diverse workforce?

- Yes
- No
- I don't know/I'm not sure

If yes, did any of these initiatives positively influence your decision to apply for and/or accept their job offer?

- Yes, my decision was a direct result of one or more of their initiatives (For example: You attended a diversity related event and it made you want to apply there.)
- Yes, my decision was strongly influenced by one or more of their programs
- Yes, my decision was strongly influenced by the fact that they have diversity initiatives, but I was not involved with any of them.
- Yes, my decision was somewhat influenced by their initiatives.
- No, my decision was not influenced by their initiatives.
- No, I was not aware of their diversity initiatives at the time.
- No, I found their initiatives somewhat off-putting but attended in spite of that.
- No, I found their initiatives very off-putting but attended in spite of that.

Comment: Maybe instead of "in the country you live in" you should apply this to a smaller area. Maybe city? In a large country the ethnicity can vary a lot between different cities and the national average might not actually represent the people you interact with on a daily basis.

Comment: “Less than 50 %” seems like a strange threshold.

Comment: @Kara - The first question is just about whether or not the user belongs to the majority group. It's not meant to say anything about who the user interacts with. I considered adding a question about their city to the question but wasn't sure whether the typical user is going to know the exact demographics at a local level.

Comment: @5gon12eder - There's definitely a better way of wording that, I just couldn't think of one at the time. What I'd really want to ask is if the user belongs to a group other than the one with the most power (which in some places isn't even the one with the largest population) but I know the second I word it that way, people are going to get upset. It's almost certainly impossible to word that in a way that accurately describes the info desired without people complaining so this was my attempt to get "close enough".

Comment: @Kara - I changed this to ask whether their group is underrepresented in IT. Should I still also ask about this at a local level instead of just national?

Answer (score -1):

### **Which music genre/style you usually listen to while you are developing?**

(This guy seems to misunderstood the answer)
[image: http://a57.foxnews.com/images.foxnews.com/content/fox-news/tech/2013/06/18/11-stupid-tech-tricks/_jcr_content/par/featured-media/media-1.img.jpg/876/493/1422578424872.jpg?ve=1&tl=1]

- Deep House
- Country
- EDM
- Radio
- I don't listen to music while I'm developing!
- Metal
- Pop Music
- Alpha Wave
- Psychedelic Trance
- Chill Out

More genres/styles are welcomed, feel free to suggest in the comments!

Comment: I would like to see this question in the next survey. My experience so far is that most of my coworkers listen rock and hates (other genres). I personally don't listen music while I'm working, but if I work remotely _which is rarely_, I listen different musical themes :)