# Disparity between OS measurements in the 2016 Developer Survey

Tags: discussion, survey-2016

I'm reading through the [2016 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016), and I'm curious about the details on the most popular OS. While looking through the previous years, I can see it's always been this way. Here are 2013's results, for example:

[image]

As you can see, Mac OSX is listed once, even though there are 12 major versions of it, from 10.0 (Cheetah) to 10.11 (El Capitan). Meanwhile each major version of Windows (because of how Windows handles its updates, understandably) is listed separately. Because of this, in 2016 we can see the results look like Mac (using the general term) is the most popular operating system:

[image]

In reality, 52.2% of users are on Windows and only 26.2% (about half as many) are on Mac.

I know it could be said that it doesn't matter because OS X updates are made available for free to all OS X users via the App Store and Windows OSes up to 10 have all been separate purchases, but I think there are a great many people on different versions of OS X still, like there are a great many iPhone users out there still on any number of models older than the 6s.

Considering that OS X (10.0) and Windows XP both came out in 2001, and Windows 10 and El Capitan both came out in 2015, I think it's a little misleading to split the question into these categories. Shouldn't either all Windows OSes be grouped, or all OS X users be asked what version of OS X they're on? (Heck, my dad still keeps an OS 9 VM around so he can play Caesar III)

In a perfect world, I suppose we would be presented with four proportionally-sized pie charts instead of bar graphs, one each for Mac, Windows, and Linux distros, and a fourth for "other". Each slice of each pie would be either a major version or a distro in the case of Linux.

I am also aware that it will become less of an issue over time as Windows 10 moved the Windows environment to the same kind of "free updates pushed over the internet" model that OS X uses.

Comment: OS is one of those questions where we simplify the phrasing of the and the ecosystem because that's the way we did it previously (makes it easier to spot trends), and because it's easier to answer. A lot of people don't know what version they're running. I thought you might ask us to ask you next time if you use multiple OSes in your daily life. I wonder if we do that, how we'd be able to measure results vs. the previous years.

Comment: @samthebrand Is using relative-size pie charts something you'd be open to for such measurements in the future? There may be other topics where they're more useful than bar graphs.

Comment: I think the chart gives the impression at first glance that OS X is the leader.  I know one could argue that if you look closely Windows is the most used OS but I also had similar thoughts as what you relayed - +1

Comment: I'm reasonably certain the number of developers using anything less than 10.5 would be insignificant, and even then, several version onward is likely insignificant. Previous versions would only run on PowerPC processors, for which virtually nothing is still developed for. You couldn't develop modern iOS/OS X apps on such an old version, and even browsers for PPC OS X are hopelessly outdated. Heck, most OS X software these days requires x86_64, and does not include an i386 executable.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7, 8 & 10 are very different things and (technical) users make a careful decision about which one they will use.

On the other hand, most people running OS X update to the most recent version that will run on their hardware.

The breakdown of OS X and Windows makes sense in that context.  However, the non-breakdown of linux doesn't.  It would be interesting to see how the usage of different distributions compare to other OS's.

Comment: I do concede above about the differences in how Windows updates and OS X updates are handled, but I'd argue that El Cap is nearly as different from Cheetah as Windows 10 is from XP, even moreso for power users like the users on Stack Overflow. You could sit an avg. person in front of a Cheetah install and they would recognize that it's a Mac computer, just like they would recognize that an XP install is a Windows (PC) computer. There's also less choice than you are suggesting w/ Windows PCs, IMO. Soon W7 *won't* be a choice at all. Most PC users just use the OEM OS on the computer they buy.

Comment: We actually do split out the Linuxes in the body text for [the OS section](http://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology-desktop-operating-system). We just had so many darn charts this year that we couldn't fit everything in, though you can compare this years Linux breakdown vs. [last years](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2015#tech-os).