# Would you like to test the 2017 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

It's December, which means we're gearing up for our annual developer survey. (Also, [hats](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/), but that's another story.) The basic goals remain the same since our [first survey in 2010](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/stack-overflow-annual-survey/) only with more stakeholders. Initially, the driving factor was advertising. Now we've added [Talent, Jobs, Enterprise and marketing teams](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/11/How-We-Make-Money-at-Stack-Overflow-2016-Edition/) who want to know you better. As a Community Manager, I look forward to seeing how a broad swath of users view Q&A and, as of this year, [Documentation](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/07/Introducing-Stack-Overflow-Documentation-Beta/) and [Developer Stories](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/10/Bye-Bye-Bullets-The-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Story-is-the-New-Technical-Resume/). In addition, journalists and researchers love our data. So the survey has [gotten quite extensive](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016) recently.

We estimate that responses to the 2016 survey cost **14.6 years** of total developer time. To pay back that cost, it's vital that the survey teach us how to make developers’ lives better. We want to see how we can improve our Q&A and Documentation products so that developers find information they need to do their jobs. We want to learn how to help software engineering become more efficient in the future. We want to know how to match people to jobs where they can make a difference. We want to show ads for products that save projects time and effort. Finally, we want to share our research so that the world outside our industry understands us better.

This year some questions are only asked of a subset of survey takers based on previous responses or randomly assigned groups. That should reduce the average time investment to about 30 minutes. But in order to be sure we are in that range and that our questions work, we'll need a variety of users<sup>1</sup> to beta test the survey. That's where you can help us. Testers will take the survey and then answer some questions about the survey. Once that's done, we might ask a few followup questions so that we understand your feedback. At most, testing will take a couple of hours of your time. <strike>If this sounds interesting, please [sign up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)!</strike> I'm closing signups, since we have plenty of volunteers. Thank you all!

### What would *you* like to learn from the survey?

Last March, [we asked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers) for survey questions you'd like us to ask. The current survey draft covers many of those suggestions, including:

- [diversity concerns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319295/1438)
- [work schedules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319270/1438)
- [developer type](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319305/1438)
- [meeting scheduling](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319301/1438)
- [learning resources](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319325/1438)
- [disabilities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319239/1438)
- [freetime activities](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319304/1438)
- [browser preferences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319369/1438)
- [social interaction and learning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319328/1438) and
- [how you spend your work time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319390/1438).

(We don't have [detailed questions about monitors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319267/1438), however.)

Please use the answers below to let us know what we missed. It's more helpful at this stage to explain the **knowledge you hope to gain** rather than the exact question you'd like to ask. Our most interesting insights are likely to be the result of [cross tabulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table), which requires careful survey design. Basically, what should be in the 2017 [survey results](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016)?

---

<sub>1. We are limiting participation in the beta, so not everyone will be invited. Our goal is to get a reasonable cross section of the sorts of users who take the survey.</sub>

Comment: A survey about being surveyed about The Survey. Sign me up :-)

Comment: Surveyceptilicious!

Comment: The sign up form is blocked for me at work, so I'll have to wait a whole ten hours (to include an engagement and travel) before I can access this. :( (The internet here sucks for phones. So not a great option there either.) But it sounds like a fun thing to help test!

Comment: Betcha editors saw *Inception*...

Comment: sign me up please !!

Comment: @MarkYisri: Don't forget to follow [this link](https://goo.gl/forms/YLFKfzSwe1xweVBl2)!

Comment: @Jeroen: I just looked at the results. The first response was from someone on our team testing the Google form. Test early and often. ;-)

Comment: I added a suggestion 3 weeks ago about [what OS your phone runs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338590/4660897). My suggestion didn't get much feedback since I posted it last month and not in March. I think data like this is interesting to see and helps you get a feel of what technologies programmers prefer outside the actual work office.

Comment: @TotZam: We do have a question about that. One criticism we've had internally is that we can glean that information from logs. However, I do think it would be useful to ask in the abstract rather than how people might access the site.

Comment: Can we include anything interesting like Artificial Intelligence and about VR?

Comment: Does the survey have anything about how happy you're with your current tech stack(s), and how great a yearning you have to use another (and which?)

Comment: The question I want asked is something like "Do the categories in the jobs section  adequately cover you" and "if not, what category would cover you". And yes, I'm coming from a place where it seems that SE jobs doesn't believe that I or most of my colleagues even exist.

Comment: I'm always disappointed when I get the short census form, and I'll be equally disappointed if you "save my time" by skipping what are probably going to be the more interesting questions in this survey. I'm already disappointed to have missed the beta opportunity. I realize that letting users pick long-or-short may bias the data, but meh.

Comment: Argh that's the first time in a long time I've legitimately been Rick Rolled

Comment: @ArlieStephens: You won't be missing much in any case. The random groups will be assigned to get either question A or B, but never both, for instance. The other branching paths are used to eliminate questions that don't apply. So if you aren't a mobile developer, we won't ask which mobile platform you develop for. That sort of thing.

Comment: @Pekka웃: We are asking similar questions to the ones that generated the [loved, dreaded and wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#technology-most-loved-dreaded-and-wanted) in previous years. It's a really popular section of the results. ;-)

Comment: TIL google docs is blocked at work for me... bummer. I'd love to participate in this.

Comment: @maxshuty It was only changed to Rick Astley today after the stopped accepting survey entries.

Comment: "That should reduce the average time investment to about 30 minutes". Then maybe start by dropping all the silly "joke" questions, as a sign of respect to whoever is taking the poll.

Comment: @Lundin: I would agree if not that those questions have a serious purpose. If you've ever spent 30 minutes answering a survey, you'll notice that it gets tedious. So we purposely break up the serious questions with something more lighthearted. These tend to be very quick to answer (and eminently skippable). If you look at past surveys, these questions are also fairly popular for readers of the results. Yes they are silly, but they are in no way a sign of disrespect.

Comment: @JonEricson Anyone in any form of professional career nowadays gets constantly bombarded with polls and customer surveys. Since every other such survey strives to be professional and minimal to avoid wasting people's time, the SO survey stands out quite a bit.

Comment: @Lundin I'd wager that to most of us here, it stands out in a positive way, though. The SO survey is one of the very few such survey I would even *consider* taking and the light-hearted tone is one of the reasons

Comment: When does this survey ends?

Answer (score 78):

I would love to know more about how people's technology stack has changed over their career and more about how technologies lead into each other.

e.g.
Does C lead more to Java or to C++? Do people who learn Python learn Java or do Java people learn Python? What comes before Erlang? What languages come after Fortran? If you go Lisp, do you ever go back?

I get that this could be tough to try and cover, but I'd be very interested in the results.

Comment: I'm going to point this to our resident data scientist, David Robinson. He's done similar research using CVs and Developer stories. Our data from the site itself only goes back 8 or so years. But people fill in technologies they used decades ago when showing their work experience to apply for a job. Might be a good topic for a blog post.

Comment: This would be interesting. It may show how everyone chose a career path and how successful is one career path compared to another in terms of languages chosen.

Comment: I personally don't know how I would be able to answer this question.  I did 5 years of .NET development at the start of my career and I have now worked 5 years exclusively as a Java developer.  .NET development did not lead towards Java for me.  In my case, I have just used whatever technology the client was paying for me to use...I really don't see "how technologies lead into each other" as you put it...

Comment: ...Can you learn any serious tech after getting into PHP? :)

Answer (score 37):

I'd like to know, whether people are using the latest version or stick to some older, more mature version. Examples would be: Latest GCC? Python 2 or 3? Java 8 or older?
In many projects I followed discussions about dropping the support for older versions. Unfortunatley, nobody has any clue, how many user use these old version. Maybe we can shed some light into this area, even in a more general question.

Comment: This is a great point! I've been frustrated in the past trying to ask questions about an older version of something and only get told "upgrade it". In an ideal world... but in my workplaces I've always been constrained to particular versions for some reason or another. I'm not sure how granular the data could feasibly be (we can't ask about every tech, obviously), but it'd be interesting to know.

Comment: I think this would be interesting, but how would you create such a question without making it too specific and detailed? It would be interesting to know which C and C++ versions people use.

Comment: ES3 vs ES5 vs ES6 too

Comment: @Knu considering that ES is mostly (almost always?) used in a web development context, I doubt people care much about differences between one and another (unless they do something that breaks most of the programs, which is doubtful).

Comment: @Braiam Old IEs are still in the wild, and sometimes we're required to support them.  [Even new browsers don't support all of ES6](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), which is why transpilers keep popping up.  Usage of said transpilers (are people actually writing ES6 style?) would be interesting.

Comment: @Izkata if you have to support IE (not even edge), is because you deserve it. >:D On the other hand, who cares which "parts" of the specification do browsers support, as long as you only need some you should test for said features, not for "browsers" which is the sensible solution.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but probably not practical for the survey. The specific questions (Python 2 or 3, for instance) would not apply to too high a percentage of the respondents. A general question is probably going to be too vague to be useful. That said, I expect we'll get some data once (and if) Documentation gets traction. Since we [support older versions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-versions), we'll be able to tell the relative importance of new and old version by metrics such as traffic and contributions.

Comment: @JonEricson How do you get information about used older versions from Doc?

Answer (score 33):

Can we have separate answers for Visual Basic .NET and earlier version of VB on questions concerning language preference?

C#, C++, and Objective C have separate answers. VB.NET, VB6, and VBA are just as distinct and different from each other.

Last year's results made it pretty clear than we don't like Visual Basic. However it wasn't clear if that dread was for all flavors of the language or just for the older versions.

Comment: Good point. I have pretty positive feelings about Visual Basic, but I haven't used it since the mid-90s. I left a note on our draft survey.

Comment: I don't think people who dread Visual Basic actually make a distinction between the dialects. Or even know the difference enough to be able to make a rational distinction if given the opportunity.

Comment: @CodyGray But the dreaded question says it is the "% of developers who are **developing with the language** or tech but have not expressed interest in continuing to do so". If they're actively developing in it, I would hope they know the difference.

Comment: [_"For nearly all programming purposes, VBA and VB 6.0 are the same thing"_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993300/difference-between-visual-basic-6-0-and-vba). But VBScript is separate from VB.NET and VB6/VBA, and perhaps should be a distinct option.

Comment: @CodyGray I have been working in VB.NET for almost 4 years now and have previously worked with VBA and VBScript. The distaste (dread is a little strong) I still feel for VB.NET's sheer verbosity is still surpassed by my distaste for the other variants.

Comment: A PoS, by any other name, will smell just as bad. The differences between those 3 VB dialects are quite marginal - I have unfortunately  worked with all 3 of them. If you think VBA is as different from VB.NET as C# is different from C++, you clearly haven't worked in any of those languages. As for if VB would be interesting... no. I want to know as little about VB as possible.

Comment: @Lundin VB.NET has nearly all the same paradigms as C# -- BCL, CLR, true OOP, delegates, compiler expression trees, LINQ, iterator functions, async, multithreading -- but with a VB6-inspired syntax, and is thus far closer to C# than anything else. Neither VBA/VB6 or VBScript has any of the above-mentioned paradigms, and are thus far more limited languages, and perhaps belong in a separate category.

Comment: I'd say the opposing view points expressed in these comments are a great example of why we need separate options. And why the survey is such a great tool. We are, if nothing else, an opinionated group.

Comment: @ZevSpitz Which only means that there is absolutely no reason why anyone would use VB in the year 2016, when you could be using C#.

Comment: @Lundin Agreed, 100% (well, 99% because of XML literals). But there are more/other reasons why people would prefer to avoid VBA/VB6 and VBScript, than just the reasons to avoid VB.NET, and therefore each should be a separate options.

Comment: The question about which technologies respondents used in the past year, and which they want to use in the coming year, has been broken up into several questions to accommodate adding lots of languages, new and old, to the list, including various VB versions.

Answer (score 24):

We would be interested to know how much % of work time developers spend in Code reviews and code refactoring.
Many good companies routinely follow code reviews and code refactoring. I feel it's really a good practice to keep the code clean and optimized but not all companies think this way (It happened in my prev. company).

Additionally, we would also be interested in knowing how many developers actively practice Data structures, Algorithms, Design patterns etc. **even after getting jobs.**

Comment: How can you work with programming without using data structures and algorithms? As for "design patterns", it is just a fancy buzzword for "useful tips and tricks".

Comment: @Lundin Perhaps he means "all that stuff taught in CS courses which seems irrelevant when writing an average LOB application"?

Comment: @ZevSpitz exactly my point!

Comment: @Lundin It is pretty easy: just don't use them.

Comment: We tried to write a survey question that got at the first question, but ended up with something that felt like a combination between a tax return and one of those forms you fill out in a dentist's waiting room. In addition, people are notoriously bad at estimating how they spend their time. The second question might require a follow-up study.

Answer (score 20):

We like to see the results for each and every country.

Not only selected ones.
eg: [2016-work-job-discovery](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#work-job-discovery) only states US, Germany, India and [2016-work-job-priorities](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#work-job-priorities) also the same and there are many.

Comment: We're planning to provide reporting for any countries where we have both a sufficient sample size and a reasonable belief that the responses constitute a random sample of SO users in that country.  That said, we may not be able highlight results from every country on the 2017 version of the site that you linked to—reporting for some countries may be limited to PDF cross-tab tables or the public data set.

Comment: Yeah that's good

Answer (score 12):

I would like to know more about how people prefer to contribute to opensource; for example:

1. Raise issues in a public bug tracker
2. Validate bugs
3. Help with documentation
4. Help with translation
5. Fix bugs
6. Donate
7. Manage community

Further, along the same lines I think it would be interesting to know what people look for when deciding to contribute to an opensource project:

1. Number of stars / forks
2. If the project has a code of conduct
3. If the project is backed by an organization
4. Community
5. Founders (who is behind it?)
6. Age

Others?

Comment: I share your curiosity in this. I'm working on a project to address problems faced by first time contributors while doing open source
https://github.com/Roshanjossey/first-contributions
I believe these details will help me a lot

Comment: As somebody who hasn't ever contributed to opensource, I would add "How did you find a worthwhile project?"

Comment: @sudobangbang Hmm, I followed your link, and it looks like the focus is the mechanics of contributing to projects hosted on github. My intuition suggests that git tutorials are a dime a dozen, and that's not the big barrier to entry. I'd also like to point out that not all open source projects are on github, or even in git.

Comment: And while I'm thinking about it - I write code. That's not the same as fixing bugs, and if all I expect to ever get to do is fix bugs, I'm unlikely to become an enthusiastic contributor. On the other hand, if I am a _user_ I'll both submit bugs and verify bug fixes _without ever considering myself part of the project_.  I may submit my bug reports complete with a suggested patch - i.e. "fix bugs" - still without considering myself part of the project. You need to separate "add features and other development activities" from "fix bugs".

Comment: @ArlieStephens thanks for your feedback. I definitely wanna evolve it in to a project that addresses a lot of problems by first time open source contributors. The git/github tutorial is like baby steps (you can also say MVP) towards that goal.

Comment: Our counterparts at GitHub are planning a survey of the open source community; that's probably a better venue for these questions.

Answer (score 10):

Last year there was a question something like "What book should every developer read?" but I don't remember seeing any mention of it in the published dataset.  I like the question, so I hope you ask it again this year *and* summarize it in some fashion in the published data.

Comment: The survey team is planning to spend the time that the survey is in the field finally combing through those responses from last year and producing a blog post around them—stay tuned.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to learn about how SO users are trying to free themselves from the shackles of corporate slavery, e.g. things like:

1. Current and/or past side businesses
2. Successful transitions from being an "individual contributor" (i.e. corporate employee with no direct reports) to management, business ownership, or freelance consulting
3. Financial success or failure pertaining to any such side businesses or past transitions
4. Level of interest in financial/business autonomy

Answer (score 6):

As someone who works on producing a Linux distribution, I find the "preferred desktop OS" question to be very exciting.

I would also like to learn what developers are writing *for*. Are they on Windows desktop but targeting Linux servers (of some flavor), or are they on Linux desktop writing mobile apps? Are developers for a given target platform more likely to use a certain desktop OS? Do more Mac developers write Linux/cloud apps than they write Windows desktop apps? Etc.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to know the tools people use for managing/tracking their open source projects.

How they follow an [agile strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development), what tools they use to manage [sprints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprint_(software_development)) and what tools they use to list and track bugs.

Which version control (VC) system/tools are used by them to manage their code. Which VC tool is more versatile and easy to deploy on their environment.

What tools are used by people to build and automate their testing.

Which is the best strategy to follow in overall management of an application from its development till its release.

Answer (score 1):

**Which recent language would you like to learn if given the time?**

The question could be reworded if necessary. I just wanna know which programming language developers wish they could learn if they were given the opportunity. Specifically at their workplace and **not on their free time**.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing as the question about which technologies the user would like to work with?

Comment: @TinyGiant it's not really the same thing. Here the emphasis is put on the *new* languages that the developers **don't know** yet.

Comment: I believe the question included the distinction that the user wasn't already working with the technology, I don't see why there should be a distinction between whether or not the technology is new, and how you would define new.

Comment: @TinyGiant again you are missing the point. It's about having to **learn** it. Even if you didn't work with a "technology", you do not necessarily have to learn it.

Comment: I do see your point, I just don't see it as a necessary distinction.

Comment: @TinyGiant rare are the places which give you that luxury. The all point of the question is to setup a what-if situation which will generate different answers. The previous questions were about putting into practice; this is about getting paid to learn. Afterward you might not want to work with it.

Answer (score 1):

What about preferred keyboard layout (and input method for non-Latin text if applicable).

Examples for keyboard layout:
Qwerty, Dvorak, Programmer-Dvorak, etc.

Examples for input method for Chinese (we could add input methods for other languages as well):
Full pinyin, half pinyin, wubi, zhuyin, etc.

Comment: Most countries that are not the US have weird keyboard layouts. In Germany there are a lot of professional programmers and a lot of games using the US layout because it's more convenient. I also have a physical US keyboard. In my opinion this is a good question.

Answer (score 1):

As it is a developer survey, and I had to face this issue quite frequently; how often do the devs./programmers deal with issues such as inconsistent charset in their codebase, or even inconsistent design patterns, inconsistent indentations, inconsistent timezones/dateformat/logging-utility, inconsistencies all around!

Perhaps it could be broken/combined into a wider section of question(s).

Comment: I like the thought behind this but answering "how often" would be difficult for me...I do "often" run into these issues but I'm not sure "how" often...guess it would be interesting from a general perspective

Answer (score 1):

What is the preferred channel to communicate with colleagues about code when face to face is not feasible? Phone, mail, Slack, HipChat, Issue tracker etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think would be interesting to know the problem solving flow that the devs follow to face them every day.

There's a lot of new languages, technologies and frameworks that really don't help or improve the existing. Would like to know if the main part of devs share my opinion: "Stop creating new tech that waste our time and improve the current technologies"

Answer (score 1):

I would like to know whether people like to stick to methods they have used for a long time or if they like to experiment with new methods and technologies! Does someone try to avoid using something which could be considered a risky move? Does someone like to measure and test a new method and an old one against each other?  This would be a very interesting survey question!

Answer (score -2):

> It's more helpful at this stage to explain the knowledge you hope to
>   gain rather than the exact question you'd like to ask.

First, super hype the disability question made it into the draft.

If there are enough responses from disabled users, I'd be interested in seeing how the answers to the questions on browser preference and development environment compare to responses as a whole.

Comment: Looks more like a comment than an answer…

Comment: @usr1234567 They explicitly said they aren't looking for exact questions at this point.

Answer (score -3):

What developers consider their "top 3" of helpful/not helpful things like...

- Tools ([Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA), [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29), etc...)
- Focus helpers (noise-blocking headphones, disconnect Internet, coffee, etc...)
- Hindrances (meetings, noisy co-workers, ridiculous expectations, etc...)
- "Most helpful" programming languages and/or libraries (Java, JavaScript, jQuery, C#, PHP, etc...)

  - "Least helpful" would be nice to know as well
- "Most helpful" sites ([MDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Developer_Network), Stack Overflow, etc...)

I'm mostly curious about what other developers consider to be their "top 3" of what they find helpful/not helpful to get work done.

Answer (score -4):

I would like to get some specialized info.

**Like info from the top 100 people of a specific tag**. Or people who had reps over 50k. Not that I'm not interested in answers from low reps, but surely the opinion of high reps is more valued. Yet there's nothing to distinguish them.

**Additionally generic questions don't convey value much value**. I mean we all know a good number of folks are self-taught, some have CS degrees, we all know some are satisfied and some aren't. I as an iOS developer want survey results from people who have categorize themselves as iOS developers. I don't want answers from Android developers or Linux developers.

Just so you can get an idea, I'm interested in the following specific information, from `iOS` developers

- Do they use TDD, BDD, MVVM, VAPOR?
- What Podcasts are they listening to? What blogs do they frequent to?
- books are they reading, what books do they suggest?
- What tools do they use next to their Xcode? Do they use fastlane? Jazzy?
- Do they use storyboards or do it programmatically?
- What frameworks do they use?

**But then also allow users to filter results based on the answerers reputation**

To achieve you would have to have someone design questions for iOS, Android, Web development, Linux, etc. And make the questions more of a checkbox kind of question. I'm guessing there would be 25-30 different fields, so it's a lot of work...

**Add questions were the answers would vary per year**. Currently you have questions that their answers are almost identical the next year or very small changes.

- What was their favorite WWDC video last year?
- Did you install any new tool this year?
- What was their top 3 answers they liked (answers from others or themselves)?

---

Not exactly what I'm suggesting yet similar:

[The 12 YouTube videos new developers mention the most](https://medium.freecodecamp.com/the-12-youtube-videos-new-developers-mention-the-most-f2d1fce337ca) — Free Code Camp

Some of its more related videos are:

[Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway? | JSConf EU 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

[How To Teach Yourself Code (ft. Quincy Larson)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZKvZzRynLE)

[Best of Fluent 2012: /Reg(exp){2}lained/: Demystifying Regular Expressions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkluES9Rvak)

[JavaScript Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fju9ii8YsGs)

Mike McCaughan has commented "That's the kind of information their customers (advertisers and job providers) want to know."

Exactly. But how does that serve the developers?! In 5 years the surveys could/may be beneficial...but the 4 videos of the above can help to bring me closer in understanding CS instantly.

If anyone else can offer insight (in the comments) as to why these surveys are good for the developers I'd really appreciate ...

Comment: This level of detail would introduce wayyyy too much complexity to what is meant to be a generic developer survey. It's taking up a lot of time as it is. Plus who cares what high-rep users think about the future of Siri or WatchOS? They may know the platforms well, but you know what they say about opinions. Their guess is largely as good as anyone else's.

Comment: @Pekka웃  well at least it's better than knowing "number of folks are self-taught, some have CS degrees, we all know some are satisfied and some aren't". I was just trying to give an example. I removed that bullet, you can address the rest of it. As for opinions, yes they are opinions but it's coming from someone who has a high rep. You may not care, but for others like me it could be a good touchstone. All I'm saying it can get more specialized and I don't mean to ask these questions from high reps only. Ask it from every iOS developer, but then **allow reports to be filtered based on reps**

Comment: @Pekka웃 additoinally facts are all there, and doing another survey is with 90% same questions doesn't offer more value, you're questions have to have something where it's answers would vary per year...which is why a question like : "What was their top 3 answers they liked" is a terrific question. The problem with sorting questions based on votes, sometimes leads to finding very basic questions that everyone has to know. But if it's per year, then it there could be questions where the problem had a higher complexity or the debugging was a huge eye-opening experience

Comment: Those sound like great topics for individual blog posts or a discussion forum, or Quora. But not survey questions. You'll find most people wouldn't be able to answer questions like that meaningfully -  I couldn't tell you what my favourite 3 answers were *last week*, let alone *last year*.

Comment: Actually, that's one of the points of the survey; to see how answers to the same questions (like how many developers have CS degrees) vary from one year to the next. They publish all of the data, and people can make those kinds of comparisons. They don't change radically from one year to the next, perhaps, but over 5 years they may. That's the kind of information their customers (advertisers and job providers) want to know.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan OK, *You* have a reason that they are needed. I disagree but but this question is asking what **else** do you want to know...I'm just requesting for something to be add to it. (No need to erase anything. Keep it so the advertisers and job providers are pleased). Something that varies per yer and is useful. Are my suggestions still irrelevant?!

Answer (score -5):

I'd like to know which Big Data software people are engaged in. Whether if it's committing/contributing, using, learning, etc. I'm talking like Hive, Pig, HBase, Spark, etc.

Answer (score -8):

In addition to everything already listed, I would be interested in knowing if programmers here listen to music while working, and optionally, what kind of music!

i.e.

> Do you listen to music while programming?
>
> - yes
> - no
> - depends on the task
> - prefer not to answer
>
> (optional, enabled unless "no" answer given) What genre? `<input>`

---

**Edit:** I'm pleased to see that my suggestion was *somewhat* accepted. The survey did include a question

> Suppose you're about to start a few hours of coding and have complete
>   control over your auditory environment (music, background noise,
>   etc.).  What would you do?

Answer (score -8):

Just out of curiosity:

## Do you use cracked software?

Some professional programming tools are expansive, for example, those built by [JetBrains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains). Many everyday software, such as [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), [VMware Workstation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware), and Windows (the operating system), are also not cheap. I think it would be a common situation where a programmer eagerly need a software which is not provided by the current company, but he/she cannot afford it, or simply don't want to pay.

Compared to ordinary users, programmers know software better, which makes it more tempting for them to use creaked software, or even crack them on their own. On the other hand, programmers build software, and nobody wants to see his/her own software to be creaked. By asking this question, I want to know whether victims are sometimes themselves offenders.

Comment: Meh, not sure whether "do you do this illegal thing?" is terribly likely to yield useful (truthful) data.

Comment: @Pekka웃 In fact, using cracked softwares is not necessary illegal, depending on the country you live in.

Comment: Considering that a developer might get fired from their job by answering "yes" to that I think this question would not yield very "truthful" results...

Comment: @ZackMacomber I thought this survey would be taken anonymously!

Comment: @SunQingyao - Good point...forgot about that...

Comment: @Sun it will... but there's the risk of the survey data getting hacked, for example - and at some point I think you will be asked for an E-Mail address if there's a prize. The risk is probably minuscule in Stack Exchange's case, but still.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then what about this one: `Randomly choose one of the following two questions to answer: 1.Do you use cracked softwares? 2. Is the last number of you SSN even?` We wouldn't be able to know whether an individual respondent uses cracked software, which effectively protects their privacy. However, say, if we receive 100000 "yes"es and only 10000 "No"s, we can still infer that most respondents use cracked softwares.

Comment: @SunQingyao that wouldn't be much different from just answering "yes", though. I doubt that Stack Overflow will participate in such shenanigans in their survey.

Comment: @SunQingyao off topic, I'm curious what the "Normal" in "East China Normal University" stands for, do you know?

Comment: @Pekka웃 The Chinese name for "East China Normal University" is `华东师范大学`. "Normal", or in Chinese, `师范`, means it educates students to be teachers.

Comment: @SunQingyao ahh, I see! Thanks!

Comment: @Pekka웃    It's the same in French, the Ecole Normale Superioeur (ENS) was founded as a university program for teachers and turned later to become an elite club for future presidents.

Answer (score -9):

I recall one of the questions asked in a former survey was [Star Wars vs. Star Trek](https://stackoverflow.com/research/developer-survey-2016#star-wars-vs-star-trek), so while it is kind of off-topic, I still want to ask:

## Cat or dog(, or pony)?