# Survey ends at 57%... intentional joke or actual bug?

Tags: bug, status-completed, survey-2017

I finished the survey and the "percent complete" shown on the last question was 57% or something close to that. I was wondering if that was meant as an intentional joke (or maybe to make people feel like the survey is longer/shorter than it actually is) or if this is an actual bug.

If it is a joke, it's quite amusing. :)

(I don't have a screenshot for proof at the moment, and I'd prefer not contaminating the survey result by entering a duplicate set of answers just to get to the last screen. Maybe someone else can take a screenshot if they see the same issue?)

Comment: Also experienced the 57% progress when I submitted the final question.

Comment: The Survey Monkey sampling isn't accounted in the progress bar - seems like a bug there. We will likely turn off the progress bar at a quiet time.

Comment: You completed the other 43% in a parallel universe simultaneously. Showing both progress bars might result in a tearing of the fabric of space-time .. though we never actually tested that. Turning it on now to see what hap

Comment: Mine finished at 58%.  There was also a lot less humour in it compared to last year.  Questions were boring and it all just seemed like market research for careers / developer story stuff.  Lame.

Comment: R.I.P @Tim Post, you were a brave mod.

Comment: I think the 43% are the other questions you would have been presented with if you answered differently in your previous questions. Just a hunch.

Comment: I think the 43% are the other questions you would have been presented with if you answered differently in your previous lives. Just a hunch.

Comment: I finished at 48%

Comment: Is this just a ploy to get us all to do the survey? :/

Comment: I finished at 40-something percent. I expected some more interesting questions too. The best question was probably Tabs vs Spaces, but that only took two seconds. Spaces, obviously.

Comment: @owacoder Tabs, obviouslier.

Comment: I 'agreed' that the survey was too long because I saw my progress bar was at 47 percent when I got that question, even though my survey ended at 50 percent. Something to think about when looking at the statistics.

Comment: Progress bar that never completes neatly sums up my career as a programmer.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get the joke (if any) behind this 57% thing. Can anyone explain ?

Comment: @EtsitpabNioliv It sounds like it's actually a bug, not a joke. However, I first interpreted it as a joke because I thought perhaps it was the SO staff's way of teasing us: "Let's make it seem like the survey is really long when it's actually not that bad, I bet we get a bunch of reactions from the community."

Comment: I have experienced this today.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks for pointing this out, and sorry to everyone whom it annoyed.  We turned the progress bar off last night.

The reason it wasn't working properly is we are rotating some blocks of questions in the middle of the questionnaire so they appear earlier/later in the survey for different respondents.  (The very beginning and very end of the survey are the same for everyone.)  That was interfering with the software's ability to determine how many questions are left for any individual to complete.

Comment: Why not just have one survey for everyone to complete? What does the rotation accomplish? Simply asking out of curiosity.

Comment: Lack of progress bar is not exactly great UX :-/

Comment: @owacoder: Mostly it [saved time](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339532/would-you-like-to-test-the-2017-developer-survey). It also allowed the survey to be a little smarter about using information previously known to be used later. So if you said you don't use SO very much, we can ask questions about that without wasting the time of people who say they use it constantly. (And, of course, the other way around.)

Comment: Surprising this wasn't noticed during testing.

Comment: @MartinSmith: SE doesn't do testing :)

Comment: Wergh; apparently, in this instance, [they do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/339532/560648).

Comment: Testing in Production? No! Say it aint so!

Answer (score 12):

Clearly you are Jon Skeet's sockpuppet/robot that:

> You completed the other 43% in a parallel universe simultaneously. Showing both progress bars might result in a tearing of the fabric of space-time .. though we never actually tested that.

or Tim Post forgot his keys again...

Anyways, I assume this is because not all the questions loaded. Why? Maybe because your responses refused to trigger *all* follow up questions. For example, I mentioned that I am self-taught. The survey then had a follow-question related to me being self-taught. Maybe, just maybe, the survey only loads certain questions based on what you answered.

Also, you might have selected that you strongly agree that the survey was too long. Screenshot of 44 percent:

[image]

Comment: I think this is likely. There's probably sub-questions and their software counts them as (total answered)/(total questions)

Comment: I would have liked to have seen all the questions whether they applied to me or not...

Comment: @TylerH - Ah, but last year there were people complaining about being shown questions that didn't apply to them based on their earlier answers.

Comment: @TylerH You can! In April..