# Take the Developer Survey 2017!

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

**Edit:  The Survey is now closed!  Thanks to all of you who responded.  We're cross-tabulating the results now; expect an announcement in mid-March.**

In addition to awarding a [silver “Census” badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge) to survey respondents, there are a few things we’re doing differently this year that are notable:

- In the past, we asked respondents to choose one “label” that fits them the best, such as “data scientist” or “front-end Web developer.”  One thing we discovered was that only about 7% of respondents were self-describing as “mobile developers.”  By contrast, survey research conducted by other organizations has found that about half of developers are involved in developing for mobile in some way.  This year, we’re asking respondents to check all labels that apply, so (for example) someone who primarily works as a full-stack web developer but also spends a significant amount of time on mobile development can choose both.
- In past years, we asked respondents to choose which technologies they had used in the past year, and which they want to use in the coming year, presenting one long list of technologies.  In order to accommodate additional technologies, we’ve broken this up into a series of four questions — one about programming languages, and the others about databases, platforms, and frameworks and other tools.
- If you think you’re not a typical Stack Overflow user, don’t self-select out of taking the survey!  We’ve added question paths that are just for people who aren’t full-time professional developers, or aren’t heavy users of Stack Overflow.

As in the past, we’ll be releasing the results (including the anonymized data set) to the public in March.  For those of you who have already taken the survey, how do you expect the results will compare to last year’s?   Which trends in technology adoption or developers’ work environments will we find?

Comment: Thanks for the cherry reminder! I didn't know it was going on since two weeks... Heading towards the Survey! .......✈

Comment: oops, wasn't aware you track where people coming from using the link itself. Don't you use referer header for this?

Comment: I have completed the survey in the past. Out of curiosity I clicked the link again and WHOA, it is again opened for me. Shouldn't it be showing as *"You already did the survey .. something.."* which I saw in the past? I think there is some bug.

Comment: @Zanon "Strongly disagree" - The results are always very interesting and couldn't be that detailed without a survey that long. Cheers :)

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri for me it does show "You have already taken this survey". Most likely it's using a simple cookie, not any OpenID trickery, so if you switch browser, computer, or just clear cookies, it can't remember you took the survey already.

Comment: @zanon we're definitely going to be looking at the responses to that question (and the others on that page) for guidance on what the "just right" length for the survey is.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri thanks for telling us, looking into it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard we _might_ be able to capture the referer header into Survey Monkey -- will look into it....

Comment: @Kevin thanks, people might post links elsewhere, so better not rely on this alone. :)

Comment: `It has taken most respondents about 30 minutes to complete` That is way too much!

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri same for me. Might be influenced that I am at my home computer and not at work

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Well, yeah - the link is not tied to your account as it's anonymous. Thus it's impossible to accurately detect whether or not you've taken it before. Surveymonkey uses a cookie to track completion of the survey, so either you're on a different device or you're cleared your cookies since.

Comment: Feedback for future: There are many academics--professors, researchers, etc.--who use SO, I'd guess, using programming mostly as elements of their research projects.  Asking an academic how large their organization is, is probably giving you misleading data.  What you want to know, I think, is: How big is the organization to which this programmer's work contributes?  Academics contribute to their organizations through research, of course, but generally by pursuing projects, individually or in teams, that are unrelated to most other research projects in the same university.

Comment: There were several questions where you assumed that the person answering is a professional programmer. I just program for fun so I didn't really know what to answer to those questions.

Comment: I’m working for a corporation and the codebase I contribute to is just one of many (technically unrelated) codebases in the company, @Mars. Corporate environment might be more unified and also differ in other aspects, but I guess total size of the organization and size of team/codebase are well defined in both and have the same meaning.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão  You can only get out what goes in.  2 minute/5 question surveys can't look into anything in depth; and I never felt any of them were padding for the sake it making it longer.  IMO a long survey is only a problem if it doesn't warn you up front that it's going to take more than a few minutes to complete.  This year's survey does up front, so it's good.  You can decide if you want to put the time in or not.

Comment: @j08691 - In their defense, the survey this year was dynamic so not everybody got all the same questions. Maybe have two separate sets of numbers? X/Y - questions everyone must answer and A/B where B = total number of optional questions? At least then you'd know you're going to answer Y + B at most even though it will probably be less than that.

Comment: @Mars - It would be good to repeat this on the "What should we ask next year" post when it shows up.

Comment: A survey should **always** show you either how many questions remain or what your progress percentage is. I hate going through them with no idea how much is left. *(reposting the comment I made earlier fixing a typo I forgot to edit)*

Comment: Thanks @BSMP.  I'll try to keep an eye out for that.

Comment: @Palec, yeah, there are gray areas, specially with software companies such as Google that have separate research teams that have nothing to do, at present, with their core business.   Those research endeavors are very much like academic projects, and the people working on them may have come from academia to do exactly what they were doing before.  Yet for many academic researchers no one in the university administration guides or oversees their choice of projects, which may have nothing to do with what anyone else is doing, and which might be the same regardless of university size.  Dunno.

Comment: @j08691 I agree that lack of a progress bar is not ideal, but it's much better than what was happening when we had the bar turned on:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341414/survey-ends-at-57-intentional-joke-or-actual-bug

Comment: @Mars I see your point.  What it really comes down to are that there are analyses for which knowing department/team size would be more relevant, and there are other analyses for which knowing overall org size would be more relevant.

Comment: @DanNeely, I am not denying any of that. But there is a fraction of users that believe that 30m is way too much and this make it not getting *any* information for trying to get 30m of information. I am just pointing this out.

Comment: I used to participate in costumer surveys for a small monetary reward (think Amazon coupons). I stopped doing that because I realized my time was more worth to me than what I was getting out of it. Answering surveys usually is not a fun activity for me. Thus, I usually don't participate in surveys that take more than five minutes even if they contribute to a worthy cause (and I'm not sure that's the case here).

Comment: @J.C.Leitão Personally it took me 25 minutes - but I spend about 20 of those minutes thinking about how .gif is pronounced

Comment: @Daniel, it also took me much less than 30m. Maybe people are not filling it out in one go and leave the page open for later while the clock continues ticking? IDK

Comment: Q23 is about what sources you used to learn a new technology.

It lists several different sources of information (Official docs, forms/IRC/mailing lists, SO answers, SO docs). I thought "Blog articles" were a big omission, but I also felt it missed the methodology I see most often which is "I Google for what I want to know, then I open the top few results, without much regard for where those pages came from"

It would be interesting to know both where people ended up getting the information and how they got there, but I don't know if that's really something people think about when learning

Comment: Will the Developer Survey 2018 ask about our political stance?

Comment: I gave up at question 32-33... way to long. at least you should warn user about this...

Comment: "For those of you who have already taken the survey, how do you expect the results will compare to last year’s?" - I'd love to compare my _own_ answers to those from last year. Is there a way to see my answers from last year? Or is there at least a way to save my answers from this year, for comparison next year?

Comment: @oliver we don't have a facility for providing records of individual responses at this point, but we'll definitely consider that as a potential feature for future surveys.

Comment: I took the survey but didn't get silver badge yet. Did anyone get it yet?

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu the survey said the badge would be awarded "in bulk at the end of January".  Do people completing the survey in February still get it?

Comment: @dckuehn yes, people who take the survey in February will still get the badge!

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu we've been awarding the badges in batches about once a week.  See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341924/4669458

Comment: hey I participated The Developer Survey 2017 last week and finished it.but my badge is not awarded yet.

Comment: Wasn't there just recently a survey.  How many of these do we have to do.  Stop mining our data!

Comment: @JonH - There's only the one survey each year. This isn't a new survey it's just a new announcement for the existing one because they never made a Meta post linking to it.

Comment: @MiheretabAlemu, Nope haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck Me too.

Comment: Am I the only one who gave up after 10 min?

Comment: when the questions are choice type, They lack some inclusiveness to options that should be included

Comment: @KevinTroy when is the next round of badges being awarded.  I'm starting to wonder if I was one of the people that screwed up the last profile-url badge thing.

Comment: @dckuehn We haven't done a batch since you took the survey.  Your badge should be awarded in the next few days!

Comment: do we know when the badges will be awarded?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint - See the first answer at the link in the post.

Comment: @KevinTroy The authors of the Developer Survey 2017 write that they would be very, very curious to hear about other ways to pronounce GIF. Here is one: French-speaking developers are likely to [pronounce](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OAh4x_Ddszk) it as [J]if with a J as in the French name Jean.

Answer (score 82):

You should ask developers how much they liked working with technologies. Or at least if they did. The fact that I do not plan working with some programming language or framework doesn't mean I didn't enjoy it. And vice versa, people might end up having to plan to use technology they dislike as a necessary part of their project.

And I think it is really interesting to see relationship between what people have to work with and what people love.

Comment: I strongly agree with this. Adding a third column to specify "I enjoy working with x" would be a great idea.

Comment: If only they had done this...  This would be a very interesting statistic, I agree completely.

Answer (score 75):

I broke down and took the survey. Aside from all the other criticisms that have been made elsewhere, which I still very strongly agree with, I thought the omission of Stack Overflow's own Jobs site from the list of options for sites where you maintain an online resumé/CV was quite curious:

[image: "On which of the following sites do you maintain a profile, CV, or resumé? Please check all that apply." What about Stack Overflow Jobs?]

Is there a reason this was not included, or was it simply overlooked?

There was a question that asked about my involvement with Stack Overflow, including whether or not I had created a CV and/or Developer Story, but that came *after* this question, so I had no way of knowing that it would be covered elsewhere. And even so, I think it is fair to include your own site as an option, given how many of us taking the survey probably use it.

---

In the spirit of [providing a complement to accompany a criticism](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-the-Compliment-Sandwich-to-Critique), I think it was really neat and thoughtful how you had provided follow-up questions for the "big list"-style questions, asking if there was any language/technology/etc. that had been omitted from the list.

Comment: Our main concern with that Q is that it wouldn't be clear to more casual users whether we were asking about having a login/profile for Stack Overflow in general, or asking specifically about having a Developer Story.

Comment: @KevinTroy Well, you could go for a long option name: "*Developer story on StackOverflow*" But I can't tell if that's 100% unambiguous to someone who's filling the survey in haste of course.

Comment: @TomášZato Nobody filled in *that* survey in haste.

Comment: They don't really need to either seeing as they can easily get those statistics.

Comment: For some reason I really like the annotation (sick writing)

Comment: @ThomasYates: That's what I initially thought as well. But when they asked for a link to your profile page to request the *"Census"* badge, I was puzzled. Is there or is there not a way for Stack Overflow to associate the survey with a user?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to associate answers with a particular user account, unless you provide the link to your profile page. And even then, I'm not sure that they actually *will* make the connection, other than to award you the badge (which happens manually). That said, I think what Thomas meant is that they can get the statistics on how many Stack Overflow users have Jobs profiles, independently of the survey. And even though people who *don't* use Stack Overflow can take the survey, you need a Stack Overflow account to create a Jobs profile. Still, should be included for consistency!

Answer (score 44):

In the future, the question for "field of study" should be checkboxes rather than radio buttons. I have two undergraduate degrees, and many programmers had multiple majors.

Comment: That's right! There were some other questions which need checkboxes instead of radio ;)

Answer (score 40):

**TL;DR**: This survey [was ridiculously long](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017/342812#comment438681_342400)

I understand that you want to gather as much information as possible (not entirely sure what for), but I think you are forgetting that the longer the survey the more people will either [drop out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017/342812#comment440898_342400) or start just [checking random boxes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge#comment430366_341214) to get over with and earn [the useless badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341214/introducing-the-silver-census-badge) already. As a result, you may end up with a drop in both quantity and quality.

Designing a survey is [not a joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_methodology). I really hope you had some guidance rather just "*Ask all the questions!*" approach.

Alternatively, [as suggested in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017/342812#comment439860_342400), you could at least show some progress bar or inform us on how many question there are in total.

---

As a side note, it would be interesting if you'd post the stats on how people answered the last question regarding the survey length.

Comment: True, it really annoyed me when survey went beyond 30Qs.

Comment: I thought the survey length is just fine.  None of the questions were particularly challenging so each could be answered in a few seconds.  It took less than 10 minutes to complete the whole thing.  If it *had* actually been over 30 minutes, then I would express some displeasure.

Comment: @wallyk Welp, OP himself says "*It has taken most respondents about 30 minutes to complete.*" which means that most of the people didn't have the same experience as you had.

Comment: It actually had a progress bar first, but it was kinda bugged because there were various "optional paths" and for some of us the survey ended at 55-60% of the progress bar.

Comment: Huh? Stack Overflow is for developers. Staying focused for even 30 minutes is something that can easily be expected. It's not like they asked me to debug an issue for 12 hours.

Comment: @IInspectable I don't work for SO and no one pays me to waste 30 mins on a survey. I'm volunteering to take that survey out of a good will and I don't expect it to become such a burden. In other words, the fact that you are developer doesn't mean that random platforms should assign random tasks to you where are you supposed to stay focused for long time or work very hard in order to accomplish. It's like saying: "*Oh you work as a street cleaner? Come clean my home for free, it should be very easy for you compared to your day to day work*".

Comment: So what happened in between reading the introduction to the survey and writing this post? Surely, **I** was told up front: *"Look, this is going to take you roughly 30 minutes. Are you cool with that?"* Based on this I made the decision to participate. Based on what did you decide to volunteer? And were you not told what kind of a *"burden"* this was going to be, **before** you made that decision? Did you not make a conscious decision, or was your self-assessment, that focusing for 30 minutes were easily doable for you simply wrong?

Comment: @IInspectable I took the survey before reading this post. I decided to volunteer based on the assumption that I could help SO team to improve the site (UX or Careers or whatever-wise). I thought this will take me a few minutes and I will just move on- but it kept going endlessly. I thought about dropping out, but I felt that it can't be **that** long and it should end any time now. If at the first question I had something like "1/1e4" at the top, I wouldn't even bother taking it. Also, regardless of the progress-bar, I strongly suggest they will make this survey **much** shorter in the future.

Comment: That's probably closer to reality than you'd hope it to be. Since you apparently missed it (because you don't RTFM's either): The information was readily available to anyone taking the survey, without visiting blog entries or other posts. Here is the [cached version](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:v6QVgCFzA6IJ:https://www.surveymonkey.co.uk/r/) of the introduction (*"The survey should take you about 30 minutes to complete. We encourage you to complete it in one sitting."*).

Comment: Nothing good will come from continuing this tangential argument after you've both made your points, so let's end it here. Please ensure that comments stay focused on the content/arguments being discussed, and don't stray into the territory of commenting on the person making the the post/arguments. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

For some reason I was unreasonably annoyed with the question

> 30. If two developers are sharing an office, is it OK for one of them to get a mechanical keyboard with loud "clicky" keys?

There's only answers are for Yes or No... personally I think it's not for me to say if it is OK or not. That decision should belong to the other person sharing the office and has to listen to it all the time, not me. Personally I wouldn't care, but I'm a loud typist myself and my boyfriend frequently comments on my "keyboard pounding" ways or asking what my keyboard did to deserve my hatred, so I understand that point of view as well.

---

And why on earth is "I was looking for a job" not an option for question

> 31. Think back to the last time you updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What prompted you to do so?

---

Last of all, Question 34 needs an "Ability to adapt and learn on their own" option. That's #1 recommend for me if I were advising a technical recruiting company.

Comment: I totally second your point about 31. Definitelly surprised me, had to fill it in. Actually all your comments are great.

Comment: Number 30 is asking *in general*. Imagine yourself under a [veil of ignorance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veil_of_ignorance)—would you allow this in a hypothetical society of programmers? I agree that your annoyance with this question was "unreasonable". :-) But agreed with the rest of the points!

Comment: Our intent with the "last updated CV" question is to figure out why people take a significant step on the job search process.  It's assumed that you're either looking actively, or preparing yourself to be approached passively.

Comment: @KevinTroy, That "intent" and associated assumption wasn't clear when answering the question. I read it the same way Rachel and Tomáš seemed to read it, and wanted the option to select "looking for a job".

Comment: @KevinTroy I had wondered if that was the case and debated choosing the option that would best represent why I had chosen to move on from my previous employer, but ultimately decided to use Other instead because I wasn't sure if that was what the question was asking, and that reason didn't apply to my current job. I think the wording there could have been better to convey that point if that is what you had wanted... even something like *"Think back to the last time you wanted to look for a job and updated your resumé, CV, or an online profile on a job site. What prompted you to do so?"*

Comment: *"And why on earth is "I was looking for a job" not an option for question"* - That. Or actually "I was preparing to start looking".

Comment: Took me a few good seconds to realize what the issue with #31 was. To me it's pretty obvious that they are interested in knowing *the reason* why you would be looking for a job.

Comment: I totaly agree with the 30, there should be more choices, choices should be : 1. yes 2. no 3. no but i've been through worst 4. yes, i have this keyboard 5. this question is even more annoying 6. How should i know... i'm just a unicorn...

Comment: The question about fictional programmer is interesting... first thing popped into my mind was Wally from Dilbert. Then I saw "most unrealistic". I left both boxes empty and moved onto the next question with tear in my eyes.

Comment: *It's assumed that you're either looking actively, or preparing yourself to be approached passively.* @KevinTroy - Oh! Oops. My answer isn't going to be very useful; neither of those things were true for me last time I updated it.

Comment: *That decision should belong to **the other person** sharing the office* - Isn't that the same as "No"? What you're saying is if the other person is bothered by it they should be able to tell that person not to use a loud keybboard. If you felt that the other person should get over it if it bothered them then that would be a "Yes". It could have been worded differently but "Who should have to change their behavior if the keyboard is a problem" was the question that was being asked.

Answer (score 20):

I think it would be worthwhile to gather data on how much of a survey taker's company is actually software focused. I responded as a software developer for a 100-200 person company, but I'm the only software developer of any kind here. The company's size doesn't mean I'm part of a proportional team, or a team at all.

The question about what field you work in can partially indicate this (ie. I put down "media") but an explicit question about how much software development focus there is would provide more accurate insight.

Comment: Good point—this could make the survey results super biased, man.

Answer (score 4):

Since we're giving some feedback on the survey...

I'd originally posted this as a comment to the original [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/), and it seems worth adding to the feedback here.

Somewhere between "Some college or university study, without receiving a bachelor’s degree" and "Bachelor's Degree" is an Associate's Degree. The local community college is turning out a fair number of people that do get *a* degree, it's just not one of the ones on the list - and it's different than those who just completed "Some college or university study, without receiving a degree"...

Also, you might want to forward some of the feedback to the company that hosts the survey software as I too couldn't move back.

For me it was when they asked for an email address, but wouldn't take a tagged (e.g. me+tag@example.com) email address. I wasn't going to give one without the tag, it wouldn't let me move forward with out providing one, and I couldn't move back to change the option that prompted for the email address in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

For question - **Which of the following best describes your current employment status?** one more option needed to add **Full Employment and freelancer**

Comment: Fulltime meant "employed fulltime directly by an employer". That just needs to be worded better so it's clear that it's about *who* employs you, not just the number of hours.

Answer (score 2):

I was kind of hoping for the Linux distro question (including built from scratch).

Comment: This should be a comment really

Answer (score -14):

Why include the gender PC question into something like programming survey ? I mean really, can't anything today go w/o talking about that

Comment: The gender question was purely optional and even provided an option to share your own value for that question.  If you feel uncomfortable answering that question, don't.

Comment: What is the "gender PC question"? I don't remember a question asking about the gender of my PC!