# Not Faq tagged question is displaying in the Frequently Asked section

Tags: discussion, support

In the [MSO main page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), under the Frequently Asked section, usually [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tagged questions are displaying. Today I see a strange behavior, the [not faq tagged post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017) is displaying in this section.

Is this a bug or any other reason for that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The *Frequently Asked* section usually displays [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) questions but it is **not restricted to just FAQ** and may contain [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) posts as well.

This is confirmed by [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) in his [answer on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50242/what-is-frequently-asked):

> It is an editorially controlled ad spot

---

The [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) [tag excerpt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/featured/info) also mentions this:

> A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. **A question with this tag can be seen on the main site, in a special sidebar**, in the questions list, and when viewing individual questions

<sub>* emphasis above is mine.</sub>