# Questions without the featured tag appear featured on the CB even when it has been removed

Tags: bug, community-wiki, featured-questions

The ["Take the Developer Survey 2017" question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017) no longer has the [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), but it still appears in the Community Bulletin, under the "Featured on Meta" section:

> [image]

Comment: The sidebar is heavily cached. In the past shog has invalidated this cache to remove the link from the sidebar IIRC

Comment: @TinyGiant that would be ok if 1) wasn't more than 2 hours old cache (CB cache is valid for a 1 hour tops); 2) it didn't disappear and appear.

Comment: Your circles are perfect.