# Please change the review icon back to a text link

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, top-bar

It's become pretty clear by now that, whatever [the other merits of the top-bar redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349204/has-the-top-bar-redesign-met-its-goals), it has been [a disaster for review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349118/is-the-top-bar-redesign-the-sole-cause-of-the-suggested-edit-slowdown/349125#349125):

[image: active reviewers per week, over time]

[image: reviews per week, over time]

As a result, Triage isn't able to handle VLQ flags on questions, Low Quality isn't able to handle flags on answers, and Suggested Edits are just piling up until further edits are blocked. We managed to relieve the congestion on the last one for a couple of weeks by reducing the number of reviews needed, but as reviewing continues to decline it's been hitting the limit regularly again.

Now... There are probably a lot of things contributing to this in one way or another. But it's hard to ignore that, after the initial "novelty" spike, the activity in review has been declining pretty consistently ever since we changed the textual link to an icon.

[image: what does it mean?]

As much as I appreciate the elegance and consistency of the new design, it's somewhat more important to me that [moderation on Stack Overflow actually *works*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251175/stack-overflow-is-not-yet-a-vast-wasteland-a-history-of-moderator-tooling) - and for the past 5 years, we've leaned heavily on thousands of people lending a hand via review to make that work; if that falls apart, we're gonna have to elect a lot more moderators, really fast.

So... Can we please have a plain ol' textual link that says "review" back?

[image: a text link]

Comment: Alternative feature request: change the review icon to something more readily identifiable, like 

Comment: @Cody Gray: That's reserved for the mod queue.

Comment: Give it 6 to 8 weeks ... I would organize elections anyway, in case it slips ...

Comment: IMO, it would also be helpful to have the badge back for reviews (regardless of if we have the text "review", or the icon), but only if the badge is *only* displayed when the review queues are particularly full. Having the badge always displayed was ineffective. When it's always displayed people become use to it being there and just ignore it. If it is displayed only at times when the queues are particularly full, people are likely to pay attention to this "new" thing in their view and actually act on it.

Comment: You did role out this topbar on the other SO sites. Did you see the same trend there?

Comment: @Makyen:  I'd like for that to be A/B tested personally, since that makes sense.  When you see a thing with numbers always on it becomes background noise; when you don't ever see it but all of a sudden it's there...wonder how that'd make a dent in reviews.

Comment: Too soon, @rene - top bar has been active on RU.SO for about two weeks. Thus far, we've seen a spike in activity similar to the one that followed the SO launch; whether it will also decline or stay high remains to be seen. Comparisons with other sites tend to suffer; Stack Overflow has at least an order of magnitude more reviewers than the next largest site.

Comment: So... the new Review icon managed to break Triage even worse than it was already broken? That's quite an accomplishment

Comment: Agree with @Makyen here. There are three icons there (I'm not counting the sites one) and two of them call for attention. The third doesn't... so you don't click on it. I propose [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1t4Q6.png) to show up when a queue you have access to gets more than say 70/75% full.

Comment: @rene you make me remember the 6-8 weeks fun

Comment: And on top of that you ban your reviewers for 4+ days for selecting 'Needs Editing' instead of 'Unsalvageable' in Triage Reviews. Unfathomable.

Comment: I'm afraid the next step is to use the `<blink>` tag...

Comment: Honestly, I don't see any need to make this obnoxious @Zanon - a text link worked remarkably well for years. We've seen a drop in traffic *across the board* for links that were converted to icons; I strongly suspect folks just gloss over 'em.

Comment: @Coldspeed the community knows that audits aren't perfect... you can always raise a meta post about it so a mod can review it and look at your review history and lift the ban if needs be - but that's not the topic of this post.

Comment: @Shog9 what bugs me is to mix text links with icons. If we need to go back to text links, I hope that the design team will propose a better layout than to use 1 text link between 3 icons.

Comment: Is there any explanation for the big dips in October 2014, and is there any possibility that whatever happened then is what's happening now?

Comment: 2014 involved a lot of changes to review @Scott - lotta tweaking to the close queue (early in the year) and VLQ queue (mid-way through) - so there was a *huge* bump in activity in the first few months of the year, followed quickly by a lot more to review, and then a gradual return to previous levels as we adjusted the number of reviews required and folks settled in; then at the end of the year we rolled out Triage and a lot more people started reviewing. Normalizing reviews by tasks created makes it a lot easier to see this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mn57.png

Comment: Perhaps 'Users' could be moved into the icon-set on the right hand side as an icon? And review could be added as a text link in it's place?

Comment: I was wondering what happened to the reviews link.

Comment: "*at the end of the year we rolled out Triage and a lot more people started reviewing*", why? Because they like ? Maybe because of a three shiny new badges?

Comment: Are these graphs misleading or has the review numbers been on a steady downwards trend for the last 2 years?

Comment: Probably both, @Dukeling: the number of tasks added to review isn't constant, nor is the number of reviews needed to complete each task... So the volume of reviews fluctuates with the number of questions & answers posted. That said, there was definitely a peak in 2015 - probably worth noting that we haven't really added anything since then.

Comment: Are you **absolutely sure** that edits piling up is because of the new design? Could it be that since February some dedicated users decided to stop contributing because of the "Take a stand" mess [and](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342903/well-always-endeavor-to-do-whats-right-well-try-to-do-it-better-next-time) [your](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290662/were-implementing-an-announcement-tag-for-direct-communication-from-the-team) reaction? Also, if suggested edits fluctuate based on Q/A posted you might want to make a graph taking that into account.

Comment: See my reply to Scott (above) for a normalized graph, @fermi

Comment: Can we have "Suggested Edits" in **bold** as well?

Comment: I blame the drop in Triage reviews on the fact that the powers that be refuse to correct the blatantly incorrect review guidance for the "Requires Editing" button that continually causes reviewers to fail review audits when they use the button in the exact (incorrect) manner the guidance suggests they should. Why don't we try finally correcting that first?

Comment: I thought the icon meant "Ask Question". It would never have occurred to me that it meant "Review".

Comment: just get rid of the new top bar

Comment: @shog9 Since the graphs are misleading as you said, why not use the normalized graph in the Question instead?

Comment: Have you considered making the review queues less painful to use instead?

Comment: Like @Womble it is always a surprise to me that the icon means review. I'm not sure what the iconography is supposed to represent but it doesn't scream out review to me. Also, I agree with the 5 second rule here https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/ : "if it takes you more than 5 seconds to think of an appropriate icon for something, it is unlikely that an icon can effectively communicate that meaning."

Comment: Because the normalized graph is misleading in *other* ways, @fermi and requires more explanation for what it does display. The graphs above serve to highlight the problem, but I can probably put together a more extensive report next week if you're interested.

Comment: Constantly, @jpmc; most small improvements take months to implement if feasible at all, so unhelpful for an immediate problem.

Comment: Nearly all audit failures for Requires Editing involve posts that were marked as spam, @tiny.

Comment: @JonClements Off-topic, is it possible for the ban to be lifted for a "possible" wrong audit?

Comment: I can't say I'd  review more if the icon was changed back, because I rarely did before, but I can say the current icon means nothing to me. I had to click it to find out what it was, and seeing it now doesn't make me want to click it again.

Comment: @Shog9 If making changes is time consuming and difficult, maybe the interface should be simplified? I almost always find myself going outside the review queue to take some other action or check something, anyway. What if the review interface was just a small modification of the normal question/answer interface? That might make it possible to prompt users to review a question when they arrive at it from outside the queues, too. (There's probably no one better qualified to review than someone who was interested without going through the queue.) Or is the problem deeper than just the UI?

Comment: none of the icons make any sense to me.  icons are typically used in places where something is very familiar - in this case i've got 4 of them and constantly have no idea what any of them do.  if i get a +10 it shows up under the rhombus thingy, then after i click it moves over to the captain america cup.  to be honest i thought SO had just done away with reviews after the redesign - this is the first i've thought about it since.

Comment: It's almost like they made UI changes without actually consulting a UX expert.  When will they learn.... ?

Comment: The UX is fine if you ask me. Ok, you have to be curious what those icons means. I would add a visual effect like that you see at the inbox or the rep box. But there is always a review to do, so it doesn't make a difference.If you ask me, the current design helps to exclude robot reviewers ...

Comment: I think there's no need to a counter badge if a better icon is used (like a flag) and a better color is used when the icon is being highlighted (like the color of counter badges). That would certainly draw me more attention.

Comment: I would rather think that the complete and utter unwillingness of SO to fix the broken review audits - most notably those in the VLQ review queue - is a major culprit why people stop reviewing. These audits are so utterly stupid that you keep insulting or even review-banning veteran user moderators who did nothing wrong, over and over and over again. I think the audits in the VLQ review do more harm than good.

Comment: There might be other reasons for this then the navbar redesign. The broken triage queue, robo-reviews galore in the SE queue, some truly asinine audits, just to name a few. It may also be that reviewing has become very very stale and changes in the review queues have been absent or minor at best. Face down, sifting through a mountain of rubbish every day and having to be extra attentive while doing it because there could be some special non obvious audit rubbish in it is tiring out for lots of people, so a bunch of them stop after they hit their 1000 per queue.

Comment: @jpmc26 don't pay attention to these smokescreens about months-to-implement, these are just polite way to say "we won't do anything until it starts frying our a$$" (which finally happened with that infamous icon). For example, the most efficient way to address [awful reviewers attrition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601) is to teach them use skip without hesitation with mere additional badge requirement - and [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773) hangs ignored for 3+ years. That's just the attitude

Comment: @magisch true, but that describes why people quit reviewing, which should not have changed because of some vague icons in a navbar. The described problem here seems more that new people fail to find the review feature to fill the gap left behind by the people that quit. Its the only way I can see that the change in the navbar is basically accelerating the problem of declining reviewer numbers.

Comment: So that's what that icon is for!

Comment: @Shog according to the review guidance, selecting "Requires Editing" for spam is an acceptable course of action.

Comment: The on-page guidance makes no mention of spam at all, @Tiny - save for the "spam" option listed as the first option when you click "unsalvageable".  The [longer guide](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/is-there-a-guide-for-the-triage-queue/295674#295674) linked from the first sentence on the Triage page lists spam as the first reason to use Unsalvageable, which is the first option (after Skip) listed. The problem tends to be audits where the question arguably *wasn't* spam (even though it was flagged and deleted) - "something is wrong with my site <link>" and so on.

Comment: @Shog9 _"**Requires Editing** for questions where edits by the author or others would result in a question that is clear and answerable"_. Edits by the author or others to a spam question could result in a question that is clear and answerable.

Comment: Sure, @Tiny. In the sense that if you completely replace the text with text which is in no way similar then *any* post could result in a question that is clear and answerable.

Comment: @Shog9 Which is the crux of the issue. At face value, the guidance for "Requires Editing" could apply to any post on Stack Overflow, meaning that (according to the guidance) it is always an acceptable option.

Comment: Remember that we are not (on average) dealing with rocket surgeons here. When people are getting acquainted with the review queues, there should be no ambiguity in the guidance they are provided. Especially so if following some reasonable interpretation of the ambiguous guidance could get them into trouble.

Comment: Your low opinion of reviewers is clouding your perception here, @Tiny. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603445/aftership-api-and-trackingmore-api-which-is-better-and-why) is the sort of thing that gets used as an audit - no one's failed that one. Problem is, so does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600399/clarification-for-selecting-particular-stream-in-ece) - that's almost certainly *not* spam, but it got flagged and used as an audit anyway. No one's failed that one either, but hopefully you can see where a problem might arise.

Comment: I didn't say I was a rocket surgeon. This problem doesn't _just_ affect  audits. It also affects people following the guidance who end up pushing reviews to the H&I when they shouldn't be. The H&I has low participation due to this. Most reviews I see in there shouldn't be there. Triage has low participation as well because of this. Imagine you've been following the directions only to find out that you've been doing it wrong the whole time and making everyone else clean up your mess. This is one of the many usability issues with review that have nothing to do with the icon used.

Comment: I guess my main point here (no one truly knows their own intentions) is that there are a significant number of significant issues with the review system that are all contributing to the steady decline in review participation. The least of which is going to be the icon used. On one hand I'm glad to see some kind of change, on the other this just seems like another layer of paint on the bike-shed.

Comment: Three-quarters of the questions triaged as "should be edited" *are* in fact edited, @Tiny. Does that turn 'em into great questions? No - most of 'em are crap because *half of everything going into Triage is crap*. But remember, *this was the goal* - [to get low-quality posts out of the way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/236537), after it became apparent that we just couldn't close ~2K questions every day. If Triage manages to quickly queue up the *worst* questions for closure / deletion, the rest can wait. HIQ is another matter; it exists to placate folks upset about Sturgeon's law.

Comment: It is a common practice to perform minimal edits to unsalvageable questions in the H&I in order to remove them as review tasks. I don't do this because I know that it doesn't help anything but others do and that will skew your numbers. I doubt that any meaningful observations can be made from looking at review statistics because the system is so broken as it is. The only way to get any meaningful observations out of review is to actually review and to talk directly with people who review regularly.

Comment: That would still be common practice if there were fewer / better questions in it, @Tiny - there's no particular motivation to make good edits (I'd originally proposed a system that would only give you credit for a review if the question you edited went on to do well, but that was deemed too complex). HIQ was largely a failed experiment; folks who both want to and have the ability to make substantive improvements have no shortage of opportunity in new questions, in their favorite tags, stuff on the homepage... As such, it mostly serves as purgatory.

Comment: If that is the case, the best course of action that I can see would be to discontinue the H&I, then remove the "Requires Editing" option from triage. That leaves us with "Looks OK" (on-topic and answerable in its current state) and "Should Be Closed" (off-topic and/or unanswerable in its current state).

Comment: That then defeats the purpose of triage, @Tiny. Put questions back into LQ review, figure out a different way to prioritize the close queue. Which may be where we end up, but... I'd rather do that because folks legit didn't want it, not because they couldn't *find* it. Also still leaves us with the same issue in LQ review, with suggested edits...

Comment: It's fair to say that the icon change isn't helping review participation, and even to say that it may be hurting review participation. I just hope the "fixing" doesn't stop with this next layer of "new and improved bpa free lead paint". This stuff has been broken for a long time, and y'all have known that it has been broken for a long time.

Comment: @Gimby, are you implying that burnout is an _expected_ pattern and the trouble is a lack of warm bodies to replace the casualties? SO is a pyramid scheme and I never knew it! ;-O (On-topic: I heartily agree [with Zanon.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link#comment482711_350836))

Comment: That's pretty much true of anything, @Michael. I mean, if nothing else... People die after a while. If you don't provide a way for new folks to find stuff, there's a pretty hard maximum length of time it can possibly stay in use.

Comment: This is purely anecdotal, of course, but it always takes me a few moments to find *which* icon is /review and I *know* it's there. In fact, whenever I need it, I am already deliberately looking for it. +1 for not making it an icon  anymore (or maybe adding text below every icon?)

Comment: Peter Reid's suggestion to move "Users" to be an icon made me wonder... why is Users even there? It seems like it could be easily dropped to make room for Review as a top level text link next to Questions, Tags, etc. Aside from easily telling how far behind Jon Skeet you are at the moment, the Users link doesn't seem like it has a lot of value to me. Not enough to warrant its prominent placement, at least.

Comment: Does [this](http://i.imgur.com/Lga19O2.png) look better in design? If it was changed back to text but stayed at the right corner of the bar, it would look weird

Comment: I really don't understand why you posted this @Shog. Just.... change this back to text and be done with it. Why wait for users feedback 6-8 weeks/months/years now?? Of course you won't get 100% users saying "YES CHANGE IT BACK", but as you said yourself, changing this to fancy icon was a mistake. Just correct the mistake and all will be good again.

Comment: @Michael sure seems like it

Comment: I stopped reviewing because of the review process, not because of an icon. Fix the engine before you start debating about whether to keep the new paint job or not.

Comment: All these developers and we still haven't come up with a way to just draw a "freehand red circle" around an icon to draw attention to it.....

Comment: I don't see any correlation between number of reviews and the top bar redesign. You are making problem from nothing, this question is bureaucratic and thus should be closed.

Comment: [Questions like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351054/1541563) make me think the redesign is definitely lowering the intuitiveness of the UI in general, not just for finding the review queue.

Comment: I don't really get the idea behind icons.  You're replacing a word that explains what clicking on it would do into an icon that, at best, does exactly the same thing. At best. I can understand play/pause/stop etc because over time you learn that a triangle makes the movie start and the square makes the movie stop but it's a bit much expecting people to learn hundreds of icons and for these icons to be universal. Why, for example, is "inbox" (that is, messages) represented by a sort of robot bra?

Comment: Where am I supposed to look in your graphs? I don't know when the change happened. You'd better tell us. Ideally inside the graphs, with a vertical red line or so.

Comment: @StefanPochmann the [a disaster for review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349118/424903) link explains a lot more

Comment: I'm fairly happy with the icon once I leaned it TBH, it also takes away the reliance on any particular language for the link, though I admit there might be a better icon available for review (maybe something with a check mark?). What *does* bug me is that it lights up orange even when the only reviews available to complete are *ones that I do not have enough rep to interact on* this is pretty pointless and the main thing that leads to me ignoring it sometimes.

Comment: @Gimby Thanks, though I really shouldn't have to go research elsewhere in order to understand this question. That piece of information is crucial and should be included.

Comment: Democracy is when the leaders feature-request themselves.

Comment: The current icon is the same one Google Maps uses for "Your contributions".

Comment: @Shog9 You removed the featured tag here, but I'm seeing it in the "Featured on Meta" section again. Maybe some cache clearing is in order?

Comment: This particular cache has a mind of its own, @tiny

Comment: Still there Shog. Might be time to check out this bug https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343232/792066

Comment: Just to put things into context: since SO has the new bar, my site usage is: digit the site address in the browser -> do whatever I want to do -> if in doing it I changed page -> close the tab, open a new tab, digit the site address. Rince and repeat. The new bar is such a mess, and so different from all other sites' bar, that I'm now unable to navigate on SO to the point that I find it easier to start over every time.

Comment: Shog, on the matter of review participation, your help in getting related statistics would be much appreciated here: [Looking for stats on how frequency of skip actions correlates with amount of reviews done by user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351269/839601)

Comment: @DrEval Its an icon of a physical (in-)box like the kind people have (had?) on their desks.

Comment: I long ago gave up reviewing, and was never a heavy reviewer in the first place. It's just dull and entirely unrewarding. Even participating in Q&A is not much fun any more. Add in the political mess and blah blah blah and I think you're just losing activity in people; I don't think it's because of an icon in the toolbar.

Comment: Can you add a red line or text to indicate when in your graphs the review queue was implemented?

Comment: Why should Spolsky care about quality when he is making money? Because he has ethics? HAH!

Comment: Use this as an alternative: https://userstyles.org/styles/162940/stackoverflow-header-buttons-text

Answer (score 428):

Go for a hybrid, imo. When accompanied by an icon, maybe the text doesn't have to be as big as the first-class links.

[image: icon text hybrid links]

Run this in your browser's developer console to get a preview:

```js
((d,o,c,s) => {
  c = d.createElement("style");
  c.textContent = '.s-topbar--item:not(.s-user-card){display:flex;flex-direction:column;justify-content:center;}.-menuitem-caption{font-size: 10px;}';
  d.head.appendChild(c);
  for (let n in o) {
    s = d.querySelector(o[n]);
    if (!s) continue;
    c = d.createElement("span");
    c.className = "-menuitem-caption";
    c.textContent = n;
    s.appendChild(c);
  }
})(document, {
  inbox: ".js-inbox-button",
  awards: ".js-achievements-button",
  review: ".js-review-button",
  help: ".js-help-button",
  network: ".js-site-switcher-button",
  hats: ".-link.icon-winterbash"
})
```

Comment: Nice! This would, at least, justify that the new top bar is almost twice as tall as the old one.

Comment: So allow people to disable the image, leaving them just with the text that explains what happens when they click on the text?

Comment: That looks super clean and professional. It really fills out the area in a way that doesn't make it feel over-filled either. I love it.

Comment: Nice, I love this idea! Keeps the icons consistent but still allows people to see what they do at a glance. Fantastic work!

Comment: This is definitely the way to handle it. I've been thinking on the review icon for a few days and I still can't figure out what it's supposed to look like. And I have absolutely no clue what other icon might be more clear to replace it. Text is the only fix.

Comment: +1 Now wait for the edit by a Moderator which includes [meta-tag:status-completed] tag for your post.

Comment: Now if you tell the same on UX@SE, you'll get heavily downvoted. Icon with text is frowned upon, because there's too much "paint" for this functionality. If the icon requires a text to be understood, that's a bad icon. Fixing or removing the icon is a better option than monkey-patching the design. Also your icons are now off center line, unlike all the other items in header.

Comment: I've never been a fan of labels being fully lower-case...I have to make an exception for this.  This looks like an outstanding improvement.

Comment: Yes, please -- many icons are cryptic to some and illegible to others.  I don't see that well; combine that with a "WTF is that supposed to be?" icon and usability of a site tanks for me.  Yeah yeah tooltips, but I'd bet that actually making the information passively available instead of requiring user action will produce better results. (If I can turn off the icons and use *only* the text, I usually do -- that'd be a nice option to offer people.)

Comment: This mockup is fabulous. Absolutely fabulous. Yes please!

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph Since when have UI designers ever recommended icons with zero explanatory text?  That's the opposite of usable.

Comment: @canon Well hopefully people rediscover what "usability" means and that fad goes away.

Comment: @canon So *this* is why more and more phone apps have just icons at the top with no way of knowing what they do until after you click on them.  Ugh.

Comment: @canon Yeah, it cost Android users billions of dollars spent on phones. Or is material not "flat" enough? Irrelevant article.

Comment: OH my, this is so perfect WHY HAS IT NOT BEEN DONE

Comment: Here is a stylish script which achieves this: https://userstyles.org/styles/162940/stackoverflow-header-buttons-text

Answer (score 72):

To me also the two rightmost icons are meaningless and unclear. I certainly have reviewed much less after the change.

What's more, in that particular area the first couple of items are "personal": my picture, my rep, my medals, my inbox, my recent achievements. Then suddenly the last two aren't personal, instead they are sitewide/networkwide, but without visual aide or distinction.

Last but not least, because some of the personal items show count badges, I feel that subconsciously I assume that 'no count badge' = 'no need to click it'.

Perhaps the Review should be moved into a bigger block similar to 'Featured' and 'Hot posts'. Or you could even make a single block with rotating contents: if it is different on every page load then it will grab more of my attention than blocks that are static for hours if not days at a time.

Comment: "*Then suddenly the last two aren't personal*" The last one is very much personal. It has the "your commujnities" listing which are the sites you choose to put there. Followed by all available communities. So the only odd one out is the review section.

Comment: I see, but the tooltip promises otherwise: "A list of all 169 Stack Exchange sites". That makes it a button I will hardly ever use.

Comment: It does show those 169 sites. But it shows them after your user communities sites. And I use that button *all the time*. Just like I used the down arrow beside the website's name all the time in the old layout. That's good, useful functionality, even if you personally don't use it.

Comment: I never even realised that right-most button switched to the other sites, and I thought I had just imagined that functionality existing.

Comment: `subconsciously I assume that 'no count badge' = 'no need to click it'.` <-- this is the perfect response.

Comment: @MacroMan When it was first switched, the reviews icon always had a big red indicator, identical to the inbox messages.  I wonder how many were like me and used something like Stylish to just permanently hide it because of that, and then never bothered to check if they fixed it...

Comment: @Izkata: They actually had that in the beginning. But they removed it because, unlike the other indicators next to it, it would *never* go away. Remember: the top bar moves with you; it's always there. So seeing an alert is like being poked in the eye. Alerts you can get rid of are fine. But alerts that you can *never* get rid of simply become annoying.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, that's what I said.  I'd also forgotten that the bar by default moves with you, that makes it even worse; that's another thing I've changed with Stylish.  It just sticks to the top of the page for me.

Comment: You don't have to hack it with Stylish, @Izkata. Having the top bar not move with you is a preference: https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current. Oded implemented this because legions of established users descended upon SE with pitchforks when this stickiness was demoed.

Comment: Oh! I had assumed it was a hamburger icon ( http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-31602745 ), and hence led to some settings. Apparently it's a sitelist. Who knew?

Answer (score 68):

The review icon is indeed perfectly unclear. Dominos? Someone drawing a line with chalk on a blackboard? A stapler? Some sort of marker pen?

This does however go hand in hand with the other fashionable monochrome icons. Because the right-most icon is even more confusing. The only thing it is close to resembling is a hamburger. Most users don't know what to expect when clicking on a hamburger.

The point here is, if the reviews have started to drop because of the domino icon, then you should experience a similar pattern for items below the hamburger icon.

Has meta participation by new users dropped after introducing the hamburger? Are there fewer new users finding their way to the chats? Do other sites get fewer re-directs from SO?

If you could assemble similar statistics for items below the hamburger, then indeed that would be proof that the icons are to blame. If not, then the dropping review participation depends on other factors. (I could name a lot of those, but lets not derail the topic.)

Comment: The "hamburger" is (a smaller version of) the logo for [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com), and clicking on it allows you access to any site on the exchange. That seems logical to me.

Comment: The left-most icon is pretty unclear, too. What happened to the envelope icon? Is this an old tape recorder or a toolbox with a handle?

Comment: @vojta - I think it is an inbox/tray

Comment: Agreed! When they introduced the icon I found myself clicking on the icon over and over because I kept forgetting what it was supposed to mean.

Comment: Yeah, clicks on the Help and site-switcher drop-downs (the two icons which were formally text on the far left and far right sides of the top-bar) have also diminished significantly, @Lundin. The secondary effects there are harder to gauge - it doesn't look like the site-switcher was responsible for most traffic to meta or other sites, and the help menu *definitely* wasn't responsible for sending very many people to help (context-sensitive links such as those in the close reasons and "you can't vote" pop-up are far and away the biggest sources of traffic to help).

Comment: Thought you meant Dominos the pizza...

Comment: @MageXy You know what, I would actually have realized it was the logo if it had colors. Now someone had to explain it to me instead. But monochrome icons are _fashionable_, so who cares!

Comment: @Shog9 Well there you go then, seems like the new top bar is to blame. Should be easy enough to rollback to the old one.

Comment: "The left-most icon is pretty unclear, too. What happened to the envelope icon? Is this an old tape recorder or a toolbox with a handle?" --- It appears to be a cat litter box.

Comment: "Most users don't know what to expect when clicking on a hamburger." - yes they do, .. it's just not what happens here when you click on it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamburger_button

Comment: @commonpike Okay so there is a different term called hamburger button. But this is not what this is meant to be - it is meant to be the SO logo. And it is not 3 straight lines, it is 1 straight in the middle and 2 rounded, hamburger bread-shaped lines where to lower one has got a bit sticking out of it (some onion ring or salad about to escape, perhaps). That being said, I don't think the symbol in the linked wiki is particularly intuitive either.

Comment: I'd rather *not* have something with a number in it.

Comment: I don't find this a logical argument at all. For a start, the hamburger icon is very common. But more importantly, the use is totally different. Review is something that people can be encouraged to do. It is logical to think that having a text link with the word review encourages people to do so and reminds them about it. The hamburger leads to other sites and is a totally different case. To say that unless there is the same data on the hamburger icon, it's not true, is plain nonsense.

Comment: @SuperDuperApps If it is not a logical argument but nonsense, then your argument must be that a monochrome, hamburger-shaped icon is more intuitive to humans than various click-able text labels named "help", "chat", "meta", "SE network". Okay... If the hamburger icon is very common, kindly share some examples of sites using one, apart from fast food restaurants. Again, it is _not_ supposed to be the "hamburger button" in the linked wiki, it is supposed to be the SE logo. (Yes, it is very hard to tell.) If other sites are using the SE logo I believe they might be up for a lawsuit.

Comment: @MageXy Also, it's not actually a link, it's a dropdown.  Its "hamburger" shape makes perfect sense then due to the prevalence of the hamburger menu icon nowadays.

Comment: That's not my argument, and sorry I didn't express it very patiently last night. My argument is that the two situations are unrelated. The icons may be next to each other, but how people think about and use them is very different. Having a review icon, in text, will encourage people to carry out reviews. Having a non-intuitive/non-attention grabbing icons stands in the way of that. When people are making use of the options in the hamburgeresqu menu, it is stuff they will go looking for. That is very different from review which can remind/encourage them to do some if got right.

Comment: So the usage of one is not necessarily related to the other. And also, because it looks so similar to the hambuger menu, which is very common for bringing up site menus, that makes a difference too. Also it being right-most gives it a certain priority. They are very different cases.

Comment: @MageXy I just realized that it is a mix of the SE logo and the hamburger menu icon. Very clever! Not that obvious tho...

Comment: I think that the StackExchange logo looks very similar to a hamburger menu icon, and it does the exact thing you would expect a hamburger icon to do, which is display some type of menu. You probably won't have a similar drop pattern for that reason.

Comment: I honestly couldn't figure out how to navigate to other SE networks anymore until this thread. Some still have the old banner at the top, so I thought the functionality was removed from some of the sites. I think the issue is the site name in the top left exists on all SE network sites but has different functionality in different places.

Answer (score 54):

In general:

Icons are *always* unclear. They force people to spend precious seconds trying to figure out what this symbol is supposed to mean. The number of icons that have entered the general consciousness can probably be counted on one hand.

(the save icon is one - how long has it been around? Plan on something being around for that long, and standardized for every program, if you want people to start to recognize a new icon. And note that by this point, meaningfulness is gone - recognizability is all that matters)

Words? We invented those for a reason (and block printing > cursive > hieroglyphs by Darwinism). They are always instantaneously clear (as long as it's a sane font, and not a homonym). Even if it's not a native language, people are good at learning words.

For that matter, if completely nonsensical words were assigned, people would learn them and get up to real-word speed very quickly.

---

In specific:

As it is, the *only* icon that is even slightly intuitive is the "trophy" icon ... which is also the least important. The others are just "generic square #1", "generic square #3", and "generic square #4".

Comment: To be fair, The inbox looks like an [inbox](http://www.blucapp.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Inbox.png)

Comment: @NathanOliver Understandable, but for how much longer?

Comment: @BoogaRoo How much longer will people know what an inbox is?

Comment: @NathanOliver Are you sure that isn't an Out box?

Comment: @NathanOliver OK, after looking at the picture, I can see that the icon is supposed to be in "perspective", i.e. the part in the back appears narrower than the part in front even though they're supposed to be the same length.  Trouble is, there's nothing in the icon that makes it look like it's supposed to be a 3-D picture, unless one is already expecting a 3-D picture.  It looks to me like a trapezoid with some lumpy stuff at the bottom. In fact, there are some sedans with that approximate shape, and those lumps look like tires.  So this looks more like a car than a box to me ...

Comment: @NathanOliver Inboxes look different in my country... [more like this](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTCrji0q61qlETDrrjbPMKT4niWpQj5-3Ex3R9DiyyZiGMeUT6Iog)

Comment: @NathanOliver _"How much longer will people know what an inbox is?"_ I, of course, don't have any priviledged information about the future, but it **could** keep its meaning "forever", even after inboxes are long gone. I mean... [it has happened before](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CSBHOBiUcAAGqQ5.jpg)! Time will say. (I, for one, have never ever seen a real inbox in my life but I recognize the icon)

Comment: @ajb Looks more like my "in progress" box...

Comment: I don't associate the trophy icon with reputation and badges, it's more of a "click here and participate in our ongoing contest.......". But I'm sure the developers did proper A/B testing and came to the conclusion that these icons are great and everyone loves them so who am I to judge their bad taste.

Comment: +1 to this! The review icon does not clearly say "review" to me. I still keep mixing up it and the SE logo when I click because they're both gray speech bubbles. Giving it a unique shape would go a long way towards fixing that.

Comment: I wonder how long it will be until people don't even know what the picture-that-is-the-save-icon even *is* (a [3.5" floppy disk](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/aa/Floppy_disk_2009_G1.jpg/1200px-Floppy_disk_2009_G1.jpg), if (generic)you are one such person).

Comment: Lets just have the worst of both worlds and just use WingDings text!

Comment: Um... what's an Inbox?   I haven't seen one of those physical things in 20 years.  On the other hand a cat box -- yeah that's where my kitty leaves me special messages.

Comment: A thousand times this! We were made for words, and we've honed our wetware our entire lives for words. Hieroglyphics are always confusing. Bring back labelled navigation with real honest to goodness words, not hieroglyphics alone.

Answer (score 26):

After some thought, I think the best thing to do is keep the icon **but add the number of pending edits on top of it**, like the number of new inbox items:

> [image]

This will make people notice the item better and want to click it.

Comment: Honestly, I think having a badge icon anywhere on the top bar would stress me out. It would definitely draw attention, but I think this might be going too far the other way.

Comment: @BiscuitBaker I don't think so. It was the same in the old design, just without icon. Maybe have a different color, e.g. the old orange.

Comment: A more muted colour would definitely reduce the feeling of urgency. I'd completely forgotten that this was part of the old design!

Comment: @BiscuitBaker I didn't, lol. The number was always off but still, it was there and was useful IMO.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not opposed to this if it was part of the old nav. It obviously didn't bother me if I've completely forgotten about it.

Comment: ++ Exactly this. Having the number there (in bright red even), tells you not only that there is a queue, but also how large it it and that it's changing. Having just the icon, either orange or grey, isn't calling you to action. And of course the other icons work, because they are for the users themselves. *I* want to jump to the other community or fap over all the rep that I gained. Nobody is looking for the review queue; people need to be reminded that it exists. All. The. Time. I think this red number is the most subtle way that could still work.

Comment: I like this idea, but at the same time.. I don't. As someone who reviews rarely (only when I'm incredibly bored) that little box is going to get annoying always popping up. I'll be clicking on it to simply get rid of, which I don't want to be doing every time I'm navigating around. I think just the review text would work best like Shog9 suggested.

Comment: I'm having flashbacks of the email icon on my old iPhone...

Comment: The main problem touched upon here is that you don't see what the truth is until you navigate to a specific page - showing a number of just one queue is only solving a tiny part of the total equation. A (configurable) block on the side which shows the cached numbers on the different queues makes it far easier to see what is up in any of the queues while you're out and about doing your regular SO things. Or otherwise I want a stock-tip type of scrolling banner which shows the numbers :) Show people when its prudent to dump their close votes!

Comment: For me, when I see a number badge that's *always* there, I just learn to ignore it.  Like @MacroMan mentioned, my iPhone always tells me I have a billion new emails because I get a lot of emails, and I don't read them all.  That big red number on top of the icon doesn't tell me anything useful, so my eyes don't even notice it anymore.

Comment: Related: ["we no longer show a count for this at all"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/7586) (your question, by the way!). The count was removed also because the queues contain several hundreds of items, which is just distracting.

Comment: Even a no-count red pip would be a call to action, and worth doing.

Comment: A problem could be that if it is lit all the time, people might get used to it so it won't do any good. I suggest just lighting it sometimes, like suggested in [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link?cb=1#comment482656_350836). It would also be a good idea to add an option in the profile settings to disable it lighting up in case some users think it's stressing.

Comment: Please don't do this. It used to be this way but it was **incredibly irritating**!

Answer (score 18):

I... hesitate to post this, but I don't understand. The people who do the reviews, are not newcomers. They are people that have

- an account
- sufficient reputation
- the desire to review stuff

How is it that they wouldn't learn from day one that the icon is the new review icon?

To be honest, I was confused when the new design was rolled out, I searched for the review icon, **exactly once**. Then it was done. I know what icon it is.

So while I agree that it's not exactly crying out loud "review" just by looking at it, I can't fathom how someone will be seriously discouraged from reviews by an unwieldy icon.

... Sadly for me, numbers seem to contradict my thinking.

Comment: Don't feel bad; you're not the only one caught off-guard by this. I totally didn't expect it either.

Comment: Fact of life: bad UX hits everyone to some extent, even experts.

Comment: Goes to show the importance of UX. It's a great case study, this.

Comment: my experience was the same, _confused first time -> search for new icon -> use it -> get surprised to find that numbers show it had such a pronounced impact on others_. The only reason that comes to mind is folks who dropped were uncomfortable doing reviews. You know, those who waste half an hour or more breaking through 20-40 unfiltered reviews without even skipping. When word "review" was there it could serve like call of duty, "please do it, site needs your help". After it disappeared they maybe felt nothing but relief. "Out of sight, out of mind"

Comment: There is also the problem that, as old reviewers retire, new reviewers need to take their place. The Super problem is that, Retired-Rate > New-Rate. That is the real issue that needs to be addressed.

Comment: @Tezra you might find it interesting that statistics shows "old reviewers retire" happens [typically after mere 50 reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601), go figure

Comment: @gnat I'm not surprised. Reviewing isn't the funnest task. (The badges keep me going =P) 1 rep for x approved reviews, or being able to earn silver/gold badges repeatedly would REALLY help the motivation =P

Comment: "Sharp drop at 10-50 likely indicates that many users find it difficult to work in review queue. Drop after 250 (silver badge) suggests that even after substantial amount of reviews, many users still fail to discover a way to work productively..."

Comment: "the desire to review stuff" is not always really true. Many people review out of sheer boredom, when they have nothing better to do, So if you make it harder for them, they will simply find something else which is easier to find/do, possibly outside of SE. :/

Comment: _"Sadly for me, numbers seem to contradict my thinking."_ But they don't. The data are not convincing at all. There's a _massive_ leap being made in the OP's conclusions.

Comment: Because I can't remember icons well - text I understand every time - icons I have to look up most times

Answer (score 13):

Basic UX suggests that the upper right hand corner is one of the least viewed webpage areas.

I suspect that the move of the review button there (vs the previous location in prime "eyes on" screen real estate) had a significant effect as well. I am less convinced the button vs name is the root and core problem here.

I know for a fact I am less aware of the review button because I generally ignore the right hand side of webpages (particularly SE because most of the content there is ads). Particularly since on the browser I use, the icon is actually nearly off the page because of the top bar's width.

Anyone who is not browsing on a very wide screen simply is not going to even see the icon regardless of what it's called.

I would caution against *only* renaming the icon vs also being aware of the impact that moving it and removing the count has had.

Add in the removal of the count and identity crisis of the top bar?

Comment: But the old review button was also on the top right side of the screen, wasn't it? It still is on other SE sites.

Comment: @MageXy sort of? It's nearly centered (probably about 10% to the right of center on my monitor), is aligned with the parts of the page you actually read, and has both a notification count as well as the "review" text.

Answer (score 13):

I've actually been searching everywhere for the review link. I just recently got enough points to be able to access it and I wanted to check it out, but in all the questions and the documentation pages about the review process, they all say to click the review link at the top of the page. Until this post I didn't know where it was and had to manually type it in the url. I thought it might just be a bug that it wasn't there or something was wrong with my account. If they do keep the icon, please update the site documentation to reflect it.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's not the icon itself that's the problem, it's the fact that even when highlighted, it doesn't draw enough attention (orange is a common branding color throughout the UI, so the brain immediately learns to ignore it). Changing it back to a text link would obviously break the new design; instead, we could consider improving it's visibility, while keeping the icon itself. Something like:

[image]

Obviously this is a bit of a crude example, but you can see how the bright red color, combined with the urgency of the badge count, draws attention.

Comment: So true. People who were used to reviewing can certainly find this icon, but you're just not invited to click it.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of opinions about icons in general here. 
I think the main point is the icons (all 4 of them) are just not very clear. The 'review' icon, even if you recognize it- what does it do, speak or write, or both ? And the hamburger balloon, why is that a balloon anyway ?

There are widely recognized icons for all four actions, though; no need to revert to text; just improve them. But first define what these actions really are:

- '**incoming**' stuff is usually an arrow down to some plate at the bottom, differentiating it clearly from outgoing.
- '**awards**' is the least obscure icon, <del>but a star would already do</del> leave it as it is
- '**review**' - I would say this icon means 'moderate' instead. moderators wear crowns or police caps. if you dislike the hierarchical implications, it may mean 'meta/discuss', which is often overlapping speech balloons
- '**other SE**' takes you out of this site. that's usually an arrow escaping a box, often to the top right. If you would claim this is a 'network' icon, that's a number of connected bubbles.

I think all these icons are widely accepted and recognizable, unless you are an icogynist.

@PeterB made the valid observation that the last two icons are of quite a different level or scope. The first two belong to you, the last two belong to the site. They could be visually separated a bit more.

---

https://www.google.com/search?q=icon+incoming&tbm=isch

https://www.google.com/search?q=icon+awards&tbm=isch

https://www.google.com/search?q=icon+moderator&tbm=isch

https://www.google.com/search?q=icon+network&tbm=isch

Comment: A star would be a bad idea: it usually means "favorites", and the Stack Exchange sites already use stars with this meaning. Even Google uses it. The use of stars to mark something as favorite is so widespread it's even become a verb: you can *star* this question, for example, by clicking on the star icon, just below its score. And apart from this, I think the trophy is the only icon that conveys its meaning, and I wouldn't change it.

Comment: agree - changed that in the answer

Comment: I think the other sites icon is just fine because it's the Stack Exchange logo. It's the same on other sites, except that on other sites it's in color and is followed by the text "Stack Exchange".

Comment: @DonaldDuck and it has a dropdown triangle, it opens properly as a tab (including a tab label) and it's usually on the left. I didn't even notice it was *that* icon, .. also never noticed it was a balloon there .. but you're right. in which case, I would find it confusing everywhere if it had no label :-)

Answer (score -15):

ICONS - **I**ncomprehensible **C**ryptic **O**bfuscated **N**onsense **S**ymbols

Enough said!

Comment: [[citation needed](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/Webcomic_xkcd_-_Wikipedian_protester.png)]

Comment: Icons are nice and playful, we had them in a recently built application. And then during the testing phase that was quickly swapped out with a dull dropdown menu so people could actually do their work properly.

Comment: @Gimby Dropdown menus are just workarounds for missing shortcuts.

Comment: @xDaizu, It's [possibly "original"-ish](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Incomprehensible+Cryptic+Obfuscated+Nonsense+Symbols%22&t=ffcm&ia=web).  I prefer the long-established ["mystery meat" navigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystery_meat_navigation). ;)

Comment: Can I upvote this a 100 times - I need to take a copy into often used clipboard

Answer (score -22):

Color does a great job of communicating, attracting the eyes attention, and bringing contrast to different elements. Here's a quick mock up using color in the navbar that might make each icon stick out a bit more.

[image: Just the icons]

[image: The full nav bar]

Comment: Are the colors too distracting?

Comment: The contrast should be high enough, sure, but color is overrated. It helps to distinguish between the icons, but it doesn't add actual *meaning*. Also, the benefit is mostly gone when you're among the 10% that are color blind. Regardless, you still have to figure out that that (red) icon means 'review'.

Comment: @GolezTrol great points, just thought I'd throw this idea out there. My thinking is that the issue isn't that the icon is unclear, so much as it blends in too well, so I'd never click it unless I was prompted to like inbox and the trophy does.

Comment: Just a detail, but if you really want to do this, I would put the Stack Exchange button in blue since the Stack Exchange logo is blue.

Comment: @GolezTrol Except humans have a very good ability to associate abstract symbols together with their function. You can put any nonsense symbol there; if a human click on it long enough they will remember what that symbol does. Colors help memorizing much faster. It's like [these games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concentration_(game)), which would be significantly harder for humans if there were no colors at all. Now of course if they weren't monochrome nonsensical symbols in the first place, we wouldn't need to play such guessing/memory games.

Comment: Color blindness is mostly trouble separating red from green, rather than not seeing any colors at all. It is not really a good argument to raise, as there are lot of other disabilities you could as well consider. For example it is very common that people have poor sight and might therefore not be able to see tiny, blurred, abstract icons well. In which case colors help them a lot.

Answer (score -37):

icons are fine good to understand and reduce the space as well

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2805971/rohit-heera?tab=activity&sort=reviews Two reviews shortly after posting this answer, prior to which you've never even *used* the review queues (all other reviews were on edits on your own posts). For all we know, you only discovered review today after seeing the question and learning what that icon meant. So I'm not so sure your statement that "icons are [...] good to understand" can be taken seriously.

Answer (score -42):

Are we absolutely sure it has something to do with the new icon?

If somebody is interested in the quality of the site, I am very sure this person would also ask themselves, "what is this shiny icon next to my achievement icon?"

What would this person see?

[image: tool tip]

For the other people, that are only interested in asking/answering questions I am not really sure if it makes much difference whether it's text or an icon.

Certainly, reviews are in need of more traffic. I am only asking if your proposed way is the right way to handle it.

By looking at the charts, yes, the activity is lower since the top bar redesign. But was this process started by the redesign? I see a clear downward trend before this change (If we remove the triage spike).

This leads to the following question:

Why did we have a spike for the introduction of Triage? Can we tweak something to reproduce this?

In my opinion, badges are an motivation for many people here (regardless of whether they are interested in site quality or not). For me, the explanation for Triage is that people had the chance in getting 3 more badges.

Maybe we could temporarily test multiple gold badges for reviews?

Also, I find this idea very interesting:

> IMO, it would also be helpful to have the badge back for reviews
>   (regardless of if we have the text "review", or the icon), but only if
>   the badge is only displayed when the review queues are particularly
>   full. Having the badge always displayed was ineffective. When it's
>   always displayed people become use to it being there and just ignore
>   it. If it is displayed only at times when the queues are particularly
>   full, people are likely to pay attention to this "new" thing in their
>   view and actually act on it.

‐ [Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link#comment482634_350836)

**tl;dr**: Review needs some work to draw attention. But is changing the icon really the right way?

Comment: Having to hover the mouse to see a description in order to understand what a given thing does, is extra work, and unnecessary if a word is used instead of a non-standard icon.  I still do not understand the icon, but my guess is that it is a pencil on a line?  Or an eraser?   Why can't "review" have a word when "Questions" can? (Where a question mark would be the perfect icon)

Comment: I only guessed it's a pencil on a line only **after** knowing it's the review button. the icon is awful

Comment: Yes, the icon is not the greatest. Maybe we could exchange it.

Comment: I always thought that the icon was a flying chalk drawing something in a mixture of a speech bubble and a blackboard. Not a great icon, certainly. Now I realize it makes more sense if it is an pencil... I agree with Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, it should be a word, like "Questions", "Tags" and "Users".

Comment: I agree with the difficult to understand icon, but my take is a fluorescent pen highlighting errors.

Comment: If it's worth anything, I am a prime example of this: I have some experience on SO, so most of the icons made sense to me immediately. I don't tend to review (including before the top-bar change) so, come my first exposure to the new navigation, I did exactly what this answer suggests and hovered over the icon to see what it was. I can say that I'd be more likely to visit reviews if I *occasionally* had a little red badge on the icon when the queues were filling up, or some similar call for action.

Comment: @KenY-N Your description helped me finally understand what it is. I've thought it's an odd-looking command prompt inside of the bubble.

Comment: I personally found *all* of the new icons, and their placement, confusing, and totally out of sync with the rest of SE. It was a week or so, before I worked out what was where. Yes, I should have "hovered with the mouse", but I am busy and it was easier to go to other SE sites where I didn't have to work out how to use the UI all over again.

Comment: I worked at a place where our ecommerce site had three confusing icons with no text. Next to them was a link to a *video* that explained 'how to use the icons.' The video mostly just explained what features the icons linked to. Because when users don't know what an icon means they'll watch an explanatory 'what these icons are' video.

Comment: @ScottHannen That seems like a pretty bad trade-off to me. Presumably the link was text. If so, it must've taken about the same amount of space as the original links, but using it less efficiently as you now had to explain unintuitive icons in a separate video, instead of just describing each link in-place. It's worse that it's a video, not e.g. a popover - as I suspect a fair number of folk, like me, hate sites that expect them to watch videos if they didn't visit with the intention to do so, and will often close without watching them.

Comment: @underscore_d Even if someone does want to watch videos, I can't imagine wanting to watch one about how to use basic site features. If users need a video to figure out how to use the site something is wrong. And the videos become obsolete the moment anything changes.

Comment: @ScottHannen Indeed! Before, I couldn't tell whether you thought it was an OK idea or not. :P