# Edit needed on Access Review Queues - username no longer shown at the top of every page

Tags: bug, help-center

The [Access Review Queues](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) page states:

> The first queues you gain access to are Late Answers and First Posts.
> These and all other review queues are accessible from the "review"
> link that appears at the top of every page **next to your user name**
> though you will only be able to perform reviews in the queues open to users of your reputation level.

[Emphasis mine]

Though user names are no-longer found at the top of every page.  Perhaps it would be better to refer to it as being

> These and all other review queues are accessible from the "review" <strike>link</strike> **icon** that appears at the top of every page **in between the trophy and  hamburger-menu icons**

or similar.

Comment: "accessible from the "review" icon" is a bit better, because it currently is an icon instead of text. But there is a feature request to use the text again, instead of an icon ([link to the request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link)).

Comment: @Tom, are you following me ;-)  I've edited post to change 'link' to 'icon'.

Comment: No, I'm just currently following both meta sites :D

Comment: Also, it's not a hamburger menu. That icon is a smaller version of [Stack Exchange's logo](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/se/se-icon.png?v=93426798a1d4) (note the tail) and opens up the list of network sites.

Comment: It is outdated.  But.  Would you really want to leave review up to people that can't figure out how to start reviewing?  Hmm.  No.  Erm, wait.  Yes.  Yes, whatever it takes to end this scourge to humanity.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought the same about Shogs feature request. If someone can't even find the review icon (and remember then that this is the review icon), then how should that person be able to do proper review.

Comment: @Draco18s I initially called it the stack-exchange hamburger-menu, but that seemed too convoluted!

Comment: @HansPassant ironically, that's exactly how I got to posting this.  I hit 500 points, and then thought, I want to start reviewing - now what?  I think the badge I earned led me to the page I linked to, but then honestly spent time wondering where on earth my name was, and that darned review link!

Comment: I found the review queue when I was exploring those icons, I knew I got enough reputation to access a 'review queue' but I never knew where was it until I randomly clicked on to them :P

Comment: "in between the trophy and hamburger-menu icons" - it would be better to say "to the right of the trophy icon"; maybe people don't know what us the hamburger icon

Comment: Related: we should re-introduce text under the icons like suggested in https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351081/1033581. Eventually re-introducing the username as well.

Comment: Im with @Cœur : some people struggle with icons when their function is not immediately obvious to all users; including text is easier on them and brain cycles.