# Stack Overflow moderation queue gone?

Tags: support, moderation

I remember getting a request to moderate new questions and it was fun to do, now I can't find a link to review queue anywhere.

How do you access it?

Comment: Are you searching for this? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: @BhargavRao My gratitude.

Comment: There is currently a feature request to turn the icon back into a text link: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link

Answer (score 11):

It has be hidden behind [image: review icon] in the top bar.  I'm not sure what this is supposed to represent but clicking on it gives you

[image]

Comment: It's a pencil writing on top of a text-bubble icon. It's supposed to give the impression of marking up something that's been said (in this case, posts).