# Why are some flags reviewed very fast?

Tags: support, flags

Recently I've noticed that some of my flags:

- get marked as helpful almost instantly. Does the system itself mark some flags as helpful? Or why is this happening?
- and some are waiting very long and just get aged away. I do have **26 flags aged away**, of which **17** flagged questions were deleted later. And most of my flags are **too broad**, **unclear what you're asking**, **off-topic**, or **duplicate**.

Comment: `Does the system itself mark as helpful some flags?`  Yes.  Mods also prioritize certain flags over others.

Comment: per my observations lowering LQ reviews from 6 to 4 dramatically increased speed of processing flags (at least flags on blatant NAA / VLQ answers), handling these flags went like from 8-12 hours down to 1-3 hours

Comment: **My question is not a duplicate.** In fact, I've never yet flagged anything as **low quality**.

Comment: The original duplicate didn't really apply here, but the two questions linked above should cover the core points.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only flags that age away are close vote flags, and those largely aren't handled by moderators. They're reviewed in the Close Votes review queue. That queue is known for being quite full, and has been designed to focus attention on immediate issues. It ages away flags that probably aren't going to ever be reviewed.

"not an answer" and "very low quality" flags are also reviewed by the community in the Low Quality Posts review queue, but they are presented to moderators after being in that review queue for a duration. That review queue, among others, has been having some problems lately [due to the top bar redesign](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link). Moderators have been stepping in to burn down those flags to try to prevent this from getting out of hand. A moderator election is being called to handle this increased load in the short term.

Custom flags, spam / offensive flags, and comment flags are only handled by moderators. They don't age away, but they can be handled at varying rates. Spam / offensive flags go to the top of our list, and obvious spam or trolling is usually handled within minutes. Posts that receive multiple flags also get sorted up, so those tend to be handled quickly.

Everything else can vary, depending on who's working on what. I might search for plagiarism flags, for example, and handle ones cast three days ago at the same time as ones that came in just now. Tricky issues that might require some internal discussion can be put off for a while, where simple things to deal with might get acted on right away.

Comment: `The only flags that age away are close vote flags.` Strangely enough I don't yet have an ability to vote to close questions (except my own ones), but I do have **26 flags aged away**, of which **17** flagged questions were deleted later. And most of my flags are **too broad**, **unclear what you're asking**, **off-topic**, or **duplicate**.

Comment: @sudo - Right, you can't cast votes directly, so you have to use flags for your close votes. Every one of your aged away flags were close flags, and the questions that were deleted were done so automatically by the system due to downvotes, age, and lack of answers. No one reviewed them before the system automatically removed them.

Comment: Spam and rude/abusive flags [age away, too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204347). Does not happen often, possibly never on SO, but it can happen.

Comment: @Alex - Huh, did not know that. Guess I haven't seen a flag of those types last that long, because those are the first categories we act on.