# When are the results for the Stack Overflow Developer Survey released, and where can I find them?

Tags: discussion, survey

Each year, Stack Overflow conducts the yearly Developer Survey.  The last one has been closed for a while.

When can we expect to see the published results of the survey?

How long did it take to prepare them?

Where can I find the results once they're available?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

| Opened | Released | Survey Opened Blog | Survey Opened Meta Post (MSO) | Results Released Blog |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Dec. 2010 | Jan. 2011 | [Stack Overflow Annual Survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/12/21/stack-overflow-annual-survey/) | N/A | [Survey Says](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/11/survey-says/) |
| Dec. 2011 | Feb. 2012 | [Come Here Often?](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/12/14/come-here-often/) | N/A | [2012 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/10/survey-results/) |
| Dec. 2012 | Jan. 2013 | [Hey there, stranger!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/12/14/hey-there-stranger/) | [Stack Overflow Annual User Survey 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158456/) (MSE) | [*2013 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/01/25/2012-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) |
| Dec. 2013 | Feb. 2014 | [Who are you? Take the 2013 survey!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/12/18/who-are-you-take-the-2013-survey/) | [Stack Overflow Annual User Survey 2013 Edition](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/211850/) (MSE) | [*2014 Stack Overflow User Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/02/19/2013-stack-overflow-user-survey-results/) |
| Feb. 2015 | Apr. 2015 | N/A | [Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2015 - Now Closed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285178/) | [Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2015: The Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/04/07/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2015-the-results/) |
| Jan. 2016 | Mar. 2016 | N/A | [Stack Overflow Annual Survey 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314186/) | [2016 Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2016/03/17/stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/) |
| Jan. 2017 | Mar. 2017 | [The 2017 Stack Overflow Developer Survey is Now Live](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/11/the-2017-stack-overflow-developer-survey-is-now-live/) | [Take the Developer Survey 2017!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342400/take-the-developer-survey-2017) | [Now Live: Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2017 Results](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/22/now-live-stack-overflow-developer-survey-2017-results/) |
| Jan. 2018 | Mar. 2018 | [Take the 2018 Developer Survey](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/08/take-2018-developer-survey/) | [Take the 2018 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/361588/) | [The 2018 Developer Survey Results are Live](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/03/13/2018-developer-survey-results-live/) |
| Jan. 2019 | Apr. 2019 | [Our 2019 Developer Survey is Open to Coders Everywhere!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/01/23/our-2019-developer-survey-is-open-to-coders-everywhere/) | [Take the 2019 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379281/) | [The 2019 Stack Overflow Developer Survey Results Are In](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/04/09/the-2019-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results-are-in/) |
| Feb. 2020 | May 2020 | [The 2020 Developer Survey is now open!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/02/05/the-2020-developer-survey-is-now-open/) | [Take the 2020 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/393644/) | [The 2020 Developer Survey results are here!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/05/27/2020-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/) |
| May 2021 | Aug. 2021 | [The 2021 Developer Survey is now open](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/05/25/the-2021-developer-survey-is-now-open/) | [Take the 2021 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407914/) | [The full data set for the 2021 Developer Survey now available!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/30/the-full-data-set-for-the-2021-developer-survey-now-available/) |
| May 2022 | Jun. 2022 | [The 2022 Developer Survey is now open](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/11/stack-overflow-2022-developer-survey-is-open/) <sub>(and [The Overflow #126](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/05/20/the-overflow-126-the-2022-developer-survey-now-open/))</sub> | [Take the 2022 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417991) | [Asked and answered: the results for the 2022 Developer survey are here!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/06/22/asked-and-answered-the-results-for-the-2022-developer-survey-are-here) |
| May 2023 | Jun. 2023 | [The 2023 Developer Survey is now live!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/05/08/the-2023-developer-survey-is-now-live/) | [Take the 2023 Developer Survey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424565) | [2023 Developer Survey results are in: the latest trends in technology and work from the Stack Overflow community](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/06/13/developer-survey-results-are-in/) |

* <sub>- It appears that these blogs were renamed to increment the year in their title at some point, as the URLs for the blog reference a year prior to their title.</sub>

Links to download the raw data (in CSV format) of each year's survey results are available on https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/.

See [@ElegyD's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397027) for more exact day counts on the length of time each survey was open, and the time between closure and results.

Answer (score 25):

I made a little overview of all surveys so far:

| Year | Opened | Closed | Days open | Results | Days pending | Days total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | 2010-12-21 |  |  | 2011-01-11 |  | 21 |
| 2011 | 2011-12-14 |  |  | 2012-02-10 |  | 58 |
| 2012 | 2012-12-12 |  |  | 2013-01-25 |  | 44 |
| 2013 | 2013-12-16 | 2013-12-31 | 15 | 2014-02-19 | 50 | 65 |
| 2015 | 2015-02-02 | 2015-02-15 | 13 | 2015-04-07 | 51 | 64 |
| 2016 | 2016-01-07 | 2016-01-25 | 18 | 2016-03-17 | 52 | 70 |
| 2017 | 2017-01-11 | 2017-02-06 | 26 | 2017-03-22 | 44 | 70 |
| 2018 | 2018-01-08 | 2018-01-26 | 18 | 2018-03-13 | 46 | 64 |
| 2019 | 2019-01-23 | 2019-02-12 | 20 | 2019-04-09 | 56 | 76 |
| 2020 | 2020-02-05 | 2020-02-28 | 23 | 2020-05-27 | 89 | 112 |
| 2021 | 2021-05-25 | 2021-06-15 | 21 | 2021-08-02 | 48 | 69 |
| 2022 | 2022-05-11 | 2022-06-01 | 21 | 2022-06-22 | 21 | 42 |
| 2023 | 2023-05-08 | 2023-05-19 | 11 | 2023-06-13 | 25 | 36 |

Comment: Why does `Days open` vary so much?  We only get 11 days this year.  Seems short.