# Where can I find the developer survey 2021 dataset?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2021

I can't find the link to the SO 2021 survey (that was released recently) CSV data set [here](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey). Any idea when the data set will be made public?

Comment: Related: *[When are the results for the Stack Overflow Developer Survey released, and where can I find them?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396864/when-are-the-results-for-the-stack-overflow-developer-survey-released-and-where/397027#397027)* and *[The 2021 Stack Overflow Developer Survey is here!](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/02/2021-stack-overflow-developer-survey-results/)* (blog post)

Answer (score 6):

We have just published a [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/08/30/the-full-data-set-for-the-2021-developer-survey-now-available/) announcing the release of the raw data for the **2021 Developer Survey**. The data can be found on our [Survey Insights](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey) page.

Happy analyzing!

Answer (score -1):

In case you are interested in the Stack Overflow developer survey results of previous years, you can also find them on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/). For example, for the 2020 survey there are more than 15 data analysis and data mining [projects](https://www.kaggle.com/aitzaz/stack-overflow-developer-survey-2020/code) happening. So you can gain some project ideas and insights from there as well.