# Why is there no [featured] meta announcement about the 2017 Developer Survey?

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

According to [this](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/821438441489473536) Tweet the survey has been publicly fillable for 22 hours at the time I'm posting this question. I only found out about the survey being available because I accidentally opened my Twitter feed and that post was peeking through the cobwebs.

In previous years I'm fairly certain there was a featured meta post about it, how come there isn't one this year? Or is it advertised by other means throughout the site and I just missed it?

Comment: It's been fillable [since the 12th.](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/The-2017-Stack-Overflow-Developer-Survey-is-Now-Live/) Don't know if the post was in the CB on main or not, but I don't recall seeing that blog post on the one on Meta... But I might not have been (read: really wasn't) paying attention.

Comment: All of the [survey] Meta questions turned into a big embarrassment, so maybe it isn't [featured] because they've taken it offline, are resetting the data, and plan to start over. But I'm afraid they're still in the denial stage.

Comment: @CodyGray Are you OK?

Comment: Yes, I'm fine. Thank you for asking. Although I'm not sure why you did. @bsmp

Comment: They [Tested it first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339532/would-you-like-to-test-the-2017-developer-survey) !

Comment: It shows on and off. Depending caching.