# Show notification for future surveys

Tags: feature-request, survey

One clear takeaway from the comment sections in the recent ["Women in the 2016 Stack Overflow survey" blog post](http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/women-in-the-2016-stack-over-survey/?cb=1) seems to be that some people didn't hear about the survey during the phase it was actively promoted in the side bar.

It would seem acceptable to display this as a notification, like the one for moderator elections, to improve participation. No?

It's unobtrusive, easy to dismiss, and yet it makes sure a lot of users see it.

Related:  [Why is there no [featured] meta announcement about the 2017 Developer Survey?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341826/why-is-there-no-featured-meta-announcement-about-the-2017-developer-survey)

*I can't believe this isn't a duplicate....*

Comment: I presume they want to prevent the stampede that happened on [MSE with the changes of the ToS that flooded it a while back.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278562/213575)

Comment: @CodyGray oh - I completely overread that the data Julia was examining was *last year's* data. I assumed 2016 to mean "late 2016". Will fix

Comment: *I can't believe this question has no answer yet....*

Comment: @Alex well, it seems a little late to implement for the survey that's currently running. It's likely something that can and will be considered for the next survey the earliest

Comment: @Braiam The issue with ToS notification was that it led users to a Mata.SE post, they got lost there and posted off-topic stuff. If a notification linked to a survey, that wouldn't happen -  SurveyMonkey doesn't look like a Q&A site. I guess someone would still type their programming question in the survey, but not many.

Comment: I think one big improvement they could make that wouldn't take much effort is to **make the survey open at the same date/time each year**. I would just set a reminder on my phone to take it.