# When does the Developer Survey open?

Tags: support, survey, survey-2017

How do we know when the survey opens?

Do you need a certain number of reputation to take it? If not, is there a way to set up a notification or email when the survey is open?

I'm one of the few female programmers out there, so I feel like I'm doing a disservice by not making my voice heard.

Comment: You can take the survey even if you don't have an SO account. Currently there's no way to be notified when the survey opens (there's an open [feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342014)) though.

Comment: "I'm one of the few female programmers out there, so I feel like I'm doing a disservice by not making my voice heard." [You would be right.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/19/women-in-the-2016-stack-over-survey)

Comment: You don't even need a SO account. But at end of survey(after 50+ question(really tired of it)), you can enter your profile link and then you will be awarded with a silver badge.

Comment: it's true that this year I didn't even saw it, while I did last year.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is Anita Taylor in Stack Overflow's Developer Marketing group.

We are sorry that you missed out this year on making your voice heard.

First, you do NOT need a certain amount of reputation to take the survey. All devs are eligible to take the survey -- even those who don't use Stack Overflow.

This year, to drive survey participation, we mostly relied on banner ads on stackoverflow.com, as well as social media. That said, we did make a concerted effort to try to reach more women programmers -- but it was mostly through word-of-mouth.

Next year, we definitely are considering using email to try to broaden the net even wider.

Thanks for sharing your concern!

Comment: There is a quick way to see if someone is really from Stack Overflow, normal people cannot post things on meta if they have a reputation lower than 5, but SE people can

Comment: obligatory standard sentence: *Thanks for coming to meta.  Please read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/292385)*; It seems like you lost your ♦ somewhere.

Comment: I'm on SO almost every day, for years, but I also didn't see this survey.

Comment: If they are using banner ads, then anyone with > 200 rep would be likely *not* to see it http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads which seems problematic for the accuracy of results.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt duly noted. Edited the question.

Comment: @Loren that makes so much sense, because I'm always on here and didn't see any banners.

Comment: @Bevor I'm pretty sure the survey was also discussed in one of the [featured] blog or meta posts

Comment: @Bergi: It was, but there's always something "featured" or "hot" so it's one link like any other and unless you actually *read* the text of the link it blends in the normal day occurrences.

Comment: @Loren: Interestingly, I do have a banner for the **results**; I must admit I did a double take, it's been close to 10 years since I last had ads on StackOverflow.

Comment: *relied on banner ads* .... brilliant idea in times when most people are using adblockers for self-defense

Comment: I didn't notice the survey was open, and I visit SO every day. :( It really would be good to announce this more loudly.

Comment: Maybe there should be a global inbox message for this? Or, as there is a e-mail about survey results, there can be e-mail about survey participation.

Comment: I use an ad blocker much of the time, and I have a bit of rep on SO, yet I did see multiple items referring to the 'take the survey', even after I'd taken the survey, IIRC.  I'm pretty sure there was a pinned item in the blogs/hot meta-posts section of the page for most of a month — it was in January mainly, and there was also news about the Winterfest and so on in there.  If you don't look at those boxes, I suppose you might have missed it.