# Could the survey include role-related questions?

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2017

I would like to know why, if for any reason, are there (basically none) role/career-related questions in the Survey. I did only get one question regarding **actual** job title, while I think it should be more interesting what's your **desired** job title. Think of questions like:

1. Have you thought of changing role in the last year?
2. If (1), into which of these roles are you thinking on moving (or have you thought of)?

   - Management
   - Leading
   - Infrastructure
   - Business Analyst
   - QA
   - Others (specify)
3. From which of these roles do you come from?

   - Support
   - Infrastructure
   - Only been a programmer
   - Non-technical role
   - Others (specify)

I am asking just out of curiosity, but as per the works I've had, these switches are common and I'd think this affects a lot on what people do with their jobs.

Comment: No one is allowed to become 'only' a programmer, only switch out of it? /s

Comment: Did you [suggest a question for the survey](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221/what-else-should-we-ask-developers)? Also, did you really not get any job related questions? Did it not even ask what your current job title is?

Comment: After the 2017 survey is over, there should be a meta post where you can suggest questions for the next year (here's [the post last year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319221), for the current 2017 one).

Comment: @BSMP current job title and **desired** job title are very different things

Comment: *I would like to know why, if for any reason, are there not role/career-related questions in the Survey.* - Current job title is a role/career related question. That statement made it sound like you never saw it.

Comment: @BSMP I'll edit the question :)

Comment: I think the phrasing "Role" is better than "Title" as it connotes what you actually do/did. For example, in my case, I have served many different Roles over the years with the same official Title.

Comment: The problem I foresee is that these "roles" are so ill-defined and nebulous that it would be like trying to nail a blob of jelly to the wall to figure out what is meant, or what someone who picked it meant.

Comment: What if I have multiple roles?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for these suggestions -- we'll definitely keep them in mind for next year and/or smaller follow-up studies!