# Where is the answer about the preferred working hours?

Tags: discussion, survey-2017

Last year, you asked [What else should we ask developers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319221/3182664), and I suggested asking them about [What are your preferred working hours?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319502/3182664)

I was happy to see this question (in a somewhat simpler form) in the last survey. It contained a slider where you could set the preferred time of the day to start working.

Unfortunately, this information was not included in the [survey results for 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/insights/survey/2017/).

Did I overlook it? Was it left out intentionally? Was it left out due to technical reasons (e.g. not enough responses)? Will it be published elsewhere in 6-8 weeks?

I'd **really** be curious to see the distribution of preferred starting hours over several thousand developers.

Comment: Also missing:  the question about which fictional character is the most closely portrayed to an actual software developer.

Comment: JamesQMurphy: True. But the preferred working hours question is something that is *important* in view of the recent shift of Stack Overflow towards Jobs (which also was well reflected in the survey questions in general). (Side note @jonrsharpe: I know, salutations are usually noise, but here, they had been "on topic" ;-) however, it's OK to omit them)

Comment: @Sayse To avoid misunderstandings: This question is *not* about which of the questions was included in the *survey* or not. The question about the preferred working hours *was* in the survey. But the results of this question are not shown on the *survey results* page. (So I assume that the answers are available somewhere, but haven't been published)

Comment: Oh sorry I misread that part of the question.

Comment: I've purged a bunch of comments about the salutation thing. [There are better places to discuss that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were a couple of questions we decided we'd answer in more depth in blog posts and future analyses. For example, @JamesQMurphy noted in the comments that the question about fictional developers wasn't included, [and today it's been published as a blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/28/realistic-developer-fiction/)!

The question about preferred working times in particular will be interesting in combination with other Stack Overflow data- you can expect the analysis soon.

Just like in previous years, all of the (anonymized) data from the survey will be released in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Was this ever published anywhere other than Marco13's chart below?  Was there a blog post?  I searched the blog but found nothing.

Answer (score 4):

As of the published data set from https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/ , here is the answer:

[image: WorkingHours]

The graph shows the number of responses for each possible start time. More precisely, it is the histogram of the column that is described as follows in the schema:

> `WorkStart`,Suppose you could choose your own working hours for an 8-hour day. What time would you start work for the day? Please adjust the slider to the hour nearest your ideal start time. The box next to the slider will display your selection using a 24-hour clock

I didn't expect the peak to be so prominent and sharply decreasing between 10:00 AM and 11:00 AM, but obviously, there are at least *some* more nocturnials, preferring 2:00 PM, 6:00 PM and 8:00 PM. I think that employers should more strongly consider this. But <sarcasm> there's probably no reason to care about minorities </sarcasm>.

Comment: Is X axis start time?

Comment: @billynoah I added a short description of what the graph shows. One could select the "preferred work start time". The x-axis are the possible start times. The y-axis is the respective number of respondents.

Answer (score 3):

> Was it left out intentionally?

The pattern for the initial results post seems to be to mainly focus on certain demographic, usage, and technology questions, have a section about a new major aspect for this year's survey, and then give the results on the questions that's mostly for fun.

The preferred working hours didn't fall into any of those categories.

The data that doesn't make it into the results post is still included when they release all of the data so we'll be able to see how people answered.

Comment: This might be true, and I hope that the data dump will bring additional insights here (or that it will be confirmed otherwise). However, I think the information about the preferred working hours would have fit somewhere near the "Remote Work" section on the results page.

Comment: That's interesting, because "tabs vs spaces" and "how do you pronounce GIF" are in there...

Comment: @paddy Those were the "mostly for fun" questions. It wasn't plural in my original post because I forgot about the GIF one.