# Can I run my own survey with a stack audience

Tags: discussion

I have just seen the Stack Overflow 2017 results. It's great. But I need something else.

I'm doing the research for my thesis and I'd like to run my own survey. I have a Google Form already done. My study is about the effectiveness of web development frameworks on the delivery of a project.

Is there a way my survey can be accommodated within Stack Overflow so that the many developers may give their inputs. I will gladly share the results with all users. I don't want to put the link here as I'm not sure if it will be welcome.

Comment: Related post: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284350/where-one-can-ask-survey-kind-of-questions-about-stack-exchange-stack-overflow

Comment: I've just learn't that stackoverflow has a blog and this post is a the results of a survey: https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/06/15/developers-use-spaces-make-money-use-tabs/?cb=1

Comment: Perhaps my survey can be on a blog article?

Comment: You would have a hard time trying to fit it into SO or any SE platform for that matter. It wouldnt fit..Your question would end up being closed. You could _probably_ request people to fill your form in any of the chatrooms depending on the rules of the particular rooms..

Comment: Hey, that's a great idea for a start, although it would take me more time. Thanks for that tip, and I hope I won't be marked as some sort of bot - smiles...

Comment: @suraj I'm in the PHP chatroom. Perhaps you'd like to give it a go and share the link on a social network that allows it. Thanks!

Comment: @suraj just FYI, that was tried and that message is now flagged for being spam. So I guess that was either bad advice or they picked the wrong room. My advice: just don't spam the users here for your own benefit.

Comment: @rene oh .. I see..Apologies.. But I did say depends on the rules of the room

Comment: @suraj yeah, the PHP room guidance is not explicit about it in their dont's but nor do they advertize it in their do's (for obvious reasons). The OP did post that link also in at least one other room. That might have contributed if users that were in both rooms and saw that message coming in. Not your fault.

Comment: @itsols please disregard that advice. There is no real way to share your survey questions in the platform. It is not a good fit..

Comment: @rene Are you suggesting that my chat message was marked as spam? How would I know if it is flagged? There is no indication anywhere to say that it is flagged. Furthermore, if you think that my post is spam, just walk into the php chat room right now and see what kind of nonsense is going on. Anyway, thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'm not fantasizing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FRvSL.png see the blue marker and that is shown for every 10K-er currently in chat.

Comment: @suraj personally, I believe that your advice was great. But if it is unwelcome, I'm leaving the chatroom. I was hoping that I will be able to help someone in turn with some issues they're facing but it seems like this is not the way to go about it. Thanks!

Comment: @rene, I'm thankful for your inputs. All I'm saying is that I don't see any warnings or indicators on my screen. Anyway, thanks again. I'm leaving the chat room now.

Comment: A final note, I just refreshed my screen hoping to see the 'blue mark' and guess what? My post is gone. So you made your point. Thanks guys! This was a hard lesson.

Comment: if you ask a "question" referring survey in your blog, it will likely be deleted as spam, see [Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/278252/165773)

Comment: You could look into getting an ad on the site promoting your survey.

Comment: Yes @BSMP , that's a good idea. For an academic project, my immediate concern is time, and then cost. But yes, I'll look at this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. Such a feature is not provided. Also don't ask a question, because it would be primarly opinion based by definition.

However, [every year](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278846/suggest-a-question-for-the-2015-stack-overflow-user-survey) the community is asked about the questions, they want to know about.

If you have a good one, you could propose one. But there is no warranty it will be in the survey.