# Use Stack Overflow for survey-like questions

Tags: discussion, survey

I'm currently embarking on an assignment for an analysis of user-centred software, which I have to collect several different data points for. The software I have chosen is the IntelliJ Range, for various reasons.

Part of the assignment is to perform a survey on the users of this software in regards to its usability and interface. As I personally do not have sufficient contacts which are also users of this software, performing such a survey will prove to be problematic.

Therefore I would like to post this survey on Stack Overflow, in the hopes of reaching sufficient numbers of users to be able to perform analyses, etc. on the given responses.

As Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, with heavily regulated question-formats, my instincts say no, and several other posts on the meta site seem to indicate this also, however no definitive answer jumped out at me, hence I'd like to ask directly,

#### Am I allowed to post surveys on Stack Overflow?

If not, are there any conditions I could adhere to that would make collecting information possible?

Comment: Note also that down-votes on this question can mean that site members disagree with your proposed creation of a survey and do not necessarily mean that members feel that your asking a question on it here in meta is in itself bad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'd started to notice a few downvotes.

Comment: One thing you could do is paying for an ad: https://stackoverflow.co/advertising/ Not sure how cost-effective that would be.

Comment: Note that posting a survey and waiting for people to fill it in can very well lead to [self-selection bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-selection_bias)

Comment: @legoscia That's a very good suggestion. How quickly would you estimate responses to come back in?

Comment: @VLAZ As it happens, the self-selection bias is a topic of the subject, which I also need to make reference to in my final report.

Comment: What is "IntelliJ Range"? Do you mean [IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA)?

Comment: There are a plethora of IDEs based on the technology used in IDEA, such as Android studio, Web Storm or DataGrip. All of these are the IntelliJ range, as the platform the IDEs are built on is called IntelliJ

Comment: Ah, yes. *"[Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio) ... built on JetBrains' IntelliJ IDEA software"* (based on the [Community Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#Open_source_projects)). The other two are internal JetBrains (presumably based on an internal edition)

Comment: Correct. If you ever get the change to trial the paid version of the software, I would highly recommend it, they're amazing (hence the focus of my assignment)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your instincts are correct, and any attempt to post a question as a survey will be quickly, and correctly, shut down. There are no conditions that would allow this, save for surveys created by the Stack Overflow team itself.

I will also add that you are wise in posting this meta question first before embarking on the survey.

---

Related Stack Overflow meta and main Stack Exchange meta questions and answers:

- [Where can I post a survey link to collect the data from Stack Overflow members?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384609/where-can-i-post-a-survey-link-to-collect-the-data-from-stack-overflow-members)
- [Can I run my own survey with a stack audience](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350863/can-i-run-my-own-survey-with-a-stack-audience)
- [Where one can ask survey kind of questions about Stack Exchange/ Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284350/where-one-can-ask-survey-kind-of-questions-about-stack-exchange-stack-overflow)
- [Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278250/are-research-survey-questions-expected-to-be-handled-with-close-votes)

Comment: Somewhat related (as it be might the next step, getting contact information for users one way or the other): *[A Terms of Service update restricting companies that scrape your profile information without your permission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277369/)*