# Is it okay to delete and re-make a question to stop everyone hyperfocusing on a simple mistake?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-delete

So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651377/why-is-pre-increment-in-c/) a few minutes ago about a language design issue (which now that I think of it belongs more on Programmers than here anyway...) but made a simple syntax mistake. Now the question's been heavily downvoted and everyone's locked on to the distinction between `i++` and `++i` when the question is about the concepts those symbols represent and not the symbols themselves at all, even though I corrected the mistake as soon as it was pointed out.

Would it be acceptable to delete the question and re-post it with the same content so it can have a do-over without the huge irrelevant misunderstanding?

Comment: Rather improve the existing question. Deleting questions pushes you more in direction to a question ban.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, that's the thing; there was nothing significant wrong with it in the first place and fixing the issue everyone was fixating on hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: _"there was nothing significant wrong with it in the first place"_ No you are mislead. Its an off topic question (asking for opinions), not much of improvement applicable there.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What opinions? The question is "for what engineering reason does this exist?" That's not an opinion question.

Comment: It is nothing but a request for opinions.  How can we answer that?  Are you looking for a good example, rather than people's opinions as to why something exists?  What, exactly, kind of answer are you looking for?

Comment: I think this is still a valid discussion to raise. I've had questions before where instead of answering my question, everyone also gravitated to a separate issue that detracted from my actual problem set.

Comment: Is this just a matter of the question being open to interpretation in multiple ways?  I can see that questions that aren't specific enough would tend to have wandering answers too.

Comment: @Will There's actually nothing opinion-based about it.  There's at least one observable difference between pre-increment and post-increment, such that pre-increment allows the compiler to generate more efficient assembly (since it doesn't return the original value, it performs one write instead of two), while post-increment is less efficient (requires more assembly instructions), but can be more useful to the programmer in some situations.  [Assuming, of course, that the question is interpreted as asking why the language has both pre- and post-increment operators.]

Comment: If interpreted as asking what pre-increment can do that post-increment can't, or something similar, though, it does indeed become quite opinion-based.  Even if one doesn't mention that compilers are able to optimise the post-increment version into the pre-increment version when it wouldn't affect program logic (such as in a loop's increment statement), there are a lot of opinions about which to use when, and why.

Comment: @Schilcote You have stumbled upon the microcosm of the C/C++ tag. Unfortunately C/C++ users are FAR more free about downvoting than other tags. And if that was all there was to the site, then I'd just tell you to stay away. But with that bad, please know that there is an incredible amount of intelligence on this site as well. So 1) take an extraordinary amount of care when writing a C/C++ question 2) relish the fact that the answers to your questions will be of extremely high quality.

Comment: *there was nothing significant wrong with it in the first place*, yeah there was something very non-trivial wrong with it in the first place, still is.

Comment: *instead of answering my question, everyone also gravitated to a separate issue*, this is an problem isolated to **you** not asking clear concise questions. Do not blame the general population for misunderstanding your questions in general. That points directly to you and not the general population.

Comment: @JonathanMee - if the [tag:java] tag were so lucky. I think the [tag:php] and [tag:javascript] tags would set the SO servers on fire if the down votes flowed as deserved in those tags!

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't often venture into the territory of C's offspring (other than C++) But when I do I find them to be like the land of milk and honey compared to C/C++'s brutal downvoting climate. But then, I also find the answers vague and frequently based upon personal experience. So... yeah, I'm here for the wisdom. I'll take it with the downvotes.

Comment: @JonathanMee my observation has been that C and C++ programmers actually read the manual, and this expectation breeds intolerance towards questions which are answered in the manual. Or which could be considered trivial to understanding the manual

Comment: @will Are you using "Opinion based" as a proxy for "It's likely to be unknowable, so people will just be offering up opinions and incomplete answers?"

Comment: @BenPen Well, I'm the only one who can answer that question, unless there is a record somewhere that explains why I said it in the first place.  Maybe we should ask some folks other than me what the answer to that question is?  Of course, asking for a cite is asking for offsite resources, so that's off topic.  Maybe you'll get lucky and I'll swing by and answer.

Comment: @will BenPen scratches his head.   That is inscrutable.

Comment: @JonathanMee - not sure if you can see deleted questions, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39578513/how-to-create-a-flashcard-consist-of-10-screens-of-picturese-g-can-be-alphabet) is pretty typical for [tag:java] on a daily basis. Hourly for [tag:javascript] as far as I can tell. Probably worse for [tag:php].

Comment: @JarrodRoberson There is a difference however. The question you linked was certifiably terrible. The question from the OP here was reasonable. Yes it had a typo, it may have been a little off topic, but It certainly didn't deserve the 6 downvotes it got almost immediately. That is my point C/C++ is extremely hostile to newcomers who just want to ask a question they don't fully understand.

Comment: @Jeutnarg I agree with you. And as i mentioned that's why I frequent http://www.stackoverflow.com But the OP's question shows the dark side of the C/C++ population's intelligence.

Comment: @JonathanMee - how can we recruit some of those [Tag:c], [tag:c++] people to express their *"dark"* side in the [tag:java] tag instead?

Comment: IMHO, your issue is one of a systemic tendency to be too pedantic. However, rules do prevent chaos. Some moderators do need to give some lee-way though and be less critical.

Comment: if people are hyperfocusing on small details in their answers. why not wait for an adequate answer to come around?

Comment: @maxpleaner I think your "wait" statement needs to apply to voting as well. Or at least if you're going to downvote you should be responsible for evaluating whether what your downvoting is corrected. Coming from a C/C++ background is why I'll take the hit for asking questions like this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266370/consideration-for-removing-the-downvote-button-from-questions

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Meh, I disagree. I think the darkside in C/C++ voting costs http://www.stackoverflow.com a lot. I have seen a lot of very intelligent colleagues driven away from http://www.stackoverflow.com by this darkside. I don't know if there's a fix for it, but it's not healthy.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well, you can't delete it - it's already been answered.

As to whether you *should* if you *could*...

I'd say it's usually pretty rude to delete a question and re-post *the exact same question*. But deleting a misunderstood question and posting a much-clarified version? Nothing wrong with that: gets rid of a distraction, adds a good question. You should avoid doing it too often, simply because of the time wasted by the temporary question... But hopefully this isn't an every-day occurrence either.

But, back to the situation at hand: your question has been answered; you can't delete it, and you should probably avoid making edits that invalidate the answers. Ideally, you can edit it to remove distracting mistakes *without* invalidating the point, and then everyone can move on... But if you can't, go ahead and just post a new question that looks nothing like the current one but manages to focus folks' attention on the problem you *meant* to solve in the first place.

Comment: It is somewhat non-intuitive to leave behind questions you didn't intend to ask, but perhaps is it recommended to put a bit of effort in to sharpen the question to remove ambiguity towards the best of the answers to the alternate understanding of the question?  It does sharpen the question on when to put a question on hold as unclear/ambiguous to give members a chance to clear it up before the answers start making interpretations...

Comment: Yeah - ideally we'd be able to hold questions faster, @Ben - and release them quickly when fixed. Too much overhead right now.

Comment: It is also true that sometimes, asking the precise question you mean to have answered means you don't get an answer.   In this particular example, it would take someone who was contributing to the original spec (K&R ++ ) to give all the reasons why both ++I and I++ are offered.  Nuances that make pre better in some situations and post better in others, and the ability to aim towards a assembly language intent are two, but who knows how many others there were.

Comment: except if the new question will be **off-topic: too broad or opinion based** then you should just leave well enough alone.

Comment: Sure, but that's a bit different than "I made a typo and folks hated me", @Jarrod. FWIW, I don't see this question as being either too broad or opinion-based; it's just confusing because it's not clear whether he's talking about pre-increment (as is repeatedly stated in the question) or postfix increment (as the example would seem to imply).

Comment: Note that the question is now deleted, @Ben. If you can re-write it to be less confusing, I would repost it (or ask on [programmers.se] if you think that'd be better; they're actually debating the topicality of history questions over there right now, so it might prove an interesting test-case).

Comment: It's not clear to me that there is a documented reason beyond, "Sometimes postfix increment is clearer..."   Maybe That's an interesting question if someone has better information...

Comment: @shog9 http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/331870/origins-of-having-both-prefix-incrementi-and-postfix-increment-i-in-the is my attempt, here...

Comment: Though, it's implicitly answered here: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/43067/why-do-we-have-postfix-increment?rq=1  It's related, but not exact...

Comment: Yeah, that gets into C++ territory as well, where there's a much different use for the operator.

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks for the tip, The bit about pop and push in Eric's answer is particularly enticing reason for Symmetry.

Comment: @Shog9 - I think if people think down votes on their questions literally mean *people hate me*, then they have bigger issues and probably should not be on the internet to begin with. That said, what happened to the *"Vote on the Content Not the Person"* mantra, does not that not go both ways, the asker needs to see that as well as the voters.

Comment: @Shog9 - I see it as **too broad** just like I see questions about [tag:java] that can and do vary from `JVM` implemenation are **too broad** as they fit the description pretty tightly *There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format.*. I am not even an expert at [tag:c] or [tag:c++] and I know that the implication of the implementations and optimizations vary wildly and would take a book to explain and still not actually be 100% definitive or correct.

Comment: I was being somewhat flippant, @Jarrod; ideally, a post can just be fixed (as I noted here), but in cases where the post as developed a "reputation" (and essentially this is what post score *is*, a numeric reputation for the content), this may avoid dragging that along during significant revisions.

Comment: @Shog9 - ok, I am good with flippant! ;-) And I agree with your assessment that the down voters are unlikely to remove their votes even if something comes back into line, that is why I think it is even more important to close things early that have problems and for people to pay even more attention and effort to writing good questions.

Comment: The interesting thing about this question (to me at least) is that it *isn't* about C++, @Jarrod. The differences between these operators in C and C++ are well known, but attempting to find the rationale for their existence tends to fall into a several decades rut of weary explanations related to operator overloading... Which does not exist in C. Indeed, one might well consider them nothing more than syntactic sugar, and in many languages that have been inspired by C *they are just that*... But whether that is their origin I do not know. Perhaps no one does...

Answer (score 13):

It's not ok to remake *that* question, since it is an exact duplicate of [What are the historical reasons C languages have pre-increments and post-increments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30429753/103167) and also https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/43067/7757

(I can't close it as a duplicate because it is locked)

Seriously, does no one ever look at the sidebar of related questions to see whether any of them contain the answer already?

Comment: Damn... I searched for a good while looking for something like that, and managed to miss it in the sidebar? Thanks for the sanity-check - I've unlocked and dup'd the question.

Comment: Aie, sorry, I'll close mine down soon.  I'm encouraging people to move answers over to the existing historical reasons question before because there are some valuable answers there.