# Why are questions with upvoted answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-answers

I have just seen one of my answers that I was rather pleased with suddenly disappear along with the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39651377/what-purpose-does-the-pre-increment-operator-serve-in-c/39651545#39651545). All right, the question was probably not on-topic in either its original or edited form, so maybe I was a mug to try to answer it. The irony is that as the question was steadily being downvoted, my answer was steadily being upvoted, which amused (and pleased) me somewhat.

I suppose that we have all been there. We have all seen questions that we have tried to answer deleted by the questioner. It's galling but it's a fact of life. Some people are thoughtless and ungrateful. You either live with it or move on. However, this is the first time that I have seen an answer that people seemed to appreciate wiped of the face of the Earth, even if only coincidentally.

It's very dispiriting. What can be done to preserve and acknowledge contributor's work done in good faith and without any expectation of reward?

Comment: I think you have a valid question, if you could rephrase this to: "why was this question with an upvoted answer deleted?" As it stands, while it may feel good to vent about your answer being deleted, you're unlikely to achieve much by this question.

Comment: I accept that it's a moan. I'll change the title and add a rider. Thanks for the suggestion. I'd like to have a discussion but I suspect that this is well-trodden ground. I'd like to contribute to the site but this seems to be incredibly difficult right now.

Comment: I've had this happen to me when I answered a question that did have some merit but were asked in such a whiney and confrontational way that it received lots of downvotes and was eventually closed. Meanwhile my answer was sitting at +8 or so. In hindsight, after it was deleted, I realized that I should have edited and fixed the question before answering it. That would probably have saved it. You have enough rep to edit questions so your take-away from this should probably be to fix bad questions before answering them, and if they can't be fixed don't answer.

Answer (score 8):

I liked your answer; I can't say for sure whether it was correct or not, but you presented a plausible theory with historical background to back it up. I'd say that's probably the best we can do here.

Unfortunately, the question was rather confusing. You can find a long discussion of it here: [Is it okay to delete and re-make a question to stop everyone hyperfocusing on a simple mistake?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335085/is-it-okay-to-delete-and-re-make-a-question-to-stop-everyone-hyperfocusing-on-a) ...wherein I encourage the author to clarify his question.

Since it wasn't clarified and *was* deleted, I encouraged him to re-post it to Programmers a few minutes ago. You can find the resulting question here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/331870/origins-of-having-both-prefix-incrementi-and-postfix-increment-i-in-the

I would strongly encourage you to re-post your answer there, tailored to the re-write of the question.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I have no record of it and I'm not going to re-type it.

Comment: @MickSharpe Well, it's undeleted now.

Comment: I've undeleted and locked the SO question for the sake of discussion, @Mick.